# Print the ASCII table

Tags: code-golf

The task is to display *n* characters of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You may write a function (or a program that takes the argument as a parameter, STDIN is allowed as well) that takes a parameter *n*, which will be the index of the last character to print.

The task is quite simple, so as an example here's a possible implementation in Python 2.7:

```
(lambda n:map(chr, range(n)))(256)
```

As I said it's a simple task. So this is code-golf and the shortest codes wins!

**EDIT**

As some of you pointed out this code doesn't print the result. It's just an example since I might struggle explaining the problem in english ;-).

**EDIT2**

Feel free to post the answer in any programming language, even if it's not the shortest code. Maybe there are some interesting implementations out there!

**EDIT3**

Fixed the example so it prints the result.

Comment: 1. Does it have to be a function? 2. According to your reference code, *n* would be the first character that is not printed.

Comment: Actually the reference code prints nothing. It just returns a list of the characters and lets the REPL do whatever it wants with the result.

Comment: @Dennis I updated my question, you are allowed to use the parameter as an program argument. And you are correct, n is the first char that is not printed.

Comment: @manatwork You are correct. But when it's executed in the console you see the resulting array. So basically it's just an example since I might struggle explaining something in english ;-)

Comment: So, it has to be a command-line argument? STDIN is not allowed?

Comment: @Dennis Updated the question again, STDIN is allowed as well

Comment: Can somebody please explain the downvote? I am sorry if my english isn't that good. If there's something unclear within the question please tell me.

Comment: `for x in range(input()):print chr(x)` Would actually print the characters, if you want to edit your example.

Comment: nota `[i for i in range(n)]` is quite similar to `range(n)`

Comment: In BF the code is very simple: ` ,[->.+<]`, with a tiny problem: it can't parse real numbers!!!1!11!!oneone!!1!!!11

Comment: @ciu Did you see my answer or did you just think of that yourself? In case it's the latter, I [actually solved this in brainfuck](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40513/14509) :D

Comment: You didn't say we had to output them in ascending order, so is outputting the characters backwards allowed? How far can I bend the rules?

Comment: True ASCII is 7 bit, not 8 bit

Comment: What is the desired range? 0—n-1, 0—n, 1—n?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## CJam, 4 bytes

```
ric,
```

Full program that reads from STDIN (input field in the [online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)).

This simply executes `range(chr(int(input())))`, taking advantage of the fact that `,` gives a return an array of characters if its argument is a character.

I call dibs on `c,` (2 bytes), just in case that assuming the input is already on the stack turns out to be allowed.

Comment: Do you have to specify some input? The online runner just outputs the code itself.

Comment: @manatwork: Just a sec. You have to hurry when you post these... ;)

Comment: I am a little confused by this.  The character at 0 ( aka 0c )prevents anything else from being printed after it.  ric,( seems to work fine.  This means the code doesn't work.

Comment: @kaine: I've tested this with Chrome, Firefox and the Java interpreter. It works just fine for me.

Comment: Interesting I am using the linked interpreter but internet explorer (I know pity me but that is all i can use here).  There is no output for any integer input.  If it works on yours though, i'd still count it as working. "In C library and Unix conventions, the null character is used to terminate text strings; such null-terminated strings can be known in abbreviation as ASCIZ or ASCIIZ, where here Z stands for "zero"."  This quote is probably why.

Comment: @kaine: Internet Explorer is written in C++, which does not use null-terminated strings. According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/diff/parsing.html#preprocessing), null characters are parse errors in HTML 5; the browser must replace it with a � or abort processing the document.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to enter a sufficiently large `n`, because the first few dozen of ASCII characters are non-printable characters. Fun fact: this program also outputs the Unicode table, for example n=9999

Answer (score 26):

## brainfuck - <del>169</del> <del>146</del> 142 bytes

```
-[+>+[+<]>+]>+>>,[>,]<[<]<[->>[->]<[<]<]>>>[[<[-<+<+<+>>>]+++++++++[<[-<+>]<<[-<+>>>+<<]<[->+<]>>>>-]]<,<<,>[->>>+<<<]>>>---------->]<-[->.+<]
```

Limitations:

- EOF must be 0
- Requires 8-bit wrapping cells
- Because of ^, mods input by 256

Not the shortest answer here, but hey, brainfuck! This would be a really, really good brainfuck challenge, except for the fact that it requires human readable input without guaranteeing the number of digits. I could have required input to have leading zeroes to make it 3 characters long, but what fun is that? :D One major problem with taking input this way is that brainfuck's only branching or looping structure checks if the current cell is zero or not. When the input can contain zeroes, it can cause your code to take branches it shouldn't be taking. To solve this problem, I store each digit of input **plus 1**, then subtract the excess at the last possible second. That way, I always know where my zeroes are.

I did say that this would have been a great brainfuck challenge without having to parse input. Why is that? Well, let's pretend that we don't take a numeric input. We'll say the challenge is "Given a byte of input, output all ASCII characters below that byte". Here's what my answer would be:

---

## brainfuck - 8 bytes

```
,[->.+<]
```

---

It's quite a difference! The real program uses 135 instructions to collect the input (over 95% of the program!), just because it's a human typing it. Store the number as a byte and give *that* to me, and it only takes one.

(Fun fact: If you understood the hypothetical program, then congratulations! You understand brainfuck in its entirety. The whole language has only eight commands, and that program happens to use each one exactly once.)

**Explanation**

```
-[+>+[+<]>+]>+               abuse 8 bit wrapping to put 47 in cell 4

>>,[>,]                      starting in cell 6; get each character of input

<[<]<[->>[->]<[<]<]          subtract the value of cell 4 from each input character
                             '0' has an ascii value of 47 so subtracting 47 from each
                             digit gives you that digit's value plus 1

>>>[                         if the number is in more than one cell
                             (when the program first starts this means "if the input has
                             more than one digit")

[<[-<+<+<+>>>]               copy first input cell to 3 new cells

+++++++++[<[-<+>]<<          do some fancy addition magic to multiply that value by 10
[-<+>>>+<<]<[->+<]>>>>-]]

<,<<,>                       clean up a bit (abusing comma to set cells to 0)

[->>>+<<<]>>>                add the value to the next cell of input

----------                   because we multiplied (the digit plus 1) by 10; the answer
                             is 10 too high; so subtract 10

>]                           if the input is still in multiple cells; do the song and
                             dance again (multiply by 10; add to next cell; subtract 10)

<-                           we never got a chance to fix the final digit; so it's still 1
                             too high

               ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
               ;;         we have now finished processing input         ;;
               ;;     the tape is empty except for the current cell     ;;
               ;;  the current cell contains the number that was input  ;;
               ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[                            while the cell containing input != 0

-                            subtract 1 from it

>.+                          go a cell to the right; output that cell; then add 1

<]                           repeat
```

Comment: Nice! Definitely +1 for the effort :-)

Comment: You could save some bytes on the outputting part: `>[-]<[->.+<]` Set cell next to current cell to 0, then count down the current cell while increasing the cell next to it and simultaneously printing the value.

Comment: @shu That's an excellent point! I didn't think of that at all. In addition to being shorter, it fixes the problem I had with choking on large inputs and it's probably faster! Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, it's much, much faster now. I also didn't need the `>[-]<` part because I was already next to an empty cell. :)

Comment: <s>`.+[.+]` shorter</s> this prints always 256 chars

Comment: Because it's not specified which order the characters had to be in, you could golf the printing part from `[->.+<]` down to `[.-]`, saving 3 bytes.

Comment: Also, [your second answer is valid.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4719/61384)

Answer (score 12):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
VQCN
```

Basically a translation of the Python 3 program:

```
for N in range(eval(input())):print(chr(N))
```

Answer (score 11):

## Befunge 93 - <s>23</s> 21

```
&> :#v_,>:#,_@
 ^-1:<
```

## Befunge 93 - <s>15</s> 13 (by Ingo Bürk)

This one prints the list in reverse, but OP only said we need to print the first `n` characters, not that it has to be in order.

```
&>::>v
@^-1,_
```

Might not be golfable any further without moving on to Befunge98 (for the ";" operator, see [@Kasran's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40524/32047))

Try it here:

```js
function BefungeBoard(source, constraints) {
    constraints = constraints || {
        width: 80,
        height: 25
    };

    this.constraints = constraints;
    this.grid = source.split(/\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]/).map(function (line) {
        return (line + String.repeat(' ', constraints.width - line.length)).split('');
    });
    for (var i = this.grid.length; i < constraints.height; i++) {
        this.grid[i] = String.repeat(' ', constraints.width).split('');
    }

    this.pointer = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    this.direction = Direction.RIGHT;
}

BefungeBoard.prototype.nextPosition = function () {
    var vector = this.direction.toVector(),
        nextPosition = {
            x: this.pointer.x + vector[0],
            y: this.pointer.y + vector[1]
        };

    nextPosition.x = nextPosition.x < 0 ? this.constraints.width - 1 : nextPosition.x;
    nextPosition.y = nextPosition.y < 0 ? this.constraints.height - 1 : nextPosition.y;

    nextPosition.x = nextPosition.x >= this.constraints.width ? 0 : nextPosition.x;
    nextPosition.y = nextPosition.y >= this.constraints.height ? 0 : nextPosition.y;

    return nextPosition;
};

BefungeBoard.prototype.advance = function () {
    this.pointer = this.nextPosition();
    if (this.onAdvance) {
        this.onAdvance.call(null, this.pointer);
    }
};

BefungeBoard.prototype.currentToken = function () {
    return this.grid[this.pointer.y][this.pointer.x];
};

BefungeBoard.prototype.nextToken = function () {
    var nextPosition = this.nextPosition();
    return this.grid[nextPosition.y][nextPosition.x];
};

var Direction = (function () {
    var vectors = [
        [1, 0],
        [-1, 0],
        [0, -1],
        [0, 1]
    ];

    function Direction(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Direction.prototype.toVector = function () {
        return vectors[this.value];
    };

    return {
        UP: new Direction(2),
        DOWN: new Direction(3),
        RIGHT: new Direction(0),
        LEFT: new Direction(1)
    };
})();

function BefungeStack() {
    this.stack = [];
}

BefungeStack.prototype.pushAscii = function (item) {
    this.pushNumber(item.charCodeAt());
};

BefungeStack.prototype.pushNumber = function (item) {
    if (isNaN(+item)) {
        throw new Error(typeof item + " | " + item + " is not a number");
    }

    this.stack.push(+item);
};

BefungeStack.prototype.popAscii = function () {
    return String.fromCharCode(this.popNumber());
};

BefungeStack.prototype.popNumber = function () {
    return this.stack.length === 0 ? 0 : this.stack.pop();
};

function Befunge(source, constraints) {
    this.board = new BefungeBoard(source, constraints);
    this.stack = new BefungeStack();
    this.stringMode = false;
    this.terminated = false;

    this.digits = "0123456789".split('');
}

Befunge.prototype.run = function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= (this.stepsPerTick || 10); i++) {
        this.step();
        if (this.terminated) {
            return;
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this));
};

Befunge.prototype.step = function () {
    this.processCurrentToken();
    this.board.advance();
};

Befunge.prototype.processCurrentToken = function () {
    var token = this.board.currentToken();
    if (this.stringMode && token !== '"') {
        return this.stack.pushAscii(token);
    }

    if (this.digits.indexOf(token) !== -1) {
        return this.stack.pushNumber(token);
    }

    switch (token) {
        case ' ':
            while ((token = this.board.nextToken()) == ' ') {
                this.board.advance();
            }
            return;
        case '+':
            return this.stack.pushNumber(this.stack.popNumber() + this.stack.popNumber());
        case '-':
            return this.stack.pushNumber(-this.stack.popNumber() + this.stack.popNumber());
        case '*':
            return this.stack.pushNumber(this.stack.popNumber() * this.stack.popNumber());
        case '/':
            var denominator = this.stack.popNumber(),
                numerator = this.stack.popNumber(),
                result;
            if (denominator === 0) {
                result = +prompt("Illegal division by zero. Please enter the result to use:");
            } else {
                result = Math.floor(numerator / denominator);
            }

            return this.stack.pushNumber(result);
        case '%':
            var modulus = this.stack.popNumber(),
                numerator = this.stack.popNumber(),
                result;
            if (modulus === 0) {
                result = +prompt("Illegal division by zero. Please enter the result to use:");
            } else {
                result = Math.floor(numerator / modulus);
            }

            return this.stack.pushNumber(result);
        case '!':
            return this.stack.pushNumber(this.stack.popNumber() === 0 ? 1 : 0);
        case '`':
            return this.stack.pushNumber(this.stack.popNumber() < this.stack.popNumber() ? 1 : 0);
        case '>':
            this.board.direction = Direction.RIGHT;
            return;
        case '<':
            this.board.direction = Direction.LEFT;
            return;
        case '^':
            this.board.direction = Direction.UP;
            return;
        case 'v':
            this.board.direction = Direction.DOWN;
            return;
        case '?':
            this.board.direction = [Direction.RIGHT, Direction.UP, Direction.LEFT, Direction.DOWN][Math.floor(4 * Math.random())];
            return;
        case '_':
            this.board.direction = this.stack.popNumber() === 0 ? Direction.RIGHT : Direction.LEFT;
            return;
        case '|':
            this.board.direction = this.stack.popNumber() === 0 ? Direction.DOWN : Direction.UP;
            return;
        case '"':
            this.stringMode = !this.stringMode;
            return;
        case ':':
            var top = this.stack.popNumber();
            this.stack.pushNumber(top);
            return this.stack.pushNumber(top);
        case '\\':
            var first = this.stack.popNumber(),
                second = this.stack.popNumber();
            this.stack.pushNumber(first);
            return this.stack.pushNumber(second);
        case '$':
            return this.stack.popNumber();
        case '#':
            return this.board.advance();
        case 'p':
            return this.board.grid[this.stack.popNumber()][this.stack.popNumber()] = this.stack.popAscii();
        case 'g':
            return this.stack.pushAscii(this.board.grid[this.stack.popNumber()][this.stack.popNumber()]);
        case '&':
            return this.stack.pushNumber(+prompt("Please enter a number:"));
        case '~':
            return this.stack.pushAscii(prompt("Please enter a character:")[0]);
        case '.':
            return this.print(this.stack.popNumber());
        case ',':
            return this.print(this.stack.popAscii());
        case '@':
            this.terminated = true;
            return;
    }
};

Befunge.prototype.withStdout = function (printer) {
    this.print = printer;
    return this;
};

Befunge.prototype.withOnAdvance = function (onAdvance) {
    this.board.onAdvance = onAdvance;
    return this;
};

String.repeat = function (str, count) {
    var repeated = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        repeated += str;
    }

    return repeated;
};

window['requestAnimationFrame'] = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};

(function () {
    var currentInstance = null;

    function resetInstance() {
        currentInstance = null;
    }

    function getOrCreateInstance() {
        if (currentInstance !== null && currentInstance.terminated) {
            resetInstance();
        }

        if (currentInstance === null) {
            var boardSize = Editor.getBoardSize();
            currentInstance = new Befunge(Editor.getSource(), {
                width: boardSize.width,
                height: boardSize.height
            });
            currentInstance.stepsPerTick = Editor.getStepsPerTick();

            currentInstance.withStdout(Editor.append);
            currentInstance.withOnAdvance(function (position) {
                Editor.highlight(currentInstance.board.grid, position.x, position.y);
            });
        }

        return currentInstance;
    }

    var Editor = (function (onExecute, onStep, onReset) {
        var source = document.getElementById('source'),
            sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display'),
            sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
            stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
        var execute = document.getElementById('execute'),
            step = document.getElementById('step'),
            reset = document.getElementById('reset');
        var boardWidth = document.getElementById('board-width'),
            boardHeight = document.getElementById('board-height'),
            stepsPerTick = document.getElementById('steps-per-tick');

        function showEditor() {
            source.style.display = "block";
            sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
            source.focus();
        }

        function hideEditor() {
            source.style.display = "none";
            sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";

            var computedHeight = getComputedStyle(source).height;
            sourceDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = computedHeight;
            sourceDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = computedHeight;

            sourceDisplay.textContent = source.value;
        }

        function resetOutput() {
            stdout.value = null;
        }

        function escapeEntities(input) {
            return input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        }

        sourceDisplayWrapper.onclick = function () {
            resetOutput();
            showEditor();
            onReset && onReset.call(null);
        };
        execute.onclick = function () {
            resetOutput();
            hideEditor();
            onExecute && onExecute.call(null);
        };
        step.onclick = function () {
            hideEditor();
            onStep && onStep.call(null);
        };
        reset.onclick = function () {
            resetOutput();
            showEditor();
            onReset && onReset.call(null);
        };

        return {
            getSource: function () {
                return source.value;
            },

            append: function (content) {
                stdout.value = stdout.value + content;
            },

            highlight: function (grid, x, y) {
                var highlighted = [];
                for (var row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
                    highlighted[row] = [];
                    for (var column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                        highlighted[row][column] = escapeEntities(grid[row][column]);
                    }
                }

                highlighted[y][x] = '<span class="activeToken">' + highlighted[y][x] + '</span>';
                sourceDisplay.innerHTML = highlighted.map(function (lineTokens) {
                    return lineTokens.join('');
                }).join('\n');
            },

            getBoardSize: function () {
                return {
                    width: +boardWidth.innerHTML,
                    height: +boardHeight.innerHTML
                };
            },

            getStepsPerTick: function () {
                return +stepsPerTick.innerHTML;
            }
        };
    })(function () {
        getOrCreateInstance().run();
    }, function () {
        getOrCreateInstance().step();
    }, resetInstance);
})();
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.so-box {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    border: 1px solid #c47b07;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: #f88912;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
}
.control {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
}
input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}
span[contenteditable] {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    background: #cc7801;
    color: #fff;
}
#controls-container, #options-container {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
#stdout {
    height: 50px;
}
#reset {
    float: right;
}
#source-display-wrapper {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#source-display {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 2px;
}
.activeToken {
    background: #f88912;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <textarea id="source" placeholder="Enter your Befunge-93 program here" wrap="off">&> :#v_,>:#,_@
 ^-1:<</textarea>
    <div id="source-display-wrapper">
        <div id="source-display"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="controls-container" class="container clearfix">
    <input type="button" id="execute" class="control so-box" value="► Execute" />
    <input type="button" id="step" class="control so-box" value="Step" />
    <input type="button" id="reset" class="control so-box" value="Reset" />
</div>
<div id="stdout-container" class="container">
    <textarea id="stdout" placeholder="Output" wrap="off" readonly></textarea>
</div>
<div id="options-container" class="container">
    <div class="option so-box">Steps per Tick: <span id="steps-per-tick" contenteditable>500</span>

    </div>
    <div class="option so-box">Board Size: <span id="board-width" contenteditable>80</span> x <span id="board-height" contenteditable>25</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I used an inline interpreter from [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/40331#40331) :)

Comment: The question doesn't state that we must print it in any order, so this is five byte shorter: `&> #- #1:# :#,_@` (it just prints it in reverse)

Comment: I shaved off another bytes for a total of 15. Because of newlines I will edit it into your post.

Comment: Well played on the extra golfing :) As for the inline interpreter, I wasn't aware there was one. It's great, thanks :)

Comment: The interpreter is new from the linked challenge. I just thought I'd actually use it when I saw your answer. :)

Comment: @JamesHolderness Well spotted. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

## Java, <s>151</s> <s>128</s> <s>77</s> <s>62</s> 56 bytes

First try at code-golfing.

```
void f(int n){for(char i=0;++i<=n;System.out.print(i));}
```

Usage:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int num = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        new A().f(num);
    }

    void f(int n) {
        for (char i = 0; ++i <= n; System.out.print(i));
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Shujal, @flawr, @Ingo Bürk and @Loovjo for the serious byte reduction.

Comment: You can save some chars by declaring the int while opening the scanner: `int i,n=new Scanner(...` and changing the loop to `for(;++i<n;)`. Also, you don't need to invoke `Character.toString`. You can just feed System.out a char value and it will happily output it.

Comment: @Shujal I have much to learn yet. Thanks!

Comment: The challenge allows the use of your `a` as input. And I think you can shorten the `for` loop by abusing the increment place as loop body: `for(;++i<n;System.out.print((char)i));` (but you might have to change the initialization or end value by +- 1)

Comment: You are allowed to write a function, so no need for an entire class and everything.

Comment: @IngoBürk I'm dumb enough to write the whole thing and not read that I can and cannot do. Oh well...

Comment: @RodolfoDias You can drop the `public` keyword and honestly, the `static` as well. It's still a function/method. You can also replace `++i<n+1` with `++i<=n`.

Comment: @IngoBürk Hmm, if I don't put the `i+1`, the function prints the `n-1` first ASCII charachters. At least, it's what it's happening here :/

Comment: @RodolfoDias Are you sure? Obviously, `++i<n+1` should be equivalent to `++i<=n`. Note the `=` in there, however! It just saves one byte. It works for me.

Comment: @IngoBürk Damn it, next time I have to double our triple-read comments before posting. Of course it's the same think... _hides_

Comment: So we come down to `void f(int n){int i=0;for(;++i<=n;System.out.print((char)i));}` which is 62 bytes. At least I don't see more to golf now. :)

Comment: 56 bytes: `void f(int n){for(char i=0;++i<=n;System.out.print(i));}`

Comment: @Loovjo 55 bytes actually if you remove the = and post-increment instead of pre-increment: `void f(int n){for(char i=0;i++<n;)System.out.print(i);}`

Comment: @JackAmmo You're right that you can change the `<=` to `<` by also changing `++i` to `i++`. However, you then also have to change the `char i=0;` to `char i=1;`. So this: `void f(int n){for(char i=1;i++<n;)System.out.print(i);}` (and indeed **55 bytes**) [Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#PY4xD4IwEIV3fsWNbUgadK0MjM6MxqEi6Bl6kPaKGsJvx4qNb7nk8t733op2HBzDw0xGBcZe1Y0hap3Omt54DxXMWQZRY7j02IBnw/FMA17BGiRRs0O6nc5gZLRCEhIDBQslUPuExBT123NrFZJU1L74SCyk/me@zkpI1YmYTP/lV77VdWKjyrkbnGjuxgGWO415fiCdyENgNcY9LFBKvWTLuu6L4gM)

Answer (score 7):

### APL,5

```
⎕UCS⍳
```

Example usage:

```
⎕UCS⍳256
```

Comment: You don't have to make a dfn. Just ⎕UCS⍳ would work fine.
So 5 chars

Comment: You don't have to support code points over 127. Just ↑⎕AV would work fine. So 4 chars

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, ES6 - <s>52</s> <s>58</s> <s>56</s> <s>53</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
n=>String.fromCharCode(...Array(n).keys())
```

Paste this into the Firefox console. Run as `f(NUM)`.

<s>Had to make it longer because the first didn't properly accept input.</s>

Down 3, thanks edc65! Down to 44 thanks to Swivel!

Comment: This doesn't really handle neither parameter nor input.

Comment: Just change the 70 to a different number; that's the input.

Comment: Okay, i updated it to take input, at the cost of 6 bytes.

Comment: Much better. But the parenthesis around fat arrow function's single argument is not necessary: `f=n=>…`.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is the first time i've really done ES6.

Comment: -2: f=n=>[...Array(n)].map((v,i)=>String.fromCharCode(i))

Comment: @edc65 -3 by my count, thanks!

Comment: Remind me what `[...Array(n)]` does?

Comment: @WallyWest It creates an empty array of length n, then populates it with 0s via the spread operator, so that map will work.

Comment: 44 Characters! `f=n=>String.fromCharCode(...Array(n).keys())`

Comment: @Scimonster No +1 for 9 byte weight loss assistance? :P

Comment: You don't need the `f=`, unnamed functions are allowed.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>17</s> 23 bytes

```
flip take['\0'..]
```

Not sure if it is possible to do any better without imports.

### Edit

My first solution didn't actually *print* the result, so allow 6 more chars for that:

```
print.flip take['\0'..]
```

Also, not shorter (25 chars with printing, 19 without), but an interesting alternate approach (it requires 'Data.List', though):

```
print.((inits['\0'..])!!)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually print the result.

Comment: @nyuszika7h now it does

Comment: ```(`take`['\0'..])``` saves a byte.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 17 bytes

```
say chr for 0..$_
```

Comment: Too many parenthesis. `print chr for 0..$ARGV[0]`

Comment: You're right! It has been a while since I used perl

Comment: You can use `shift` instead of `$ARGV[0]` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: If you are allowed to print the characters on different lines, you can use `say`. Also, the character count is shorter if you do it as a one-liner with `-n`. `echo "90" | perl -nE'say chr for 0..$_'` would count as `18` characters. `17` for `say chr for 0..$_` plus `1` for the `n`.

Comment: You're right. But `say` won't work with every version of perl.

Comment: @Demnogonis `say` was introduced in 5.14 and you're allowed to use it on here to save 2 bytes if you want to.

Comment: You should remove the old versions instead of using strikethrough. That's what the revision history is for.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Old habits die hard. I was forced to work with active perl 5.6 until last year.

Comment: You can avoid the +1 for `-n` by using `<>` in place of `$_`.

Answer (score 4):

## awk - 27

```
{while(i<$0)printf"%c",i++}
```

To give the parameter on stdin run it like:

```
awk '{while(i<$0)printf"%c",i++}' <<<96
```

---

Just for fun: The "think positive version" starting with a definitive `yes`:

```
yes|head -96|awk '{printf"%c",NR-1}'
```

`NR-1` is needed to print `(char)0` for `NR==1`.     :-(

And why don't we have a `no` command? That's kinda mean!

Comment: `alias no='yes no'`

Comment: ...but then I'd have to count the chars of that alias definition too... :-(

Comment: This made my day. @nyuszika7h.  My gosh XD thanks for this

Answer (score 4):

## Bash+BSD common utilities, 9 bytes

```
jot -c $1
```

## GNU dc, 20 bytes

```
?sc_1[1+dPdlc>m]dsmx
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, <del>31</del> <del>30</del> <del>28</del> 27

```
k;f(n){putch(k++)<n&&f(n);}
```

Since putch is nonstandard, here's the fully compliant version:

```
k;f(n){putchar(k++)<n&&f(n);}
```

Must be called from main:

```
main(){f(255);}
```

EDIT: Improved by taking advantage of putchar return value
EDIT 2: Reduced by another character through recursion

Comment: putch is a non-standard function. Also, may I ask why this answer was downvoted?

Comment: @Stuntddude I'll add an alternatve version that uses putchar, and no idea why this is downvoted. After all, it is one of the shorter ones.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 3

```
,:c
```

I assumed the argument to be the top stack element.

Example usage:

```
256,:c

ri,:c
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 30 characters

```
puts (0..$*[0].to_i).map &:chr
```

Answer (score 3):

### J - 5 bytes

```
{.&a.
```

`{.` is Head, `a.` is Alphabet ( a list of all chars) and `&` Bonds them, generating a monadic verb called like:

```
{.&a. 100 NB. first 100 characters
```

*Note*: It seems this does not work interactively: Jconsole and jQt seems to set up a translation, outputting box characters instead of some control characters. In a script or from the commandline, it does work though:

```
  ijconsole <<< '127 {. a.' | hd
```

Comment: Notice that the alphabet is not exactly ASCII.

Comment: Up to `{.&a. 127`, it is no?

Comment: No because J has box drawing characters instead of some of the control characters.

Comment: Actually, writing this to a file and inspecting it with a hex viewer tells me that J outputs the correct values (0x00 0x01, ...) . it's only the J interpreter/ IDE interpretting those values as boxdrawing characters instead of control characters. It does exactly the same as all other languages using `char` or equivalents do.

Comment: That's weird because I tested it on my UNIX box and it did indeed output Unicode characters for some of the code-points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25398/discussion-between-jpjacobs-and-fuzxxl).

Comment: Oh please not...

Answer (score 3):

## gs2, 2 bytes

```
V.
```

This should be competing, I think! It would’ve worked even in the early days of gs2. [Try it here.](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=Vi4&input=MTAw)

Comment: Successfully tested with [this version](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/tree/ed40c6a509e70f4deef9a0a5982f42a41524341d), which predates the challenge by a month.

Answer (score 3):

### Brainfuck, 44 bytes

> ```
> ,
> [
>   <[>++++++++++<-]
>   -[>-<-----]
>   >+++>,
> ]
> <[>.+<-]
> ```

Expects a decimal string without a trailing newline.

[Try it online.](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs8Wz4rKysrKysrKysrPC1dLVs-LTwtLS0tLV0-KysrPixdPFs-Lis8LV0&input=MTAw)

Reading integers in the range `[0, max_cell_size]` in brainfuck is not difficult. I encourage you to invent a clean method on your own. I consider this a beginner level exercise. (The reverse operation of printing a cell's numeric value is more involved, and could be considered an intermediate level task.)

Here's a 58-byte version that can handle `256` on 8-bit implementations:

> ```
> ,
> [
>   <[<+> >++++++++++<-]
>   -[>-<-----]
>   >+++>,
> ]
> <[>]
> -<<[>.]
> >[>+.<-]
> ```

Comment: Why haven't I thought of this??? This is ingenious!!!

Comment: Can I borrow this to use on future answers?

Comment: @FinW I'm guessing you don't know about [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values/4719#4719).

Answer (score 3):

## [√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/UnprintableName) , 3 bytes

*Note: Language post-dates challenge*

```
IrW
```

#### Explanation

```
I   › Take input from command line, evaluate and push to stack
 r  › Push the range from 0 to top value + 1
  W › Output the whole stack as Unicode characters
```

## Alternate Solution

As pointed out by @FlipTack in his Java answer, it is not clear if the OP wants us to print up to and including the input or excluding the input.

If the second is true, the solution below is the correct answer.

```
IrPW
```

#### Explanation

```
I    › Take input from command line, evaluate and push to stack
 r   › Push the range from 0 to top value + 1
  P  › Pop the top value from the stack
   W › Output the whole stack as Unicode characters
```

Comment: Link to language?

Comment: @user Added: https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/UnprintableName

Answer (score 2):

## Golfscript - 5

Thanks to @Dennis

```
~,''+
```

Comment: `~,""+` is shorter and correctly processes input from STDIN.

Comment: @Dennis That doesn't produce any output for me...

Comment: Are you using the online interpeter? To correctly simulate input from STDIN, you have to use, e.g., `;"65"`, since the input from STDIN will always be a string.

Comment: @Dennis Oh thanks that works now!

Answer (score 2):

### Lua - <s>43</s> 41 Bytes

```lua
for i=1,arg[1]do print(string.char(i))end
```

Comment: You can shorten this by a byte
`a=""for i=1,arg[1]do print(a.char(i))end`

Comment: You can shorten this by 2 bytes `for i=1,arg[1]do print(("").char(i))end`

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge 98, 22

```
&:00pv>0gk,@
0::-1<^j`
```

Kind of sad that this is so long.

```
&:00p        ; gets numerical input, stores a copy at cell (0,0)               ;
     v       ; IP goes down                                                    ;

     <       ; IP goes left, so I execute 1-::0`j^                             ;
 ::-1        ; (1-::) subtract one from our number and duplicate it twice      ;
0       `    ; (0`) compare the number with 0, push 1 if greater else 0        ;
     <^j     ; if the result was 0, go up, otherwise continue going left       ;

      >0gk,  ; get the value at cell (0,0), print that many numbers from stack ;
           @ ; terminate program                                               ;
```

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL: <s>68</s> 63

As a print loop

```
DECLARE @i INT=64,@ INT=0A:PRINT CHAR(@)SET @+=1IF @<=@i GOTO A
```

### T-SQL: <s>95</s> 86

As a query

```
DECLARE @ INT=64SELECT TOP(@+1)CHAR(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY 0/0)-1)FROM sys.messages
```

**Edit:**  Made changes and fixes pointed out by Muqo.  Thanks.
Fixes and golfing suggested by @t-clausen.dk

Comment: For the loop, you can save 5 or so characters converting the WHILE to a `GOTO` with label.  For the query, maybe specify `msdb.sys.objects` to guarantee enough objects.  Also, it doesn't output CHAR(0).  However, as consolation you can `ORDER BY @`.

Comment: Second answer is invalid. You can rewrite it this way and golf 9 characters: DECLARE @ INT=64SELECT TOP(@+1)CHAR(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY 0/0)-1)FROM sys.messages

Comment: @t-clausen.dk not sure how I let that one through.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 23

```ruby
f=->n{puts *?\0..n.chr}
```

### Explanation

- Input is taken as the argument to a lambda. It expects an Integer.
- The "destructuring operator" (`*`) invokes `#to_ary` on the Range to print every character on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.4 - 36 bytes / 43 bytes

```
print(*map(chr,range(int(input()))))
print(*map(chr,range(int(input()))),sep='')
```

255
input()

How this works is:

1. Get upper limit of range
2. Generate a range of the table.
3. Map the range to chr function ( takes int, returns ascii ).
4. Consume the map via splat argument expansion ( number -> character -> print! )

The second one just removes the space separating each character in exchange for 7 bytes.

Comment: You could very much make this into a lambda, as the question states this, and in Python 2, `map` returns a list, so you could just do `f=lambda i:map(chr,range(i))`

Comment: That's true, and my initial solution was similar but I didn't want to use a lambda so that I could immediately print output. I wish map kept the trend of returning a list instead of an iterator, even if it is more pythonic that way.

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal 87

```
program _;var c:char;n:byte;begin n:=0;readln(n);for c:=chr(0)to chr(n)do write(c);end.
```

## Pascal 73

```
program _;var c,n:byte;begin readln(n);for c:=0to n do write(chr(c));end.
```

Builds and runs fine from http://www.onlinecompiler.net/pascal

Comment: FreePascal (and if I remember correctly, Turbo Pascal too) only needs 60 of those characters: `var c,n:byte;begin read(n);for c:=0to n do write(chr(c))end.` http://pastebin.com/aFLVTuvh

Comment: Quite possibly, I've only used Delphi.  But someone edited that out of the title.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 ASM (Linux) (many many bytes unless you compile it)

Written as a function, assumes parameter is passed in AX (I forget the number for the read syscall)
Also doesn't preserve [SP] or BX.

```
test ax,ax
jz @Done
mov [sp],ax
@Loop:
mov ax,4
mov bx,1
mov cx,sp
mov dx,1
int 0x80
sub [sp],1  ; Can I do this?  Or do I need to load/sub/store separately?
jnz @Loop
@Done:
ret
```

Comment: (I should have put a F00F exploit in there, it's not like anyone will run it anyway)

Comment: I was going to run this. I'm not going to run this now.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl - 29

```
sub f{print map{chr}0..shift}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia: 20 characters (REPL)

This is close to the question's example: just generates the characters and let the REPL to do whatever it wants with them.

```julia
f(n)=map(char,[0:n])
```

### Julia: 33 characters

Prints each character in a separate line.

```julia
print(map(char,[0:int(ARGS[1])]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## M (MUMPS) - 21

`R n F i=1:1:n W $C(i)`

In expanded form: `READ n FOR i=1:1:n WRITE $CHAR(i)`

Answer (score 2):

## BrainFuck - <strike>140</strike> 112 Bytes

```
,>,>,>-[>+<-----]>---[<+>-]<[<<<->->->-]<[>+<-]<[>>++++++++++<<-]<[>>>>++++++++++[<++++++++++>-]<<<<-]>>>[>.+<-]
```

[Try It Here!](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LD4sPiw+LVs+KzwtLS0tLV0+LS0tWzwrPi1dPFs8PDwtPi0+LT4tXTxbPis8LV08Wz4+KysrKysrKysrKzw8LV08Wz4+Pj4rKysrKysrKysrWzwrKysrKysrKysrPi1dPDw8PC1dPj4+Wz4uKzwtXQ==)

*Saved 28 bytes by changing `[<<<->>>->+<]>[<<<->>>->+<]>[<<<->>>-]` to `[<<<->->->-]`.*

**What it does**

```
,>,>,>                                                              Takes three inputs
                                                                    in three separate cells

-[>+<-----]>---[<+>-]<[<<<->->->-]<                                 Takes 48 off of each to
                                                                    convert them to decimal

[>+<-]<[>>++++++++++<<-]<[>>>>++++++++++[<++++++++++>-]<<<<-]>>>    Combines them into a
                                                                    three digit number by
                                                                    multiplying the first
                                                                    by 100, the second by
                                                                    10 and then adding all
                                                                    three

[>.+<-]                                                             Repeatedly prints the
                                                                    value of the adjacent
                                                                    cell and then adds one
                                                                    to it until it reaches
                                                                    the input value.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby - <s>35</s> 33 bytes

Please note that I can't Ruby at all:

```ruby
$*[0].to_i.times{|i|puts i.chr()}
```

Comment: As far as I know there is an alias for "puts" that is simply "p". So -3 bytes if that's correct?

Comment: @Forlan07, not really an alias. `p` is equivalent to `puts whatever.inspect`.

Comment: @manatwork OK, nice to know :-)

Comment: This prints every character on a separate line. Shouldn't it be `print`?

Comment: Fixed and 3 bytes shorter: `puts (0..$*[0]).map(&:chr)*''`

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$*[0].to_i`, which makes it 2 bytes longer rather than 3 shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell - 20

```
%{0..$_|%{[char]$_}}

Usage:
56 | %{0..$_|%{[char]$_}}
```

Comment: A bit debatable to call a piece of syntax that isn't even valid a program or function ;-) (you cannot use `ForEach-Object` standalone like that). The function part of that is the script block, but it won't ever work as a function, because the context (`$_`) is provided by `ForEach-Object`. You can shorten it a bit by casting the range to an array, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 125 bytes

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a){p(256);}static void p(int l){int i=-1;for(;i++<l;){System.out.println((char)i);}}}
```

Simply puts in the number of characters to print from the ascii table @ p(n) where `n` is the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-98, <s>26</s> 20

```
0&;1-::0`j;;,$>:#,_@
```

<s>It's longer than the other Befunge-98 answer, but it's not self-modifying and only uses one line. (Also, the pointer only moves to the right until it gets to the print loop.)</s>

This is shorter now. Also, it's still not self-modifying. Hooray, jumping trickery!

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - <strike>35</strike> 34

```
for n 0 do input 1[prin to-char n]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm allowed to have another answer in a different language, here goes...

## Pascal: 91 bytes

```
PROGRAM A;VAR i,n:Integer;BEGIN
n:=0;readln(n);FOR i:=0 TO n DO
Write(chr(i));readln;END.
```

(just for kicks, really, I haven't messed in Pascal in ages)

Comment: Posting multiple answers is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Dennis is well aware of this. Just check *all* the questions he's answered

Comment: You can re‑use your input/length variable `n` as the counter variable in the `for`-loop:
`program p(input,output);var n:integer;begin read(n);for n:=1 to n do write(chr(n))end.`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 — 51 bytes

```
lambda n:sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(range(n+1)))
```

This is a variation of a line I keep in my shell history for when I need to refer to the ASCII table.

It first calls `range()`, passing `n + 1` as the sole argument. When used like this, `range()` returns an iterable of integers between `0` (inclusive) and the argument (exclusive—hence the need for the `+1`). The iterable is then passed to `bytes()`, which returns a bytestring, interpreting each integer as one byte. The bytestring is then written directly to the `buffer` for `stdout` (passing it to `sys.stdout.write()` or `print()` would result in an exception; those accept `str`ings, not `bytes`trings).

Note that `n` must not be greater than `255`. If it is, `bytes()` will raise an exception, because values greater than `255` do not fit in a single byte.

Also note that this doesn't bind the function to a name. I'm assuming that's acceptable, given that it *does* still create the function.

Comment: 1. There's no need for all of that: `lambda n:print(str(bytes(range(n+1))))` is just 38 characters. 2. If you go with your current method, you need to include `import sys`.

Comment: Actually, just `lambda n:print(bytes(range(n+1)))` works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 47 bytes

```
<?=join(array_map('chr',range(0,$argv[1])));
```

Usage:

```
php ascii.php n
```

Comment: `join` does the same as `implode` and is 3 bytes shorter.

Comment: @Titus good catch, updated!

Answer (score 1):

## LiveScript - 47

```
f=->alert String.fromCharCode.apply(,[0 to it])
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 36

If PHP Notice are set to off then this:

```
<? for(;$i<$argv[1];)echo chr($i++);
```

## PHP - 42

Otherwise:

```
<? for($i=0;$i<$argv[1];$i++)echo chr($i);
```

Comment: I think you can remove the PHP tag. JS answers typically don't include script tags, either.

Comment: OK, ty. First post so not sure how it goes :)

Comment: @IngoBürk That may be because Node.js doesn't need any script tags. You need `<?php` (or `<?` if short tags are enabled) for any PHP script, though.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Node doesn't support ES6 and yet ES6 answers don't include tags.

Comment: I don't see your point. It does have partial support via `--harmony`, but that doesn't have to be counted unless perhaps the answer relies on Node-specific APIs. Script tags are just a way to include JavaScript in a HTML file, on the other hand even standalone PHP scripts need an opening tag or they won't work.

Comment: @nyuszika7h [You're right](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). Although it can at least be the short tag `<?` without a closing tag. Sorry for the wrong suggestion, Dexa.

Comment: @IngoBürk not a problem at all. Few chars more or less wont make any difference, other languages do this much better anyway :)

Comment: -1: omit the whitespace after `<?`. I have read somewhere in meta that warnings are ok; cannot find it at the moment though.

Comment: @Titus -1 for this? I'll just smile and walk away :)

Comment: @Dexa -1 bytes. But actually it´s -3 with the unnecessary PHP tags.

Comment: @Titus Oh I meant you downvoted because of this. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

## F# - 66 characters

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let m a=
 for x in char 0..a.[0].[0]do printfn"%c"x
 0
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 20

```
[char[]](0.."$args")
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# - <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 52

```
c=>{for(var i='\0';i<=c;)System.Console.Write(i++);}
```

Inspired by [Java solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40515/41482)

Usage:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new System.Action<char>(c => {for(var i='\0';i<=c;)System.Console.Write(i++);})((char)255);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Martin for the help.

Comment: You can probably save two bytes by a) using `var` instead of `char` and b) by doing `...Write(i++)` and leaving the third section of the `for` statement empty.

Comment: I just saw a python solution using lambdas. So would this be a valid solution: `c=>{for(var i='\0';i<=c;)System.Console.Write(i++);}`?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C#'s lambdas, but I think so.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB: 13 bytes

```
@(n)char(0:n)
```

This is an anonymous function that prints the string.

### MATLAB: 17 bytes

This one takes STDIN.

```
char(0:input(''))
```

*I think these are pretty short for a non-golf language. :)*

Comment: The standard tips for casting to chars when golfing in MATLAB / Octave: `@(n)[0:n,'']`. =) Saves you a byte!

Answer (score 1):

## x86 DOS (11 bytes)

Takes parameter in CL

```
-u100
07AD:0100 mov ah,02
07AD:0102 cwd
07AD:0103 int 21
07AD:0105 inc dx
07AD:0106 cmp dl,cl
07AD:0108 jb 103
07AD:010A ret
07AD:010B
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pip, 3 bytes (not competing)

The language is newer than the question, but happens to do very well with it:

```
C,a
```

`a` is the first command-line argument. The unary range operator `,` constructs a range of all numbers 0 <= n < a. Finally, `C` converts them to characters. The resulting list is autoprinted, by default without any delimiter. Works into Unicode range too!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```perl6
put (^@*ARGS[0])».chr
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 43 bytes

```
fun n->Seq.iter(printf"%c")['\x00'..char n]
```

That is...

```
fun n->                                     // A function that takes n
                           ['\x00'..char n] // Generates a list of chars from NUL to n
       Seq.iter(          )                 // For each one,
                printf"%c"                  // Print it!
```

I tried using `\0` for `NUL`, but it doesn't work in F#. I couldn't get it under 4 characters, in any case. =P

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 7 bytes

```
Uo md q
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=3c017df05a10332dad3e27109fbdd291ef376837&code=VW8gbWQgcQ==&input=MTI4)

#### How it works

```
      // Implicit: U = input integer
Uo    // Create the range [0..U).
md    // Map each item X in this range to X.d().
      // If X is a number, this turns into the character with that char code.
q     // Join the array with the empty string.
      // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 42 bytes

Sorry for the necro.

```
n=>String.fromCharCode(...Array(n).keys())
```

If you need it as a program, 54 bytes:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(...Array(+prompt()).keys()))
```

However for some reason I can't get the above to work as a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 37 Bytes

```
a=...for i=1,a do print(a.char(i))end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ḶỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm0Pd/f8///fyNQMAA)

According to current reference implementation as of time of posting.

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
‘ḶỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yHO7Y93N3z//9/I1NTAA)

Inclusive. Reference implementation is exclusive.

Comment: @ASCII-only Well, I may update the links here, but [it's not just the certificates](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44510587#44510587).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```php
<?=join(range(a^a,chr($argv[1])));
```

yup. PHP can create a range of characters.

Takes argument from command line. Save to file, execute.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 2 bytes

Input is given on the command line, `$ pushy asciitable.pshy 90`. Note that this will not work for numbers larger than 127.

```
X"
```

Explanation:

```
    \ Implicit: Input number on stack
X   \ Get range [0, n)
 "  \ Interpret as charcodes and print
```

Answer (score 1):

### ><>, 14 bytes

```
0:o1+:r:@=?;$!
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=AwLg9gjA1CBOIAEC8B+A3AEgIRA)

#### Explanation

```
0              push 0 to the stack                [n, 0]
 :             duplicate the top value            [n, 0, 0]
  o            output it                          [n, 0]
   1+          add one                            [n, 1]
     :         duplicate top value                [n, 1, 1]
      r        reverse the stack                  [1, 1, n]
       :       duplicate the top value again      [1, 1, n, n]
        @      move the top value back twice      [1, n, 1, n]
         =?;   pop top two values, if equal, end  [1, n]
            $  swap top two stack values          [n, 1]
             ! skip next instruction (0)
```

### or

```
0:o1+$1-:?!;$!
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=AwLg9gjA1AJBC0ID8BCA3DFQ)

#### Explanation

```
0              push 0 to the stack                [n, 0]
 :             duplicate the top value            [n, 0, 0]
  o            output it                          [n, 0]
   1+          add one                            [n, 1]
     $         swap top two values                [1, n]
      1-       subtract one                       [1, n-1]
        :      duplicate top value                [1, n-1, n-1]
         ?!;   if n is 0, end                     [1, n-1]
            $  swap top two stack values          [n-1, 1]
             ! skip next instruction (0)
```

For both simply place `n` on the stack and the result will be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 47 bytes

```
set i 0
time {puts [format %c $i];incr i} $argv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVPBgKskMzdVobqgtKRYITotvyg3sURBNVlBJTPWOjMvuUghs1ZBJbEovez///@GRsYA)

Comment: Making the user set n is not valid

Comment: @ASCII-only: I am in the process of reviewing my older answers. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 31 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR I=.TO N?CHR$(I)NEXT
```

`.` is read as `0.0`, and I could have just used 0 in this case, but `.` looks cooler.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 8 bytes

```
f=:{.&a.
```

Explanation:

```
f=:{.&a.
f=:      define a function f
      a. the ascii sequence
     &   attach it to the next operator
   {.    take the first n items of
         you'll notice I don't say how many,
         that's because in J you can leave blanks and the interpreter fills them in
```

Comment: I trust that you did something, but I don't see what changed.

Comment: Riley's edit formatted the header by prefixing `#` so it would be styled as a header (larger font, bold).

Answer (score 1):

## [evil](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil), 10 bytes

I've been playing around with evil lately, and this is my first PPCG submission (albeit 2.5 years late). I find it a fun esolang to use partially because it seems nobody uses it!

```
ramlwalusb
```

### Explanation

```
r   // Store input character to Accumulator as byte
a   // Since we are writing then adding, add 1 to Accumulator
m   // Drop a loop marker
l   // Swap Wheel and Accumulator
w   // Output Accumulator
a   // Increment Accumulator
l   // Swap Wheel and Accumulator
u   // Decrement Accumulator
sb  // Go back to m if A != 0
```

evil is also an easy language to write an interpreter for. I think there's a javascript one floating around somewhere, but I ended up just writing my own.

EDIT: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/evil)

Comment: Cool answer! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
cat(intToUtf8(1:scan()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzULD0Ko4OTFPQ1NT87@hkfF/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 26 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]`

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:?Chr(i):Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 34 bytes

```vb
Input""n
For i=1To n
?Chr$(i)
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESSmPyy2/SCHT1jAkXyGPy945o0hFI1OTyy@1ouT/fzMTAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 42 bytes

```
{n:Int->for(c in 0..n-1)print(c.toChar())}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoJAEEDvfsV4mzm4ZJdASpBOQre@YDDXhmw2pjUI8du37V3fe48QZ9HkF4UniyLb9G46M/4er9FEp5bWAjIfnsHDKa3a9Bqr1gfDAURh55xWNb1yHHFwMZzvbEi0pf/m0Ua@XURHpLLMNs9ZFluq94cf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Check](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/check-lang), 2 bytes

```
,o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ITc7@/18n/////4ZGFgA)

Check has:

- Implicit input
- A range builtin
- A builtin to output a list of codepoints as characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 25 bytes

```
0*-8j0j+1-=*0-9*00+-1*0j1
```

Outputs the characters in reverse order. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P/fQEvXIssgS9tQ11bLQNdSy8BAW9dQyyDL8P9/QyMDAA)

### Explanation

```
0   *-8     #            [0] = read num
j   0       #  label j0: goto j0
j   +1-=*0  #  label j1: goto j(1 - !![0])
-9  *0      #            print char [0]
0   +-1*0   #            [0] = 1 + [0]
j   1       #  label j2: goto j0
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), 4 bytes [(SBCS)](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/wiki/Code-Page)

```
¿ï(,
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N////0P7D6@M1dP7/NzQwAAA)

Push input, output ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

## [Snap!](https://snap.berkeley.edu/), 121 bytes

[image]

```
when gf clicked
set[a v]to(
ask[]and wait
for[i v]=(1)to[answer v]
set[a v]to join[a v]unicode[i v]as letter
end
say[a v]
```

Snap! is quite better than scratch, but I am having problem at the scratchblocks2 syntax because Snap! has some extra blocks.

Answer (score 1):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), 122 bytes

```
I0A3L0S1M4V0G0D1A0
G-1A0A0
A0C4G1G1A0
A0
A0G1G1G1V0P0S1A0
A0A1G-4G-4A0
G-4

A0A0
C3G1G1A0C3G1G1A0
A0G-6A0
A0A1G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

Works by creating a loop where one line counts how many iterations (from x to 0) have been done and the other line prints each character (from 0 to x). The first line is constructing during run-time based on the inputted number in the first line of the code.

```
L0 S1 M4 V# G0 D1 ; first line, the # indicates user number
L0                ; compares 0 to the inputted number
   S1             ; adds 1 to the comparison result
      M4          ; multiplies this result with 4
         V#       ; sets this result to the G0
            G0    ; jumps this result of lines below
               D1 ; subtract one from the inputted number

G1 G1 G1 V0 P0 S1 ; second line
G1 G1 G1          ; no-ops to align the instructions with the first line
         V0       ; the operand, sets the value of the next instruction
            P0    ; prints the value set by the operand
               S1 ; adds 1 to the operand
```

For the jumping, jumping by 4 (we hit the last number) will jump to an empty line, halting the program, while jumping by 8 (we're not finished yet) gets us into a loop below which jumps back up to the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 byte

```
r
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=r&i=255%0A&m=2)

Integer arrays are auto printed as strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
od
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=b2Q&input=MjU2)

```
od     :Implicit input of integer
o      :Range [0,input)
 d     :Get the character at each codepoint
       :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 1 byte

```
L
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhYLfZYUJyUXQ3kLFhuZmkGYAA)

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 bytes

```
LCJ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi32cvZYUJyUXQ_kLFhuZmkGYAA)

##### Explanation

```python
L  # Implicit input
L  # Lowered range
   # B flag casts the list of ordinals
   # into a string of characters
   # Implicit output
```

```python
LCJ  # Implicit input
L    # Lowered range
 C   # Cast to characters
  J  # Join into a string
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell - <s>16</s> 22 characters

```haskell
(`take`['\0'..])
```

### Edit

Now printing the result

```haskell
print.(`take`['\0'..])
```

Comment: nice trick to get rid of a character

Comment: This doesn't actually print the result.

Comment: @JanDvorak he pretty much removed the space, as (``) does the same thing as flip here, in just as many characters...

Answer (score 0):

Lua

```
for i=0,255 do
    print(string.char(i))
end
```

Comment: This is code golf, so please include the byte count of your submission in the answer. Also, you don't need the line breaks. You can put all of this in one line like `for i=0,255 do print(string.char(i)) end`.

Comment: This is not valid solution as it not handles input/parameter as required.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 31 bytes

```
i;f(n){for(;i<n;)putchar(i++);}
```

Use:

```
i;f(n){for(;i<n;)putchar(i++);}

int main(void)
{
    f(34);   //Call the function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The challenge says to output all ASCII characters, not just the printable ones, and also to print "n ACII characters", not "ASCII characters up to n", so you could save 4 characters by letter i default to 0 and changing the loop condition to <.

And you could save 1 (or 2, depending how eager you are to invoke undefined behavior) character by moving the call to putchar() into the loop condition.

Comment: Thanks. Does the program look ok now?

Comment: @Stuntddude In whch way moving the putchar inside the loop condition would trigger UB?

Answer (score 0):

### PL/SQL 59

```
select chr(rownum)from dual connect by rownum<=&i
```

Didn't see a requirement that said output had to be a concatenated string, so this should work?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 65 bytes

First code golf, but here's my simple JavaScript implementation:

```
function f(n){for(i=1;i<n;)console.log(String.fromCharCode(i++))}
```

Not great but decent. ;)

Usage:

```
f(x) // x could be any number, but generally numbers
     // greater than 0 are better. ;)
```

The output is rather long so I'm not going to copy it but if you run it I think you'll get the idea. :P

Uncompressed:

```
function f(n) {
    for (i = 1; i < n;)
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(i++)); // by using i++ we increase
                                               // i right as we get it
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I don't think you need those braces, and you do the `i++` when call the function like `...fromCharCode(i++)` and then leave the third section of the `for` statement empty.

Comment: However, I just noticed that your answer isn't quite valid. You should write a function which takes `256` as a parameter.

Comment: Also, I think you should start the loop at `0` rather than `1`.

Comment: Ah, I'll update to fit what you guys have pointed out. :)

Answer (score 0):

## **C#, 112 | 83 bytes**

Full program, 112 bytes:

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){for(int i=0;i<int.Parse(a[0]);i++){System.Console.Write("{0}\n",(char)i);}}}
```

A function, 83 bytes:

```
static void f(int n){for(int i=0;i<n;i++){System.Console.Write("{0}\n",(char)i);}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Microscript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript), 9 bytes

`i1{d1s}ah`

Or alternatively:

`i1cs1]fah`

Answer (score 0):

#### Excel VBA - 143

```
For i = 1 To 127
Cells(i, 1) = i
Cells(i, 2) = Evaluate("DEC2HEX(" & i & ")")
Cells(i, 3) = Evaluate("DEC2OCT(" & i & ")")
Cells(i, 4) = Chr(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## K: 8 bytes

```
{10h$!x}
```

## Q: 11 bytes

```
{10h$til x}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 43 characters

```
*=@set{i;0}@repeat{*;@int-char{$i}@incr{i}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '*=@set{i;0}@repeat{*;@int-char{$i}@incr{i}}' <<< 96 | xxd 
0000000: 0001 0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f  ................
0000010: 1011 1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f  ................
0000020: 2021 2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f   !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0000030: 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3a3b 3c3d 3e3f  0123456789:;<=>?
0000040: 4041 4243 4445 4647 4849 4a4b 4c4d 4e4f  @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
0000050: 5051 5253 5455 5657 5859 5a5b 5c5d 5e5f  PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 45 Bytes

```
func a(n)for(x=0;x<n;print((x++).toChar())){}
```

Run and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=e0672c1f1e480867cdbd4769daf3e3a5)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 9

```
0{d1+,i}c
```

How it works:

```
0     # Push 0 to the top of the stack.
{     # Start a for loop.
 d    # Duplicate the top of the stack.
  1   # Push 1 to the stack.
   +  # Add the top two elements of the stack.
 ,    # Switch to for loop iterators.
  i   # Get input
   }  # End for loop
c     # Print stack as joined array of chars and exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 48 bytes

```
SELECT CHR(LEVEL)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 21 bytes

```
[1+a:0[$1+$a;<][^,]#]
```

<kbd>[Try it here!](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda. Usage:

```
256[1+a:0[$1+$a;<][^,]#]!
```

## Explanation

```
[                     {start lambda}
 1+a:                 {inputnum is end of range (saved to a)}
     0                {0 is start of range}
      [       ][  ]#  {while loop}
       $1+$a;<        {dup, increment, check if top of stack < a}
                ^,    {if so, output char}
                    ] {end lambda}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 70

Thanks to Mego for saving 4 bytes.

```java
public void f(int x){for(int u=0;u<x;u++)System.out.println((char)u);}
```

Previous versions:

```java
class f{public void f(int x){for(int u=0;u<x;u++)System.out.println((char)u);}}
class f{public f(int x){for(int u=0;u<x;u++)System.out.println((char)u);}}
```

The second version needs to be called by `new f(n);`

Feel free to give me ideas for making it even smaller.

Comment: You can do a standalone function: `public void f(int x){...}`. For even less bytes, if you're working with Java 8, you can use a lambda: `x->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,x).mapToObj(n->(char)n);`

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the `public` - a default-scoped function is fine.

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 14 bytes, NC

```
:[a|?chr$(b-1)
```

Takes a number form the command line and loops from 1 to that number, feeding each iteration into `CHR$`.

Non-competing, QBIC was thought of a year after this challenge was posted.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 6, 9 bytes

```
(^*).chrs
```

The header and code alone are too short, so have this extra sentence.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 45 bytes

A lambda expression which takes an integer and prints the table to `STDOUT`. Golfing suggestions welcome!

```java
x->{for(char i=0;i<x;System.out.print(i++));}
```

It's not clear whether OP wants `x` to be the last character printed, or the first character *not* printed. If it's the second, just change `i<x` to `i<=x` :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

An unnamed lambda function which returns the result as a string.

```py
lambda n:('%c'*n)%(*range(n),)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqJBnpaGumqyulaepqqFVlJiXnqqRp6mj@b@gKDOvRCNNw9DIXFPzPwA)

This uses the `printf`-style string formatting: when `'%c'` is formatted with an integer, it converts the integer to a character and displays that. So, we multiply the string by `n`, and format it with all values in `range(n)`.

## 29 bytes

If we want to be cheeky and return a list of characters instead of a string, we can get 1 byte shorter:

```py
lambda n:[*map(chr,range(n))]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqJBnFa2Vm1igkZxRpFOUmJeeqpGnqRn7v6AoM69EI03D0MhcU/M/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [QC](http://github.com/0xqookie/qc) 18 bytes

`'00901)01016010003`

```
'00 Read from stdin and store in memory at address 00
901 Print memory from address 01 until 0 is reached
)0101 Increment memory at 01 by 1
6010003 Jump to 03 if value at 01 and 00 are not equal
```

Edited because of invalid amount of bytes

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 28 bytes

```
say xrange('0'x,d2c(arg(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair ZX81 171 bytes for the listing (method 1):

```
 1 LET N$=""
 2 GOTO 2+(INKEY$<>"")
 3 LET A$=INKEY$
 4 IF A$=CHR$ 118 THEN GOTO 9
 5 IF CODE A$<28 OR CODE A$>37 THEN GOTO 2
 6 PRINT A$;
 7 LET N$=N$+A$
 8 GOTO 2
 9 LET N=VAL N$
10 IF N>255 THEN LET N=255
11 PRINT AT 0,0;
12 FOR I=0 TO N
13 PRINT CHR$ N;
14 NEXT I
```

This is using the `INKEY$` command to build a string of numbers, which is checked by comparing each input to the character range from 0 to 9 inclusing in line 5. Each character is stored in the `N$` variable and outputted to the screen. `CHR$ 118` is the ZX81 equivalent of a new line `"\r\n"` in PHP for instance.

There is a check to see if you have entered a valid range once you have pressed `NEW LINE` (0 to 255 inclusive) - as you can only enter numbers, the range is not going to be below zero.

Then there is a simple `FOR...NEXT` loop from line 12 to output the non-ASCII compatible character set. So I lose points because the ZX81 does not handle ASCII without some conversion tables.

Also, the ZX81 character set is incomplete to upper-case and inversed upper-case only; the remaining characters are either graphical symbols or they are ZX81 BASIC keywords, such as PI, INKEY$, PRINT etc... There is a much simpler method that I will post later, but is more prone to human error.

### Method 2, 34 bytes for the listing, no error checks and sanitizing inputs:

```
 1 INPUT N
 2 FOR I=0 TO N
 3 PRINT CHR$ I;
 4 NEXT I
```

Of course I'm sure that someone has already pointed out that true ASCII is 7 bit and the first 8 bit compatible ASCII set was PETSCII.

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore 64/128

This solution uses `PETSCII` which is an 8-bit wide ASCII-compatible character set.

### Solution 1 - 42 BASIC bytes used (35 bytes for the listing)

```
0 printchr$(14);:fori=0to255:poke1024+i,i:next
```

### Solution 2 - 10 bytes assembled, ~72 bytes source code

```
* = 49152
lda #$00
tax
.loop
    sta $0400,x
    dex
    txa
bne loop
rts
```

The assembly is doing what the BASIC listing is doing (without switching the character set to business mode first), but is obviously many times quicker. As the 6502 (6510/85xx) processor has an 8-bit accumulator and [8-bit] registers, we start at zero and count down, so 0 - 1 is 0xff. Each character is stored in the screen RAM located at 0x0400 (1024) and `sta $0400,x` says `store the content of X to location $0400 + x`. The `bne loop` will `branch` back based on the zero flag, once that is set (i.e., `x=0x00`) it will drop out of the loop and return to BASIC with `rts`.

Once assembled, run with `sys 49152` - this solution should work on the C64 and 128. It will work on other Commodore machines as long as you move the routine to a free area of RAM and relocate the starting point of the screen RAM from 1024.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
L<ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx@bw8v//jUzNAA)

```
L<ç  # full program
  ç  # convert...
     # (implicit) each element of...
L    # [1, 2, 3, ...,
     # ..., implicit input...
L    # ]...
     # (implicit) with each element...
 <   # decremented...
  ç  # to chars
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## C

I still get better,
hopefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    for(int i='a';i<='z';printf("%d\n",i),i++);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 19 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 19 bytes.

Now the debut of lazypxem.min.posixism.

- Filename (escaped some): `._.c.w\001.-.c.c.a.s.p`
- Content is empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5khCclgVCRGpeC1nKNUrXVZAV2BBAVD4JCgaOB89d49kyAQeruua2lmfvs5@zEPn4OnX58/79m2s@Pqhf3dbnt/197e3zcMo7PT3u/qutspAGp09@x24VPghkh1J@ZkYAfPSNcLBdOdjobjEJ1VHspnZ1bFxOHbyEWPbtgZ@t1sls86w8HA9h1yqDnui@ZPPA8VDrM0m02EL8rXXy1BxAkfUkcLBZxExIh95NI8HqhzYWH2R712@/D9umoVdH17AV58@167Pfv5UPl2dXVSubao2UCCGH0pf//6cHNy9b32rV6S3@YCstAbamWzfFVDNBoGvWk8k7/EInf/Q8IdTDw7dFHwxPmHoxCGr8OxE4y8XpjN2l7PDpD6iCQxorIgHgtzyZLYV8pm6z/OzirnVavEbWBmzzGDp143NPkYMb4EcDtPQyR@JswyZZYzYKgw9JzDLIT@xfaQkEFd2wtcYTZbpXHVXHo6C1wHSYE21d40M4A/75rEFb6jFhPiXMCzEO1ggoeQhLKP1JdwQmfhGKmVADUburrfQlKj6eda0uxx7I5QPlau3Ru7ohaVyqbYNuum1vT5/ALM3efzTV/TzHbZnMfTxj3TQ2lB1EaaGa6CRX0To5SK2jAF7u1vYpSCtJ9mLG5iVN8RtV6acXsT2we@hzQGljspbHdvE6MUhIP0@rY3MUrBxZc04@4mRnWIWDfttr6JUR0i5qZ93N/EKDVEbZw2XdjEKAXp1zTj3iZGC@DPNM1Y3MRoAXx8SzPub2K0AP68p5Og/wYDd@z0onc2MUohtmHasrGJUR3cGaTjvbeJUR3ccdKmi5uYAemX0xi4qKawbeDLpDHwWkxj4MwWw@bSDHfsZLtwSNKUvF@16JQ15dR0oP9OmXQT55ukiZs@@5vPNYmoNbebhSbVgCvQ8jno1ul6f5c8U8xEWuN1@vZuOy0tE9XNtgcK5@YbNLuGNFNr3CdUVuKihhxtTYfqIykx37g/VlpgFzzAjXgILhSOEXPhKeGJcZTPAYl7FluH9Yy4m6KmMLQNLkCKI5hlogBGZW1kti8BjdmUY1Dwweh8MDpadcG4xragJHEojU0xis0dI6YatjjOjcoLJCzz0IqZOlCafgOp762cw7SF4xUElsTj04oXq3GSDWwjntN4cXYsNQdvS5cfKvPct/Aytecm8fgKkamWIS7TJLk8ssu4xfE5TTTx39iV2JMk678TlNDi6FhJiNbrYs9uu55lCU0qkIivBDdGQ7/30Aleuu44HMgZcUttMe4mxcTUHmMeVo/NiCrNOSNd4CZNaPaqS8GkjQWWEEFh0kcwFkrCsaBws2SeGFzn/xNzVdTaY9d@5hPIWxkL3nA4Qv4wRAM77Dz1/EcBWKXFcmVMtDamhPGrfKzGkwyf6HwswvifZLzFx8ADfch7UOoOx0mYwBnTJJFkfjSoNJcI@fWfevn8xJLyD/lO/rWp6zSvwqiTt/NBfiR9qnyrX5/Ur61fwbhjSV9OTmv1CEIvB67rkGAM1yTMh/PuxO@EvaGPLnCVRN8bz8rfmLSsqgnDliwv6SeYRGM3nIx9lJGBZ0n5a0kB/JAuKX8vKUzdknC9RmAmVbpCvsVXJLqygIu7oapmwny15JngColG454fosoSPcVXyt2HbrgGej3fPdSPRL2krjj2NTYgUpOn/57XlgxVIAhkDUIxtGn@BzM/8a0V22V8vvDofCZAvuA6xK6avRCtmB7B0l@fep6LMxBSMlyNJEwiAGezCb4F2pLg45pyo1QVj7AscsHoxgIe07M8138Mn/ANMVnV1OC@WjuwPJNMMK5asJYgHOMbpSbLCiXkX4GvSziqykaxZOyQ@dJID6xf4NM1ww/4XKkod8pPEp1bQv6hhOpQ9jZy3E5vAPdHWKz76I7hO5qEglmxQNy8Ax@YL6xwwV1j76CSzVYOdoqEN5IJWOVf4d5obO@0RNgD7izDUCuJcNxrwIKLsRg1ICAVy9oukChmgat92PMn7pxFnLFWDowi8Bzu7BEGxcaXZmPN5KeFfxJUUY2iybJnXuC73M@VtXYW0b/A12tBCBaE29VkvUBO@soNiWqWzi32LV7HEP4@K1ulr6ot64Ylis1qLQ5CHlp83m@thH68NA0Rxbw/SY7VwIrB12XTbHozxZcKt5WBdmQRzsDskpfIjXV5wHgT2Zul0NsfhQ5/L/T@4QaT4m6oa66Ei8U8Qe9aa6QBkJ6hWBC8fC4wo68Q29iGgMYl/her8AtsH4G4bLNIlG6TiJjLHSNnUbWQw/aBTnIsZ/BdCeo/aX39pGNuk8Xifs4jUDFgRshvwcafh2oUSujOHcM9qPfSC0CNwAqFJcU@6h96R/0tr@Rt9Ut8rPEx5Gge77DgmaW3oBzgsYb5TtCFhxTfqoVZhwjS0rkuRGKNK9mxhdnm4@kPbycrPnTik15jZxB7wqpj/5nOOhMYORKSkNotLA4nuJdc4Cxhb7gVb1xey/GhF0Hd8np@lmVTlvsHmO3BrGYh4nH0@8kUBsT8/SrYah3Xc@GZC2mGTkh2J@gPWa4dgLhM447gB02Na5QptEm858vxvDWXTHZQsfc93IQ6iP8PYMIaZDhgL1oAxxvgMoSOgdS6scYwm@ERvK7L8GTvOYob9gauMuqMJspL8G468C4nqykw/vx@RaHd8@B2aqwEmN2QoyK7pfC7kDSzX59BF7IttUCNPaO4vWsUkRTZsiXq85N6NTk0bDjYhU//d/oTrUl02EeABMB5L3CSJOpwxYIfAQVxerCwNRQUUSfSbGqPHyEGtSlKMjdFn/mqmdVf9L8)
The footer has `|od -vtu1` to be commented; uncomment it to inspect the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 16 bytes

```
[ <iota> print ]
```

In modern versions of Factor, you can output sequences directly as strings. Here's a pic:

[image]

To get it to run on build 1525 (the one TIO uses), you'd have to convert the range to a string like this:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 21 bytes

```
[ iota ""like print ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqskJmvkJ1alJeao2DNxWVoZP4/GihUkqigpJSTmZ2qUFCUmVeiEPs/OTEn5z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

```c
f(c){c&&f(c-1),putchar(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1mzOllNDUjrGmrqFJSWJGckFgEFrWv/5yZm5mloKlRzKQBBmoZ6lbqmNVftfwA)

## C (MSVC), 25 bytes

```c
f(c){c&&f(c-1),putch(c);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 7 bytes

```
n[:o,]o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8v2ipfJzb//39LMwA)

This one, like at least one previous entry, prints the numbers from largest codepoint to 0, which wasn't disallowed in the rules as far as I can tell.

```
 n        - read the number of characters to print
  [   ]   - loop until the top of stack is 0
   :      - duplicate the top of stack
    o     - print it
     ,    - decrement the top of stack
       o  - print the x'00' entry
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 2 bytes

```
ʁC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiyoFDIiwiIiwiMjU2Il0=)