# Print a Symbolic Negative of your Code

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, source-layout, printable-ascii

(This is a variation on [Print a Negative of your Code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42017/print-a-negative-of-your-code), which I enjoyed a lot! Thanks to [Martin Büttner♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) - almost all of this text is his.)

Let's consider the *symbols* to be the following printable ASCII characters (note that space is included):

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

And the *alphanumerics* to be these:

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Consider a square of printable ASCII characters for side length N, like the following:

```
ONE, 
{two}
&3,+=
!four
f|ve.
```

We also require each row and each column to contain at least one symbol and one alphanumeric. (The above example satisfies this.)

We define the *symbolic negative* of such a square to be a square of the same size where each symbol is replaced with an alphanumeric and vice versa. For example, the following would be a valid symbolic negative of the above example:

```
[&]OK
a...b
1/100
i@#$%
(R) z
```

The choice of specific characters is irrelevant as long as they are in the categories above.

#### The Challenge

Your task is to write a program with square source code with side length N > 1, which prints a symbolic negative of its source code to STDOUT. Trailing spaces must be printed. You may or may not print a single trailing newline.

The usual quine rules also apply, so you must not read your own source code, directly or indirectly. Likewise, you must not assume a REPL environment which automatically prints the value of each entered expression.

The winner is the program with the lowest side length N. In the event of a tie, the submission with the fewest *symbols* in the source code wins. If there's still a tie, the earliest answer wins.

Comment: Is this really a "quine" type challenge since the output doesn't need to be source code of any type?

Comment: Good point, I don't think it actually is.

Comment: @LiamNoronha I'd consider it a generalised quine in that the output is a function of the source code, and the standard quine rules apply.

Comment: Define "reading your own source code"; if there is a command that, say, _copies_ characters to the output, would this be an instance of said "reading"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## GolfScript, 3 × 3 (4 symbols)

```
4,m
`3/
n*o
```

Try it online on [Web GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=NCxtCmAzLwpuKm8%3D).

#### Output

```
[0 
1 2
 3]
```

#### How it works

```
4,  # Push the array [0 1 2 3].
  m # Undefined token. Does nothing.
`   # Push the string representation of the array. Pushes "[0 1 2 3]".
 3/ # Split into chunks of length 3. Pushes ["[0 " " 1 " "2 3]"].
n*  # Join the chunks, separated by linefeeds. Pushes the output.
  o # Undefined token. Does nothing.
```

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, 3 × 3 (5 symbols)

```
[5,
S*3
/N*
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B5%2C%0AS*3%0A%2FN*).

#### How it works

```
[   e# Unmatched [. Does nothing.
 5, e# Push [0 1 2 3 4].
S*  e# Join the integers, separating by spaces. Pushes "0 1 2 3 4".
  3 e#
/   e# Split into chunks of length 3. Pushes ["0 1" " 2 " "3 4"].
 N* e# Join the chunks, separated by linefeeds. Pushes the output.
```

#### Output

```
0 1
 2 
3 4
```

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 3x3, 4 Symbols

```
S]1
.5;
S]1
```

#### Output:

```
[1]
0.5
[1]
```

#### Explanation:

- S sorts the one element list `]1`
- The numeric literal `.5` gets printed as `0.5`, `;` terminates the statement (does nothing in this case)

Comment: I though long and hard about how I could get `<alphanum><symbol><alphanum>` in Pyth or CJam. It never occurred to me to use floats... Nice work!

Answer (score 6):

## C++, 18 x 18

"Always choose the worst tool for the job."

```
#include<cstdio>  
int main(){ for  (
int line =  0lu;  
1lu*line <  18l;  
1lu*line++){pri\  
ntf(line == 0lu * 
123*line? "\x41.\\
x2e\x02e...\x2e\\ 
x42\x02e...\x2e.\ 
CDE\x00a":  14l!= 
1lu*line?".\x2e.\\
x46\x02e...\x47""\
HIJ\x02e..""KLM"  
 /*O*/"\n":  /*The
bad code:*/"NOP.\ 
QRS\x054." "UVW\  
XYZ\x02e" "\x2e\\ 
x2e\x00a"); 0lu;}}
```

Output:

```
A.......B......CDE
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
NOP.QRST.UVWXYZ...
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
...F....GHIJ...KLM
```