# Largest power of 2 that divides \$n\$

Tags: code-golf, math, number

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126172/create-a-binary-ruler), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71833/how-even-is-a-number)

## Introduction

The [ruler sequence](https://oeis.org/A001511) is the sequence of the largest possible numbers \$a_n\$ such that \$2^{a_n}\mid n\$. It is so-called because its pin plot looks similar to a ruler's markings:

[image: Pin plot of ruler sequence]

However, with a slight modification, we can also get a similar sequence. This sequence is \$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,…\}\$ where \$a_n\$ is the largest **power of 2** such that \$a_n\mid n\$ ([relevant OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006519)).

The first 100 terms of this sequence are:

```
1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 16, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 32, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 16, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 64, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 16, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 32, 1, 2, 1, 4
```

## Challenge

Your challenge is to do one of these three things:

- Take a positive integer \$n\$ as input and return the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> term of this sequence.
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ as input and return the first \$n\$ terms of this sequence.
- Output the sequence infinitely.

## Test Cases

```
12 -> 4
64 -> 64
93 -> 1
8 -> 8
0 -> (undefined behavior)
```

## Rules

- You may output the sequence in any convenient format - e.g. as a list or some other iterable or separated by any non-digit separator, as long as it is constant between all terms.
- You may output the term(s) in any convenient format - e.g. as an integer, as an integer string, as a float with the decimal part consisting of only zeros, ditto but as a string, or as a Boolean (`True`) if and only if the term is `1`.
- You may choose to use either zero- or one-indexing.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Trailing whitespace is allowed.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Can you edit the set of terms so that it doesn't include the '0th' term? Doesn't seem like you've included it in your list of first 100 terms.

Comment: Good point. I'm on it

Comment: If you convert the number to binary, and count the index (starting at 0) from the right to the first 1 and then raise this index to the power of 2. Should work?

Comment: Close, you actually raise 2 to the power of the result. Other than that, that's actually the exact method used in [my comment here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220520/largest-power-of-2-that-divides-n?noredirect=1#comment513375_220526). Tw`o` raised to the power of `k` (index) of the first `1` from the `R`ight in the implicit input in `b`inary

Comment: Ahh, yes that's what I meant... Woops.

Comment: Though this challenge is well-written, I think it would be better if it didn't define and plot the ruler sequence \$a_n\$, then say actually you need to output \$2^{a_n}\$. Best to say the actual task itself at the start.

Comment: Could you add some test cases so I can better understand the challenge, e.g. `12 -> 4`?

Comment: @xnor I was just trying to provide some background to the challenge.

Comment: @expressjs123 Sure thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
N&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99P7b@hgYH14XaVR01r3P8DAA)

Takes \$n\$ as input, outputs the \$n\$th term

### How it works

Uses [dinglelooper’s observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220527/66833)

Comment: Nice! The shortest possible 05AB1E answer seems to be 5 bytes too.

Comment: nvm, it's 2 bytes that's the shortest in 05AB1E... also, this is pretty much identical to the 05AB1E 2-byter.

Answer (score 19):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 13 bytes

Takes a positive integer \$ n \$ as input and returns the \$ n \$th term of the sequence.

```python
lambda n:n&-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk9NN@9/ooKtQrShjoKRjgKQNAGTELYFEhtZ3NAMhwQuDcZGJGog2QYzE1rbgOqHWC6utPwihUwdhQqFzDyF1LzS3NSixJJUjURNKy6FgqLMvBKFNI1MBW0FQ00FW1uFiv8A)

The largest power of \$ 2 \$ that divides \$ n \$ is also the lowest set bit. The bitwise magic is a bit difficult to explain, but it uses the fact that `~n + 1` in its binary representation produces the same lowest set bit as `n`.

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

Outputs the sequence infinitely.

```python
n=1
while 1:print-n&n;n+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WkKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EN08tzzpP29bw/38A)

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

Takes a positive integer \$ n \$ as input and returns the first \$ n \$ terms of the sequence.

```python
f=lambda n:n*[0]and f(n-1)+[n&-n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qTyvaIDYxL0UhTSNP11BTOzpPTTcv9n@igq1CtKGOgpGOApA0AZMQtgUSG1nc0AyHBC4NxkYkaiDZBjMTWtuA6odYLq6Cosy8EmBYGhoYaCrY2iok/gcA)

Comment: [Why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250963/15195862)

Answer (score 12):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 13 bytes

```
(x+?)(\1\1)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc@9UsJAFIbhW4kZh5xDTCCMWLAuVBY0FFoCxQ4ckqObzc7u8iM/rRfgJXojEQtmrJ/i@953tVN@5diGzFtek6sb80GfrZOG9tErlS8HC3CU4163hUM6QVgUiwK79223d8Q8NG/BsSkBc695RfD0kD0iCi/7Yl@xJgAtHam1ZkOAeCfNVms8lVLn3moOkGQJCt4AGFnmmkwZKhwPzmf2MzUDllY5T1MToJz3l4g3oP9gxsWkGP0xhso1@3hqdkrzOnLKlDSK4lSLTeNA8LMkwWmK18Faxoc4d2RJBWDMaxVWFTjEk@907DUqwF9HIew2@OCA0yT6@fqOkrSeF8vbVXG5tP1sMBz@Ag)

Works by finding the smallest positive natural number that divides the input yielding an odd quotient. As such, this algorithm is generally applicable to any power of \$p\$, where \$p\$ is prime: find the smallest number that divides the input yielding a quotient that is not divisible by \$p\$.

Takes its input in unary, as a sequence of `x` characters in which the length represents the number. The output is returned in capture group 1.

```
          # No anchor needed, since every input N>=1 returns an output
(x+?)     # \1 = the smallest number >= 1 for which:
(\1\1)*$  # \1 divides N and N / \1 is odd
```

Below is a demonstration showing how the algorithm above generalizes to other prime powers:

Largest power of \$3\$ that divides \$n\$ (17 bytes): `(x+?)\1?(\1{3})*$` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc@9UsJAFIbhW4kZh5xDTCDIWLAuVBY0FFoCxQ4ckqObzc7u8iM/rRfgJXojEQtmrJ/i@953tVN@5diGzFtek6sb80GfrZOG9tErlS8HC3CU4163hUM6wUUxgUVxerxg977t9o6Yh@YtODYlYO41rwieHrIhovCyL/YVawLQ0pFaazYEiHfSbLXGUyl17q3mAEmWoOANgJFlrsmUocLx4HxmP1MzYGmV8zQ1Acp5f4l4A/oPZlxMitEfY6hcs4@nZqc0ryOnTEmjKE612DQOBD9LEpymeB2sZXyIc0eWVADGvFZhVYFDPPlOx16jAvx1FMJugw8OOE2in6/vKEnrebG8XRWXS9vPBsPBLw)

Largest power of \$5\$ that divides \$n\$ (21 bytes): `(x+?)\1{0,3}(\1{5})*$` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY87csIwFEW34ngy@D2MjU0IBYqgSkFDkZSEQgPCfoksayTxCeA2C2CJ2YgDBTOpbnGKe86n2Am3smR84gytpa1q/SW/W8u13Advsng9GIAjn/S7LRziKX7kp6z31MB1nxvsPrbd/hFTX797S7oATJ2ilYRRLxkiMsczti9JSQDFrRRrRVoC4gPXW6XwVHCVOqPIQ5REyGgDoHmRKqkLX@JkcD6Tm4s5EDfCOjnTHopFtkS8A/kf6Ek@zcc3jL609T6c6Z1QtA6s0IUcB2Gs2Ka2wOiFS0ZxjNfDioeHMLXSSOGBMK2EX5VgEU@u0zHXKA@3jpyZrXfeAsVR8PtzCaK4WuTLuyprmjZLRoPhHw)

Largest power of \$17\$ that divides \$n\$ (23 bytes): `(x+?)\1{0,15}(\1{17})*$` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9bsIwFEZfJY0qci8hIalaqHANUwcWhnakDBaY5LaOY9nmp0BWHqCP2BdJYUDq9kln@M75FFvhlpaMT5yhlbRVrb/kd2u5lrvgTRavewNw4ON@t4V9PMGP/Jj18qcGLiMfNti9b7v9A6a@fveWdAGYOkVLCYNe8ojIHM/YriQlARS3UqwUaQmId1xvlMJjwVXqjCIPURIhozWA5kWqpC58ieOH04ncTMyAuBHWyan2UMyzBeINyP9Aj/NJPrpi9KWtd@FUb4WiVWCFLuQoCGPF1rUFRi9cMopjvBxWPNyHqZVGCg@EaSX8sgSLeHSdjrlEebh25MxsvPMWKI6C3/NPEMXVPF/cVFnTtFnyPBj@AQ)

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes

```hs
l=1:do x<-l;[2*x,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8fW0ColX6HCRjfHOtpIq0LHMPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCSWJ2qoKRAZCV8/9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Generates an infinite list. This list is defined recursively using the property that the list is unchanged if we double each value and intersperse 1's at every other position including at the start.

So, we start the list with a `1`, then iterate through the list itself, each time producing the doubled number followed by a `1`. Haskell's laziness allows this kind of self-reference.

```hs
1   <- initial value
2 \ 1 doubled
1 /
4 \ 2 doubled
1 /
2 \ 1 doubled
1 /
8 \ 4 doubled
1 /
2 \ 1 doubled
1 /
...
```

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 10 bytes

```hs
gcd=<<(2^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPz05xdbGRsMoTvN/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCbmKBQppCtKGenpFB7P9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Outputs the n'th term. Equivalent to `f n=gcd n(2^n)`. We take the greatest common divisor of `n` and a large power of 2.

Comment: Being only familiar with Haskell, I understand what `l=1:do x<-l;[2*x,1]` is doing conceptually, but not syntactically.  Do you mind elaborating on the mechanics?

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
LoÖOo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ//wNP/8//8tzQA)

Takes \$n\$ as input, outputs the \$n\$th term

### How it works

```
LoÖOo - Full program. Input n
L     - Range from 1 to n
 o    - Raise 2 to the power of each
  Ö   - Yield 1 if divisible by n, for each
   O  - Sum, counting the 1s
    o - Raise 2 to the power
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
(&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fQ@3/f0szAA)

Boring bitwise solution. Calculates the bitwise AND of \$n\$ and \$-n\$

Comment: you need to use the bathroom?

Comment: @Lyxal `NoÖOo` :P

Comment: Nice job! My idea was `bR1ko`, but this deserves more attention for its audible appeal. +1

Comment: Also, correction: now that I think about it, there's a 2-byter which returns the \$n\$th term.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Also, in case for some reason you didn't know you can use `---` or `***` to make a horizontal line in Markdown.

Comment: @Makonede I did know, but my phone doesn't, so insists on em dashes :/

Comment: I feel you, autocorrect is quite annoying. not so much for simple punctuation issues like this, but still annoying.

Comment: [`Óнo`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8OQLe/P//7c0AwA) works for 3 bytes (`2**the exponent of 2 in the prime factorization`). And, borrowing from xnor's Haskell answer, [`o¿`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//9D@//8tzQA) is another 2-byter.

Comment: @ovs Funnily enough, Н is pronounced like N, meaning `Óнo` is pronounced "oh no" :P

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 18 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&1||2*f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYrLCoMwEADvfsWe6qb2pSAU0vRHSg8ihq7IJmRXT/57moungZmZh22QMVHU6/bM2Tt2bz61@96dPfK9M3kMLAppknVRAQefr618SIDLpEBFtLbgBf2jsGnMsd7iKj/0SMbYKiZixaPMgRjrC9Ql5T8)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) x86, 14 bytes

Takes a positive integer \$n\$ as input and returns the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence.

```
f(n){n&=-*&n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZCxDoIwEIZ3nuJCAilyxBSJMWLjg6iDwdZ0sBBgMBJWH0Dj5tP5IngqYFxcHOzQP/16@XP5kmCbJE2jmPEq44pg4Jq4bnZrbZgHlQV0tClB7jOZlHKzWIGAimOIHCN85QQ/33yM3wdGIf7YMI7w3zvU8VOOSnNgD0OaxPCYYiag0AeZKtZJ84YtGPSEBn2/E9xJLqhCMe3FH1QS7fXrgK/e31lOA4rZTgHOBm7HE8XS2AiFEHJu365ne0r3hYgm2BbXVt3cAQ)

```
f(n){*&n&=-n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZCxDoIwEIZ3nuJCAilyxBSJMWLjg6iDwdZ0sBBgMBJWH0Dj5tP5IngqYFxcHOzQP/16@XP5kmCbJE2jmPGqgWtcEZi4bnZrbZgHlQV0tClB7jOZlHKzWIGAimOIHCN85QQ/33yM3wdGIf7YMI7w3zvU8VOOSnNgD0OaxPCYYiag0AeZKtZJ84YtGPSEBn2/E9xJLqhCMe3FH1QS7fXrgK/e31lOA4rZTgHOBm7HE8XS2AiFEHJu365ne0r3hYgm2BbXVt3cAQ)

Same bitwise formula as used [ChartZ Belatedly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220522/17216), [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220527/17216), and many more. Thanks to [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220550/17216) for the nice idea of showing ✓ or ✕ in the TIO code depending on correctness; I haven't done that before, but might use it some more in the future.

Uses the very common code golf hack of avoiding the non-golfy `return` keyword (by taking advantage of the fact that results to most calculations get stored in the accumulator, the same register that is used for return values), but without resorting to use of global variables or fake function parameters. This is done by taking the address of `n` and then dereferencing that address.

This of course requires the default optimization level `-O0`. Using `-O1` will break gcc `return` avoidance hacks (and in clang, they don't even work at `-O0`).

In 32-bit x86, this compiles to the following (`[ebp+0x8]` is the `n` parameter):

```
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 neg    eax
 mov    edx,eax
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 and    eax,edx
 mov    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],eax
```

Whereas `f(n){n&=-n;}` doesn't work because it compiles to the following, which acts like `f(n){return-n;}`:

```
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 neg    eax
 and    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],eax
```

An essentially equivalent result occurs in x86-64 and MSP430.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) - many other platforms, 12 bytes

```
f(n){n&=-n;}
```

On many architectures other than x86, this actually works:

[ARM64 gcc 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/8xdcav)
[ARM gcc 10.2.1](https://godbolt.org/z/KahGEK)
[KVX gcc 7.5 (ACB 4.1.0-cd1)](https://godbolt.org/z/6P441M)
[MIPS64 gcc 5.4](https://godbolt.org/z/z57arq)
[MIPS gcc 5.4](https://godbolt.org/z/ebY7n6)
[PowerPC64 AT13.0 (gcc9)](https://godbolt.org/z/x3jrEz)
[RISC-V rv64gc gcc 10.2.0](https://godbolt.org/z/EKzGEG)
[AVR gcc 5.4.0](https://godbolt.org/z/joGo8x)

This is case in point for why I hate the gcc `return` avoidance hack so much. It's not merely reliant on `-O0`, and not only uses undefined behavior in general, but it's not even portable within different architecture targets of `gcc` itself.

Here it is failing to work as desired on x86 and MSP430, contrasted with the `*&` forcing it to work:

[x86-64 gcc 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/v6zrWb)
[x86-32 gcc 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/asYenx)
[x86-32 gcc 5.4](https://godbolt.org/z/W5WWe4)
[MSP430 gcc 6.2.1](https://godbolt.org/z/o3b5d5)

There is no guarantee that the same undefined behaviors will still behave the same way in future versions of gcc (and/or the toolset) even on the same architecture.

This is why I prefer to post "C (clang)" or "C (gcc `-O1`)" answers instead of "C (gcc)". If the fragile undefined behavior hacks work, you have to use them in "C (gcc)" answers to stay competitive with other "C (gcc)" answers.

In any case, people posting answers that use this hack should probably call the language "C (gcc) x86" instead of "C (gcc)".

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

Outputs the sequence infinitely.

```
main(n){for(;;)printf("%d   ",-n&n++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0@zOi2/SMPaWrOgKDOvJE1DSTWFU0lHN08tT1tb07r2/38A)

Saves 1 byte by using tab (which can be used literally) instead of newline (which would require `\n`). Takes another shortcut by using the first parameter of `main()`, the command line argument count, which is 1 when there are no command line arguments (because the pathname of the executable is treated as the first argument, at index 0).

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 52 bytes

Takes a positive integer \$n\$ as input and outputs the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.

```
main(n){for(scanf("%d",&n);n;)printf("%d    ",-n&n--);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0@zOi2/SKM4OTEvTUNJNUVJRy1P0zrPWrOgKDOvBCzEqaSjm6eWp6uraV37/7@hgQEA)

Abuses a loophole by printing the first \$n\$ terms in descending instead of ascending order. Without this, it would be **<s>57</s> 56 bytes**:

```
main(i,n){for(scanf("%d",&n);n--;)printf("%d    ",-i&i++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1MnT7M6Lb9Iozg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHLU/TOk9X11qzoCgzrwQsyKmko5uplqmtrWld@/@/oYEBAA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

Takes a positive integer \$n\$ as input and returns the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.

```
f(n){int*m=malloc(n*4);for(;n;)m[n]=-n&n--;n=(int)m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZDBSsQwEIbvPsVQWEm6KdK1LGIMPkjtYckmEthMlqaCWHr1ARRvPt2@SB3bbaEXL2sOM8mXf4aZX2fPWve9Zchbh03qld8dDkEzTAsubaiZRMl9iZXK8BqzTKJiJORedr3fOWQc2iugQxDM69HoxuzLChS0udiIXBRizHdi@c634m/B7UZc2GFbiH@boZPDljpgbIZddXihqCC6NxMsm1bncDOhdGZydij1VGLZUHzGZDL8WgqOvnJJ6UGN3em@Xk/@Th0iqXzpsrySC26Iz/4vv481CSxLVhFWezi9f1B6wkRAVMo8Jqfvz@Se4hcRR/A8VzdOVxvDPKGu/wE)

`4` is `sizeof(int)`.

`m[n]=-n&n--;` works because by the time `m[n]` evaluates, `n` has already been decremented; it's equivalent to `m[n-1]=-n&n;--n;`.

The array returned is allocated by this function, and must be `free()`ed after use.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>6</sup> 4 bytes

```
AND-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Hf1cdP9rcvk56SkY6igY6YBIEx0E2wKJbcLFlZqcka@QpqStYKidqWdo8B8A)

<sup>-2 thanks to FrownyFrog</sup>

Just because expressing [dingledooper's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220527/15469) in J is nice....

- `...-` The whole thing is a J hook, so that the verb `...` will receive the input and its negative as the left and right argument.
- `AND` Elementwise "and" on the bits.

Comment: You can also do `AND-`

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>28</s> 23 bytes

*5 bytes off thanks to [@Giuseppe!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

```matlab
@(n)2^sum(factor(n)==2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0/TKK64NFcjLTG5JL8IyLW1NdL8X5JaXKJgq2BoZWhgYM2VWFSUWJlWmqeRpqMAktHUU/8PAA)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(n)                      % Define anonymous function of n
          factor(n)       % Vector of prime factors of n, possibly repeated
                   ==2    % Compare each element with 2. Gives 1 (true) or 0 (false)
      sum(            )   % Sum
    2^                    % 2 raised to that
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(n,t=2^(n:0))t[!n%%t][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfU5BfUpKSZ/s/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fE1ihOI8/KQFOzJFoxT1W1JDbaMPa/skJaZlFxiYKhgYFCSWpRbrEVV3FiQUFOpYahFVBMB2qS5n8A)

Constructs a series `t` of powers of 2 in reverse (`t=2^(n:0)`), then gets the first element (`[1]`) for which n MOD t is zero (`[!n%%t]`).

This works *in principle* for any `n`, but is limited by floating-point accuracy and - more obviously - calculation time and memory.  A faster and less memory-hungry (but 7 byte longer) version using the same approach would be: `function(n,t=2^(0:log2(n)))max(t[!n%%t])` ([try it](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoMwEADvecUWEXaph5jeAr6kVAg1akA3IVmhfX1air0OM5PrlqLIxEOdD35KiIzcyWBG1HaLi0Emot29UO4Xblt5UG1gDrkI9FqD@LwXq4pLaXtjb7@sO4@kVAOyekAz3szVkKw/HTAeUsLkIbD4xWfIjhdPVp3h368f)).

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
f=function(n)`if`(n%%2,1,2*f(n/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsMgEADvvmIhBHZbodHehHwlJDSaCukqujn09baU9DrMTGl7TiIrjy2M4eCHxMTINMcwI/e91UbbS0C@WaLWQYilCphhAPHlVZ2qS877G437Mn2@SKkO0E53e7Ukz58KmA6pcfUQWfzmC5SFN09OndHfbx8)

An alternative recursive approach (ported from [user81655's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220525/95126)) is 1 byte longer, but runs significantly faster and so can actually be tested for very large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 19 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$n-band-$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyVPNykxL0VXJe/////GAA)

It does:

- Take a positive integer \$n\$ as input and return the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> term of this sequence.

Thanks to @xnor

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```scala
n=>n& -n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzVWWmKOQZqXgmVeiYGsHof7n2drlqSno5v0vKMrMK9EwVCjJVzAyUMhNLFBI0@Sq/Q8A)

dingledooper's idea works also in Scala

Comment: Apparently an alternate 8 byte solution is `n=> -n&n`. Why don't `n=>-n&n` and `n=>n&-n` work? Are `=>-` and `&-` being parsed as different operators?

Comment: When Scala finds a sequence of characters that can be part of an operator, it tries to make one operator of it. You need a space to separate them.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 11 bytes

```
GCD[2^#,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277393ZJdooTllHOVbtf0BRZl6Jgr5Dur5DUGJeemq0oYFB7P//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ÝoʒÖ}θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Nz8U5MOT6s9t@P/fzMA)

Turns out I'm way too used to Vyxal. -2 thanks to Makonede

### Explained

```py
ÝoʒÖ}θ
Ýo      # 2 ** range(0, input) // vectorised
  ʒÖ}   # filter(lambda x: x % input == 0, ^)
     θ  # ^[-1]
```

Comment: You can golf off 2 bytes by removing the `Is`. You're pushing the input to the top and swapping the current element in the list to the top, however implicit input's default behavior is acting as if it was on the bottom of the stack if there are less than <arity of operator> elements on the stack.

Comment: @Makonede that's a result of functions in Vyxal re-using arguments as implicit input if nothing is avaliable

Comment: [Beat you to 5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220526/66833)

Comment: lol. BTW, you made a couple typos; `use` should be `used`, and `2 ** range(0, input)` should be `(2**i for i in range(input()+1))` or `map(lambda x:2**x,range(input()+1))`.

Comment: @Makonede `2 ** range...` is intentional. It assumes vectorisation

Comment: ah ok. i see now. however, it should be `range(0, input+1)`, as `range` is half-inclusive. you could also just remove the `0` altogether to just simplify it to `range(input+1)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
N⍲
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=N%E2%8D%B2&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Just a port of the bitwise stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 7 bytes

```javascript
n=>n&-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5PTTfvf6KCrUK0oY6CkY4CkDQBkxC2BRIbWdzQDIcELg3GRiRqINkGMxNa24Dqh1gurrT8IgWNTFsDa4VMm0S9nNS89JIMIFtbW5NLITk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI00jU0FbwVBTwdZWITE6M1bzPwA)

dingledooper's solution (for Python) adapted to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 7 bytes

```java
n->n&-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVGxasNADN3vKzQVG8dHnYZQcF3o2KlDKBRCBtWxXbln@biTU0Lwt7vXtENayJChi3hPepKQXos7TNvt@0Sd7Z1AG7gehIyuBy6FetaPLM@Mbv9kK4fSu1yVBr2HFzgoAC8oVMJfEdTFxOk9X6U85UrZ4dUE1Y9419MWOiSOVuKIm/UG0DU@DgOJ5YtBAVx9wJEdshnMZxDi4hi/8e0JPs1nyzOFcw038wsbLt6wXPz3ht83jOHhdbAgCu8DKq5zoDvUpuJG3gJOkljBau@l6nQ/iLbBAjEc1RqtNfsHH7yMCBLIYigKwDVt4lyNapw@AQ)

dingledooper's solution (for Python) adapted to Java

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```
function(n)bitwAnd(n,-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTzMps6TcMS9FI09HN0/zv7JCWmZRcYmCoZG5QklqUW6xFVdxYkFBTqWGoRVQTCdN8z8A)

While it's good to have a variety of answers using different techniques, the actual shortest in each language should be represented too. As is the case in most languages, I think the bitwise hack is the shortest here.

Comment: This is probably indeed the shortest, but I think it's worth pointing-out that it doesn't actually work for large numbers: [try it](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTzMps6TcMS9FI09HN0/zf5qGUZyxkbaR5n8A).  Any number that is internally represented as a floating-point number will fail...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen That's an interesting point. I'd also point out that your 33 byte answer doesn't just fail due to slowness, it [runs out of memory](https://tio.run/##K/qfU5BfUpKSZ/s/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fE1ihOI8/KQFMzNUejJFoxT1W1JFYTplTDKM7YSNtI8z8A). Though I suppose it would still work with unlimited memory, whereas the bitwise version here wouldn't.

Comment: Yes, you're right: I've updated my answer to point this out, too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```
{it&-it}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J@SmqaQZvu/OrNETTezpBbMT1SwVYg21FEw0lEAkiZgEsK2QGIjixua4ZDApcHYiEQNJNtgZkJrG1D9EMvFlZZfpKCRmVeikGlrYK2QaZOoV5xZlaqhCWRra2tyKRQUASVz8jTSNDIVtBUMNRVsbRUSozNjNf8DAA)

dingledooper's Python solution, translated to Groovy

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 15 bytes

```c
a;f(n){a=n&-n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVFNj4IwEL3zKyYkGpCSCH7ETZe9GH@FcGhKccm6s4aaSEL461tHQIWDBw426WQ@3ut05kn/IKUxgmcOupWIcOojr82vyNFxrcoCOjmeQZUnJc8q3ScQQRUwCBmQXTa29Tc9v58P1i8KrwiLcCRhdIf18t0dhjPUvFmk/BbFjKySP6poN2nH5S6My48t3ZXNoB8v7I6X/RXg3FTIMVUl0ea8cz8hmFPgeU3oQivYXTQkaIvzIOCDkqbSTfJhVlH2oXTDTJ6AU0GQzLEnKfhfQHaiY6QvIwPNHlPpKFJJ92xt1eZfZkdx0Ma/XAE)

Inputs a positive integer \$n\$ and returns \$2^a\$ which is the largest power of \$2\$ such that \$2^a\mid n\$.

Comment: Why not [`f(n,a){a=n&-n;}`](https://tio.run/##tVHLroIwEN3zFRMSDVxKIviIBnFj/Aph0ZTiJfc6GmoiCeHXrSOgwsIFC5t0Mo9zOp05wj0IoXVqIeN2yUMcuxhU@sgztGyjNIBOhheQxVmKi0z2MYRQegx8BmRntW38Zcfv5r3Fh8InwtQfSBjcYTH7dof@DFVQL1L88vyHrBR/Mm82aUbFzo@K1Zbu3GTQjadmy0tPOVgPFTJMZEG0SdC6a/AmFDhOHdrQCPYUDQna4Bzwgl5JUYlEt/tZSdmX0jUzfgPOOUFSyxwl4G6A7EhFSF9GBoq9plJhKOP22cqo9E2k//ygtHu9Aw)? That is a bit cleaner, avoiding the use of global variables.

Comment: @Deadcode Same length and purely a matter of personal preference whether you consider a fake function parameter "cleaner" than using a global variable. And who worries about cleanliness anyway in code golfing? T_T

Comment: [-1 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220553/17216) avoiding the need for either global variables or fake parameters.

Comment: @Deadcode So you took my answer and my TIO tests and reposted them with your -1 byte golf? T_T

Comment: Sure, isn't that standard practice? I like it when people do that with my TIO code. Anyway, my final version is just using your idea of showing ✓ and ✕. Where the ✓ ✕ is shown, and the TIO code itself, is actually completely different now.

Comment: Also, I came up with `f(n,a){a=n&-n;}` before you posted your gcc answer, but I didn't post it because I hated the fake parameter hack. It made the `return` avoidance hack seem even more ugly to me.

Comment: @Deadcode If you have a completely new way of solving the challenge then fair enough this is, after all, a competition. But simple tweaks are usually given to the original poster out of basic good manners and decency. What you came up with before anyone posted an answer is immaterial.

Comment: Yes, and if it were a simple tweak I would have given it to you as a comment. I've done that often. But I feel that what I came up with was something novel and open for general use in many challenges, and I wanted to give a detailed explanation for it. Would you have give an in-depth an analysis of it in your answer if I'd given it to you as a comment?

Comment: @Deadcode Fair enough then. Maybe if your comment here focused on that rather than looking a a golf suggestion would have made things clearer.

Comment: Oops! You're quite right, and now I understand why you reacted how you did. I should've said something like "I found a way to get -1 byte without a global value or fake parameter, and felt it was worth posting my own answer:"

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes (recursive approach)

```julia
!n=n%2>0||2*!(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPNk/VyM6gpsZIS1EjT99I839BUWZeSU6enoahlaGBgYKerZ2CniKEo6n5HwA)

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 7 bytes (bitwise approach)

```julia
n->n&-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/T9cuT003739BUWZeSU6enoahlaGBgYKerZ1CGpSjqfkfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 bytes

```perl
sub($n){$n&-$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY9BDoIwEEX3nGKCE2gDJKJIjNjoBTyBusCkNY2mJS2sCFe3Im5wwYKFmz8vM/PnZypunhuHgjnb3Agq2qIKElSdK7xjCQxIGsMqhl6zQb@8HfG4n@YTgynDejXTMDshz/6d8PsDLTxPaAMEJVsWgHKPi/JTo4hC60FlpKpJgKJfgAhSCowBlmeUVzhAqB8h7CDkxmgTxv5F@f3Bzr10VUutrEtOgpd1Y3hk5V0NZN8)

dingledooper's Python solution, translated to Perl 5

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

`U` is the first input, same bitwise approach as many other answers already covered.

```js
&-U
```

[Try it out here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Ji1V&input=MjA=)

Comment: `&n` for 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 72 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
	X =1
I	J =N / X
	X =X * 2	EQ(REMDR(J,2))	:S(I)
	OUTPUT =X
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hIszQsHWkMuT00vB1k9BXyECLBChoKVgxOkaqBHk6usSpOGlY6SpyWkVrOGpycXpHxoC1AdUw@Xq5/L/v6ERAA)

```
	N =INPUT				;* read input
	X =1					;* set X =1
I	J =N / X				;* set J to N / X
	X =X * 2	EQ(REMDR(J,2))	:S(I)	;* If J is divisible by 2, double X and goto I, else
	OUTPUT =X				;* print X and exit
END
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>56</s> <s>50</s> 46 bytes

- Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Bubbler!
- Saved 4 bytes thanks to @chunes!

```
[ 2 over [0,b] n^v [ 2 * mod 0 > ] with find ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY07C8IwGEV3f8WdRULq@wGu4uIiTqVCbL9o0H6paVoR8bfHVLpcOGc4V6vcWxdOx/1ht8adHNMDlSPv35Uz7FHTsyHOqUap/O0/wim@9kLohnNvLPfYUtersRl8kGCMCaaYYY4FllghkfgipNHblhxSObpk4HOLTg1R2gISW2R4mfilDRfIQgxXEOEH)

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 53 bytes

```
[ 0.5 [ [ 2 / ] [ 2 * ] bi* over dup floor = ] loop ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYixCgIxEAV7v@LVV0QRtFCsxcbmsDquiHGDwZiNm43g18dwDLx5jLdOWdptvFzPB7xIEkVkIdVflpAUhT6VkqOCt9XnMsbX5DRwKjiu9m3CxuwwdbZYY148dN/DAP6S4FEzfGQWnHruJ2NucDZGmPYH)

Comment: I don't think this is valid as it outputs errors to STDOUT, and therefore doesn't give valid output.

Comment: Both `math.functions` and `math.ranges` are available by default. `2^` is a shorthand for `2 swap ^`.

Comment: @Makonede It is just a problem with the TIO environment, and stray output on STDOUT is not a problem since it is a function submission (everything is OK as long as the result is returned on the top of the stack).

Comment: @Bubbler OK then... I don't know Factor so I'll take your word for it xD

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI The second one is not valid as-is. (Did you forget to move `6` and `call .` to header/footer?) Also, to suppress the `Quotation's stack effect does not match call site` error at the end of the program, you can put `clear` at the end of the footer.

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks, I didn’t know about 2%, and I’ll make sure to use the auto use script next time. I need to fix the second one, but I’ll do it tomorrow when I’m on my laptop

Comment: `2 over [0,b] n^v` is shorter than `dup [0,b] [ 2^ ] map`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 14 bytes

```
[ dup 2^ gcd ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hci9CsIwFAbQ3af43GOhP0hVcBWXLuIkCiG91dL2Nt7cDCI@exSXM5zOOp0lnU/H5rDFQMI0wgupvrz0rAj0jMSOAiarjz9ZF9lpP3PAbvFGXmBdYVOixgdLrPaozG8McoM6XdBGj@KGu2txTZP1yOBGspK@)

[J42161217's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220573/78410) and [xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220539/78410) approach: GCD with a large power of 2.

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 18 bytes

```
[ dup neg bitand ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcixCsIwEAbg3af43WOhWqQquEoXF3ESh5heNdhe08tlEPHZo7h8w9dZp6Pk86k5HrZ4kjD1CEKqryCeFZGmROwoYrD6@FN0iZ36kSN2szfKJdYVNivU@GCOxR6V@Y1BaVDnC9oUwHTHzavlFtc82IACricr@Qs)

Bitwise approach already done by many different answers.

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 18 bytes

```
[ factor-2s . 2^ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xC8IwFAZ3f8XnnhYai1SFruLiIk6iEMILFtvX@PI6iPjbY@lyHLdccF5HydfL6Xzc40XC1CMKqX6idKxI9J6IPSUMTp8LyjCx127khMPqi8piW2O3QYMf1iha1GYuBpVBk28Iy6KwCSXsA/c8uDir78lJ/gM)

There's a built-in that is supposed to do most of the job: `factor-2s`, which takes a positive integer `n` and returns `[ exponent-of-2 odd-part ]` on the stack. Unfortunately the power of 2 is the secondary return value (so you need to discard the top with `.`) and it is the exponent (not the power of 2 itself) so `2^` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>29</s> 24 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @TaylorScott*

A port of [Dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220527/101349) to Excel.

```
=BITAND(2^47+A1,2^47-A1)
```

### Original much worse answers, 29 bytes

```
[A2]=2^47+A1*{1;-1}
[A4]=BITAND(A2,A3)
```

Had to use 2 cells because `BITAND` requires 2 arguments.  The formula in A2 spills to A3. Works up to 2^47 - 1.  Can save a byte changing 2^47 to 8^9.  This lowers the range to 2^27-1.

### Excel (one cell), 35 bytes

```
=2^SUM(1*(MOD(A1,2^(ROW(1:47)))=0))
```

This is what I came up with on my own.  Works up to 2^41.

[Try them online](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJm32SpsepsFNWTPjw?e=ai5tmg)

Comment: Why not `=BitAnd(2^47+A1,2^47-A1)`?

Comment: That is a good point.  I guess sometimes you just get stuck on a train of thought.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 43 bytes

```scala
n=>Stream.iterate(1)(_*2).find(n%_>0).get/2
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d5Bu24wuSeCvmvdyIJqN8g)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
o¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX/fHZ5w5A/4oCm4oaSw7Auw7g//2/Cv/8s/zEyCjY0CjkzCjg)

```
o¿  # full program
 ¿  # greatest common divisor of...
    # implicit input...
 ¿  # and...
o   # 2 to the power of...
    # implicit input
    # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes

N<sup>th</sup> Term

```apl
{2*(⊥⍨~)2⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵}
 2* ⍝ exponentiation
   ⊥⍨~ ⍝ number of trailing zeros
      2⊥⍣¯1⊢ ⍝ bit vector conversion
            ⍵ ⍝ argument
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqIy2NR11LH/WuqNM0AjMWH1pv@Khr0aPerbVAJQqGRlxpCmYmQMLSGEhYALEBAA)

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

First N Terms

```apl
{2*(⊥⍨~)∘(2⊥⍣¯1⊢)¨⍳⍵}
 2* ⍝ exponentiation
   ⊥⍨~ ⍝ number of trailing zeros
      ∘ ⍝ curry
       2⊥⍣¯1⊢ ⍝ bit vector conversion
             ¨ ⍝ each
              ⍳⍵ ⍝ range of 1–n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqIy2NR11LH/WuqNN81DFDwwjMWXxoveGjrkWah1Y86t38qHdrLVCxgqERV5qCmQmQsDQGEhZAbAAA)

Comment: This is 16 bytes, not 14.

Comment: And your second one is 21…

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that the enclosing brackets or parentheses didn't count towards the total. Genuinely wasn't trying to pull a fast one on anyone. Guess I'm going to have to update all of my other answers as well.

Comment: @Makonede Thanks for pointing that out, no one had mentioned it on my other answers.

Comment: No problem. [filler]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
Đ~∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIS6Rx3L//83NgIA)

Port of dingledooper's Python solution

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes

```
DnA&
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLXPIc1SBMqMiCRZZmEBYA) or [verify the first 100 terms](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wXJDBUMDQ6vqpaUlaboWS1zyHNUgzEVR3hDG0milFKXYBRAOAA)

Uses [dingledooper's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220527/114446).

```python
DnA&  # Implicit input
Dn    # Duplicate and negate top copy
  A&  # Bitwise AND of the two numbers
      # Implicit output
```

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
ZhAJ2@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLojIcvYwcIByo2IJFlmYQFgA) or [verify the first 100 terms](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wXJDBUMDQ6vqpaUlaboWy6IyHL2MHCCcJYZ1Ud4Q5tJopRSl2AUQDgA)

Inspired by [ovs's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220520/largest-power-of-2-that-divides-n?page=1&tab=scoredesc#comment513432_220526).

```python
ZhAJ2@  # Implicit input
Zh      # Prime factor exponents of the input
  AJ    # First element (i.e. the exponent of 2)
    2@  # 2 ** that
        # Implicit output
```