# Count the trailing zeros

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

Given two positive integers \$n\$ and \$b\$, such that \$n > 2\$ and \$n > b > 1\$, count the trailing zeros when converting \$n\$ to base \$b\$. Your program should be able to handle any value of \$b\$ within your integer maximum.

The digits of \$n =  18\$, \$b =  3\$ are \$[2,0,0]\$, so the correct output is \$2\$.
The digits of \$n = 107\$, \$b = 43\$ are \$[2, 42]\$, so the correct output is \$0\$

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
  n   b  out
512   2   9
248   2   3
364 265   0
764   2   2
336 284   0
517 422   0
554  37   0
972   3   5
 12   6   1
 72   2   3
 44   2   2
 51  16   0
 32   2   5
 56   7   1
 60   2   2
  8   3   0
 18   3   2
107  43   0
```

---

<sub>Credit to [Anush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98590/anush) for the [inspiration](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57752871#57752871)</sub>

<sup>There is a one byte answer in Jelly. Can you find it?</sup>

Comment: This is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71833/how-even-is-a-number) but extended to any number.

Answer (score 11):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
Ǒ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%91&inputs=2%0A512&header=&footer=)

*laughs in stolen jelly built-ins*

Comment: [6 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C3%B7%CF%84%E2%80%A0%E1%B9%980%E1%B8%9F&inputs=%5B972%2C3%5D&header=&footer=) with no builtin

Answer (score 10):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
{*&|y\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU@7DsIwDNzzFTfxkkCNHScF/woTQxmQygISCPj2YqelDE7O1t35fNn2534YusNrs3g/j4/P0GG3XEkkkFJq7eWcQFm0@K/MGdQmlViQiFQkgYvuC4HVVFmLS5NzJSJmZe8lo2huDLXOq09jDrwegB7ACbjeb8EXA1774OtHzGEKYbgJHmScU5ji1PkUacQWy3JV7NmssZKA6p@tYkCh2R/p7wnLbcGrFvzjmFZ8Vkat3TLz0U7@xo8/TMEPtAt9/gU)

- `|y\x` convert `x` to base `y`, reversing the resulting digits
- `&` use [monadic where](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/docs/Manual.md#where), e.g. convert `0 0 2` into `2 2`
- `*` return the first value

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

Returns `False` for `0`.

```python
f=lambda n,b:n%b<1and-~f(n/b,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNbsIwEITv@xRzQUqkQOP1X0DNs1S2KCJSMBYEoV766uniQDmM9tPszOSf6XhOPM@HfgynuA9ITdylVfxUIe3Xv4cqfcQm1vP9OIzfUDuSAGKD823K6HEKuRrS1OAS7l9DyrepqjfXPA5ya0K@yBMyIp0afV9qs1UM4KEtsemerEk7A3ZWuCUvvPhMWjtwZ4pvlYdhXtiKp33hrS8bIkso@06kCJ7/92Hem7BK3q50oV8Z6dqH55eua995dM99yasXM6lWsqb4fw)

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, 1 byte

```
ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7t7///@bm5n8NwIA)

Don't know Jelly

Comment: "Don't know Jelly" - how you find it, then ??!!?!?

Comment: @Programmer I'm halfway through making my own golfing language, so I know a bit about the syntax and I managed to pick up what this operator does from other answers :p

Answer (score 8):

## .NET Regex, 35 bytes

```
\G(?=1+,1(1+))(?=(1\1)+,)(?<-2>\1)+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw5DkIxEEP7OQdICRmkP3uQWEou8QuQoKChQNw/TGjsZ8n25/l9ve9jW27ro8FmN9ZruZyoIRVqtSYXWqk2TDzu@Tx5DCNGBtaeKq7IbhDTQcSRu4JRoDKDmaIEHIJRIFcOMac6u0ZIDjKzOQb4ktRn7y9LPsgP) Test suite written using Retina. Takes `n,b` as input in unary as strings of `1`s and outputs the result as the number of successful matches. Explanation:

```
\G
```

Each match must begin at the end of the previous match (with the first match beginning at the start of the string).

```
(?=1+,1(1+))
```

Look ahead to find `b` and capture `b-1` as `\1`.

```
(?=(1\1)+,)
```

Ensure that `1\1`, i.e. `b`, divides `n`.

```
(?<-2>\1)+
```

Subtract `b-1` times the quotient, leaving the quotient, i.e. `n/b`. This value is then the input to the next match.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](http://python.org), <s>83</s> <s>78</s> <s>57</s> <s>47</s> 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,b:1+f(n/b,b)if n>n%b<=0else 0
```

*Finally figured out how to use a lambda to solve this*

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Instead of converting to a string, I'd suggest using a counter so you don't need `len`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 22 bytes

*-3 thanks to @user*

```javascript
d=>g=x=>x%d?0:g(x/d)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/xdYu3bbC1q5CNcXewCpdo0I/RVPb8H9BUWZeiUaahpGmhrmZiabmfwA)

Comment: [Save 3 bytes with currying](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/xdYu3bbC1q5CNcXewCpdo0I/RVPb8H9BUWZeiUaahpGmhrmZiabmfwA) (`d=>g=x=>x%d?0:g(x/d)+1`)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
_YAPf1)q
```

Inputs are in reverse order.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz7SMSDNULPw/39jLkMjYyNDAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HYs7DoNADET7uQkd/i9lpByAgiZVkiZVKJC4/zKLLD@NR8/79/z3T3@/HutPpqM/t64IUXC8QTNg6bxqsDnMEq7DKVghghWWUiTurxpwhyQVRmOFSKacaTauNDg51wU).

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `n = 12321`, `b = 3` as an example.

```
_    % Implicit input: b. Negate
     % STACK: -3
YA   % Implicit input: n. Convert n to specified base. A negative base -b is
     % interpreted as digits 0,1,...,b-1, and b can be arbitrarily large.
     % (A positive base b is interpreted as chars '0','1',...,'9','A','B',...,
     % and then b cannot exceed 36)
     % STACK: [1 2 1 2 2 0 1 0 0]
P    % Flip
     % STACK: [0 0 1 0 2 2 1 2 1]
f    % Find: indices of non-zeros
     % STACK: [3 5 6 7 8 9]
1)   % First entry
     % STACK: 3
q    % Subtract 1. Implicit display
     % STACK: 2
```

Comment: You can count the number of times \$b\$ appears in the prime factorization (including multiplicities) of \$n\$. Would that save bytes?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks. I'm using a different approach because that one seemed longer, but I'm not sure. Maybe someone else can try it :-)

Answer (score 6):

## MMIX, 28 bytes (7 instrs)

```
35020001 F7010000
1E000001 E7020001
FE030006 5303FFFD
F8030000
```

## Explanation

```
    NEG  $2,0,1     // set $2 to -1
    PUT  rD,0       // clear hidiv register
lop DIVU $0,$0,$1   // set $0 to $0/$1 and rR to $0%$1
    INCL $2,1       // increment $2
    GET  $3,rR      // $3 = rR
    PBZ  $3,lop     // if $3, jump back to loop
    POP  3,0        // return three registers; $2 goes into lowest slot!
```

The only tricks I used were to start the register at -1 to simplify the logic,
and to use the properties of `POP` to shift the register while returning.
The MMIX register shuffle is useful when golfing.

(It's possible to shave an extra tetra by using `DIV` instead of `DIVU` and omitting the `PUT`, but this changes the semantics to be signed instead of unsigned. For completeness, this leads to the following machine code.)

```
35020001 1C000001 E7020001
FE030006 5303FFFD F8030000
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 22 bytes

```
{($^n,*/$^x.../\./)-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchNDoIwEAbQq3whjVGDbZjOtBihJzEQF3blX2ADQc5eU9y9vM99eLj0nLGLaNOyV92rPBrVTVprc9XmcKI1jbcZherRBiwRX9WvBeJ7QCMVgUKJhrj@wzoGOcn0mdtZB6o5UyoPpm1FGNZnnT3Bhkv6AQ)

`$^n, * / $^x ... /\./` is a sequence starting with `$^n` (the first argument to the function), where each term is obtained by dividing the previous one by `$^x` (the second argument to the function), and ending when a term matches the regex `/\./` (ie, a period).  Subtracting 2 from this sequence treats it as a number equal to its length.

Answer (score 5):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 8 bytes

```
0+02?}?0?+1*?:0
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwKzAyP30_MD8rMSo_OjAiLCJbMTgsM10iLDBd)

### Explanation

```
0        0
+      +
0        0
2    prepend to
?        first input
}      base convert
?        second input
0  reduce
?        accumulator
+      +
1        1
*    ×
?        item
:      =
0        0
```

This problem translates really nicely to a Risky program. I had to add only two filler characters to make the tree symmetrical.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>38</s> 27 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

```c
f(n,b){n=n%b?0:1+f(n/b,b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbboMwDH3vV1hIlaBNVSBc2jG2h2lfsaKpSUOHtqUVQRpaxa@POQmgdhpyHOf4@DgX@OrIed@XriTMu8hcztmjfxcsEVgzhLKur2QDn/tKut7sMgP8NNAI1bzKlwJyuMRBSCCMNgRoEhFItaM0IRAHKboYl9sUKZqm5yjSKeRgHCMt8QlgcaCHn3bZbRNmm@gWaEls5w1qRCFGFFtQ1LAwKtgoNZ4ai@iVpmjPgjfiYFW3huAbsj8atggMHl4tw4k2iPG3fb1AL/i7qFENtJ6za5/DXbt9whE7BK7X1Bkqy1MNrt5LJQ@ixTI/G8J7UNW3OJXuuEtvPQCLCclguTRsD@xzjCeTqDQ8i8kX2U2ajWn2b1ph2v4Ft7hAfLqzv4XnGiml68zpAfRYPcAcI7WTeHZJgBFQZLojkeeqGOS7Wdf/8PJjf1T96usX)

Comment: Recursion here pays well [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbboMwDH3vV1hIlaBNVSBc2jG2h2lfsaKpSUOHtqUVQRpaxa@POQmgdhpyHOf4@DgX@OrIed@XriTMu8hcztmjfxcsEVgzhLKur2QDn/tKut7sMgP8NNAI1bzKlwJyuMRBSCCMNgRoEhFItaM0IRAHKboYl9sUKZqm5yjSKeRgHCMt8QlgcaCHn3bZbRNmm@gWaEls5w1qRCFGFFtQ1LAwKtgoNZ4ai@iVpmjPgjfiYFW3huAbsj8atggMHl4tw4k2iPG3fb1AL/i7qFENtJ6za5/DXbt9whE7BK7X1Bkqy1MNrt5LJQ@ixTI/G8J7UNW3OJXuuEtvPQCLCclguTRsD@xzjCeTqDQ8i8kX2U2ajWn2b1ph2v4Ft7hAfLqzv4XnGiml68zpAfRYPcAcI7WTeHZJgBFQZLojkeeqGOS7Wdf/8PJjf1T96usX "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AZTECCO strikes again!! Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>16</sup> 12 bytes

```
[:#.~0=#.inv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8rDwIxEIQ9v2LDiQsJNH1ue02qSFAoLJJwgRPgkPz10mfaQ1TMt9OZ3cVvyTiDszDCHijY8A4EjpfzyV/tQL7UDeT5@vjd5n57vIHDDIrxLCZwayAK4NJkQCNAFZBAWROyR1eQPEZGj8CGJM/RuiGhI1Hln4okgEmXdhYABvC/TZ3XZtkVM0wlLTEaRBeYKnEdgLTbKWjTxlGy7niZANX@Bw)

<sup>-4 thanks to xash!</sup>

- `#.inv` Convert to list of base digits
- `0=` Converts zeroes to ones, everything else to 0.
- `[:#.~` Use that number as a mixed base to convert itself to a number -- effectively zeroes out everything to the left of the rightmost 0, summing all the ones (that were originally trailing zeroes).

Comment: 12b: [`[:#.~0=#.inv`](https://tio.run/##XY87C8IwFIX3/oqLHYqiIa8maaSLgpM4uHYQlBZ10EERRPCv1zwakjpkuN85Oefeaz9BRQe1hgLmgEGbt0Cw3m83faNz9MV1ji63Vz/NdisERMHx/WwfGg7kY/QlOpBGz5wla0/nO1DooCTUDxXUY8AGQLnyAFsgSoOY4CHBe2QAzqO49TAREac@WkbEpCXl8K@0xIBKDu3EAGHA/zZBD808KSbClcREa2BJoKsU4wCBk53MrKJsR5Iczx3Asv8B)

Comment: That's a fantastic trick.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 9 bytes

```
valuation
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddDBCsMgDAbg@56khQxMNNEe@jCehjA6Kd1e37kKPcx49eM3f5Ljnu6PXMonPt/xSK@tlLyn7Ziuh4mRgOZ1XebbP5ELJ9merDgg4YqmR//DSqTkrAAFp@cYPTiiAbID63VbPIGtxD3V7aQKKi1ptJwb1mcEFL2Dbd8pFVjA6xXEjAaFcx9lDDZRImjq9VrqCw)

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##Zc9BCsMgEAXQfU@SwBSccWY0Cw@TTYpQ0hDSXt@aSImm28f3z3cZ13h/LGkK6TM@3@MWX3NKyxrnrZs6QQLqQxj624@I/UH2JKsMpJLRnOh2zERVziqQ5zYn6ICJLigM1rU2OAKbSU7K6zQLVlfpOo7/ZggCattty7OqWhRcW63mWuSPPVUNFqkiaPLvSuoL) is an equally valid answer.

Comment: I don't know how the rules work for inbuilt functions. Wouldn't it have to be at least "valuation(n,b)"?

Comment: `valuation` works as a function submission because it is the name of a function which can be called with two arguments, it is reusable (can be called multiple times), and it is reassignable (can be assigned to a new name, as in `f=valuation`). On the other hand, `valuation(n,b)` is *not* a valid submission under our rules because it is a snippet (assumes predefined variables `n` and `b`).

Comment: Well, that shrunk it *a lot*. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
IntegerExponent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY09C8IwFEX3/IpAwSlC8x0HpYuDm@AoDqGk2qFRSgYhpH89Jo/W7XDfvedNNrzcZMPY2zwc88UH93Tz@ft5e@dDvs6jD/dmfxq6rnnslltv/RJRlJQRzBJBkQmzEleikJKVNTCkXBUyorKkmmDBIJeyNLiueNBFxitVq4L9phebR1KCKdw43EpSxLBX7doxm@YPbX3IE0r5Bw)

Built-in.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
ＩＬ⊟⪪⭆↨ＮＮ¬ι0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyc1L70kQyMgv0AjuCAns0QjuAQome6bWKDhlFicquGZV1Ba4leam5RapKGpo4DCBfL98ks0MkEMJQMlTRCw/v/f0tyIy/i/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
      Ｎ     Input `n`
     ↨      Converted to base
       Ｎ    Input `b`
    ⭆       Map over elements and join
         ι  Current element
        ¬   Logical Not
   ⪪      0 Split string on literal `0`
  ⊟         Take the last string of `1`s
 Ｌ          Take the length
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+%`^(1+),(\1)+$
¶$1,$#2$*
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtLDsIwDET3vgaplBIv6k/scAIuUaEiwYINC8TZeoBeLDgs5mksv/k8v6/3vU/5uvX1USCdoUzbLVOZMa80lwTHngjTieN17L0zVmJgZG3AVlFM4/LBpihioDwcB3GsVUHw4gyG/5UPqAJZKFGFISyLZkuYLUINNLj4Dw) Link includes test cases. Takes input in order `b,n`. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert `b` and `n` to unary.

```
+%`^(1+),(\1)+$
¶$1,$#2$*
```

Repeatedly divide `n` by `b`.

```
¶
```

Count the number of divisions.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
ḃ₎,0a₁=kl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc07CgIxEIDhq4StI@Q1yVqoBwkpVgsFFwSbRWQLIwg24lFsBPE2yUViMmzsPmYmf9bHbrM79YetSOehIbMlaYZVvL2i9@F7H8P7mcLnGv2Dsi76y2Lfp2QtcEGJcJRYodpJUqssDcUGjVOps1pVDNxQogTOAfKFNIVzk2OyqFQ1vq95VTvAKeG4k3UHuYwBzaZJWzt/sPKjdO4H)

```
  ,0         Append a 0 to
ḃ₎           the digits of n in base b.
    a₁       Find the largest suffix
      =      all elements of which are equal,
       k     remove its last element,
        l    and output its length.
```

The shorter `ḃ₎a₁≡ᵛ⁰l` cannot handle cases with no trailing zeroes, since `a₁` cannot generate an empty suffix of a non-empty list, and if it could `≡ᵛ⁰` would fail on it anyhow.

Without utilizing base conversion:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
⟨{f↔∋~^}h⟩t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/9H8FdVpj9qmPOrorourzXg0f2XJ///R0aaGRjoKRrE6CtFGJhZQlrGZCZBlZgpim4PZYFFjMyDLwgTENjU011EwMQKLm5oCVRibg5iW5kDDjEEskKlmYP0w401g5pga6igYguWMYXKmQJPBBpgZQEUsYObAGQYgG41jYwE)

```
    ∋          An element
  f            of the list of factors
⟨{     } ⟩     of n
   ↔           in descending order
     ~^ h t    is b raised to the power of the output.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
f=function(n,b)`if`(n%%b,0,1+f(n/b,b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdFdC4IwFAbg@37FgRCUBrlvvfC3@BFag5pgRtSft9kodrPNq8F4eM/Ou2m5jM/61upXPU@tuip9rt/9NPb3ahmq4aFPsxp1qlGXNWpoUp0kHcoRPgypPnbmNvMGpBwTBAAkg705yp0XElY4kPohFQwBEdzC3A/lCv@JJJBIhUksWDSRY4mAERKHfB1NZRSW8lsPtZD7IdgehYU4ACXZ1iOwjfUAxwZiEV0GqDs6tAwXK5TxZUS@8Y1QOD2G3ohdGEjEuflrYL/E5QM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 48 bytes

```
f: func[n b][either(n % b)> 0[0][1 + f n / b b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDNCoMwEITvPsVcCi09qPm1PfQheg05@JOgUFIR@/x2jWLMIXw7zM7CTK5b3q4zNlv8E/4XWhPQWOOGuXfTNeCC5vZCYQprStzhEZCjIYtd/HdyddsjbsBkoCdLRj@LzER1MFcCTMnImvjQuQKrxL6rIdimS0keriM/9JrJIyPmq411ugWRMimIfLuHnzxSrUsbqyLpqE75ictCUy7PrBmnIcwwY93lH@dn6oDjGJrzsPZDArXzBw)

Comment: Do you have to include the `f:` in the answer As it's a recursive function?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oh yes, definitely! It's  not that often that I submit recursive functions in Red :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```
n*b=n%b<1&&1+n/b*b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDNbsIwEITv@xRzKYIU0Xj9F6zmSSIfMOUAQqEiQaJPn24cSCytdjye/aT15XE9H9RzGNoi1e1H@larlfpsv1KRhv7U9R1qNGQVAxhrT2yql9aknQE7K7okL3rymbR24Mpk3yoPwzxpK572We99ZkhZQuY7KUXwPPNhFiaskmeXZ6HfGZm1o@enWVcueVQvvuTVWzOpUrJm8iPR7dHLinnVJmxVxK6YbyzvP@fu93r4WzcUWplBSMhtLR@2QTje7vfTsacZEDhiZMoZ265e4DpS3Az/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ìV Ôð
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=7FYg1PA&input=MzY0CjI2NQ)

```
ìV Ôð     :Implicit input of integers U=n & V=b
ìV        :Convert U to a base-V digit array
   Ô      :Reverse
    ð     :0-based indices of truthy (non-zero) elements
          :Implicit output of first element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html), 45 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(n b)(if(=(% n b)0)(+(f(/ n b)b)1)0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/NCsJADITvPkUuQhYRd7N/LcWHsdqFghax@vxrWihNYXtL8jGTme51u4/nZz@@c8ZHl34DJBygVdgnvOIRplkrPGHCy7y0yvBBZXx/@uELmMAbAgBSCpqGh/qwInKVRFYgGxxQ8AvSAkVGQkVSZQNQ5UoqbyI4oiLybGhjCdVxCm8X5AWCuVdYkJEo0l4vcLvhOSLbhFIMsBvDTQwf@BKLMYLe/QWV7LX5ZTZIqoyOXGBV5T8)

It seems that recursive functions doesn't work for Emacs Lisp on TIO.

Answer (score 3):

## [Hy](http://hylang.org/), 40 bytes

```
(defn f[n b](if(% n b)0(+(f(/ n b)b)1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@9CsJAEIR7n2IaYQ8L7/b@EvIoYhP00CaI2Pj0cQ2E7MGlG/ZjZmce33mm271MKJcJ45WehY4QZSydqNB50aNxxpiZXu/n9AEVRMcA2BgMg4j@sCEOnUZeIZ8COMUVWYWyIOVi7fIJ3IWWK7qMwNxEUQJ9bqE@/8v7FUWFsOxKK3IaZd7bhbBbXipKTGrVgK8CqxoxySU3ayS7@wud3lX9chXSLmezDNhc8w8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
a?b|a`mod`b>0=0|c<-a`div`b=1+c?b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LbsIwEEV/xWKVyINqj19BwvADdNUlQsQOlUAlgAotm/x7OuOCxO7c4@s7@3T9@jwexzEt85Da/rxr80JFNXTzaWp3h982Ry27ZR77dDiJKPp0ed@Ky8/t4/a9Oon1dX@@iyTlREykLCFziItnrmi5ZvX2ImLs6qFKkKGr59N15TQCwqyGCm1DZIiMt4DegSIOzIBsjQdsbLFOB7CI/@wsmFBwFmgAHBGtetD8Hx@j9rnjNGhf6obfuO08hNL26lFqaIcrmoGFVnSR3WYz/gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 64 bytes

```
c=[0...log_bn]
a=n/b^c
f(n,b)=max(c\left\{a=ceil(a):1,0\right\})
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nuosdv9lpq)

[Try It On Desmos(Prettified)!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lpza3i1nai)

Function to test on: \$f(n,b)\$

It seems like it only works if you copy/paste one expression at a time, instead of copy/pasting it all at once.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,b{n%b>0?0:1+f[n/b,b]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzdasJAEIXv5ynmpqIYk93Zv2hdfQ3BirjRgGC3Ulvw99nTcaP14sDHN2fO9284NU3tB5OYhUt8CxMxFSPZr@exCFlY3JrKj8czMJIQ8Z4hkC4frEBZjWQNswDH3HoCpSxSqZM30qEmatmwUy7x0KUNjgFM@5YjAR3976N@baKRfLbpF9Wzw7/m7lz7a8Wrj@Vjn/vyyQRScFe3fgZQ5btt3Bwu1931mJ2ys6/yQ7WK3eJj3S96@edq3@2Mfr6W2977Hus5dxben2/NHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 29 bytes

```cs
f=(n,b)=>n=n%b>0?0:1+f(n/b,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBNa4NAEIbv/opBWlDcpKvrR740h0ChkHsOaSisbFohjGDsSfLb7btqQomsM7vPvvMctrzOymvVv/9yuam4FXQvRX/OPRbazwvO@VUXcitXYXD2@E2D9msHoeOJ@OtSUU5dEkaConghSKWxoMwWpVJBSZihJDguM0RszPY4tlfIYJ8glkpBGA7tL7PbXa8nvZVjpcnYF5iOI@wU5ArTI8bsuMuGqoYVq4fNTLblcCGHkLwvqMOBR/@O0SMGiXOuG/KgImuRa7TN8ADzveHv9gcgCHxyOofw2RwjZwPH6rR@QA2on6EBNM@wAcSLC9L@CHc1X@uLmR@aqjX7io334nZ8@2w7jTIrqGvQXQrIwyyMtCV3VzeNKUFX5H5wOZ18KG/9Hw)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Normally, it's fine to not count the `f=` but for functions. However, as you refer to the name of the function in the function, you should include the `f=` in your byte count, as it's a required part of the definition

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ofc! I added it, hope it's all correct now.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 52 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(LOG(A2,B2)),MAX(x*(MOD(A2,B2^x)=0)))
```

My first attempt below with built-ins was limited because `BASE` only works up to 36.  As a bonus the second attempt was shorter.  Goes to show, built-ins aren't always the answer.

### Initial Attempt, 70 bytes

```
=LET(x,BASE(A2,B2),q,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),MAX(q*(RIGHT(x,q)=REPT("0",q))))
```

### Using LAMBDA from Insider Beta, 41 bytes

```
=LAMBDA(n,b,IF(MOD(n,b)=0,f(n/b,b)+1,0))
```

The above is 40 bytes plus 1 byte to set it equal to f in the Name Manager.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
вRĀ1k
```

First input is base \$b\$, second input is \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//wqagIw2G2f//G3GZGhoBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXC/wubgo40GGb/1/kfHW1qaKRjFKsTbWRiAaaNzUx0jMxMgSxzEAskYmymY2RhAmSZGprrmBiBxExNTXSMzYEMS3MjHWMgDTTFDKQHYpgJRKepoY4hSNQYImpqpgPSYmYA5llA9EEpA6DJxrGxAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
в      # Convert the (implicit) input `n` to the (implicit) input-base `b` as list
 R     # Reverse this list
  Ā    # Truthify each value (0 remains 0; everything else becomes 1)
   1k  # And get the first (0-based) index of a 1 in this list
       # (after which this index is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
Mtf@_jGHtT;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/37ckzSE@y92jJMT6f7qluZGC8X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 58 bytes

```factor
:: g ( n b -- m ) n b mod 0 > [ 0 ] [ n b / b g 1 + ] if ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDLTsMwELz7K0aVkEAo0PiV0kpcUS@9IE7AwU2cNCK1g@0cys@HdYqEZM@OV7O7421NnXyY3173h5ctTIy@jjibdMKXDc4OGHxthogx2JQuY@hdQu8R7fdkXW3jP3vorLPBDP2PSb13Ea0P1Cj1rkMX/DRmsmP7wxadH9p5SxG3cDiiKHDG3ULPvsEaz3gn/CTMuUe6HUrcU6ZvsZtVycEZlxtCoSW4VqzKkQmhwTeSqbKC5JwpJSEq9lRxCEZVmlW5VGatKlFqJvJbaVRMr4ltsm6BNXUQbAWQB5AD@CmtsGyAhsKZEMwF/Po3csobCh1WN7K5ng/3J2/J97LZwpr6NP8C)

Answer (score 1):

## GAWK, 32 bytes

```
{for(;$1/$2^++e!~/\./;);$0=e-1}1
```

Strangely, does not work on TIO, and also couldn't run it in mawk.

```
{for(;                 starts the loop
      $1/$2^++e        divides n by b^(e), e increasing each time
               !~/\./  continue while this division does not match a dot
                       (i.e, while it's a integer)
    ;);                the semicolon after the for means "run no command while looping"
    $0=e-1             after looping, substitutes the input ($0) for e-1
}1                     shows $0
```

Comment: Is it possible in bash?

Comment: Yes, it is. Run it as `gawk '{for(;$1/$2^++e!~/\./;);$0=e-1}1'`.

Comment: :) that's not quite what I meant

Comment: @Anush Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: I meant an answer fully written in bash that doesn't call other code.