# Activate the auto destruct sequence

Tags: code-golf, animation

`This is a code golf. The smallest amount of bytes wins! :)`

## What you need to do

You're on Deep Space Nine, a Cardassian outpost taken over by the Federation, in the year 2374. The Borg, a superior race, have collapsed your shields and assimilated half of your crew. However, you have important classified information on your hands that you can't let anyone see at all. **Activate the auto-destruct sequence.**

[image: Program Sisko 197 ;)]

#### What you're actually doing

Take as input an integer value, which will set the exact auto destruct time in seconds. Once the user has passed the value, have a countdown ensue. Countdown backwards by one second each and print each number. At the point it reaches zero, make the program crash.

#### Rules

- You may use STDIN, a parameter, or any other standard input format.
- You must put each number on a new line.
- You may or may not have an extra delay of one second at the beginning and end.

I was looking at [Shortest auto-destructive loop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104323/shortest-auto-destructive-loop), so if you want to use something from that, feel free, but this isn't really a duplicate of that. You can also wait one sec at the start, but once again, I'd prefer if you don't do this:

**Note: Everything in parentheses is ignored.**

```
(input is 10)
(wait 1 sec)
10
(1 sec)
9
(1 sec)
8
(1 sec)
(..etc..)
0
(crash)
```

*And you do this*:

```
(input is 10)
10
(1 sec)
9
(1 sec)
8
(1 sec)
(..etc..)
0
(crash)
```

## Examples

If you don't have stdin but you can have a parameter inputted:

```
(grab the number from the parameter)
(once the number is loaded in, 10 in this case, print it like so:)
10
(wait one second)
9
(wait one second)
8
(wait one second)
7
(wait one second)
6
(wait one second)
5
(wait one second)
4
(wait one second)
3
(wait one second) 
2
(wait one second)
1
(wait one second)
0
(either wait one second then crash, or crash instantly)
```

If you have a form of `stdin`:

```
(allow the user to enter a number, there should be no greeting message)
(once the number is entered, 10 in this case, print it like so:)
10
(wait one second)
9
(wait one second)
8
(wait one second)
7
(wait one second)
6
(wait one second)
5
(wait one second)
4
(wait one second)
3
(wait one second) 
2
(wait one second)
1
(wait one second)
0
(either wait one second then crash, or crash instantly)
```

***Have fun!***

Comment: I don't think this is sufficiently different from your air conditioner challenge.

Answer (score 5):

### R, 46 bytes

```
for(i in scan():0){cat(i,"\n");Sys.sleep(i/i)}
```

Crashes after printing `0` because the sleep function is called using `0/0` which returns `NaN` in R:

```
Error in Sys.sleep(time) : invalid 'time' value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
import time
def f(i):print i;time.sleep(i/i);f(i-1)
```

Recursive function that takes in integer then counts down until the integer is 0 at which point it explodes with a DivideByZero exception.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 87 bytes

```
#import<windows.h>
main(i){for(scanf("%d",&i);i--;){printf("%d\n",i);Sleep(1000*i/i);}}
```

Death by division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 67 bytes

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (%1,-1,0)do echo %%i&timeout/t>nul 1
if
```

Note: the trailing newline is significant; this causes the command processor to choke on the `if` statement. The odd placement of the `>nul` is to save a byte as `1>nul` would eat the `1` parameter to `timeout/t`.