# Print strings without sharing characters

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, printable-ascii

**Edit: Allowed to reuse whitespaces.**

Your task is to write *n* programs (or functions, or bodies of functions without using parameters or the function names) in the same language. The *k*th program should output the [(cardinal) number *k* in standard English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Cardinal_numbers) in lowercase (with an optional trailing newline). So the first program should output `one`, the second should output `two`, etc. For a number having two parts, they should be separated by a hyphen like `twenty-one`.

But no two programs in your submission can share non-whitespace characters or whitespace characters doing useful works. For example, if your first program is just `"one"`, then none of `"` `o` `n` and `e` can be used again in your other programs.

You can use whitespace characters (spaces, newlines and tabs) in two or more programs, if they only serve as separators or indentation and don't do anything by themselves. So you can't reuse them in the [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace) language, and you can't use them in strings in more than one program.

You can only use printable ASCII characters, tabs, and newlines (including CR and LF). Every program must contain at least 1 character.

Your score is the sum of 1/program size^1.5. Highest score wins. You can use this Stack Snippet ([or this CJam code](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN37c~%3A%2C-1.5f%23%3A%2B&input=)) to calculate your score:

```js
function updatescore(a){var l=a.value.split("\n"),s=0;for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++){var t=l[i].length;t-=t&&l[i][t-1]=="\r";if(t)s+=Math.pow(t,-1.5);}document.getElementById('result').textContent=s;}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" placeholder="Put your code here, one per line." style="width:100%;height:150px;box-sizing:border-box" oninput="updatescore(this)" onpropertychange="updatescore(this)"></textarea><div>Your score: <span id="result">0</span></div>
```

Comment: One better scoring rule may be the sum of 1/(program size+c)^1.5, where c is a constant. But I think it's probably too late to change it.

Comment: Can we add a multiplier for getting to a higher cardinal number, since that seems to be the goal? I got to twelve, higher than all the others, but still am losing.

Comment: @mbomb007 Sorry for deliberately making Headsecks a lower score. But if Headsecks has just similar score to others, I guess Glypho will win too much (not to say Lenguage).

Comment: I want to do this in whitespace :(

Comment: @YoYoYonnY You can but it is likely that Whitespace can only print `one`...

Comment: @jimmy23013 A better scoring rule would be to count by number of programs, then by fewest total bytes. I think you could still change it, as it would encourage new answers.

Comment: @mbomb007 It was intended to discourage Lenguage and Headsecks. While possibly it's not much to change the scoring, I'll probably disqualify at least one answer if I come up with other ways to discourage them. So better not.

Comment: @mbomb007 If I'm asking a similar question again I'll probably add a small constant to the program sizes in the score. But it's too arbitrary to change in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 0.38669200758867045

Remove whitespace from all of these programs but **three**, it's only for *(coughs)* readability. **one** and **six** are gs2 programs that crash (by underflowing the stack), which conveniently [makes them quines](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/blob/aca24d4ed258dfbb6affb895bd51a2ae89afda16/gs2.py#L302).

### one (3 bytes)

```
one
```

### two (1384 bytes)

```
A?"A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0
A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0
A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0
A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0
A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0
A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A?"A"0A"0A"0A"0A
"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A
"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A
"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A
"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A
"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A
"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"00000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000A?"A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"
0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"
0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"
0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"
0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"
0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"0A"
0A"0A"0A"0A"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000
```

### three (92 bytes)

```
0a 21 2c 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21
20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21 20 21
20 21 20 2f 20 0a 21 28 3c 0a 21 2c 21 20 21 20
21 20 21 20 2f 20 0a 21 28 3c 45 21 20 21 20 21
2f 20 0a 21 28 3c 0a 21 2c 21 20 2f 20 0a 21 28
3c 0a 21 2c 21 20 2f 20 0a 21 28 3c
```

Lots of significant whitespace so here's a hex dump. It has a single line feed character at the start:

```
!,! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / 
!(<
!,! ! ! ! / 
!(<E! ! !/ 
!(<
!,! / 
!(<
!,! / 
!(<
```

### four (276 bytes)

```
f$f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$
31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$
31Mf$f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f
$f$31f$f$31Mf$f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31Mf$f$f$31f$f$31f
$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31f$f$31M
```

### five (178 bytes)

```
hd+++&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&Khd+++&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&Khd+++&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&Khd+++&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&K
```

### six (3 bytes)

```
six
```

Comment: I didn't see that requirement -- I'll go through and fix the intermediate solutions.

Comment: I get to use `20` through `7E`, `09` (tab), `0A` (LF), and `0D` (CR), right?

Comment: Yes. Edited to allow CR explicitly.

Comment: The `1` in **five** was a typo; I've gone and removed it. I'll fix **three** now.

Comment: Programs **one** and **six** are essentially syntax errors that dump the source code to STDOUT and show an error on STDERR. [Consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/) seems to be that this is OK (so kudos) but you should mention it in your answer.

Answer (score 13):

## CJam, 0.24075

#### Programs

```
BA1]100cf|
"two"
{hree}`W<7a.-
N)92+_9+_6+_2~+
S(84^I^U$F^X$G^Y$(
's'i'x
```

*Thanks to @user23013 for his suggestion to use `'` for **six**.*

#### Output, length, score, used characters

```
one    10  0.03162          01       AB         ]    c f         |  
two     5  0.08944  "                                     o  tw     
three  13  0.02133        -.     7  <        W     `a e h  r    { } 
four   15  0.01721      )+    2 6  9      N       _                ~
five   18  0.01309   $ (       4  8    FGI SU XY ^                  
six     6  0.06804    '                                  i  s  x
```

Verify the results yourself in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%3AQ%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Read%20the%20input%20and%20split%20at%20finefeeds.%0A%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20For%20each%20line%20of%20input%3A%0A%20%20%20%20_%5B%5B_~%5D%20s7Se%5Do%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20%20%20%20%20Evaluate%20the%20input%20and%20print%20the%20result.%0A%20%20%20%20%2C%20s2Se%5B4Se%5Do%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20%20%20%20%20Print%20the%20code%20length.%0A%20%20%20%20_%2C-1.5%23_%20%22%25.5f%20%20%22e%25o%20e%23%20%20%20%20%20Compute%20and%20print%20the%20score.%0A%20%20%20%20V%2B%3AV%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20%20%20%20%20Compute%20the%20accumlated%20score.%0A%20%20%20%20Qs%24_%26_%40-Ser%20oNo%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20%20%20%20%20Compute%20and%20print%20the%20characters%20used%20by%20this%20program.%0A%7D%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%0A%22valid%22Q%7B_%26%7D%25s__%26%3D*%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Push%20%22valid%22%20if%20all%20characters%20are%20unique%20to%20each%20program%20and%20%22%22%20if%20otherwise.%0ANosBSe%5DoV%22%25.5f%22e%25o%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Print%20a%20linefeed%2C%20the%20string%20and%20the%20accumulated%20score.&input=BA1%5D100cf%7C%0A%22two%22%0A%7Bhree%7D%60W%3C7a.-%0AN)92%2B_9%2B_6%2B_2~%2B%0AS(84%5EI%5EU%24F%5EX%24G%5EY%24(%0A's'i'x).

Answer (score 6):

### [Insomnia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/41868#41868), 0.100688383057110116

Just to get things started. It's very unlikely that this is going to win. Under the current scoring scheme, any language that can print `one` in 5 or less characters has overwhelming advantage.

#### one (8 bytes, 0.04419417382415922)

```
uuyp>~p~
```

#### two (9 bytes, 0.037037037037037035)

```
oeoojdoLj
```

#### three (21 bytes, 0.010391328106475828)

```
*FFFFF
=
=z"
n=nnFzzB
```

#### four (23 bytes, 0.009065844089438033)

```
)HGGGkGGGtGkGk<GGh$HGGt
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Headsecks](https://github.com/TieSoul/Multilang/blob/master/headsecks.py), 0.044623631135793776

**[Generated here](http://ideone.com/N9OzWL)**

This language is a simple BF substitution where the only thing that matters is the character value modulo 8.

Unfortunately, longer programs give a worse score, despite being able to get to **twelve**! (I could get higher if I could use non-printable ASCII, and Unicode.)

#### one

```
##%%%%%%%&##$%&#&%&%%%%%%%%%&
```

#### two

```
--------+--.+++,-..+++.--------.
```

#### three

```
5555555535563334566555555555555633333333336555555555555566
```

#### four

```
==;=====>;<=>>;;;;;;;;;>;;;;;;>===>
```

#### five

```
EECEEEEEFCDEFFCCCFCEFCCCCCCDEFFCCEFCCCDEFF
```

#### six

```
KKMMMMMMMMMNKKLMNKNMMMMMMMMMMNMKMMMNKLMNN
```

#### seven

```
SSUUUUUUUUUVSSTUVSVSSSSSUVSSSTUVVSUUUVSTUVUVSSUVSSSTUVVSSSSSSSSSV
```

#### eight

```
]][]]]]]^[\]^]^[[[[^]]^[^[[[[[[[[[[[[^
```

#### nine

```
cceeeeeeefccdeffeeeeefcccccfeeeeeeeeef
```

#### ten

```
mmmmmmmmkmmnkkklmnnkkkkmnkkklmnnkkkkkkkkkn
```

#### eleven

```
uusuuuuuvstuvuvsssssssvuuuuuuuvsuuuvstuvuvssuvssstuvvsssssssssv
```

#### twelve

```
}}}}}}}}{}}~{{{|}~~{{{~{}~{{{|}~~{{{{{{{~{{{{{{{{{{~{{}~{{{|}~~
```

Comment: You can only use printable ASCII characters, tabs, and newlines.

Comment: @user23013 I did as many as I could, and I got to 12.

Answer (score 2):

### [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 0.19245008972987526

```
one
```

This answer is inspired by @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳'s answer, in which he said

> Under the current scoring scheme, any language that can print `one` in 5 or less characters has overwhelming advantage.

Comment: OK, the scoring algorithm seems to have a loophole. Well played.

Comment: Well, this question is sandboxed so long just to get a better scoring method. And it still didn't work well... This also works in PHP, ASP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, .10062

#### "one"

```
?"one
```

#### "two"

```
PRINT MID$(@two,1,3)
```

[My other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166487/64538) is more interesting, but this one gets a higher score.

An important strategy to get the longest chain is to use MORE characters to save on UNIQUE characters (for example, using `x - -x` in program 2 to save `y + y` for program 3)

The problem with the scoring system is that it scores 2 short programs better than 3 long programs, so there is no reason to save characters for later programs if it makes the current program longer.

Also, it values individual short programs higher than a smaller TOTAL size. If I swap `?` and `PRINT` in my answer I can save 1 character, but my score is HALF as much.

I think it would've been better to base it only on *number* of programs, with total size as a tiebreaker.

Comment: I think both programs are sharing an `o`...