# How high can you count in different languages?

Tags: number, code-challenge, restricted-source, rosetta-stone

Based on [How high can you count?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124362/how-high-can-you-count) let us give an advantage to the polyglot people.

### Challenge:

Your task is to write as many programs / functions / snippets as you can, where each one outputs / prints / returns an integer. The first program must output the integer `1`, the second one `2` and so on.

**You can not reuse any characters between the programs. So, if the first program is simply: `1`, then you may not use the character `1` again in any of the other programs.** Note: It's allowed to use the same character many times in one program.

**You can only use a programming language once.** So every number must be in a different programming language.

#### Scoring:

The winner will be the submission that counts the highest. In case there's a tie, the winner will be the submission that used the fewest number of bytes in total.

#### Rules:

- You can only use a language for one integer - after that you cannot reuse the language
- **Snippets are allowed!**
- To keep it fair, all characters must be encoded using a single byte in same encoding in the languages you choose.
- The output must be in decimal. You may not output it with scientific notation or some other alternative format. Outputting floats is OK, as long as all digits *that are shown* behind the decimal point are `0`. So, `4.000` is accepted. Inaccuracies due to FPA is accepted, as long as it's not shown in the output.
- `ans =`, leading and trailing spaces and newlines etc. are allowed.
- You may disregard STDERR, as long as the correct output is returned to STDOUT
- You may choose to output the integer to STDERR, but only if STDOUT is empty.

Note: Explanations are encouraged!

Comment: I suggest you remove the tag [tag:polyglot] because the code is not being run in multiple languages, but rather each program/snippet is run individually in each language.

Comment: Also, do all the languages have to have the same encoding?

Comment: What if the same character is encoded differently in different languages? E.g. `1` is encoded as 0x65 in language A, and as 0x67 in language B. Can I then use the character `1` in both languages because they map to different bytes?

Comment: @KritixiLithos As far as I know, only the hex bytes matter.

Comment: For future reference, these types of challenges which ask for individual programs in multiple languages are called [tag:rosetta-stone]

Comment: Can we use languages where 0 bytes produces a number?

Answer (score 8):

## GS2, 3var, Alphuck, brainf***, Numberwang, evil, ;#+, Charcoal, Retina, wsf, Jelly, Beeswax, CJam, Fourier, Fireball, M, Pushy, MATL, Brain-Flak, Convex, COW, Mouse-79, Mouse-98, Mouse-2002, Pyke, Neim, JavaScript, Braingolf, Japt, SOGL, score 31

All are encoded as hex bytes in either ASCII or the language's native encoding

```
GS2 - 1: 01 01
3var - 2: 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64
Alphuck - 3: 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65
brainf*** - 4: 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b
Numberwang - 5: 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39
Evil - 6: 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61
;#+ - 7: 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b 3b
Charcoal - 8: b8
wsf - 9: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
Jelly - 10: 85
Beeswax - 11: 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
CJam - 12: 43
Retina - 13: 0a 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 0d 0a 2e
Fourier - 14: 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e
Fireball - 15: 46
M - 16: 96
Pushy - 17: 54 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 7e
MATL - 18: 32 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51
Brain-Flak - 19: 28 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 28 29 29
Convex - 20: 4b
COW - 21: 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f 4d 6f 4f
Mouse-79 - 22: 57
Mouse-98 - 23: 58
Pylons - 24: 34 21
Mouse-2002 - 25: 5a
Pyke - 26: 4e 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68
Neim - 27: f9
JavaScript - 28: 30 78 31 63
Braingolf - 29: 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c
Japt - 30: c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4
SOGL - 31: 41 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49
```

More to come :)

<sub>also if i was allowed to use any language as many times as i want i would be able to get ~200</sub>

Comment: Might be worth showing both the actual characters and the hex bytes, makes it easier to see what characters have already been used.
Also if you haven't already used ASCII `l`, 13 `l`s in Braingolf [will output `12`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/Bxn8/w8A)

Comment: @Mayube Thanks for that braingolf tip :)

Comment: if you find an easier way to make 12 in another language, but struggle with a different number later on, `n+1` `l`s in Braingolf will always output `n`, so for example 43 `l`s will output `42`

Comment: @Mayube I noticed.

Comment: [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md) programs for 31: `41 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49` (`AIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII`) or `27 0e` (`'«`) or `8c b7 52 05 fe 6a` (`∫ΠR⁵‘j`).

Comment: Your Fourier program won't work since printing isn't implicit. You should have `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^o` or `5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 5e 6f`

Comment: @BetaDecay I believe snippets are allowed.

Comment: Oh I see. I never thought you could have snippets in Fourier :D