# First code golf decathlon

Tags: code-challenge, string, ascii-art, array, multiple-holes

#### Tasks

All competitors try to solve the following list of 10 tasks:

[math](/questions/tagged/math)

1. Read a positive integer **n** from input and return the sum of the cubes of the first **n** non-negative integers.

   For input `1`, this should return `0`.
2. Read a positive integer **n** from input and return a truthy value if and only if **n** is a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).
3. Read a non-empty list of **n** integers from input and return their [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).

   If **n** is even, use the lesser of the two middle values.

   For example, the median of `[1 4 3 2]` is `2`.
4. Read an integer (positive, negative or 0), or a string representation in base 10 or unary, from input and return its digits in [negabinary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negabinary.html), without leading zeroes (with the exception of input 0).

   The output can be formatted in any convenient way (digits, array, string, etc.).

[string](/questions/tagged/string)

5. Return `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`.
6. Check the current date and return `Happy New Year!` if appropriate according to the Gregorian calendar.
7. Pseudo-randomly select 64 unique assigned code points from the Unicode block [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A) (U+3400 – U+4DB5) and return the string of the corresponding characters.

   All possible strings should have the same probability of getting selected.
8. Read two strings of printable ASCII characters from input and return a truthy value if and only if the character of the first string form a subsequence of the second string.

   For example, `abc`, `axbxc` should return truthy and `bac`, `axbxc` should return falsy.

[array-manipulation](/questions/tagged/array-manipulation)

9. Read a multidimensional, rectangular array of integers and an integer **n** from input and return the modified array with all integers multiplied by **n**.

[ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

10. Read a non-negative integer **n** from input and return a chain of **n** train wagons, as shown below.

    Example output for **n = 3**:

    ```
     ______   ______   ______ 
    |      | |      | |      |
     ()--() ~ ()--() ~ ()--()
    ```

    The output may be surrounded by any amount of whitespace as long as it looks like in the example.

#### Clarifications

- **0** is neither positive nor negative.
- Trailing whitespace is always permitted in the output.
- Several pieces of input may be read in any consistent, convenient order.

#### Rules

1. **No answer may solve two different tasks in the same programming language.**<sup>1</sup>
2. For each individual task, standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

   In particular, you can submit programs or functions with the usual [I/O defaults](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447), but cannot take advantage of [these loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061).

   Task 5 is essentially a [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge, so hardcoding the output is not only allowed but expected.
3. Only one answer per user should be posted, containing at most one solution for each of the tasks.

   Please format your answer as in the following example:

   ```
   ## Task 1, Python, 42 bytes

       <code goes here>

   Explanation, I/O, required Python version, etc. go here.

   ---

   ## Task 7, C, 42 bytes

       <code goes here>

   Explanation, I/O, required compiler (flags), etc. go here.
   ```

#### Scoring

1. For every task you solve, you get one point.

   **This means that you don't have to solve *all* tasks to participate.**
2. If your solution for the task **n** is the shortest one in that programming language, you get an additional point.
3. If your solution for the task **n** is the shortest one of all programming languages, you get an additional point.
4. The bonus points will be awarded only once for each task-language combination and each task, respectively.

   As usual, if two solutions have the same byte count, posting time is the tie breaker.

   If somebody outgolfs you later, you lose the bonus point(s) the other answerer earns.
5. You can golf submission, add/remove languages from your answer or swap the languages used for two tasks.

   Any time somebody edits his answer, all answers are rescored.
6. Once you change languages for a task, you forfeit seniority.<sup>2</sup>

The answer with the highest score wins.<sup>3</sup>

#### Per-task leaderboard

```html
<style>body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}</style><script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><link rel=stylesheet href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id=answer-list><table class=answer-list><thead><tr><td>Task<td>Author<td>Language<td>Score<tbody id=answers></table></div><table style=display:none><tbody id=answer-template><tr><td>{{TASK}}<td>{{NAME}}<td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{SIZE}}</table><script>function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),e.has_more?getAnswers():process()}})}function process(){answers.forEach(function(e){var s=e.body_markdown.split("\n").filter(function(e){return"#"==e[0]});s.forEach(function(s){var r=s.match(NUMBER_REG)[0],t=(s.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0],a=s.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1],n=e.owner.display_name;entries.push({task:r,user:n,language:a,size:t})})}),entries.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.task-s.task;return r?r:e.size-s.size});for(var e=0;e<entries.length;e++){var s=jQuery("#answer-template").html();s=s.replace("{{TASK}}",entries[e].task).replace("{{NAME}}",entries[e].user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",entries[e].language).replace("{{SIZE}}",entries[e].size),s=jQuery(s),jQuery("#answers").append(s)}}var QUESTION_ID=52152,ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/,NUMBER_REG=/\d+/,LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*.*?,\s*\[*([^,\]]+)/,entries=[];</script>
```

#### Combined leaderboard (2015-07-30 20:00 UTC)

```
User / Task      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A   TOTAL   Tie breaker (if any)

DLosc            2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2      22
Sp3000           2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2      21
Doorknob         2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2      20
mathmandan       2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2      20   Combined byte count.
MickyT           2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2      19
Alex A.          2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2      18
Jacob            2 2 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 2      13
alephalpha       2 2 2 0 2 2 0 0 2 0      12
Martin Büttner   2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 2      12   Combined byte count.
kirbyfan64sos    1 2 2 0 2 X 0 2 0 3      12   Per-language wins.
Maltysen         3 0 0 0 3 2 1 X 2 0      11
plannapus        2 2 0 0 2 2 0 2 0 2      10
jimmy23013       0 0 2 3 0 0 3 2 0 0      10   Solved tasks.
Tom              0 3 0 0 2 2 0 X 3 0      10   Combined byte count.
FryAmTheEggman   1 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0       9
Vioz-            1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0       9   Combined byte count.
Toby Speight     2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2       8
Ismael Miguel    0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2       6
Pulga            0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2       6   Combined byte count.
flawr            2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0       4     
manatwork        2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0       4   Combined byte count.
TheNumberOne     1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0       3
```

Tasks marked with `X` are present but invalid.

The combined leaderboard has been constructed by hand. Please tell me if there are any errors.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Languages count as different if they are not different versions of the same language, so there's only one JavaScript, one Python, and one TI-BASIC, but C, C++, Octave and MATLAB are four different languages.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>If you solve task **n** using language **L** in **x** bytes, somebody else solves the same task in the same language with the same byte count, you change to language **M** and roll back your edit, the other answerer will keep the bonus point.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>The number of points earned from scoring rules 1, 2 and 3 (in that order), the combined byte count of all solved tasks (lower is better) and, finally, the vote tally (higher is better) serve as tiebreakers.</sub>

Comment: Cool challenge. :) A stack snippet leaderboard would probably make your life significantly easier.

Comment: @AlexA.: Thanks! Rule 3 is designed to make that possible, but I don't think I'd have the required JavaScript skills.

Comment: So, for task 1, can the input be a function argument?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos See rule #2

Comment: To clarify, this challenge is limited to those who know at least 10 languages? I'm asking for... a friend...

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy: You don't have to solve all tasks to participate, so if you only solve one task, you only need to know one language.

Comment: Generally you'd call this a 10-hole course, not a decathlon.

Comment: @JoeZ.: We had some 9-hole challenges here, but those scored entries by the combined amount of bytes. Not that my scoring is in any way related to how decathlons are scored, but I wanted to make clear that this is a different type of challenge.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Are Octave and Matlab different languages?

Comment: For Task 10, are preceding and trailing spaces allowed?

Comment: Why not asking for a program that does everything? Ask for differents arguments (the number n then the two strings)

Comment: @lolesque: That would be a standard code golf challenge. The whole point here is using a different language for each task.

Comment: Can task 4 output with quotes? 3 -> "111"

Comment: How is it possible to do challenge #5 without falling foul of 'Optimising the output' or 'Hard-coding the output'. As far as I can tell, every answer thus far fails that. Variations on `echo pneumo...` are hardcoding. Encodings of the string (in parens for instance) are surely optimising the output. How unlike the original string does the program have to be? EG trivially `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis` is a PHP program that prints `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`

Comment: @Dennis it isn't marked as such. But if it is, I take it the PHP example would be valid?

Comment: When is it inappropriate to wish someone a happy new year?  I say Happy New Year from Dec 20 through Jan 15... and then again on various other calendars.

Comment: @NotthatCharles: I asked Gregory and he said January 1st.

Comment: I'm closing this question because [multi-part challenges with little interaction between subchallenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8464) became off topic by community consensus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Task 1, GolfScript, 8 bytes

```
~,{+}*.*
```

Same idea as [Martin's CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52188/16766) answer.

---

### Task 2, QBasic, <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```basic
INPUT a
r=a>1
FOR i=2 TO a-1
r=r*(a MOD i)
NEXT
?r*((a\2AND a)=a\2)
```

Tested on [QB64](http://qb64.net) with syntax expansion turned off.<sup>1</sup> The bulk of the program tests whether the given number `a` is prime by taking `a` mod every number 2<=`i`<`a` and multiplying the results. The result is that `r` is 0 if the number is not prime, and nonzero otherwise. The last line uses bitwise `AND` with integer division by 2 to check whether the binary representation of `a` is all ones, i.e. `a` is of the form 2<sup>n</sup>-1. Multiplying this by `r` gives 0 (false) if a number is not a Mersenne prime and some nonzero (truthy) value otherwise. `?` is a shortcut for `PRINT`.

The largest Mersenne prime I tested, 8191, gives a result of `1.#INF`--which is still truthy! (I checked with an `IF` statement to make sure.)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This doesn't change the semantics of the program. If you type the above code into the standard DOS QBasic, it will be autoformatted with extra spaces, but it will run exactly the same.</sub>

---

### Task 3, Pyth, 6 bytes

```
ehc2SQ
```

Reads a Python-style list from stdin. The main magic here is the `c`hop operator: given an int and a list, it splits the list into n pieces. So `c2SQ` chops the sorted input list in half. Conveniently, when the length is odd, the first half is the bigger one, so the median is always the last element of the first half. This is the `e`nd of the `h`ead of the chop results.

---

### Task 4, CJam, 26 bytes

```
ri{_2%z\_0>\-2/_3$+?}h;]W%
```

This could be shortened, I suspect.

Algorithm:

- Read integer.
- Do while value is not 0:

  - Take abs(i%2). This is the next digit (negabit?).
  - Divide i by -2.
  - Iff i was nonpositive, add abs(i%2) to the result. This is to correct a corner case: 3 goes to -1, but -3 should go to 2, not 1.
- Drop the superfluous 0, collect the stack into an array, reverse and print.

The fact that it's a do-while loop takes care of the 0 case.

---

### Task 5, Bash, 50 bytes

```bash
echo pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

Not much to explain.

---

### Task 6, Python, 78 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
d=date.today()
if d.day<2>d.month:print"Happy New Year!"
```

Requires Python 2. Python's chaining inequality operators can be nicely exploited here.

---

### Task 7, ActionScript, 82 bytes

```js
x=""
while(x.length<64){c=chr(13312+random(6582));if(x.indexOf(c)<0)x+=c}
trace(x)
```

[ActionScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) is a member of the ECMAScript family. This code requires ActionScript 2--much better for code golf because I get to use deprecated functions like `chr` instead of version 3's `String.fromCharCode`!

Output is to the console pane:

[image: Task 7 screenshot]

---

### Task 8, Pip, <s>9</s> 19 bytes

The regex solution didn't quite work, so here's one with string operations instead.

```
Fcab@>:o&:(b@?c)+1o
```

[Github repository for Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip).

Takes the two strings as command-line args. When `a` is a subsequence, outputs a positive integer (truthy); otherwise, the result is nil (falsy), which produces no output.

Explanation:

```
                     Cmdline args -> a,b; o = 1 (implicit)
Fca                  For each character in a:
           b@?c      Find character's index in b (nil if not found)
          (    )+1   Add 1; all possible indices except nil are now truthy
       o&:           Logical AND with o
   b@>:              Slice b to everything at index o and afterward (Python b=b[o:])
                     (If c wasn't found, b becomes nil, but we don't care at that point)
                  o  Auto-print o
```

---

### Task 9, Prolog (SWI), 68 bytes

```
m(L,N,R):-L=[H|T],m(H,N,I),m(T,N,U),R=[I|U];L=[],R=[];R is L*N.
```

Prolog is not usually at all competitive in code golf, so I'm pretty happy with this solution.

Defines a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics#Prolog_programs) `m` with input parameters `L` for the list and `N` for the number and output parameter `R`. The definition of `m` is a triple disjunction:

- If `L` can be [unified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Application:_Unification_in_logic_programming) with `[H|T]`, it is a list with at least one item in it. Call `m` recursively on the head and tail of that list, and put the results together again into a new list which is unified with `R`.
- If `L` can be unified with `[]`, unify `R` with `[]` as well.
- Otherwise, `L` is assumed to be a number; `L*N` is calculated and assigned to `R`.

Example run using `swipl` on Ubuntu:

```
dlosc@dlosc:~/golf$ swipl -qs arrayMult.prolog
?- m([1,2,3],5,R).
R = [5, 10, 15] .

?- m([[3,4],[5,6]],3,R).
R = [[9, 12], [15, 18]] .

?- m([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]],2,R).
R = [[[2, 4], [6, 8]], [[10, 12], [14, 16]]] .
```

---

### Task 10, C, <s>114</s> <s>112</s> 106 bytes

```c
#define F;printf("\n");for(i=0;i<c;i++)printf(
i;t(c){F" ______  ")F"|      | ")F" ()--() ~");putchar(8);}
```

Tested with `gcc` on Ubuntu. Defines a function `t` that takes an integer argument. Uses three `for` loops to output, greatly condensed via macro abuse. Using the backspace character to erase a trailing `~` results in a rather odd whitespace pattern, but `The output may be surrounded by any amount of whitespace as long as it looks like in the example.`

Example run of `t(3)`:

```
dlosc@dlosc:~/golf$ ./a.out

 ______   ______   ______
|      | |      | |      |
 ()--() ~ ()--() ~ ()--() dlosc@dlosc:~/golf$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code for task 8 identifies `a.c` as a subsequence of `abc`.

Comment: @Dennis That *is* unfortunate.  (Good catch, though, thanks.)  Fixed, at a cost of 10 bytes.

Answer (score 17):

Huzzah, first to complete all the tasks! \o/

### Task 1, Perl, 32 bytes

```perl
$_=eval join"+",map$_**3,0..$_-1
```

+1 byte for the `-p` flag. Commentary: Perl is *weird*.

---

### Task 2, CJam, 14 bytes

```
{_mp\)2mL_i=&}
```

My first CJam program!

---

### Task 3, GolfScript, 8 bytes

```
~$.,(2/=
```

Eval STDIN input, sort, take length, decrement, divide by two, then take the item of the sorted array at that index.

---

### Task 4, Python, 77 bytes

```python
def f(i,d=''):
 while i:i,r=i/-2,i%2;i+=r<0;r+=2*(r<0);d=`r`+d
 return d or 0
```

Thanks to @mbomb007 for shaving off 24 (!) bytes, and to @Sp3000 for another 11.

---

### Task 5, Java, 66 bytes

```java
String f(){return"pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";}
```

Boring. Knocked out a verbose language here to save room for golfier languages later.

---

### Task 6, Bash, 39 bytes

```bash
((`date +%j`<2))&&echo Happy New Year\!
```

Thanks to @manatwork for teaching me about `%j`, shaving off 10 bytes in the process.

---

### Task 7, JavaScript, 148 bytes

```js
a=[];Array(65).join('x').replace(/./g,function(){while(a.push(s=String.fromCharCode(13312+Math.random()*6582))&&a.indexOf(s)==s.length-1);return s})
```

Generate a string of 64 `x`'s, then replace them all with a callback function that returns a random one of those characters if it isn't already in the array of used characters.

---

### Task 8, Rust, 130 bytes

```rust
fn f(a:String,b:String)->bool{let mut c=b.chars();for x in a.chars(){match c.find(|&y|x==y){Some(_)=>(),None=>return false}};true}
```

Yes, Rust is very very bad at golfing.

---

### Task 9, Ostrich, 18 bytes

```
{:n;'`\d+`{~n*}X~}
```

Version [0.7.0](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang/releases/tag/v0.7.0-alpha). Inspects the array, does a regex replace to change numbers to their multiplied versions, and then evals the resulting string again.

---

### Task 10, Ruby, 58 bytes

```rb
->n{([' ______  '*n,'|      | '*n,' ()--() ~'*n]*$/).chop}
```

`"\n"` is one character longer than `"{actual newline}"`, which is one character longer than `$/`. Thanks to @MartinBüttner for shaving off {indeterminate but large number} bytes with various tricks of black magic.

Comment: Task 6 – `$(…)` → `\`…\``.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks, edited.

Comment: Thinking again, (caffeine absorption in progress…), why that lengthy %D format? `[ \`date +%j\` = 001 ]` Or even `((\`date +%j\`<2))`. (Assuming GNU `date`, which certainly supports “%j   day of year (001..366)” format.)

Comment: @manatwork Ooh, very nice. Thanks again, added to answer.

Comment: Task 4 can be shortened using the ((num+0xAAAAAAAA)^0xAAAAAAAA) alg.

Comment: Task 4: use `i,r=i/-2,i%-2` instead of `divmod`.

Comment: Task 4: `i,r=(i+1,r+2)if r<0 else(i,r)` can be `i+=r<0;r+=2*(r<0)`. Also, `d.insert(0,str(r))` can be shortened to `d=[\`r\`]+d`, unless `r` will ever be larger than `sys.maxint`, then use `d=[str(r)]+d`.

Comment: @mbomb007 Wow, that reduced the byte count by 24. All great tips, thanks!

Comment: Why not build the string directly rather than making a list of the chars then joining? i.e. `d=''`

Comment: ^ What he said. Then you can use `\`r\`+d` without the brackets.

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks, saved another 9 chars.

Comment: On task 7, does your code ensure all the characters are unique?

Comment: @DLosc No, nor is that a requirement in the question.

Comment: @DLosc Whoops, no idea how I missed that. Fixed at the cost of 50 bytes >_<

Answer (score 15):

### Task 1, 3var, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
'><k*>#aa/>sp
```

*([Esolang wiki page for 3var](http://esolangs.org/wiki/3var))*

```
'                  R = n
 >                 A = n
  <k               B = n-1
    *              R = A*B = n(n-1)
     >             A = n(n-1)
      #aa          B = 2
         /         R = A/B = n(n-1)/2
          >s       A = (n(n-1)/2)^2
            p      Output A
```

Takes input via a code point, e.g. space is 32.

Thankfully all the operations we need to implement the formula `n^2 (n-1)^2 / 4` are single chars (decrementing, multiplication and squaring), yet it takes 3 bytes to set `B` to 2 (reset-increment-increment).

---

### Task 2, Retina, <s>38</s> 33 bytes

```
^
1
^(..|.(..+)\2+|(.(..)+)\3*)$
<empty>
```

*([Github repository for Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina))*

Each line goes in a separate file, but you can test the above as is with the `-s` flag (replacing `<empty>` with nothing). Input should be unary with 1s, e.g. `1111111` for 7.

Here's what each regex substitution (specified by a pair of lines) does:

1. Tack on an extra 1 to the front
2. Replace anything of the form `2`, `1 + composite` or `not power of 2` with nothing.

This adds an extra `1` to Mersenne primes, while every other number is obliterated.

---

### Task 3, Racket, 71 bytes

```scheme
#lang racket
(define(m x)(list-ref(sort x <)(quotient(-(length x)1)2)))
```

Lisp-like languages are just too wordy. Example run:

```
> (m `(1 3 4 2))
2
```

---

### Task 4, ><>, 31 bytes

```
:?!v:2%:@-02-,
)?~\l1
!;n>l?
```

*([Esolang wiki page for ><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish))*

The above is 28 bytes, and requires the `-v` flag in the Python interpreter for [another 3 bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), e.g. run like

```
$ py -3 fish.py negabinary.fish -v -137
10001011
```

The nice thing about ><> here is that we can calculate the digits one by one via modulo and division, which gives the digits in reverse order, perfect for printing off a stack.

---

### Task 5, Parenthetic, <s>1448</s> 1386 bytes

```
((()()())(()()()())((()())((()(())()))((()(())(())())((()(()))(()(())())((()(()))((())())((()()(()))((())()()()()()()()())((())()()()()()()()()()()()())))))))((()()())(()()())((()())((()(())()))((()()()())((()(()))(()(())())((())()()()()()()()()()()())))))((()(()))((()()())((())()()()()))((()()())((())()()))((()()()())((())()()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())))((()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()))((()()()())((())))((()()())((())()))((()()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()()))((()()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()()()))((()()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()()))((()()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())))((()()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())))((()()()())((())()()))((()()()())((())))((()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()()())((())()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()))((()()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()()))((()()()())((())()()()()()()()()))((()()())((())()()()()()()())))
```

*([Github repository for Parenthetic](https://github.com/cammckinnon/Parenthetic))*

I have a CJam answer for this which is shorter than the string itself, but I can't use it so I thought I'd go the other way.

Python 3 generating code:

```py
char97 = "((()()())(()()()())((()())((()(())()))((()(())(())())((()(()))(()(())())((()(()))((())())((()()(()))((())()()()()()()()())((())()()()()()()()()()()()())))))))"
char108 = "((()()())(()()())((()())((()(())()))((()()()())((()(()))(()(())())((())()()()()()()()()()()())))))"
open_str = "((()(()))"
close_str = ")"

target = "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"
output = [char97, char108, open_str]

for c in target:
    if ord(c) >= 108:
        output.append("((()()())((())%s))"%("()"*(ord(c)-108)))
    else:
        output.append("((()()()())((())%s))"%("()"*(ord(c)-97)))

output.append(close_str)
print("".join(output))
```

Here's the corresponding Lisp-like code:

```
(define f (lambda (n) (char (+ n 97))))
(define g (lambda (n) (f (+ n 11))))

(+
   (g 4)  // p
   (g 2)  // n
   (f 4)  // e
   ...
)
```

Apparently it was okay to override `define` by naming `g` as `()()`, which saved a lot of bytes.

---

### Task 6, CJam, 26 bytes

```
XY]et1>>"Happy New Year!"*
```

Checks that the `[month day]` part of the local time array is less than `[1, 2]`.

---

### Task 7, Python, 73 bytes

```py
from random import*
print(*map(chr,sample(range(13312,19894),64)),sep="")
```

Just a straightforward Python 3 implementation.

---

### Task 8, Prelude, <s>46</s> 41 bytes

```
?(?)#(#)?(v-(#)?)10)!
      ^      1 # (0
```

*([Esolang wiki page for Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude))*

I think this works – it's probably still golfable, but it's my first time doing a non-trivial golf in Prelude. The input format is `<needle>NUL<haystack>`, where `NUL` is `0x00`. This works best with `NUMERIC_OUTPUT = True` in the Python interpreter, since that'll make it output `1` or `0` as appropriate.

I chose Prelude because there's two properties which make it very nice for this task:

- It is stack-based, so you can first read in the needle, then process the haystack one char at a time, and
- Prelude's stack has an infinite number of 0s at the bottom, so you don't need to handle the case where the needle runs out of characters.

This would have been even better if Prelude had a NOT operator.

Here's the breakdown:

```
?(?)#    Read input up to the NUL, discarding the NUL afterwards

(#)      Move the needle to the second voice, effectively reversing the stack
 ^

?(...?)  Read haystack

  v-     Compare top needle char with haystack char by subtraction

  (#)    If equal, pop the needle char
   1 #

10)!     Output 1 if the top needle char is 0 (bottom of stack), 0 otherwise
(0
```

*(-5 bytes thanks to @MartinBüttner)*

---

### Task 9, Mathematica, 4 bytes

```
#2#&
```

Something like `2 {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}` is implicitly multiplication in Mathematica, so this just puts the arguments side-by-side.

As noted by [@MartinButtner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/52188/1) and [@alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/52185/2), `1##&` is another 4 byte answer. See the former for an explanation.

---

### Task 10, Rail, <s>246</s> 237 bytes

```
$'main'
 0/aima19-@
@------e<
         -(!!)()[ ][ ______ ]{f}[\n\]o()[ ][|      |]{f}[\n\]o()[~][ ()--() ]{f}#
$'f'                 #           #
 -(!x!)(!y!)(!!)()0g<  -(x)o()1g<  -(y)o()1s(y)(x){f}#
                     -/          -/
```

*([Esolang wiki page for Rail](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail))*

I couldn't pass up the opportunity to do a train-related task in Rail :) The whitespace looks pretty golfable, but with branching taking up three lines it'll take a bit of work to compact.

Input is an integer via STDIN, but there needs to be an EOF. The top-left portion

```
 0/aima19-@
@------e<
```

is an atoi loop which converts the input to an integer while not EOF (checked by the `e` instruction).

The function `f` on the last three lines takes `x, y, n`, and outputs the string `x` `n` times, separated by `y`. The function is recursive, with `n` decrementing by one each time until it becomes zero. `f` is called three times, supplying different strings for each row. Weirdly, Rail allows variable names to be empty, which saves a few bytes.

Most of the bytes unfortunately come from `(!x!)`, which pops the top of the stack and assigns it to variable `x`, and `(x)`, which pushes `x` onto the stack. This is necessary because there's no duplicate operator in Rail, so `(!x!)(x)(x)` is the only way to copy the top of the stack.

Comment: If task 2 were in rs, you'd save 2 bytes, and it'd cost only 14 bytes to take numbers instead of unary. ;)

Comment: When i saw racket, i thought you like parentheses; but parenthetic...

Answer (score 13):

### Task 1, CJam, 7 bytes

```
q~,:+_*
```

I just wanted to get the (presumably) optimal CJam solution for this in. It makes use of the fact that the sum of the first *n* cubes is the square of the *nth* triangular number, which is itself the sum of the first *n* integers.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%2C%3A%2B_*&input=6)

---

### Task 4, Fission, <s>173</s> <s>88</s> <s>78</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

[GitHub repository for Fission.](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission/)

```
 /@\O/S@+>\
^{ }[<X/ @/;
,\?/@\J^X\
'M~\$ $
UK/W%@]  /
D
?\{\/
0'A Y
```

My second reasonably complicated Fission program. :)

The input format is a bit weird. To support negative inputs, the first character is expected to be either `+` or `-` to indicate the sign. The second character's byte value is then the magnitude of the input (since Fission can't natively read decimal integers). So if you want `111` you'd pass it `+o` on STDIN. And if you want `-56` you pass it `-8`. In place of `+` and `-` you can use any character with a lower or higher character code, respectively. This can be helpful to pass in something like `-n` (which your `echo` might treat as an argument) as, e.g., `0n`.

Let's look at how we can find the negabinary representation of a positive number. We want to compute the number from least to most significant bit (we'll push those bits on a stack and print them all at the end to get them in the right order). The first digit is then just the parity of the number, and we integer-divide the number by 2 to continue processing. The next digit is now negative (with value -2) - but it should be noted that this bit will be set whenever the 2-bit would be set in a normal binary number. The only difference is that we need to counter the -2 with positive higher valued digits. So what we do is this:

- We determine the parity again - this is the next negabit - and divide by 2 as before.
- If that digit was a `1`, we increment the remaining number by 1 in order to counter-act the negative bit (the difference between a negabit and a bit is *once* the value of the next more-significant bit).

A great simplification of the code results from noticing that conditionally adding one here is equivalent to rounding the number *up* when integer dividing (if the discarded bit was 1, we increment the integer-divided result by 1).

Then, the next bit is just a positive value again so we can determine it normally. That means we want a loop that computes two bits at a time, alternating between rounding up and rounding down for the remaining number, but we want to enter the loop in the middle so we start with rounding down.

How can we handle negative integers? The problem is that Fission can't really do arbitrary arithmetic on negative integers, because masses are always non-negative. So one would have to do something really complicated like working with the magnitude and keeping track of the sign somewhere else. However, the negabinary representation of a negative number can be computed based on a related positive number:

If *n* is negative, compute the negabinary representation of *n/2* (rounded *up*) and append the parity of *n*.

This is exactly the first step of our two-bit loop. So all we need to do is start the loop at a different point if the sign is negative.

Most of the savings from the 173 original bytes came from these insights which allowed me to compress three parity checks and a two-section loop into a single loop with a single parity check.

This post will get too long if I explain all the code in detail, but I'll point out a few sections to give the rough layout of the control flow, and you can puzzle out the details with the Fission reference.

```
 /@\
^{ }[
,\?/
'
U
D
?
```

Starting from the `D`, this reads a sign bit into the energy and the magnitude into the mass of an atom that ends up in the `[` (going right). This sign bit will alternate after each pass through the parity check and will determine whether we retain the rounded down or rounded up half of the loop input.

```
     /S@+>\
    [<X/ @/
 \  @\J^X\
 M  $ $
 K  %@]  /
```

This is the loop which computes the individual bits and feeds the correct half into the next iteration. The `S` and the `J` are used to create a copy of the right half based on the current sign bit, the `X`s do the copying. The `>` in the top right corner computes the actual bit which is then sent to the stack `K` to be retrieved later. I think the layout of the top right corner is pretty nifty and definitely worth studying in detail if you're interested in Fission.

The `%` is a switch which feeds the number back into the loop as long as it's greater than 0.

```
    O


 M~\
 K/W%

 \{\/
0'A Y
```

Once the number reaches 0 it's reflected down instead. This starts another loop which retrieves the bits from the stack, adds them to the character code of `0` and prints them with `O`. The program terminates once the stack is empty, because the control atom will end up being pushed on the stack (and afterwards there are no more moving atoms left).

---

### Task 5, Prelude, <s>219</s> <s>179</s> 96 bytes

[Esolangs page for Prelude.](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude)

[Stack Snippet interpreter for Prelude.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52454/8478)

```
29+129+716705-7607-05-4759+705-14129+05-18705-29+719+05-1507-19+39+449+767549+03-68(67+^+^+^++!)
```

This started out as a standard hand-crafted fixed-output Prelude program with three voices. After some chat with Sp3000 I decided to try a single voice. It turned out that this worked quite well, because it's much easier to reuse older letters. Then Dennis gave me a few hints and I found the current version: the idea is push all the offsets from the letter `h` onto the stack of a single voice in reverse order, and then just print them one at a time in a loop. `h` is chosen because there is no `h` in the string (which is important - otherwise the `0` offset would terminate the loop) and because it minimises the encoding of the offsets in terms of two-digit and negative offsets.

The offset encoding was generated with [this CJam script](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qW%25%7B'h-_0%3C%5Cz_9%3E%7B%5B9m9'%2B%5D%7D%26%5C%7B0%5C'-%7D%26%7D%2F&input=pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis).

---

### Task 8, Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
LongestCommonSequence@##==#&
```

Yay for built-ins. (Mathematica's naming is a bit weird here... `LongestCommonSubsequence` finds the longest common *substring* while `LongestCommonSequence` finds the longest common *subsequence*.)

---

### Task 9, J, 1 byte

```
*
```

Same as the APL and K answers, but it seems no one has taken J yet.

---

### Task 10, Retina, <s>67</s> 60 bytes

[GitHub repository for Retina.](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina)

```
(.*).
 ______  $1<LF>|      | $1<LF> ()--() ~$1
+`(.{9})1
$1$1
~$
<empty>
```

Each line goes in a separate file, and `<LF>` should be replaced with a newline character and `<empty>` should be an empty file. You could also put all of this in a single file, and use the `-s` option, but that does not allow embedding of newline characters in place of `<LF>` yet. You could emulate that by doing something like

```
echo -n "111" | ./Retina -s train.ret | ./Retina -e "<LF>" -e "\n"
```

As the above example shows, input is expected to be unary. The idea of the code is to create three copies of the unary input (minus 1), each with a copy of the corresponding line. Then we repeatedly duplicate the last nine characters in front of a `1` until all the `1`s are gone, thereby repeating the lines as necessary. Finally, we remove the extraneous trailing `~`.

Answer (score 10):

Eh, I'll start out with a couple I guess. First time golfing.

### Task 1, Python, <s>38</s> 21 bytes

```
lambda n:(n*n-n)**2/4
```

Sum a list of all the cubes up to x. Changed expression thanks to xnor

### Task 2, TI-Basic 89, 244 bytes

```
Func
If iPart(log(x+1)/log(2))=log(x+1)/log(2) Then
 Return log(x+1)/log(2)
Else
 Return 0
EndIf
EndFunc
Func
If isPrime(x)=false
 Return 0
If ipart(log(x+1)/log(2))=log(log(x+1)/log(2)) Then
 Return log(x+1)/log(2)
Else
 Return 0
EndIf
EndFunc
```

Not 100% certain on this one, will test when I find new batteries for my calculator. isPrime is a builtin, ipart is integer part (2.3 ->2)

### Task 3, Perl, <s>45</s> 34 Bytes

```
@n=sort{$a-$b}@ARGV;print$n[$#n/2]
```

perl file 1 2 3 4 --> 2. Saved a couple of bytes thanks to @nutki. Printed rather than saving to variable then printing variable.

### Task 4, Ruby, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
x=2863311530
p ((gets.to_i+x)^x).to_s(2)
```

At least it works in 1.9, don't know about 1.8. In binary, '10'*16 (or 2863311530) plus a number, xor with that 10101010... is the negbinary. Outputs a string representation with quotes (3 -> "111" rather than 3 -> 111). Can't find math to write x in less characters.

### Task 5, Malbolge, <s>682</s> 354 bytes

```
D'``_]>n<|49ixTfR@sbq<(^J\ljY!DVf#/yb`vu)(xwpunsrk1Rngfkd*hgfe^]#a`BA]\[TxRQVOTSLpJOHlL.DhHA@d>C<`#?>7<54X8165.R2r0/(L,%k)"F&}${zy?`_uts9Zvo5slkji/glkdcb(fed]b[!B^WVUyYXQ9UNrLKPIHl/.JCBGFE>bBA@"!7[;{z276/.R2r0)(-&J$j('~D${"y?w_utyxq7Xtmlkji/gf,MLbgf_dc\"`BA]\UyYXWP8NMLpPIHGLEiIHGF(>C<A@9]7<;:3W7w5.-210/(L,%k#('~}C{"y?`_uts9wpXn4rkpoh.lNMiha'eGF\[`_^W{h
```

Test online [here](http://www.matthias-ernst.eu/malbolge/debugger.html) Think this is as short as it'll go. Golfed as much as I could. Saved 300 bytes, so whee?

### Task 6, bash, <s>62</s> <s>50</s> 40 bytes

```
[ `date +%j`=1 ]&&echo 'Happy New Year!'
```

Found out about %j from another post.

### Task 10, Befunge-98, 121 Bytes

```
>&:>1-:" ____"v
   |,k8: '"__"<
   >a,$:>1-v
      > |
>' 8k,^ #
^|':k4 '|':<
v ',*25$<
>,:1-: ")(--)("v
^," ~"_@#,k6" "<
```

Changed to befunge-98. Old was Befunge-93, <s>227 157</s> 147 bytes. Used [Fungi, written in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Fungi) for testing. Used the "do multiple times k" and adding single characters to the stack with '. I have a feeling it can be golfed down to 110 or less, but I've spent far too much time on this already...

Comment: @Dennis since I can't ask on the main post, I'll ask here. Is space separated input ok for task 3? It won't be in [].

Comment: Whatever suits your needs.

Comment: You can shorten the sum of cubes with [the formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+x+%3D+0+to+n-1+of++x%5E3) as `lambda n:(n*n-n)**2/4`

Comment: You can use `0=fPart(expression) rather than `iPart(expression)=expression` in your TI-89 BASIC answer.

Comment: Task 6 would be 62 bytes as it is. It has a minor bug, since New Year is not today. :P Bash has `&&`, by the way, so you don't need the length `if` statement.

Comment: haha whoops, nice catch ^_^. Haven't used bash, will look at &&

Comment: @Dennis, 9 more rep needed. Do you consider TI-89 and TI-83 Basic the same or different languages?

Comment: That would be different versions of the same language, so you can't use both.

Comment: I think TI-89 and TI-83 BASIC are different. The commands on the TI-89 can be stored in either tokenized or untokenized form IIRC. In addition, the platforms and OSs are different: 89s have a Motorola 68000 processor while the 83/84 series has a  z80. Perhaps the most compelling argument is that I can golf TI-83 BASIC well but almost none of those skills transfer to 89 BASIC.

Comment: I think that argument doesn't work well when talking about something like Python 2/3. For example, \`n\` works better than str(n) in 2, but doesn't work in 3. I can't think of other examples at the moment, I'm more concerned with golfing that befunge answer more :p

Comment: Task 3, following your method: `@n=sort{$a-$b}@ARGV;print$n[$#n/2]` or shorter with `-pa`: `$_=(sort{$a-$b}@F)[$#F/2]`

Comment: @nutki how does the second one work?

Answer (score 9):

First thing: task 6 technically does **NOT** count; I uploaded [unc](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/unc) under an hour ago. However, I *almost* uploaded it this morning, but decided to write a test suite first. Idiot.

So, anyway, here goes!

Note that most unc things are intentionally backwards, so `&&` really means `||` and such, which is why some operations look weird (e.g. using `-` to calculate the cube).

### Task 1, Haskell, 21 bytes

```
f n=sum$map(^3)[0..n]
```

### Task 2, Hy, 135 bytes

```
(import math)(fn[n](and(if(and(not(% n 2))(> n 2))false(all(genexpr(% n i)[i(->> n(math.sqrt)int inc(range 3))])))(->> n dec(& n)not)))
```

### Task 3, Dart, 37 bytes

My first Dart function!

```
f(l){l.sort();return l[l.length~/2];}
```

### Task 5, INTERCAL, 1047 bytes

```
DO ,1 <- #46
DO ,1SUB#1 <- #242
DO ,1SUB#2 <- #152
DO ,1SUB#3 <- #208
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#4 <- #248
DO ,1SUB#5 <- #248
DO ,1SUB#6 <- #192
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#7 <- #128
DO ,1SUB#8 <- #128
DO ,1SUB#9 <- #72
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#10 <- #120
DO ,1SUB#11 <- #8
DO ,1SUB#12 <- #224
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#13 <- #200
DO ,1SUB#14 <- #208
DO ,1SUB#15 <- #32
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#16 <- #208
DO ,1SUB#17 <- #120
DO ,1SUB#18 <- #88
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#19 <- #40
DO ,1SUB#20 <- #8
DO ,1SUB#21 <- #208
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#22 <- #232
DO ,1SUB#23 <- #120
DO ,1SUB#24 <- #208
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#25 <- #248
DO ,1SUB#26 <- #56
DO ,1SUB#27 <- #96
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#28 <- #160
DO ,1SUB#29 <- #208
DO ,1SUB#30 <- #208
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#31 <- #136
DO ,1SUB#32 <- #120
DO ,1SUB#33 <- #192
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#34 <- #112
DO ,1SUB#35 <- #64
DO ,1SUB#36 <- #16
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#37 <- #128
DO ,1SUB#38 <- #48
DO ,1SUB#39 <- #208
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#40 <- #128
DO ,1SUB#41 <- #224
DO ,1SUB#42 <- #160
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#43 <- #40
DO ,1SUB#44 <- #56
DO ,1SUB#45 <- #200
PLEASE DO ,1SUB#46 <- #126
PLEASE DO READ OUT ,1
DO GIVE UP
```

### Task 6, unc, 157 bytes

```
!include>=fgQVb%U<=
!include>=gVZR%U<=
false lRNe[]<<gVZR_g t:=gVZR[5]:volatile gZ m:=-YbPNYgVZR[&t]:for[#m%gZ_Zba||m%gZ_ZQNl!=6]chgf[L'uNccl ARj LRNe#']:>>
```

### Task 8, rs, 42 bytes

```
#
+#(.)(.*) .*?\1/\1#\2 
.*# .*$/1
[^1]+/0
```

[Live demo.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%23%0A%2B%23(.)(.*)%20.*%3F%5C1%2F%5C1%23%5C2%20%0A.*%23%20.*%24%2F1%0A%5B%5E1%5D%2B%2F0&input=abc%20axbx%0Aabc%20axbxc%0Aabc%20axcxbx)

### Task 10, Pyth, 46 bytes

```
jb(j*d2m+\ *\_6Qjdm"|      |"Qj\~m" ()--() "Q)
```

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jb(j*d2m%2B%5C+*%5C_6Qjdm"%7C++++++%7C"Qj%5C~m"+()--()+"Q)&input=2&debug=1)

Comment: @Dennis Oops! Fixed!

Comment: Well, I don't know unc, but I'm pretty sure you don't need one of the `!include`s. Not entirely sure which one though.

Comment: @Dennis First include is `stdio.h`, second is `time.h`. I need both.

Comment: What does `unc` use to compile the C code? GCC will work just fine without  `stdio.h`. Not sure about `time.h`.

Comment: @Dennis unc doesn't have a set compiler. It just outputs C code; I have to compile it myself. However, that *does* make sense; I'll check it out later.

Answer (score 8):

### Task 1, APL, 7 bytes

```
+/3*⍨⍳⎕
```

You can [try it online](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html#code=+/3*%u2368%u2373%u2395) using ngn/apl, though it will work with any APL implementation that defaults to a 0 index origin.

This cubes each integer from 0 to the input (`⍳⎕`) -1 by commuting (`⍨`) the arguments to the power operator (`*`). The resulting vector is reduced by summing (`+/`) and a scalar is returned.

---

### Task 2, Julia, 42 bytes

```matlab
n->(isprime(n)&&int(log2(n+1))==log2(n+1))
```

This creates an anonymous function that accepts as integer as input and returns a boolean. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=n->...`.

First we use Julia's built-in function `isprime` to check whether `n` is prime. If it is, we check that `log2(n+1)` is an integer. If so, `n` can be written as `2^k-1` for some `k`, and thus `n` is a Mersenne prime.

---

### Task 3, [ELI](http://fastarray.appspot.com), 19 bytes

```
{f:x[<x][~.0.5*#x]}
```

This creates a monad `f` that returns the median of the input vector.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```
{f:         // Define a function f
 x[<x]      // Sort the input vector
 [          // Select the element at index...
 ~.0.5*#x   // ceiling of 0.5 * length(input)
]}
```

Examples:

```
    f 1 2 3 4
2
    f ?.!20   // Apply f to 20 random integers in 1..20
4
```

---

### Task 4, Octave, 39 bytes

```matlab
@(n,x=2863311530)dec2bin(bitxor(n+x,x))
```

This creates a function handle that accepts an integer as input and returns the associated negabinary string. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=@...`, and run with `feval(f, <input>)`.

You can [try it online](https://ideone.com/okXUXR).

---

### Task 5, CJam, 47 bytes

```
"pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"
```

The string is simply printed to STDOUT. You can [try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis%22) if you feel so inclined.

---

### Task 6, Windows Batch, 46 bytes

```
if "%date:~4,5%"=="01/01" echo Happy New Year!
```

The variable `%date%` contains the current date in the form `Thu 06/25/2015`. We can select the month and day by getting the substring of length 5 after skipping the first 4 characters: `%date:~4,5%`. From there we just check if it's January 1st and say Happy New Year if it is.

---

### Task 7, Pyth, 26 bytes

```
=Gr13312 19895FNU64pC.(.SG
```

First we assign `G` to the range 13312 through 19894 inclusive. Then we loop 64 times, and at each iteration we shuffle `G` (`.SG`), remove and return the last element (`.(`), and print its character representation (`pC`).

You can [try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DGr13312+19894FNU64pC.(.SG&debug=0).

---

### Task 8, Ruby, 36 bytes

```rb
def f(a,b)!b.tr("^"+a,"")[a].nil?end
```

This defines a function `f` which accepts two strings `a` and `b`, where `a` is the string to find within `b`.

Everything but the characters in `a` are removed from `b` using `.tr()` and we check whether the result contains `a` exactly using `[]`. This will return `nil` if the string isn't found, so we can get a boolean value by using `!` with `.nil?`.

---

### Task 9, R, 16 bytes

```r
function(x,n)n*x
```

This creates an unnamed function object that accepts any kind of array or matrix `x` and an integer `n` and multiplies each element of `x` by `n`. If you'd like, you can [try it online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=EIviowQc).

---

### Task 10, Python 3, 92 bytes

```python
n=int(input())
l="\n"
w=" ()--() "
print(" ______  "*n+l+"|      | "*n+l+(w+"~")*(n-1)+w)
```

Pretty straightforward. You can [try it online](http://ideone.com/QCt0R1).

Comment: The APL answer isn't quite 7 bytes, since there are three Unicode characters in higher ranges.

Comment: @Tom: Every answer can choose the most convenient encoding. In the [APL code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(codepage)), one character is one byte.

Comment: _You can try it online if you feel so inclined_ :-D

Answer (score 7):

## Task 1, ><>, 10 + 3 = 13 bytes

```
::*-:*4,n;
```

Run this using the [official Python interpreter](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392418) using the `-v` flag (at a cost of 3 bytes).  This squares the quantity `(n - n*n)` and divides by `4`, which of course is equivalent to squaring `(n*n - n)` and dividing by `4`.

## Task 2, GAP, <strike>63</strike> 62 bytes

```
b:=function(m)return[2]=AsSet(Factors(m+1))and IsPrime(m);end;
```

(Saved a space by writing the equality the other way around.)

## Task 3, R, <strike>43</strike> 39 bytes

```
f=function(v)sort(v,d=T)[length(v)%/%2]
```

Thanks to Plannapus for the nice improvement!

## Task 4, Piet, <strike>155</strike> <strike>135</strike> <strike>115</strike> 5*19 = 95 codels

[image]

Test using [this online interpreter](http://www.rapapaing.com/blog/?page_id=6), with codel size 13.  Or use your preferred interpreter--let me know if you have one you like!

Making it output `0` instead of the empty string for input `0` was inconvenient. I used an if-then near the beginning to take care of this case; then a while-loop to calculate the digits in the nonzero case, and finally another while-loop at the end to output the digits from the stack.

Many thanks to Sp3000 for some very helpful comments, which helped me to save some codels!

## Task 5, Lua, 52 bytes

```
print"pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"
```

You can try it [here](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo).

## Task 6, LaTeX, <strike>157</strike> <strike>139</strike> <strike>136</strike> <strike>127</strike> 128 bytes

```
\documentclass{book}\begin{document}\count1=\day\multiply\count1 by\month
\ifcase\count1\or Happy New Year!\else~\fi\end{document}
```

If the product of the day and the month is `1`, print the message; otherwise, nothing. (New Year's Day is particularly convenient for this design: since the output we're looking for is `1`, we only need one `or` statement. The `n`th `or` statement specifies behavior for the value `n`.)

Note: my previous version was missing the line return, which was a mistake. (I did try to test this function, but to really test it properly might take a while...)

My original version used the `calc` package, which was much more convenient than my current version. Something to keep in mind for "real life"!

## Task 7, Ruby, 62 bytes

```
for r in Array(13312..19893).sample(64)
puts [r].pack('U*')end
```

## Task 8, JavaScript, 78 bytes

```
h=function(l,m){u=1+m.indexOf(l[0]);return(!l||u&&h(l.substr(1),m.substr(u)))}
```

Recursive solution, testing whether `l` is a substring of `m`. If `l` is empty, then the `!l` results in `true` and the function terminates. (In this case, `l[0]` is undefined, but JavaScript is OK with that.) Otherwise, it looks for the first instance of `l[0]` in `m`. If it doesn't find one, then `m.indexOf(l[0])` results in `-1` and so `u` results in `0` and the function terminates.

Otherwise, it strips off the first entry of `l` and the first `u` entries of `m` and continues checking.

## Task 9, Python, <strike>72</strike> 60 bytes

```
def i(a,n):
 try:return[i(c,n)for c in a]
 except:return n*a
```

Drills down to the "lowest level", where `a` isn't a list anymore, just an integer, then carries out the multiplication.

Many thanks to Dennis for saving me 12 bytes!

## Task 10, Groovy, 81 bytes

```
def j(n){(' ------  '*n+'\n'+'|      | '*n+'\n'+' ()--() ~'*n).substring(0,27*n)}
```

Try it [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/). I originally tried to implement something like Python's `.join()` method for strings, which puts strings together with a particular "linking string" (like the linkages between train cars). But that cost a lot more than it saved.

*I hope I haven't run afoul of any conventions for acceptable answers in these various languages, but please let me know if I have.*

**Thank you to Dennis for a fantastic challenge!**

Comment: `except:return n*a` saves a few bytes for task 9. For task 1, I'd count the `-v` flag as one byte.

Comment: @Dennis See [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions). Although, by [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values), you can probably replace the `-v` flag with `i` (although I think it would be good if both versions were mentioned, for easier testing).

Comment: @Dennis, thanks very much for your smart improvement!

Comment: @Sp3000 I have seen a few ><> solutions where the `-v` option was counted as 3, including in your solution to this same challenge! If there's a consensus that this isn't the correct scoring, that's certainly fine with me, but 3 bytes is what i have generally seen for this particular usage.

Comment: 3 bytes is correct by the meta post above (space, `-`, `v`). I just meant that you have the option of taking in input as a code point via the `i` instruction.

Comment: btw, for #4, negative modulo isn't that strange - it just varies from language to language (e.g. Java does that from memory). One way to output the entire stack might be to keep something at the bottom of the stack which you know will not be in the output, and keep printing chars while it's not that special char. Also, there's [PietCreator](https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator/wiki).

Comment: @Sp3000, thank you very much for your help! As I understand it `i` will read one character and push its ASCII value onto the stack, so I believe some further code would be required in order to get something like `257` into memory. So taking advantage of the `-v` flag was the cheapest way I could see for this task (though maybe I'm missing something). Anyway, thanks again for your responses!

Comment: @Sp3000 Also I see you are right about the negative modulus in Java and some other languages. Thank you for the helpful information.

Comment: You can shorten your task 3 a bit, while still using the same algorithm: first `=` is equivalent to `<-`, then you can `sort` in reverse order using argument `decreasing=TRUE` which can be shorten to `d=T` and therefore use the integer division `%/%` instead of `ceiling(.../2)`, thus: `f=function(v)sort(v,d=T)[length(v)%/%2]` for 39 bytes.

Comment: @plannapus Thank you very much for the improvement, and the helpful explanation!

Answer (score 6):

### Task 1, Pyth, 5 bytes

```
s^R3Q
```

Takes number from stdin. Thanks @Jakube for pointing out the useless `U`.

### Task 6, javascript, 56 bytes

```
if(Date().slice(4,10)=="Jan 01")alert("Happy New Year!")
```

### Task 7, CJam, 16 bytes

```
6581,mr64<'㐀f+
```

Generates range, shuffles, picks first 64, and maps addition of start value and converting to character. 14 chars, 16 bytes.

### Task 8, Octave, 23 bytes

```
@(x,y)intersect(x,y)==x
```

Defines anonymous function.

### Task 5, PHP, 45 bytes

```
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

No compression, just prints.

### Task 9, APL 1 byte

```
 ×
```

The same as the K answer.

Comment: @Dennis I don't know it either - I just googled on hunch and put this answer together without testing :). I'll try to test on an emulator now.

Comment: @Dennis oh you're right, it averages the middle 2, taking that down.

Comment: What are you doing with that space in `.slice(4, 10)`?

Comment: @Dennis derrrp. sorry.

Comment: @Dennis I'm gonna cry now... fixed it though.

Comment: @Dennis cool thanks, just learning cjam.

Comment: @Dennis It seems I have two operators `+` and `c` so how would that work?

Comment: @Dennis coooooooooool.

Comment: I don't think your version of Task 5 is a 'valid' one. It is, actually, a polyglot. That means that tons of languages are excluded. But, that isn't up to only me to decide.

Comment: There's only one month abbreviation that ends with "an", so you can leave off the J when testing. (It would also be significantly shorter to do `/an 01/.test(Date())`.)

Comment: Your solution for task 8 doesn't seem to take order into account. `f('abc','axbxc')` and `f('abc','bxaxc')` give the same result.

Answer (score 6):

### Task 1, R, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
sum((1:scan()-1)^3)
```

Fairly straight forward.  Input from STDIN.

### Task 2, Perl, <s>40</s> 66 bytes

```
$a=log(<>+1)/log(2)+1;print$a==int($a)&&(1x$a)!~/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
```

Added a prime checker (Abigails prime number checker regex)

### Task 3, PARI/GP, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
m(v)=vecsort(v)[#v\2];
```

First time I touched this.  Might have to learn a bit more of it.

### Task 4, T-SQL, 235 bytes

```
CREATE FUNCTION D(@ INT)RETURNS TABLE RETURN WITH R AS(SELECT @/-2+(IIF(@%-2<0,1,0))D,CAST(ABS(@%-2) AS VARCHAR(MAX))M UNION ALL SELECT D/-2+(IIF(D%-2<0,1,0)),CAST(ABS(D%-2)AS VARCHAR(MAX))+M FROM R WHERE D<>0)SELECT M FROM R WHERE D=0
```

Inline table function using  recursive CTE.  Very large, but fun to do.

To use

```
SELECT * FROM D(18)
M
------
10110
```

### Task 5, GAP, 48 bytes

```
"pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";
```

### Task 6, Excel, <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```
=IF(TEXT(NOW(),"md")="11","Happy New Year!","")
```

Thanks to @Bond for the 3 bytes.

### Task 7, Python 2.6, <s>98</s> <s>93</s> 85 bytes

```
from random import*
l=range(13312,19893)
shuffle(l)
print ''.join(map(unichr,l[:64]))
```

This is the first time I've tried to do anything in Python, so could be lots better.  Thanks @Dennis and @Jacob for the great tips

### Task 8, TCL, 57 bytes

```
proc m {a b} {string match [regsub -all (.) $a *\\1]* $b}
```

Shame that removing whitespace kills this

### Task 9, Pike, 53 bytes

```
mixed m(array(array(int))a,int n){return(a[*])[*]*n;}
```

A function that returns the multiplied array

### Task 10, Powershell, 88 bytes

```
Function t($n){Foreach($s in "  ______ "," |      |","~ ()--() "){($s*$n).Substring(1)}}
```

A Powershell function.  I think I can shortened it a bit, but here it is at the moment.

And finally finished :)

Comment: You can save 4 bytes on task 6: `=IF(TEXT(NOW(),"md")="11","Happy New Year!","")`.

Comment: @Bond Thanks for that

Comment: I don't know Python either, but `l[:63]` should work and `(13312,19894)` is shorter than the hexadecimal constants (and the sum).

Comment: @Dennis  Thanks will try it out and change

Comment: @Dennis I picked 19893 as the high value because `range(19892,0x4DB5+1)` gave me `[19892, 19893]`

Comment: In Python 2, range is a list automatically. You can save 6 bytes with that. You can also save one byte on the print statement, taking off the last parenthesis and the first open one. from random import* can save one byte on your random.shuffle(l), since the 'random.' part won't be needed.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the tips.  Implemented.

Comment: Task 2 seems to be missing the prime check.

Comment: @Dennis fixed now I think

Answer (score 4):

## Task 2, J, 10 bytes

```
1&p:*/@,#:
```

Prepends a boolean 0 or 1 if the input is prime to its binary representation, then takes the product. Works on the current version of J.

---

## Task 5, HTML, 45 bytes

```
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

---

## Task 6, fish, 53 bytes

```
test 0101 = (date '+%d%m');and echo 'Happy New Year!'
```

Based on the bash answer.

---

## Task 8, APL, 12 bytes

```
{(⍳⍴⍺)≡⍋⍵⍳⍺}
```

This is a function expression. It compares the order of characters found in the larger string with what would be expected if they were sorted.

---

## Task 9, K, 1 byte

```
*
```

Should work in any version. Arithmetic operations distribute over arrays.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25205/discussion-on-answer-by-tom-first-code-golf-decathlon).

Comment: Your code for task 8 doesn't work for `abc` `caxbxc`.

Answer (score 4):

### Task 1, Ruby, 40 bytes

```
def f n;(0..n-1).inject{|a,b|a+b**3};end
```

First time ever writing anything in Ruby. Tested with ruby 1.8.7.

---

### Task 2, R, 50 bytes

```
n=scan();p=log(n+1,2);!p%%1&sum(!n%%2:n,!p%%2:p)<3
```

Computes `p`, check if it is an integer, and if n and p are primes.

---

### Task 5, PostgreSQL, 54 bytes

```
SELECT'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis';
```

---

### Task 6, Lua, 55 bytes

```
print(os.date("%j")=="001" and "Happy New Year!" or "")
```

---

### Task 8, Python, 65 bytes

```
import re;f=lambda s,S:bool(re.search(re.sub(r'(.)',r'\1.*',s),S))
```

Usage:

```
>>> import re;f=lambda s,S:bool(re.search(re.sub(r'(.)',r'\1.*',s),S))
>>> f('abc','axbxcx')
True
>>> f('bac','axbxcx')
False
>>> f('abc','axdxcx')
False
>>> f('abc','abc')
True
```

---

### Task 10, Julia, 73 bytes

```
f(n)=print(" ______  "^n*"\n"*"|      | "^n*"\n"*(" ()--() ~"^n)[1:9n-1])
```

Thanks to @AlexA. for helping shortening this code! Example of outputs:

```
julia> f(0)




julia> f(1)
 ______  
|      | 
 ()--() 

julia> f(2)
 ______   ______  
|      | |      | 
 ()--() ~ ()--() 

julia> f(3)
 ______   ______   ______  
|      | |      | |      | 
 ()--() ~ ()--() ~ ()--()
```

Comment: For Task 2 you could use `log2`

Comment: I count 86 bytes currently for your Julia task 10. But you can get it to 81 by using a lambda function (i.e. replace `f(n)=` with `n->`) and changing `1:(9*n-1)` to simply `1:9n-1`.

Comment: Right I counted `\n` as 1 bytes, by habit.

Comment: Rather than `(" "*"_"^6*"  ")^n`, you can use `" ______ "^n` (likewise for the `|  |` part). 70 bytes: `n->print(" ______ "^n*"\n"*"|      | "^n*"\n"*(" ()--() ~"^n)[1:9n-1])`. (The whitespace between the bars isn't displaying here though)

Answer (score 3):

### Task 1, Haskell, 17 bytes

```
f x=(x*(x-1)/2)^2
```

---

### Task 2, Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
PrimeQ@#&&Mod[Log2[#+1],1]==0&
```

---

### Task 3, JavaScript, 46 bytes

```
function(x){return x.sort()[0|(x.length-1)/2]}
```

---

### Task 5, MATLAB, 47 bytes

```
'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis'
```

---

### Task 6, Ruby, 56 bytes

```
print Time.now.to_s[5,5]=="01-01"?"Happy New Year!":""
```

---

### Task 7, Python, 106 bytes (indenting with `\t`)

```
from random import*
s=''
while len(s)<64:
    c=unichr(randint(0x3400,0x4DB5))
    if c not in s:
        s+=c
print s
```

Note that straightforward usage of `list(set(s))` does **not** work here as this will cause a non-uniform probability distribution in the space of **all possible strings** due to re-ordering of list members.

---

Comment: @Dennis re task 7: Agreed on point 1, will fix whenever I have a chance. With regards to REPL, is there a rule against that?

Comment: Fine, all fixed now.

Comment: For 1, presumably you can do `(x*x-x)^2/4`?

Comment: Annoyingly, JavaScript's default sort function converts numbers to strings when comparing, so it only compares the first digit of every number. Therefore, it fails on [2,3,10].

Comment: In 7, you can actually put `if c not in s:s+=c` all on one line, saving a few characters. Also `0x3400` can be replaced with `13312`, which is one character shorter (and similarly for 0x4db5). Finally, it won't change the number of characters, but in case you don't like the tab indentation, you can indent with a single space instead.

Answer (score 3):

### Task 1, Python, 35 Bytes

```
lambda x:sum(_**3for _ in range(x))
```

### Task 3, CJam, 9 Bytes

```
q~$_,(2/=
```

### Task 4, JavaScript, <s>55</s> 53 Bytes

```
function(n){s=0xAAAAAAAA;return((n+s)^s).toString(2)}
```

### Task 5, Pyth, 46 Bytes

```
"pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

### Task 6, C#, 65 Bytes

```
string c(){return DateTime.Now.DayOfYear<2?"Happy New Year!":"";}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Task 1, Haskell, 15 bytes

```
f n=(n*n-n)^2/4
```

### Task 2, Julia, 28 bytes

```
n->(isprime(n)&&ispow2(n+1))
```

### Task 3, Octave, 30 bytes

```
@(x)sort(x)(ceil(length(x)/2))
```

### Task 5, [Yacas](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/homepage.html), 45 bytes

```
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

### Task 6, Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
If[DateList[][[{2,3}]]=={1,1},Happy New Year!]
```

### Task 9, PARI/GP, 10 bytes

```
(n,a)->n*a
```

Answer (score 3):

### Task 2, x86 masm, 40 bytes

```
C7 45 FC FF FF 07 00 B9 
00 00 00 00 B8 02 00 00 
00 D3 E0 3B 45 FC 7D 03 
41 EB F1 B8 02 00 00 00
D3 E0 48 3B 45 FC 75 13
```

(excluding header, MessageBox, etc - only relevant bytes)

```
include     \masm32\include\user32.inc  
includelib  \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
    ClassName   db "Mersenne Prime Found",0
.data?

.code
start proc
    LOCAL IsMersenne: DWORD
    mov IsMersenne, 524287 ; put number to test in this input
    mov ecx, 0
l00p:
    mov eax, 2
    shl eax, cl
    cmp eax, IsMersenne
    jge br3ak
    inc ecx
    jmp l00p
br3ak:
    mov eax,2                                                                                     
    shl eax, cl 
    dec eax
    cmp eax, IsMersenne                                                           
    jnz n0pr1me                                                              
    invoke MessageBox, 0, addr ClassName, addr ClassName, 40h
n0pr1me:
    ret
start endp
end start
```

---

### Task 3, C, 136 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h> 
int C(void*A,void*B){return(*(int*)A-*(int*)B);} 
main(){int S=4;int A[]={3,1,2,4};qsort(A,S,4,C);printf("%i",A[((S&1)?S:S-1)/2]);}
```

Compile using `gcc -o Prime main.c`

---

### Task 10, C++, 478 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
void D(int Z){int L=9,i,X=0;const char*A=" ______  ";const char*B="|      | ";const char* C = " ()--() ~ ";char*P=(char*)malloc(27*Z+5);for(i=0;i<Z-1;i++){if(!i){memcpy(P,A,L);X+=L;}memcpy(&P[X],A,L);X+=L;if(i==Z-2){memcpy(&P[X],"\n",1);X++;}}for(i=0;i<Z;i++){memcpy(&P[X],B,L);X+=L;if(i==Z-1){memcpy(&P[X],"\n",1);X++;}}for(i=0;i<Z;i++){memcpy(&P[X],C,L);X+=L;if(i==Z-1)P[X-1]='\0';}printf("%s\n",P);free(P);}
main(){D(15);}
```

Compile using `g++ -o Trucks main.cpp`

C & C++ can be shortened but it'd add compiler error. Don't know the exact rules so I tried to leave code w/no compiler errors.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Compiler warnings can be safely ignored, as long as the compiler produces a usable binary.

Comment: In code golf, a C compiler will warn you that it can be golfed further by *not* producing a warning.

Comment: Ignore the warnings - and feel, er, _free_ to leak as much memory as you wish, too.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Task 3, Clip, 13 bytes

```
gHk[tivt}l`sk
```

Another version:

```
gHkci`v``l`sk
```

The `` ` `` seemed to cost too much.

### Task 4, KSFTgolf, 16 bytes

```
g:]2%:)-2/:;xgpc
```

[The interpreter is here.](https://github.com/KSFTmh/KSFTgolf) I'm not sure what I am doing... It will print the negabinary and then crash.

There is a bug in the interpreter. Or I'll be able to golf it down to 12 bytes using built-in base conversion (but it only work with positive integers):

```
2*02-ba'Z=;x
```

Original CJam version:

```
qi{_1&_@^-2/}h;]W%
```

I tried Pip, Ostrich, Clip and Burlesque to find out if there is an esolang with built-in negabinary. None of them worked. KSFTgolf used `numpy`, which seemed to have some convienent weird behavior when the base is negative. But it's not easy to make it work with non-positive numbers.

### Task 7, CJam, 15 bytes

```
'䶶,DAm<>mr64<
```

### Task 8, APL, 21 bytes

```
∨/↑{⍺∧0,2∧/∨\⍵}/⌽⍞=↓⍞
```

[Try it online.](http://tryapl.org/?a=%27abc%27%7B%u2228/%u2191%7B%u237A%u22270%2C2%u2227/%u2228%5C%u2375%7D/%u233D%u237A%3D%u2193%u2375%7D%27axbxc%27&run)

Comment: Lol @ "I'm not sure what I am doing"

Comment: The question wasn't very clear about this, but my intention was that the code for task 4 should handle input 0. The version without built-in base conversion seems to handle it just fine.

Comment: @Dennis Fixed. But what if I chose to use unary?

Comment: Using some fixed offset or 2's complement could work. I'd also accept a sign followed by a unary number.

Answer (score 2):

### Task 1, Cjam, 7 bytes

```
q~,:+_*
```

Edit: Just noticed martin posted this before me. I'll try something else...

### Task 3, Python, 30 bytes

```
lambda l:sorted(l)[~-len(l)/2]
```

Python 2.

### Task 5, ///, 45 bytes

```
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

[///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////) will just echo something without any `/` characters.

### Task 7, Pyth, 19 bytes

```
s>64.SmC+13312d6582
```

Program. Please tell me if I mucked up the maths. [Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%3E64.SmC%2B13312d6582&debug=0)

### Task 9, Octave, 9 bytes

```
@(a,n)a*n
```

Anonymous function handle. Octave automatically does this with matrix * scalar.

Comment: For task 7, it has to be unique.

Comment: Yeah, pyth has `.S` shuffle, and you can use `s`um instead of `jk`.

Answer (score 2):

### Task 1, jq, 24 bytes

```
[range(1;.)|.*.*.]|add+0
```

### Task 6, PostgreSQL, 54 bytes

```sql
select'Happy New Year!'where'001'=to_char(now(),'DDD')
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found time to attempt them all, but here's a start

## Task 1, dc, 8 bytes

```
d1+*d*4/
```

Input and output to top of stack, as per `dc` convention.

## Task 5, Emacs Lisp, 46 bytes

```
'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

Abuse of the rules:

```
grep 'pn.*v' /usr/*/*/brit*-large
```

The best I could manage by unpacking from compressed form
was 55, in Perl:

```
unpack("H45",'uïFVóÙ¤¼g°0Æö<¥le°°')=~y/0-9bdf/i-v/r
```

(non-printable chars above get garbled by SE, but as it's not actually my answer, I'm not fixing it)

## Task 6, SQL, 54 bytes

```
SELECT IF(now()LIKE'%-01-0_%','Happy New Year!','Hi');
```

I consider the first ten days of January to be 'appropriate' days for
this greeting, but you can adjust to taste.  The `now() LIKE` construct works out shorter than extracting day-of-year with `DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%j')`.

## Task 10, sed, 58 bytes

```
s/./ ()--() ~/g;s/.$//;h;y/()-~/___ /;p;g;y/ ()-~/|    /;G
```

Input in unary.

Comment: `strstr` seaches for substrings, not subsequences. I'm afraid task 5 is kolmogorov-complexity, so fetching the word from a dictionary might be clever, but it's not allowed.

Comment: Thanks.  I misunderstood the subsequence one.  I'll do an alternative task 5, but it's very boring.

Comment: There are a few interesting solutions to task 5, but nobody posted a *short* one so far.

Answer (score 1):

### Task 1, CJam, 10 bytes

```
li,{3#}%:+
```

[Try Here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li%2C%7B3%23%7D%25%3A%2B&input=5)

### Task 5, Retina, 46 bytes

```
<empty>
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

Answer (score 1):

## Task 5, [MarioGolf](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/mariogolf), 50 bytes

This was a language I've developed for some time.

The current version has enough functionality to allow to run this challenge.

```
Y|<pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis|O
```

You can try it online on http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismael-miguel/mariogolf/master/js/testpage.html#c:Y|<pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis|O

Currently, the development is stopped and the implementation is incomplete.

The latest commit was on 13th March 2015.

## Task 6, PHP, 37 bytes

This one is really easy, and fun!

```php
<?=date(jn)==11?'Happy New Year!':'';
```

## Task 10, Javascript, 121 byes

Yeah, not so golfed...

But it does the job!

```
console.log((' ______  '.repeat(i=prompt()))+'\n'+('|      | '.repeat(i))+'\n'+(' ()--() ~'.repeat(i).replace(/~$/,'')));
```

Try it:

```js
//Required to show the console messages on the document
console._RELAY_TO_DOC = true;

console.log((' ______  '.repeat(i=prompt()))+'\n '+('|      | '.repeat(i))+'\n '+(' ()--() ~'.repeat(i).replace(/~$/,'')));
```

```html
<script src="http://ismael-miguel.github.io/console-log-to-document/files/console.log.min.js"></script>
```

The code won't display well in the stack snippet due to it starting with `"` in the output. Adicional spaces were added to compensate it.

The original code can be executed on Chrome's console without any problem, and the output will be the expected.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you! I misread the task 5. I'm still looking on how I'll implement the other tasks, but I'm having a bad time.

Comment: Are you sure about `date(dM)`? Here it returns “25Jun”. (locale set to en_US) Maybe “j” and ”n“ would serve better, as “d” and “m” returns the values 0 padded to width 2.

Comment: @manatwork You are correct. It was my mistake. That you for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

## Task 1, Octave, 15 bytes

```
@(n)(n^2-n)^2/4
```

EDIT: I thought I added this but it seems I forgot to save: This uses the fact that `sum(1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3) = sum(1+2+3+...+n)^2 = [n*(n+1)/2]^2`

## Task 3, Javascript, 24 bytes

```
x=>x.sort()[x.length>>1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's get the easy stuff done first:

### Task 5, ASP, 45 bytes

```
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

### Task 6, JavaScript, 46 bytes

```
/an 01/.test(Date())&&alert("Happy New Year!")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Task 1, VBA, 126 bytes

```
Function f(n As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        f = f + i ^ 3
        Next i
End Function
```

I haven't got a clue how to golf in VBA. I didn't type a single space, VBA automatically insert whitespaces. `=f(5)` in a cell in Excel will display 100.

## Task 2, Octave, 32 Bytes

```
@(n)isprime(n)&~mod(log2(n+1),1)
```

## Task 5, Golfscript, 47 bytes

```
"pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"
```

## Task 9, MATLAB, 9 bytes

```
@(A,n)A*n
```

Well, it's a start...