# How's your string theory?

Tags: string, code-challenge, logic, multiple-holes

Back to the basics! You're in you comp sci class again, except wiser and golfier. You have the tools, you have the power… but do you have the *skill*? Probably.

## Crash Course for the non-Computer Scientist (skip if you don't need it)

A string is symbolically represented by an arbitrary letter (usually, for our purposes, will be [image] etc. Of course, we know a string as something like `"Hello, World!"` or `'Hello, World!'`, or, if you're the snarky Python user, `"""Hello, World!"""`.

An alphabet can be thought of as a set (i.e. no repeating characters) of symbols, of which strings can be made. For example, [image]; this is the binary alphabet, of which contains strings like [image] and [image].  These strings can said to be *strings over [image]*, or, alternatively, [image].

The length of any string is denoted [image]. For example, [image].

There is the empty or null string [image], which is equivalent to `""`. It is a valid string in over any alphabet. In other words, [image] is the unique string satisfying the property [image].

The set [image] is the set of all strings [image] over [image] for which [image].

The set [image] is called the *Kleene closure* of [image], and is the set of all strings over [image]. This can be considered the *language of [image]*.

The concatenation of two strings [image] and [image] is denoted [image], and is the string containing the characters of [image] followed by the characters of [image].

[image] is said to be a prefix of [image] if there is some string [image] that satisfies the equality [image]. (If [image], then [image] is said to be a proper prefix of [image].)

The alphabet of a string [image] is denoted [image], and is the minimal alphabet [image] so that [image] is a string over [image]

The projection of a string [image] relative to an alphabet [image] is defined as

[image]

and is essentially the removal of all characters in [image] not in [image].

---

## TL;DR

**Objective** Write a program, series of functions, series of programs etc. that can calculate as many of the following tasks as possible:

- (1) Calculate, given a string `s`, its length.
- (2) Arrive at, given a string `s` and an alphabet `Σ`, whether or not (output a truthy/falsy value) that string is over said alphabet.
- (1) Given an alphabet, arrive at whether or not (output a truthy/falsy value) the alphabet is valid (a valid alphabet can have no repeating characters, but is otherwise valid).
- (4) Given an alphabet `Σ` and a positive integer `n`, display [image].
- (6) Given an alphabet `Σ` and an integer `n`, display the first `n` entries in [image] (Remember that `ε ∈ Σ`!)
- (1) Given a string `s` and a string `t`, output `st`.
- (3) Given a string `s`, output `Al(s)`.
- (5) Given a string `s` and an alphabet `Σ`, output `πΣ(s)`.

Input is given by a string or your language's closest equivalent for a string input, an array, tuple, or *n*-ordinate of characters for an alphabet  (your language's closest equivalent), and a number for a number (or your language's closest equivalent, heaven forbid your language does not support numbers!).

Each task has a score (the number in parenthesis). Your submission's score is calculated as follows:

```
        sum points scored
score = —————————————————
         length of bytes
```

***Highest*** score wins.

### Bonuses

- ×4 final score iff you output (with the correct symbols!) the input query. E.g., outputting `\pi_{\{0,1\}}(012345678910111213)=01101111` for an input of `Σ = [0,1]; s = 012345678910111213`. (You may choose to do this in either HTML or (La)TeX. Either counts.)
- (I'm open to suggestions.)

Comment: Also, for the bonus, how would you notate the third or sixth challenges?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ There is currently no incentive to solve more than 1 challenge, because any challenge with a worse ratio will give a lower score. The scoring system needs to be changed to make this challenge work. I would recommend making it `points/length` for each problem, and then sum the scores for each problem completed. Most points wins.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That's almost there, but not quite. The point is that answering additional challenges should always improve your score. So you should sum the scores of each challenge, not compute an overall points number.

Comment: This is a situation in which the sandbox would have been handy to sort out issues prior to posting.

Comment: @isaacg actually, you can share code between the challenges.

Comment: For (6) is there a specific order required? I.e. what are the first elements of an infinite set?

Comment: For the bonus, is using unicode characters directly (and not HTML entities) also okay?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes.

Comment: The scoring has not really changed with the latest edits. It's now the inverse of what it was originally, and the highest wins. This changes the scores, but not the order of them. If somebody had score `s1` before, which was lower than score `s2`, the new scores are now `1 / s1` and `1 / s2`, where the first score is higher.

Comment: @RetoKoradi What do you suggest?

Comment: Task 6, the first `n` seems meaningless for a `set`. Do you mean `any n`?

Comment: I assume the order is meant to be lexicographical @edc65

Comment: @Mauris A lexicographical order requires an order on the alphabet. And we don’t know the alphabet.

Comment: How do we parse "complete **anything** for the challenge?" Is JavaScript's built-in string type unsuitable for [1] because it has a `.length` property and therefore completes something for the challenge? Or is it merely forbidden to use that property? If our programming language contains lazy generators can we require that the $\Sigma$ "input" be the generator for $\Sigma^*$ ?

Comment: @CRDrost For the former, it is acceptable. For the latter, I said that `Input is given by the most convenient method that does not complete anything for the challenge. E.g., you can accept a string for the first challenge, but not the length of the string.` Specifically, the use of an input that effectively solves the problem is forbidden.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I mean, I view "effectively solves the problem" as vague in these scenarios where interconversion is so trivial, which is why I'm asking you to clarify.

Comment: @CRDrost Thanks for clarifying your problem. It is a tad vague. I will disambiguate

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ OK. I posted a new entry while you were revising that but it was invalidated by your rules change, so I have put its heading in strikethrough font; I think it might be worth keeping it for historical reasons.

Comment: 0 counts as falsy in all languages, right?

Comment: @dorukayhan It depends on the language. Typically, if code inside an `if` statement runs with a value as a condition, the value is considered truthy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [multi-part challenge with insufficient interaction between the parts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8463/46076)

Comment: @pppery Thanks, but you’re retroactively applying a standard that wasn’t in place at the time the question was asked. Not really applicable

Comment: Rules about question on-topicness apply to questions that predate them. Othertwise, [First code golf decathlon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52152/46076) would never have been closed and locked. All that has happened is that this clearly off-topic question has slipped through the cracks for three years -- well, the time has come for that to be remedied.

Comment: @pppery Alright. I don't really care, not terribly invested in this site. Seems stupid and pedantic, but do whatever. Good luck getting this closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## APL, score 3

#### Task 7: 3 / 1

```
∪
```

This is a built-in that – according to [this discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7206) – can be considered an unnamed function.

Try it online on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%20%u2190%20%u222A%20%u22C4%20f%20%27abbcccdddd%27&run).

Comment: I don't know APL, so I'm just trying to understand: The meta discussion says that your code must **define** a function that was not defined before. Isn't this just **using** a built-in function? Does it actually define a new function?

Comment: The accepted answer says that `sum` would be a valid Python answer (if it did what asked for), and the comments clarify that J/APL built-ins are valid for the same reason. `∪` is like an anonymous function, which you can name via `f←∪`.

Answer (score 3):

I think, under the current scoring system, my best score is:

## Pyth, 5/3

```
@wz
```

Task 8

---

## Pyth, 295/42 ~ 7.024

#### Task 1: 1/2

```
lz
```

#### Task 2: 2/4

```
!-wz
```

#### Task 3: 1/3

```
.{z
```

#### Task 4: 4/3

```
^zQ
```

#### Task 5: 6/7

```
<s^LzQQ
```

Warning: Extremely slow.

#### Task 6: 1/3

```
+zw
```

#### Task 7: 3/2

```
{z
```

#### Task 8: 5/3

```
@wz
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40wz&input=10632416234123984610932846102836410%0A012&debug=0)

Exactly two of these are not Pyth builtins, namely tasks 2 and 5.

Comment: Please revise to fit scoring criteria.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, score 64033/52668 = 1.215785676

```
StringLength
StringMatchQ[#,#2..]&
#==DeleteDuplicates@#&
""<>#&/@Tuples@##&
Table[""<>#&/@#~Tuples~i,{i,#2}]&
#<>#2&
Union@Characters@#&
""<>StringCases@##&
```

Comment: Of course. There's always a Mathematica answer for stuff like this!

Comment: Please revise to fit scoring criteria.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about `\[Function]`, but I think here you can save two bytes with `Table[""<>#&/@#~Tuples~i,{i,#2}]` (same number of characters, but no Unicode).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yeah, using the Unicode can be a good golfing strategy at times. Too bad that most of them are in the Private Use Area and can't be displayed normally...

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, score 1/2 = 0.5

> Challenge 1:
>
> ```
> lz
> ```
>
> [Try it out](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lz&debug=0)

Comment: Please revise to fit scoring criteria.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, score 3/3 = 1.00

Best score for the current definition of the scoring function counts only task 7:

```
r_&
```

This is a complete program, and scores 3 points with 3 bytes of code.

As bonus material, here are my solutions for all the tasks but task 5:

Task 1, score 1/2:

```
r,
```

Task 2, score 2/4:

```
rr-!
```

Task 3, score 1/5:

```
r__&=
```

Task 4, score 4/7:

```
rrim*S*
```

Task 6, score 1/2:

```
rr
```

Task 7, score 3/3:

```
r_&
```

Task 8: score 5/6:

```
rr_@--
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, score = 17 / 153 = 0.111

I've just started with the tasks, I'll try to solve all of them.

Task 1 (13 bytes):

```
a=->s{s.size}
```

Task 2 (33 bytes):

```
b=->s,a{s.chars.all?{|c|a[c]!=p}}
```

Task 3 (28 bytes):

```
c=->a{a.chars==a.chars.uniq}
```

Task 4 (88 bytes, awfully long...):

```
d=->a,n{a.chars.map{|e|e*=n}.join.chars.permutation.map(&:join).map{|e|e=e[0...n]}.uniq}
```

Tash 6 (12 bytes):

```
f=->s,t{s+t}
```

Task 7 (19 bytes):

```
g=->s{s.chars.uniq}
```

Task 8 (48 bytes):

```
h=->s,a{g='';s.chars.map{|c|a[c]==p ? 0:g+=c};g}
```

Comment: Please revise to fit scoring criteria.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Done, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon score 16/167 = 1/11 = 0.090909...

This code of length 176 defines for projection, size and the iterators, giving 5 + 1 + 4 + 6 = 16 points:

`import ceylon.language{S=String,B=Boolean}import ceylon.collection{H=HashSet}S al(S s)=>S(H{*s});B v(S s)=>s==al(s);S p(S a,S s)=>S(s.filter(a.contains));B i(S s,S a)=>s==p(a,s);S c(S s,S t)=>s+t;Integer(S)l=S.size;`

The alphabet is also provided in form of a string (a character iterable `{Character*}` would work just the same, but take more code space).

I did actually implement all of the functions, but the other ones took more length per point.

All of them formatted and commented:

```
import ceylon.language {
    S=String,
    I=Integer,
    B=Boolean
}

// minimal alphabet of a string → 3 points
// taken from http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59789/2338
S b(S s) => S { for (x->c in s.indexed) if (!c in s[0:x]) c };

// is the alphabet valid? → 1 point
// we simply check if it is its own minimal alphabet.
B v(S a) => a == b(a);

// project string to alphabet → 5 points
S p(S a, S s) => S(s.filter(a.contains));
//  S p(S a, S s) => S(s.filter((c)=>c in a));

// is string s over alphabet a? → 2 points
// we check if the string is its own projection.
B i(S a, S s) => s == p(a, s);

// concatenate → 1 point
S c(S s, S t) => s + t;

// length of a string → 1 point
// uses a different syntax than the usual I l(S s) => s.size, because it is slightly shorter. 
I(S) l = S.size;

// strings of length n over alphabet a → 4 points
{S*} x(S a)(I n) =>
// defined recursively.
        n == 0
        then { "" }
        else { for (s in x(a)(n - 1))
        for (c in a)
            S { c } + s };

// first n strings → 6 points
{S*} y(S a, I n) => expand((0..n).map(x(a))).take(n);
```

(I guess I could replace the `..` by `:` in the last line, but then the score wouldn't be so nice anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, score=1/3

If function is not allowed, this submission is invalid.

The best score is task 8 with score (5/16).

Task 1(1/6):

```
length
```

I somehow misread Prelude.

Task 2(2/13):

```
all.flip elem
```

First argument is alphabet, the second is string

Task 3(1/32):

```
c[]=2>1;c(x:xs)=all(/=x)xs&&c xs
```

Sigh, is is overly long.

Task 4(1/16):

```
_#0=[[]];x#y=concatMap(flip map$x#(y-1))$map(:)x
```

Task 5(1/12):

```
_#0=[[]];x#y=concatMap(flip map$x#(y-1))$map(:)x;n&k=take k.map(n#)[1..]
```

Task 6(1/4 or 1/2):

```
(++)
```

I don't know if the paratheses is allowed to be dropped in this case

Task 7(3/32 or 3/22 or 3/20):

It is same as delete duplicates

```
a[]=[];a(x:y)=x:(a$filter(\=x)y)
```

If using library is not cheating

```
import Data.List
a=nub
```

Or even drop the `a=`

Task 8(5/16):

For Haskell it is ridiculously easy.

```
filter.flip elem
```

Comment: Functions are allowed, you can drop the `a=` in task 7, dropping the parenteses should be fine, and in task 3 change `xs` to `y` or some other single letter.

Answer (score 1):

## <strike>Haskell, 5, possible cheating</strike>

(This was invalidated by a rules update.)

This strongly depends on how you interpret the minutiae of the grading rules.

```
$
```

I claim that this solves task 8 (5 points) in 1 byte for a reasonable interpretation of the inputs. I have asked for clarification and not really received much, so I am posting this solution in order to induce more discussion.

## The scope of the liberties I am taking

The freedom afforded to us is **not** "You have to use the most obvious thing that someone would use if they talked about a "string" in your language" but rather,

> Input is given by the most convenient method that does not complete anything for the challenge. E.g., you can accept a string for the first challenge, but not the length of the string.

I am choosing some methods as "convenient" which are convenient in two niche areas of programming. They do not "complete anything for the challenge" in the sense that neither one completes the challenge by itself, nor does the challenge have any well-defined subtasks (and if these challenges *did* have subtasks then builtins would likely be disallowed!).

### Stealing a lambda-calculus-style list

In lambda calculus the usual way that you encode a list is the Church encoding with direct reference to its `foldr`; a variant encoding will run the function on the empty list `[]`, it is constrained only in its output type and not in its function. In other words, `list_from_fn f = f (:); fn_from_list ls f = foldr f [] ls.` I think that this is relatively noncontroversial because this is in fact a usual way to think of a list in functional programming circles.

### Stealing a Clojure-transducer-style alphabet.

The specification of the alphabet is more contorted and may fall foul of the rather-vague rule. For my alphabet I find it quite convenient to use a filtering arrow, more precisely the sort of filtering arrow you'd see in the Kleisli representation of the List monad. So that requires maybe a bit of explaining: there are these functions from `a -> [b]` which are composed, in the Kleisli category, with the function `(.).concatMap`. A filtering arrow is the specific `a -> [a]` which has the form

```
filterArrow predicate a = if predicate a then [a] else []
```

So far, so good: an alphabet is equivalent to its filter which is equivalent to its filter arrow, which makes perfect sense in a certain class of applications. However, these applications ***are*** used in practice: the programming language Clojure a few years ago started a big hacker-media frenzy when they introduced this Kleisli category `a -> [b]` into mainline Clojure under the name "Transducers," with the only difference being that they were transformed with a bit of continuation-passing so that the order of the composition was reversed.

So both of those seem to be relatively straightforward and real programmers really use both.

### Where cheating may be occurring

However where I might be cheating is that I actually am expecting as "convenient" for the list function to be the *concatenating* foldr applied to the empty string, `(a -> [b]) -> [b]`. This is still 100% equivalent to a list, as evidenced by the isomorphism

```
list_from_fn f = f (:[]) 
fn_from_list ls f = foldr ((++).f) [] ls
```

however I do not have any prior art of its widespread usage to represent lists. It's quite possible that someone has done it before, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1):

## dc: `1k 1 1+2 3+/p`: 0.4 points

Strings `s` and `t`, as applicable, must be present on the top of the stack at execution time, with `s` topmost.

### Calculate length of string `s`: 1pt, 2B

```
Zp
```

### Concatenate `s` and `t`: 1pt, 3B

```
rnn
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, score: 8 / <strike>491</strike> <strike>467</strike> <strike>465</strike> 462 ~= 0.0173

I just wanted to see how many tasks I can figure out.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;interface a{static void main(String[]A){char[]Z=A[1].toCharArray();switch(A[0]){case"a":out.print(A[1].length());break;case"b":int b=1;for(char B:Z)b=A[2].contains(new String(c))?b:0;out.print(b>0);break;case"c":String B="";int c=1;for(char C:Z){c=B.contains(new String(C))?0:c;B+=C;}out.print(c>0);break;case"d":out.print(A[1]+A[2]);break;case"e":String C="";for(char d:Z)C+=C.contains(new String(d))?"":d;out.print(C);break;}}}
```

The program (ab)uses command line arguments to get the tasks done. Here's how it works (note that every argument should be enclosed in double quotes like `"arg1" "arg2" "arg3"`):

- If the first argument is `a`, the second argument's length is printed (calculates the length of a given string). Syntax: `a <string>`
- If the first argument is `b`, `true` is printed in case of the second argument being over the third argument, which is taken as an alphabet (given a string and an alphabet, find out if the string is over the alphabet). Syntax: `b <string> <alphabet>`
- If the first argument is `c`, `true` is printed if the second argument is a valid alphabet where every character occurs only once (given an alphabet, find out if it's valid). Syntax: `c <alphabet>`
- If the first argument is `d`, the concatenation of the second and third arguments is printed - the second argument comes first (given two strings, concatenate them). Syntax: `d <first string> <second string>`
- If the first argument is `e`, the smallest alphabet which the second argument is over is printed (given a string, find out its alphabet). Syntax: `e <string>`

Oh wait, let me ungolf the program for you:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
interface a {
    static void main(String[] A) {
        char[] Z = A[1].toCharArray();
        switch (A[0]) {
        case "a":
            out.print(A[1].length());
            break;
        case "b":
            int b = 1;
            for (char B : Z)
                b = A[2].contains(new String(c)) ? b : 0;
            out.print(b > 0);
            break;
        case "c":
            String B = ""; int c = 1;
            for (char C : Z){
                c = B.contains(new String(C)) ? 0 : c;
                B += C;
            }
            out.print(c > 0);
            break;
        case "d":
            out.print(A[1] + A[2]);
            break;
        case "e":
            String C = "";
            for (char d : Z)
                C += C.contains(new String(d)) ? "" : d;
            out.print(C);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 27 / 158 ≈ 0.1709

I tried for as many tasks as possible instead of the highest score possible.

```
from itertools import*
L=len
lambda s,a:all(c in a for c in s)
lambda a:L(set(a))==L(a)
permutations
str.__add__
set
lambda s,a:filter(a.__contains__,s)
```

#### Task 1:

```
L=len
```

Pretty self-explanatory. I assign it because it's used later, and naming it `L` saved 4 bytes.

#### Task 2:

```
lambda s,a:all(c in a for c in s)
```

This maps `s` to a list of boolean values telling if the corresponding character is in the string. If they are all `True`, then `s` is over `a`.

#### Task 3:

```
lambda a:L(set(a))==L(a)
```

Here's where I used that `len` rename. In Python, the `set` class is a container of unique objects, and if the constructor is given a container with duplicates, it removes them.

#### Task 4:

```
permutations
```

The Python library function `itertools.permutations` does *exactly* what is needed.

#### Task 5:

[nope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdf5n-zI14)

#### Task 6:

```
str.__add__
```

Shamelessly co-opting class methods. Not much else to say.

#### Task 7:

```
set
```

Once again, the beautiful uniquefying `set` comes in handy. Here, it automatically finds the minimal alphabet.

#### Task 8:

```
lambda s,a:filter(a.__contains__,s)
```

Filters out the characters in s `s` which are not also in `a`. Alternative with the same length: `[c for c in s if c in a]`