# Tips for golfing in Starry

Tags: code-golf, tips, starry

What general tips do you have for golfing in [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry)? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Starry (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64052/8478)

Comment: There's a book on esolangs -- how interesting!

Answer (score 2):

## Use `dup` and `add` for large numbers

If you need to produce a big but reasonable number which is a multiple of 2 (and in some cases, even not a multiple), you can push half the number and end with  `+*` (dup and add) instead of pushing the whole number. The threshold for this is **8** and above.

As mentioned, sometimes you can double, then subtract one (threshold **27**), and with multiples of higher 2 powers it can be repeated to gain greater numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fAQa0FbS19LgUkIG2HheqAEIljIWuBZtyZFPAerVx6dLW@/8fAA)