# Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

Some characters are more holy than others. Using as few unholy letters as possible, display the statement above.

**Challenge**

Write a full program to print `Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!` to STDOUT or closest alternative. If you can compress the input to reduce your score, go wild :)

**Input**

None

**Output**

```
Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

**Rules**

1. This is a [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), and lowest score wins
2. The desired output can be read from a file, but that should then be counted towards your total.
3. Trailing newlines are fine in the output
4. Standard loopholes and T&C's apply

**Scoring**

Your score is your byte count, plus some modifiers:

1. Using holy characters `0469abdegopqrADOPQR@#` count as 2 points each
2. Using extra holy characters `8B%$&` are 1 point (no penalty)
3. Using unholy characters `12357cfhijklmnstuvwxyzCEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ!"^*()[]{}-=_+|\/?,.<>:;'~` carries a heavier penalty and count as 10 points per character.
4. Space, tab and newlines are 1 point (no penalty).
5. Any other characters not listed are 10 points.

*On my keyboard the key '$' and '&' are extra holy. Where font variations cause a character to become unholy, defer to the list above

The unmodified string `Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!` scores **172**
Ruby: `puts "Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!"` scores **225**

**Score checker**

@DeadChex has kindly put together a [scoring script](https://jsfiddle.net/qj5vLesq/1/embedded/result/)

Please do let me know if I need to clarify anything. I will update the list of characters if necessary - I've only included the obvious keys at this point. The idea is simple enough though - holes in characters are good.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26167/discussion-on-question-by-denham-coote-holy-hole-in-a-donut-batman).

Comment: @Doorknob You removed 2 important comments. The one that I asked if `0` should be an extra-holy character or not. (And it's answer)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That appears to have been edited into the question.

Comment: Yes, it was there from the start. It was questioned (as it could technically be extra holy) but my keyboard was my reference and I felt it was too late to change it. 0 is holy, per rule 1. Thanks!

Comment: @Doorknob Excuse my ignorance but I can't seem to find such information in the question.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it's point 1) in the scoring rules. First character in '0469abdegopqrADOPQR'

Comment: ... That still didn't reflect the comment I left ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 21 bytes, score 141

```
`¤∞ ∵⁽ In A DoṖ₃, Ṙ↳!
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%C2%A4%E2%88%9E%20%E2%88%B5%E2%81%BD%20In%20A%20Do%E1%B9%96%E2%82%83%2C%20%E1%B9%98%E2%86%B3!&inputs=&header=&footer=)

A compressed string.

Despite various attempts, I haven't found anything better than this :P

The score is 108 if you count the Unicode holy characters (`¤∞ṖṘ`) as holy.

Comment: Nice! Can you explain how this works for those of us (like me) that have no idea?

Comment: @DenhamCoote Vyxal's compressed string format is simply replacing pairs of non-ASCII characters with words from a dictionary. For example, `¤∞` decompresses to `Holy` and `∵⁽` decompresses to `Hole`. That's pretty much it :P

Comment: Also, as they're unfortunately not listed in the original scoring criteria, this submission would do extra well if the non-listed (yet still holy and extra-holy) characters were counted appropriately. (¤,∞,Ṗ,Ṙ - assume you counted those as 10 points and not 1/2 each?)

Comment: @DenhamCoote I didn't even think about that. I'll add that the score changes if you count those.

Comment: An excellent (unofficial) score in that case, well done.  As the higher score still beats out the previous best, I will accept your submission as the accepted answer. (It's been a while since I've been active on the site, is that still the right thing to do?)

Answer (score 36):

## Unary, 109,700,689,123,880,793,751,483,665,383,781,675,730,387,604,429,204,978,112,223,950,724,553,435,005,885,707,908,578,678,850,861,879,910,670,154,149,244,112,969,597,673,955,700,447,838,276,456,862,280,889,656,901,703,351,515,963,083,297,978,322,224,548,248,606,910,210,200,102,145,647,654,537,444,488,063,149,647,173,155,335,488,014,867,140,385,453,547,997,132,573,700,942,612,360 points

<sub>Calculated through [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) which is the highest precision calculator that I know of</sub>

Code:

```
54850344561940396875741832691890837865193802214602489056111975362276717502942853954289339425430939955335077074622056484798836977850223919138228431140444828450851675757981541648989161112274124303455105100051072823827268722244031574823586577667744007433570192726773998566286850471306180 zeros
```

<sub>4.5x10<sup>259</sup> Yottabytes</sub>

Well this ain't winning

Comment: If we interpret "lowest score wins" as "closest score to zero wins", and we interpret "closest" as "least 2-adic norm", then this answer would win. Unfortunately, we aren't.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't get it...

Comment: Did you seriously save this to your hard drive? An online converter is telling me this takes `4.87e268` *petabytes* of disk space...

Comment: Lucky that `0` is a holy character. Otherwise your score would have been a lot higher. (You can use [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) for extra holy characters and you don't need the extra opening `1` in the binary there.)

Comment: How does this work? I don't seem to understand.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez tldr BF with each operand converted to a 3 digit binary, put a 1 at the very start, then convert that large binary to unary.

Comment: @ThomasKwa as far as I can tell, this score (which ends in `612360`) is divisible by `8` but not by `16`.  So if anyone's score is divisible by `16`, then their score would be closer to `0` in the `2`-adic metric than this one is. (Currently kirbyfan64sos has a Pyth score of `352`, which is divisible by `32`, which looks like it would be the leader under this norm.) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNumber.html

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos There is [Golunar](//esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar), which can be used to heavily compress the zeroes.

Comment: Can you replace `0` with `8` to make this 1 point per char?

Comment: Note: You don't need to save this to the disk. Just modify the interpreter and input the number `109,700,689,123,880,793,751,483,665,383,781,675,730,387,604,429,204,978,112,223,950,724,553,435,005,885,707,908,578,678,850,861,879,910,670,154,149,244,112,969,597,673,955,700,447,838,276,456,862,280,889,656,901,703,351,515,963,083,297,978,322,224,548,248,606,910,210,200,102,145,647,654,537,444,488,063,149,647,173,155,335,488,014,867,140,385,453,547,997,132,573,700,942,612,360`

Answer (score 30):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>154</s> <s>153</s> <s>148</s> 143 points

```
" 
$&	 &
&$&% 


 %		B8B$
	 $8	
%8%8&	 	$&
 &
8
8 $B$ 	$&B8$$$B
"0$0$&$f#8b90b' f+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#FcqhEcAwDARBrK9C47wUEGL4oSrFwP13oDjwZq@Hg2meSGY4AA@zUhHmlCEUOm5MnEmQs/hniWRhTE4m96X1znX7fro/)

#### How it works

```
" 
$&  &
&$&% 


 %      B8B$
     $8    
%8%8&       $&
 &
8
8 $B$     $&B8$$$B
"

      e# Push a string of encoded base 8 digits.

0$0$  e# Push two copies of that string.
&     e# Intersect the copies to remove duplicates.
$     e# Sort the resulting string.
      e# Pushes "\t\n $%&8Bb".

f#    e# Replace each char of the original string by its index in "\t\n $%&8Bb".
      e# Pushes 213502515354211124007673102360146465020351251616237320357633371,
      e# to be understood as an array of single-digit integers.

8b90b e# Convert from base 8 digits to base 90 digits.

' f+  e# Add each base 90 digit to the code point of the space character.
      e# Pushes the desired string.
```

Comment: *scratches head* Wow, how does this work?!

Comment: Look forward to it, thanks :-)

Comment: CJam never fails to amaze and confuse me.

Comment: So 143 is the score to beat! I'll accept this on Wednesday (1 week after first posting) if it's still in the lead. :)

Answer (score 23):

## BrainF***, 3140 points

Behold, the language of **unholiness**!

```
-[------->+<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.---.-[--->+<]>.-[---->+<]>++.++++[->++<]>.-[--->+<]>++.---.-------.--[--->+<]>-.++++[->++<]>+.+[--->+<]>.-[->+++++<]>-.[->++<]>+.-[-->+<]>.++[->++<]>.[--->+<]>+++.-.+++++++.-.[++>---<]>--.------------.+[->++<]>.[-->+++<]>--.--[--->+<]>-.-------.------------.+++++++++++++.-[->+++++<]>.
```

Comment: You can use [Headsecks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks) if you want to choose the holy road.

Comment: @randomra I already did 40 minutes before you commented. See below. :D

Answer (score 19):

### Malbolge, <s>1874</s> 1239

```
(=<`$9]~6;Y327U5v-Qr*Np-&J$#jFg}Cdd@>`O<t]KZp6Wm3US0QPfe**(:9I^$o"`CkW{>Txv:99'`6oo2m1YXiggAed>P&N^?!\IlY3ExTBARc10/_nJ8IG(X&Dfec@~av<]\r8Zon4UTj0Rmfe+Lha`&HFED!BX]VzZ=Rv9UNrLKo2Hk
```

I'm pretty sure this can be golfed more. Will try running this for longer. I want to get sub 1000...

I've found shorter length programs (down to 175 I think it was), but the score was higher... Sad. Currently on a 179 length (180 is current) with 4 points less, not sure if editing for that short little bit.

Comment: Even the Doom guy would cower at the thought of *golfing flippin' Malbolge*...

Comment: Hmm, a Malbolge answer. Can you talk us through how it works...? ;)

Comment: @trichoplax sure. How detailed do you want it? It doesn't really do much apart from crazy operators in a straight line, then output them.

Comment: I was joking because Malbolge is reputed to be unreadable. So you're finding programs by leaving a search running, but you can actually understand what they do too?

Comment: @trichoplax I can understand the basic prints because of how it operates. It does a crazy thing (literally its name) then prints out one character at a time.

Comment: It might help to post the code with the first layer of encryption reversed. It's kind-of hard to explain what Malbolge programs are doing, often, but that step tends to make things more readable in most cases.

Comment: Hello World programs are the only type I could ever see Malbolge entries on. Because doing *literally anything else* is virtually impossible. +1 for the language use, good sir.

Answer (score 17):

## sed, <s>169</s> 166 points

```
s&$&\to#y \to#e I% A Do%u8, Ba8ma%!&
y&\t#8%&Hltn&
```

I've counted each `\t` as a single point, since it can be replaced with an actual tabulator.

[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=cyYkJglvI3kgCW8jZSBJJSBBIERvJXU4LCBCYThtYSUhJgp5JgkjOCUmSGx0biY&input=)

#### How it works

- Both commands use the extra holy `&` as delimiter.
- The first command replace the end of the (empty) pattern space with the string `\to#y \to#e I% A Do%u8, Ba8ma%!`.
- The second command replaces `\t`, `#`, `8` and `%` with the unholy `H`, `l`, `t` and `n`, respectively.

Because of the penalty for unholy characters, transliteration adds 12 bytes but saves 20 points.

Comment: Man, you have this challenge figured out.

Answer (score 14):

## PHP, <del>175</del> <del>168</del> <del>163</del> <del>160</del> 159 points

I did what I could to reduce the score as much as possible.
With the help of [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis), the score was reduced by 5 points.

```php
echo BeeABBeeoBodBaBdOdPQBBgDQgDdp^"\n\n\t8b\n\n\t\nb&\nb b  \n%%nb%%%\n%\nQ";
```

Yeah, not exactly short...

Replace the `\n` and `\t` with a UNIX-style newline and a tab, respectivelly.

To execute it, simply run it with the -r switch ([not counted on the score](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags/2428#2428))

---

Here's a shorter one that is only 256 points:

```php
<?=$a=Hol,"y {$a}e In A Donut, Batman!";
```

Answer (score 10):

## HTML, 169 points

```html
Holy Hole In A Donut&#44 Batman!
```

That's the only character that had a decimal numeric entity with only holed numbers.

(In the HTML specification, entities must be followed by a semicolon but it still works in major browsers without one.)

Comment: Took me a while to realise how this works out a lower score than hardcoding - I'd forgotten about the comma... +1

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript, 1337 Points

```
for(B="&$8$$&8$%&8&&%8$&%8&$8$$&8$%&8$$8$&%8&&8$$$8$&%8%8$&%8$%8$$&8$$$8&%&8&%$8$&%8$8%8&%$8$$%8%8$$$8$&%8".split("8"),$="",i=0;i<B.length;i++)$+=toDec(s[i]);alert($.split("P").join(" ").toLowerCase().replace(/\b(\s\w|^\w)/g,function($){return $.toUpperCase()})+"!");
```

This takes advantage of the face that there are 26 letters in the alphabet, and 26 characters can be represented by three digits of ternary (base-3) numbers 0, 1, and 2, here represented by `%$&` respectively.

Split that enormous string up at each '8' (I use it as a delimiter because it's extra-holy, spaces would have worked too), convert to a base-3 integer by replacement (`0` becomes `%`, `1` becomes `$`, `2` becomes `&`), convert that to decimal (`%%&` = `2`), and then put the string back together. Add 65 (the `char` value of the letter `A`) and convert each integer to a character, A-Z. Lastly, convert to title-case, and add in punctuation.

An easier-to-read unminified version:

```
B ="&$8$$&8$%&8&&%8$&%8&$8$$&8$%&8$$8$&%8&&8$$$8$&%8%8$&%8$%8$$&8$$$8&%&8&%$8$&%8$8%8&%$8$$%8%8$$$8$&%8".split('8')
    $=''
    for (i = 0;i<B.length;i++) {
        $ += toDec(s[i])
    };
    alert($.split('P').join(' ').toLowerCase().replace(/\b(\s\w|^\w)/g, function (t) { return t.toUpperCase(); })+ "!");
```

**Sure it's goofy.** But it was a fun idea to play around with anyhow!

Comment: `alert("Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!")` has a score of 238...

Comment: I saw the 'extra-holy characters' line and thought, *'hm... No way I'd win this... But I have an interesting idea......'* Kids, don't play with base-3.

Comment: also... until you post that one, I'm still winning for javascript answers ;D

Comment: @j6m8 Nah, it's so trivial. Your goal should be to beat it, whether it's posted or not.

Comment: Remove the quotes in `split("8")`.

Comment: *looks at score* I see what you did there.

Answer (score 8):

### Whitespace, 438 points

If you see nothing, then it's because of whitespace!

Reading about "*4. Space, tab and newlines are 1 point (no penalty).*" brings me to my choice of language:

- S = Space
- T = Tab
- L = Line feed

[Start of code]

```
S S S T S S T   S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   S S T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S T   S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S S T   S T L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S T   S S T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S S S S T L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S S T S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   S T S T L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   S T S S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S S S T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S S S S T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   S T S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S T L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S S S S T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S S S S T   L
T   L
S S L
L
L
```

[End of code]

Comment: Trying to copy and paste this just results in 62 linefeeds. Could you include a hexdump or a version with placeholders for tab and space?

Comment: Yes, i got trouble with them. But now you can see the invisible whitespace ;)

Comment: For anyone who is bored to remove those `STL`s, paste the code in the answer to the right of [this](http://slashes.tryitonline.net#code=L1MvLy9ULy8vTC8v) /// script (but not in the STDIN or an argument). This way, you can reinstate invisibility!

Comment: I knew there was going to be a Whitespace answer just as I saw that scoring method.

Answer (score 7):

## Batch, 197 points

```
echo Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

`c` and `h` are the only two extra characters that aren't holy - and since batch doesn't require quotes round strings, I miss out the 20 point penalty there.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, this doesn't produce the correct output if placed in a batch script and then run. You need to preface the line with an `@` resulting in +2 to your score. Alternatively, running this directly from the command prompt works just fine.

Comment: @dohaqatar7 To be roughly as pedantic, it's still Batch, even outside of a Batch script file, much like writing Ruby into IRB is still writing Ruby.

Answer (score 7):

## [Headsecks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks), <s>333</s> 470

I converted my BF program to Headsecks using as many Extra Holy characters as possible. Much holier than BF.

Since vertical tabs apparently cost 10, switched to `#`.

Note: Probably still a better score than if I hadn't used loops.

```
#&#######8B o8#$#&###8B    o8BB$###$#&###8B o8$#&####8B    o8BB$BBBB&#8BB o8$#&###8B  o8BB$###$#######$##&###8B    o8#$BBBB&#8BB o8B$B&###8B  o8$#&#8BBBBB  o8#$&#8BB o8B$#&##8B   o8$BB&#8BB o8$&###8B    o8BBB$#$BBBBBBB$#$&BB8###  o8##$############$B&#8BB o8$&##8BBB    o8##$##&###8B    o8#$#######$############$BBBBBBBBBBBBB$#&#8BBBBB  o8$
```

Answer (score 6):

## Z80 assembler, <del>539</del> 523 points

```
ld hl,Q
L: ld a,(hl)
or a
ret z
call 0A2h
inc hl
jr L
Q: db "Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!",0
```

Note that this is intended to run on [a MSX computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX), whose BIOS routine CHPUT, located at address 00A2h, prints the character passed in the accumulator without modifying any register.

(How could the score be calculated by using the assembled binary, by the way?) :-P

Comment: Can machine code be considered a programming language?

Comment: If you're masochist enough... sure! :-)

Comment: But then what encoding would you use to represent the bytes? Also, if you ship that way it seems your choice of a 8-bit CPU would make real sense.

Comment: What encoding? Hexadecimal or base-64, perhaps binary... whichever you find to be the funniest!

Comment: [Mikkel Alan Stokkebye Christia](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41570/mikkel-alan-stokkebye-christia) suggested replacing `M` by `Q` to save some points.

Comment: Indeed! Code edited. Thanks!

Comment: @Mindwin - it's not Machine Code but Machine Langauge. Also, if you're not going over an 8-bit boundary, couldn't you just `inc l` rather than `inc hl`?

Answer (score 6):

## [Insomnia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/41868#41868), 168 points

```
  doe
@opp@e p@ pp
@d
dr$%p$ opp@ p@rop@@%  @oe@@
do@ %@pr$% 
@ r$
%
po
@ 
@dp
@@ep@  d
@% %@d
@@% p@
d
@
```

Only managed to do 1 point better than HTML solution.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 182 points

```
"Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

It's not my strongest language. I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: I don't know Pyth, but you could compress the string and maybe get a better score

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 352 points

```
jkmCid2c::"B88B888 BB8BBBB BB8BB88 BBBB88B B88888 B88B888 BB8BBBB BB8BB88 BB88B8B B88888 B88B88B BB8BBB8 B88888 B88888B B88888 B888B88 BB8BBBB BB8BBB8 BBB8B8B BBB8B88 B8BB88 B88888 B8888B8 BB8888B BBB8B88 BB8BB8B BB8888B BB8BBB8 B8888B"\8\0\B\1d
```

I tried to be smart and encode the string as extra holy characters. That did not work too well...

Answer (score 2):

## [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 232 points

`␀` represents a literal null byte `\x00`, which is unholy.

```
<[.<]␀!namtaB ,tunoD A nI eloH yloH
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, noncompeting

#### 84 points

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=wrtIb8KnIEhv4oKsIEluIEEgRMKNwqksIELChc6GbiE)

```
»Ho§ Ho€ In A D©, BΆn!
```

Uncompressing a compressed string.

Comment: This doesn't output anything. Does the program not work anymore?

Comment: @mbomb007 Are you using Firefox?

Comment: No. Google Chrome.

Comment: @mbomb007 Jolf currently doesn't work on Chrome. I'll look into fixing it, but in the meantime, Firefox should work.

Comment: I didn't realise it at the time but I think it was wrong to include score modifier 5. Or, at least, I should have considered some of the other 'holy' characters.  Anyway, according to score checker this scores 134. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [Golunar](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar), 1713

Sure, it's not that competitive, but it scores better than my BF answer. Code is obtained by taking the length of the code in Unary as a number.

```
17674921849995820305790270238143323861912297173117627579717678879378201073932744615660131563027031190590108979867232158537472346711601276443457666612884962806277404746795044800422000866416680881699125205492286893675575004572084572619659104159027555358269065090420400745692716750939076
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ferNANDo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 467 points

```
8 B
B 8 B B 8 B B B
B 8 8 B 8 8 8 8
B 8 8 B 8 8 B B
B 8 8 8 8 B B 8
B B 8 B B B B B
B 8 B B 8 B B B
B 8 8 B 8 8 8 8
B 8 8 B 8 8 B B
B 8 8 B B 8 B 8
B B 8 B B B B B
B 8 B B 8 B B 8
B 8 8 B 8 8 8 B
B B 8 B B B B B
B 8 B B B B B 8
B B 8 B B B B B
B 8 B B B 8 B B
B 8 8 B 8 8 8 8
B 8 8 B 8 8 8 B
B 8 8 8 B 8 B 8
B 8 8 8 B 8 B B
B B 8 B 8 8 B B
B B 8 B B B B B
B 8 B B B B 8 B
B 8 8 B B B B 8
B 8 8 8 B 8 B B
B 8 8 B 8 8 B 8
B 8 8 B B B B 8
B 8 8 B 8 8 8 B
B B 8 B B B B 8
```

[Try it online!](http://fernando.tryitonline.net/#code=OCBCCkIgOCBCIEIgOCBCIEIgQgpCIDggOCBCIDggOCA4IDgKQiA4IDggQiA4IDggQiBCCkIgOCA4IDggOCBCIEIgOApCIEIgOCBCIEIgQiBCIEIKQiA4IEIgQiA4IEIgQiBCCkIgOCA4IEIgOCA4IDggOApCIDggOCBCIDggOCBCIEIKQiA4IDggQiBCIDggQiA4CkIgQiA4IEIgQiBCIEIgQgpCIDggQiBCIDggQiBCIDgKQiA4IDggQiA4IDggOCBCCkIgQiA4IEIgQiBCIEIgQgpCIDggQiBCIEIgQiBCIDgKQiBCIDggQiBCIEIgQiBCCkIgOCBCIEIgQiA4IEIgQgpCIDggOCBCIDggOCA4IDgKQiA4IDggQiA4IDggOCBCCkIgOCA4IDggQiA4IEIgOApCIDggOCA4IEIgOCBCIEIKQiBCIDggQiA4IDggQiBCCkIgQiA4IEIgQiBCIEIgQgpCIDggQiBCIEIgQiA4IEIKQiA4IDggQiBCIEIgQiA4CkIgOCA4IDggQiA4IEIgQgpCIDggOCBCIDggOCBCIDgKQiA4IDggQiBCIEIgQiA4CkIgOCA4IEIgOCA4IDggQgpCIEIgOCBCIEIgQiBCIDg&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 193 points

```
." Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@6@npOCRn1MJIlIVPPMUHBVc8vNKS3QUnBJLchPzFP//BwA)

This also works with the same score:

```
.( Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 28 bytes (246 points/182 points)

```
‘¨®¥Ê€†€…‘" Donut, "‘ßƒ‘'!J™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYcahFYfWHVp6uOtR05pHDQvA5DKgsJKCS35eaYmOghKQc3j@sUlASl3R61HLov//jYy5jAE)

even worse (base-5 with holy characters) - 256 bytes:

```
"BB8$$&B8&&$B$$$8B&$8B%8%$$$&8%&88$$&8%$BB$8B$B$&B8%&%B&8&$8$8&&88""8B%$&"4ÝJ‡5ö36B2ÝJ… ,!‡™
```

or (less fun, super trivial):

```
"Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

for 182 points.

Answer (score 0):

## [W.Y.A.L.H.E.I.N.](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/whenyouaccidentallylose100endorsementsinnationstates), <s>3103 score, 2784 bytes</s> 2886 score, 2558 bytes

```
14192091
121
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888.%88.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888888888.%8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%8888888888888888888888.%888888888.%888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%888888888888888888888888.%88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K69MzMlIzcz7/9/YzNTIwNKEy9DIkMsJAix8nGgJaGU8jZ094gGJ4YuhnIL4gWglwwCwliGQMKjpRHLMGnZ5B5uHBrknqZlhhm2skxuvA@bVkVUrjdbBwyMUqe8CSkyE6iWr/v//HwA)

Used with a brute forcer.

After several days, I have golfed this.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 201 Points

```
#o<$g0d"oy Hole In A Donut, Batman!"og0b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XznfRiXdIEUpv1LBIz8nVcEzT8FRwSU/r7RER8EpsSQ3MU9RKT/dIOn/fwA)

Slightly better than just printing. I imagine clever modulo stuff might be able to shave off a few more points.

Answer (score -2):

### Ook! - 15699 points

I'll see your Brainfuck, and I raise you this :

```
Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook.
```

No orangutan were harm in the redaction of this program.

Comment: Your code is basically mine pasted into a BF-to-Ook! translator program. Not much of a raise.