# Print the character names

Tags: code-golf, unicode

Every Unicode character has a name, like "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A". A Unicode character name may contain only uppercase letters, white spaces, and the minus sign.

Write a program that reads a text and outputs the names of each character on a new line. For example, if the input were "Hello, World!", the output would be

```
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
COMMA
SPACE
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
LATIN SMALL LETTER R
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER D
EXCLAMATION MARK
```

- Input should come from a file or from user input, not just a string in code.
- Output should be written to a file or stdout or printed to the screen.
- Internet and external libraries are not allowed, all necessary data should be in the code.
- Assume that the input only contains printable ASCII characters in the Basic Latin code range 32-126. You can ignore a trailing newline.
- All programming languages allowed. Shortest code in bytes wins.

The official Unicode character names can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf). Other sources:

- http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp
- http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000

This is my first question so I'd appreciate any suggestion if this can be improved.

For the purpose of this challenge the list below shall be normative.

```
    32  0020        SPACE
!   33  0021        EXCLAMATION MARK
"   34  0022        QUOTATION MARK
#   35  0023        NUMBER SIGN
$   36  0024        DOLLAR SIGN
%   37  0025        PERCENT SIGN
&   38  0026        AMPERSAND
'   39  0027        APOSTROPHE
(   40  0028        LEFT PARENTHESIS
)   41  0029        RIGHT PARENTHESIS
*   42  002A        ASTERISK
+   43  002B        PLUS SIGN
,   44  002C        COMMA
-   45  002D        HYPHEN-MINUS
.   46  002E        FULL STOP
/   47  002F        SOLIDUS
0   48  0030        DIGIT ZERO
1   49  0031        DIGIT ONE
2   50  0032        DIGIT TWO
3   51  0033        DIGIT THREE
4   52  0034        DIGIT FOUR
5   53  0035        DIGIT FIVE
6   54  0036        DIGIT SIX
7   55  0037        DIGIT SEVEN
8   56  0038        DIGIT EIGHT
9   57  0039        DIGIT NINE
:   58  003A        COLON
;   59  003B        SEMICOLON
<   60  003C        LESS-THAN SIGN
=   61  003D        EQUALS SIGN
>   62  003E        GREATER-THAN SIGN
?   63  003F        QUESTION MARK
@   64  0040        COMMERCIAL AT
A   65  0041        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
B   66  0042        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
C   67  0043        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
D   68  0044        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
E   69  0045        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
F   70  0046        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
G   71  0047        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
H   72  0048        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
I   73  0049        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
J   74  004A        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
K   75  004B        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
L   76  004C        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
M   77  004D        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
N   78  004E        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
O   79  004F        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
P   80  0050        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
Q   81  0051        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
R   82  0052        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
S   83  0053        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
T   84  0054        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
U   85  0055        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
V   86  0056        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
W   87  0057        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
X   88  0058        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
Y   89  0059        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
Z   90  005A        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
[   91  005B        LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
\   92  005C        REVERSE SOLIDUS
]   93  005D        RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
^   94  005E        CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
_   95  005F        LOW LINE
`   96  0060        GRAVE ACCENT
a   97  0061        LATIN SMALL LETTER A
b   98  0062        LATIN SMALL LETTER B
c   99  0063        LATIN SMALL LETTER C
d   100 0064        LATIN SMALL LETTER D
e   101 0065        LATIN SMALL LETTER E
f   102 0066        LATIN SMALL LETTER F
g   103 0067        LATIN SMALL LETTER G
h   104 0068        LATIN SMALL LETTER H
i   105 0069        LATIN SMALL LETTER I
j   106 006A        LATIN SMALL LETTER J
k   107 006B        LATIN SMALL LETTER K
l   108 006C        LATIN SMALL LETTER L
m   109 006D        LATIN SMALL LETTER M
n   110 006E        LATIN SMALL LETTER N
o   111 006F        LATIN SMALL LETTER O
p   112 0070        LATIN SMALL LETTER P
q   113 0071        LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
r   114 0072        LATIN SMALL LETTER R
s   115 0073        LATIN SMALL LETTER S
t   116 0074        LATIN SMALL LETTER T
u   117 0075        LATIN SMALL LETTER U
v   118 0076        LATIN SMALL LETTER V
w   119 0077        LATIN SMALL LETTER W
x   120 0078        LATIN SMALL LETTER X
y   121 0079        LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
z   122 007A        LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
{   123 007B        LEFT CURLY BRACKET
|   124 007C        VERTICAL LINE
}   125 007D        RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
~   126 007E        TILDE
```

Comment: Hi, I've gone ahead and edited your question, roll back if you disagree. You don't need more sources of the information, you need *one*, normative version in the question, to avoid issues with discrepancies. I picked http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000 as it was the most concise. Other than that, +1

Comment: Thanks for the edit @steveverrill, I was too lazy to do that myself.

Comment: [Apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318799/44853) the values are available as part of Windows, in `C:\Windows\System32\getuname.dll`. Does this also count as an "external library", even if it's built in to Windows?

Comment: I just learned the word solidus.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as [discussed in chat here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58544191#58544191), it's unclear what exactly constitutes an "external library".

Answer (score 31):

## Java - 113 bytes (152 if read from command line)

Edit: removed useless curly brackets.

Edit2: removed unnecessary variable.

Edit3: Instead of Character.getName() I use c.getName().

Edit4: Passing string as command line argument.

With command line argument (113 bytes):

```java
class Z{public static void main(String[]x){for(Character c:x[0].toCharArray())System.out.println(c.getName(c));}}
```

With read line (152 bytes):

```java
class Z{public static void main(String[]x){for(Character c:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray())System.out.println(c.getName(c));}}
```

Java has everything needed. I'm sure this could be golfed down.

Comment: Damn! A builtin! In order to make this an interesting challenge, I would consider this to be in non-compliance with "all necessary data should be in the code." Very clever, though.

Comment: @steveverrill Oh well :) . I've seen another challenge where common lisp did something similar (counting from one to 100 if I remember right).

Comment: Wow, this time Java has the chance to beat a lot of golfing languages.

Comment: Alternative Java 8 solution: `x[0].chars().forEach(i->System.out.println(Character.getName(i)));` This saves 2 chars compared to the command-line argument solution (by replacing the `for`-loop).

Comment: Or maybe `x[0].chars().map(' '::getName).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 18):

## Python 3, 56 bytes

Uses a built-in function `unicodedata.name()`, so this may be non-competent. The Java answer did it similarly, so I thought it was at least worth posting.

```python
from unicodedata import*
for i in input():print(name(i))
```

Comment: I've also wanted to post one in python but my java answer was cheaty enough :) .

Comment: Surely `for i in input():print(unicodedata.name(i))` is shorter?

Comment: @Eric No. You have to `import unicodedata`, so that's [longer](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#import%20unicodedata%0Afor%20i%20in%20input%28%29%3Aprint%28unicodedata.name%28i%29%29).

Comment: [Same length using lambda+map](https://tio.run/##BcE7DsIwDADQnVOEqTaqurAhsXMDli6mSYRR/FHqDj19eM/P@JreR32uo5F8MqX9Ma06LT9jBSEHJSnzjnip3SQdypvlkikosbj1uA3vrAEVWP0IQMTxKq3ZnN7WW77@AQ)

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript (ES6) 594 <s>618 626</s>

*Note* I could save ~30 bytes compressing the long string with atob/btoa, but the utf8 character above '~' are not well accepted by the Stack Exchange post editor. I prefer to keep a running snippet instead.

**Edit** 8 chars saved thx @Ypnypn

Obvious compression of repeated words. The newline inside backticks is significant and counted.

Test running the snippet in Firefox.

```js
// TEST SUITE
// for testing purpose, redefine alert() to write inside the snippet body
alert=x=>O.innerHTML=x
// for testing purpose, redefine prompt() to have a default text containing all characters
_prompt=prompt
prompt=(i,s)=>{
  for(s='',i=32;i<127;i++)s+=String.fromCharCode(i);
  return _prompt("Insert your message or keep the default",s);
}  
  
// That's the answer code:
z='SPACE/EXCLAMA0QUOTA0NUMBER1DOLLAR1PERCENT1AMPERSAND/APOSTROPHE3242ASTERISK/PLUS1COMMA/HYPHEN-MINUS/FULL STOP/78ZERO8ONE8TWO8THREE8FOUR8FIVE8SIX8SEVEN8EIGHT8NINE86SEMI6LESS-THAN1EQUALS1GREATER-THAN1QUES0COMMERCIAL AT3SQUARE5REVERSE 7/4SQUARE5CIRCUMFLEX9/LOW LINE/GRAVE93CURLY5VERTICAL LINE/4CURLY5TILDE'.replace(/\d/g,c=>'TION MARK/, SIGN/,PARENTHESIS/,/LEFT ,RIGHT , BRACKET/,COLON/,SOLIDUS,/DIGIT , ACCENT'.split`,`[c]).split`/`,alert([...prompt()].map(c=>(q=c.charCodeAt()-32)<33?z[q]:q<59?'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER '+c:q<65?z[q-26]:q<91?'LATIN SMALL LETTER '+c.toUpperCase():z[q-52]).join`
`)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 10):

## R, <s>54 bytes</s> 62

```
library(Unicode)
cat(u_char_name(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))),sep="\n")
```

Edit: per @flodels comment, I need to read it from connection first, so had to add `scan`. This is also probably non-competent solution according to *all* the rules.

**Usage**

```
> cat(u_char_name(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))),sep="\n")
1: 'Hello, World!'
2: 
Read 1 item
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
COMMA
SPACE
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
LATIN SMALL LETTER R
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER D
EXCLAMATION MARK
```

You can also wrap it up into a function for more convenient usage

```
UNI <- function(x)cat(paste0(u_char_name(utf8ToInt(x)),"\n"))
```

Then, the usage is just

```
UNI("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Your byte count is correct :)

Comment: And welcome to PPCG! :D

Comment: Good for you having a built in for the task, but the output is not what is requested - 4 columns table instead of 1 column table. I think you should add some core to obtain the correct output

Comment: @edc65 that easy to fix, I just thought of it as a bonus.

Comment: @edc65 fixed it.

Comment: +1 and welcome to PPCG. Depending on the question, kindly consider adding `function(x)` or a function reading from stdin like `scan` or `readLines`, otherwise this is stretching the rules a bit.

Comment: `function(x)cat(Unicode::u_char_name(utf8ToInt(x)),sep="\n")` would be an acceptable solution for example.

Comment: @flodel I already have that... You are right regarding reading from connection though, need to add that too.

Comment: Well, you don't have `function(x)` in your byte count... See this for example: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55702/5163. Or look at other people's R answers, you'll get the idea (and learn some of the tricks too :-)

Comment: @flodel where is it written that this should be a function? Most of the answers here aren't wrapped into functions neither

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28875/discussion-between-flodel-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -MCompress::Zlib -00F`, 459 bytes

```perl
@d=split/,/,inflateInit->inflate(<DATA>);say$d[-32+ord]for@F
__END__
x.m.or.0.......!.#....I&I.......v......0O.)q.g.*...PH.q....u..k...85.:sgM\.8P..Fu......r..=tR...e......9k.{.2.xUj.P\_}..Qr...!..[..$O.2.%{.bmgl.....|U.tnC...K-?..;.3..1.\s......K>.....T..y.$v.E.....6.....JaM.$.G!.5$...A..5.....y...g....s.....Y0...s..1o...av.............;..)..R..G...8..t...K)k.e.~.J..Gi. .r\.v>.........!L.'..pF. \.f......aAX.6....P..BG8......._..
....W...s"9.t....
.2......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZVrWxRHEIW/@ytKJUaiW3ZP3wGJRIWoUYnRRCMJ6ekLbLi6uxiM0b9OTi9D8FN4Hnpnlul3quucOvRxunt2epppNKGVlRW6tnBzFsf7NOoCcTrKhWfjo8VrtErHk/HhbDTbLaO0GycxzcpkdBgPypSP95ev/JVolP73GVq90S1fOS4TwJ8aloIFLu4fHRxPynS6tPTr/rinkRDr/09ZIR4fHp/MWl3LV8rpeLZ8JoafJdLCalLZKXLCJrLBaepql84XG2wha/EHupfvTo/3x7M7t@/cHh/W/SvnBAmGldhkjQ5kiw3kdJdJtSvcWrLJSnxnDVGclUeH49lotQFwMzA6MDqvEmmtJZm2qIJ2qh5lAR6o06jS9ODSzZUHay/XVheXp/HDQn47GhgKDKVUR11vK7muPZ/b26vrcEhtSURTyVSNOlR362iSf6tHk3vrvL39cGDo1o@isbPiURGdJyFtpqzmyKhICZFImCqInj3Y3uZTPuCjCQtmHhgGjNhX7BSlUCcl2qmSIJ8rdjr0CKUFKtVVImzjq3y9fTy68eg/hgUjiJJJlF5Q6J2lXHpHxclKsmSBOnSlbNGjOYPfz1cWz3lxYDgwnCzQxUk0JeKqD9mQEdq3t0uSfcLRqi9E73iHv8H@ze/5HV@exTeGCRqP2p560SfKWnlSRkKh2MRxOpNJFbqcMO9hqze8NN15unXBCE0XbwSVECGwdYZ8zBqn6gMBW9BY9CgUBYbfZF4/OT/LhPnuwIitDm06igXP9x2s5PsQKbhqKLqAfoRWoHU90ewFNpdzRtjjjwOjB6Mk@KMkyGqMjRQNyjIJUrtcDNVoZCsGdXDHp6/@5M2t7U/MP04uzpLAkLa4JmtHKZmefM0W7mxq1AY3nSHX5KemLL9lXngO2lcfLxi5zUsHU1mHqQroHRXtK6XeJZTV@qExc1pF@KM/2NmfH@SfVzw7vH/BKM0fvjrSbSJUxaNJq54wxYqqypWUBNckKIQ6noy@ZV5mxSx5azowauuHCZ5C7CFw9Bk0VSh0sFwO3lGsRuN8/sJj/GR1/vHywh@y5YcLskcDYFEMjqEQQqJq4N0SFGzra6FaYTT6wAvv@eGcYC89Jlt@ZK0j5hxWCqGDF4RuLcYJlMFtiRlOqQgF4sfxKS/wxlU2C0CsDYyWH9mH3IwJo1lUVKzXqC01mXBI6xKmry@2ncXMi/iA353LOlp@SIOGJYtB9aEG8ugPJk06MCRkVUlRTqrVMZ0j3rS5x6UcGC0/bMXrpOnnwWWxUzRJMGT4XrYltAUZdIS9cZjbL/rR8qOGAjF9U7QXsFdTI/Twfx/B1Q5mDRmz3HRZZl5khuc3Lhl2PnOhnRjBHEvB5FQNmdqUyIjxkdYVQvJHzBzzrIm7uIep@cyPB0bLDw9v4HUIcl87gfxAlJqEPHAWTkFGJsDlvI6NMRNPtvj96hdnafkBPznKnUDxqZOkk/DUOYjjkxPIgx63wqTBY1d/4K@Zj9eZtgZGyw8pEeReB2SyL20RptkF/yp8C6Imtcyl6VLPexnXXs9NNjBafniLYZdSRtJwK9rTnFJQjKxYQltMW4iRQd9t@EGV7QtGy49UBVLDRujY1UjGxXIuhFNdhwzCd05XfTEvvzR3XAto78Bo@VEq8kPkZu6uIoRrrRRT0tQy9MufRujOQWdndPXa9YWvbnx9c/GbW7dHfAeeV9pY58PS8srd1W/vrX13/8HD9Y3vHz1@8sPTZ883f3zx08tXP//y@s2vb7d@@337j4iwL3Vnd/zn3v7B4dHxu8l0dvL@r9MPf3/859PnfwE)

### Explanation

Pretty straight-forward, `@d` is constructed from Zlib compressed data (stored after `__END__`), which is just the compressed list of raw comma separated character names that is inflated, split on `,` and can be indexed via `ord - 32`. `-00` sets the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) to `\x00` (`NUL`) which slurps the `__DATA__` in one call to `<DATA>` instead of having it split on newline. `@F` is initialised with the input data as an array (via `-F`), which is iterated over and the corresponding index from `@d` is output.

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -F`, 672 bytes

```perl
$b=BRACKET;say+(SPACE,<"{EXCLAMATION,QUOTATION} MARK">,<"{NUMBER,DOLLAR,PERCENT} SIGN">,AMPERSAND,APOSTROPHE,<"{LEFT,RIGHT} PARENTHESIS">,ASTERISK,'PLUS SIGN',COMMA,'HYPHEN-MINUS','FULL STOP',$s=SOLIDUS,<"DIGIT {ZERO,ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE}">,<{,SEMI}COLON>,<"{LESS-THAN,EQUALS,GREATER-THAN} SIGN">,'QUESTION MARK','COMMERCIAL AT',<"LATIN CAPITAL LETTER {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}">,"LEFT SQUARE $b","REVERSE $s","RIGHT SQUARE $b",'CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT','LOW LINE','GRAVE ACCENT',<"LATIN SMALL LETTER {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}">,"LEFT CURLY $b",'VERTICAL LINE',"RIGHT CURLY $b",TILDE)[-32+ord]for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHpQtNAFIVfJdZqwN7UAtYNikwnN8nQWdJZuiEqFVAUaW1xwVof3Tgpij6A/2bunHvynZPpyey8WRTVcautCe2g3Z4fXdXWTE4owk5lgQPKiSCWKQldp@zqtAwE0Z3KbimQTrRRQ6w4Jxpy1BSlXQaGpdILiPATQ2QMJFfGapVnK1uOiQXN0sxLc6L9SoaGmXLDWNTMdCDMuTMrnxCoEoJAmA39uowEk86EECaO88BYlYdQnbeM4ix2xrvHLGU2WIxQK1ASwfYV2EwjQqKchoT1EAwbgMEeSsCSAiSTuCwTLfxYsCVVXMnda1RjIpsRr@w6wg2kGolnXM1ugoZdh6bsZlWNhyuRfRmM8IDY0BtxX50MKMmZ9TOO1nsECwJtoBCDZ4MUMmCwDx3gIECCghy6oMGABQc96MMAhjAqMStlgYHxQBqD6rgCFe3DaOMv8/JSZvr3OaRMUycSjoOA0PIXeUSu@gH3uf0x1aSHNy9/YI0g/D@hUqf58BrFc1pGyw5W3/4N@1dgGY9x/SDa2qxNZseHp5PZXlIUwa3K7eqdu@Ha@r0aRPX7jY3NrQfNh48eP3m6vdPafbZH2jTGJM3YfocLqfKuNtb1@oPh6OD54YuXr47Gr49PTt@8PXv3/vzDxWT6cTa//PT5y9erb4vvyx8/J9PLs8nFvIiSIhLN@kaj3vgF)

### Explanation

A (marginally) less boring version of the script without tool-based compression, mostly taking advantage of `glob`s.

Answer (score 7):

## C, 644 <s>656</s>

Full program, reading from standard input

Test on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9njuPP)

This is a porting of my JavaScript answer to C. The C language is good at manipulating single characters as numbers (no need of `.toUpperCase` and the like), but it's weaker in string manipulation.

```c
char*s,*p,*q,b[999],*d=b+99,c,*l[129];
main(k){for(k=32,p="/SPACE/EXCLAMAaQUOTAaNUMBERbDOLLARbPERCENTbAMPERSAND/APOSTROPHEdcecASTERISK/PLUSbCOMMA/HYPHEN-MINUS/FULL STOP/hiZEROiONEiTWOiTHREEiFOURiFIVEiSIXiSEVENiEIGHTiNINE/gSEMIgLESSnbEQUALSbGREATERnbQUESaCOMMERCIAL ATdkfREVERSE h/ekfCIRCUMFLEXj/LOWmGRAVEjdlfVERTICALmelfTILDE/";
c=*p;p++)c>96?q?(p=q,q=0):(q=p,p=strchr("aTION MARK/b SIGN/cPARENTHESIS/d/LEFT eRIGHT f BRACKET/gCOLON/hSOLIDUSi/DIGIT j ACCENTkSQUARElCURLYm LINE/n-THANz",c)):c-47?*d++=c:(*d++=0,l[k++]=d);
for(;~(k=getchar());puts(k<65?l[k]:(k&31)<27?b:l[k<97?k-26:k-52]))sprintf(b,"LATIN %s LETTER %c",k<91?"CAPITAL":"SMALL",k&95);}
```

Less golfed

```c
char *all = "/SPACE/EXCLAMAaQUOTAaNUMBERbDOLLARbPERCENTbAMPERSAND/APOSTROPHEdcecASTERISK/PLUSbCOMMA/HYPHEN-MINUS/FULL STOP/hiZEROiONEiTWOiTHREEiFOURiFIVEiSIXiSEVENiEIGHTiNINE/gSEMIgLESSnbEQUALSbGREATERnbQUESaCOMMERCIAL ATdkfREVERSE h/ekfCIRCUMFLEXj/LOWmGRAVEjdlfVERTICALmelfTILDE/";
char *subs = "aTION MARK/b SIGN/cPARENTHESIS/d/LEFT eRIGHT f BRACKET/gCOLON/hSOLIDUSi/DIGIT j ACCENTkSQUARElCURLYm LINE/n-THANz";

main(int k)
{
    char c, *s, *p, *q=0, 
    b[999], // work buffer
    *d = b+99, // first part of buffer is used later
    *l[129]; // characters descriptions (used 32 to 126)

    // Uncompress the descriptions of all char except letters
    for(k = 32, p = all; c = *p; ++p)
    {
       c >= 'a' // substitution word are marked as lowercase letters
        ? q  
           ? (p = q, q = 0)
           : (q = p, p = strchr(subs, c))
        : c != '/'
           ? *d++ = c 
           : (*d++ = 0, l[k++] = d); // end char description
    }
    // Scan the input string and print each char description
    for(; (k=getchar()) != -1; )
    {
       sprintf(b,"LATIN %s LETTER %c", k<91 ? "CAPITAL":"SMALL", k & 95);
       puts( k<65 ? l[k] : k<91 ? b : k<97 ? l[k-26] : k<123 ? b : l[k-52]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 21 bytes

I did not see a rule specifically against using a built-in method for getting the unicode names.
(Also the Java answer which is the currently highest voted one does the same)

```perl6
.say for get.uninames
```

Comment: Perl 6 is weird. I love it, though.

Answer (score 6):

## awk - <strike>794</strike> 739

```
     1  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
     2  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
     3  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
     4  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
     5  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
     6  LEFT CURLY BRACKET 
     7  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
     8  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
     9  LATIN SMALL LETTER L
    10  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
    11  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
    12  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
    13  QUOTATION MARK 
    14  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
    15  COMMA 
    16  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
    17  LATIN SMALL LETTER V
    18  COMMA 
    19  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
    20  LATIN SMALL LETTER V
    21  COMMA 
    22  LATIN SMALL LETTER A
    23  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    24  COMMA 
    25  CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT 
    26  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    27  COMMA 
    28  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
    29  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    30  COMMA 
    31  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
    32  COMMA 
    33  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
    34  COMMA 
    35  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
    36  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
    37  COMMA 
    38  LATIN SMALL LETTER C
    39  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
    40  COMMA 
    41  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
    42  COMMA 
    43  LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
    44  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    45  COMMA 
    46  LATIN SMALL LETTER G
    47  COMMA 
    48  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
    49  COMMA 
    50  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
    51  LATIN SMALL LETTER U
    52  COMMA 
    53  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
    54  COMMA 
    55  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    56  LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
    57  COMMA 
    58  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    59  LEFT CURLY BRACKET 
    60  COMMA 
    61  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    62  LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
    63  COMMA 
    64  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    65  LATIN SMALL LETTER D
    66  COMMA 
    67  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    68  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
    69  COMMA 
    70  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    71  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
    72  COMMA 
    73  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    74  RIGHT CURLY BRACKET 
    75  COMMA 
    76  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    77  LATIN SMALL LETTER K
    78  COMMA 
    79  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    80  LATIN SMALL LETTER L
    81  COMMA 
    82  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
    83  LATIN SMALL LETTER O
    84  COMMA 
    85  LATIN SMALL LETTER E
    86  COMMA 
    87  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
    88  COMMA 
    89  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
    90  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    91  COMMA 
    92  LOW LINE 
    93  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    94  COMMA 
    95  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
    96  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
    97  COMMA 
    98  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
    99  LATIN SMALL LETTER V
   100  COMMA 
   101  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   102  TILDE 
   103  COMMA 
   104  SPACE 
   105  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   106  GRAVE ACCENT 
   107  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
   108  COMMA 
   109  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
   110  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
   111  COMMA 
   112  LATIN SMALL LETTER C
   113  GRAVE ACCENT 
   114  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
   115  COMMA 
   116  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   117  REVERSE SOLIDUS 
   118  REVERSE SOLIDUS 
   119  COMMA 
   120  VERTICAL LINE 
   121  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
   122  COMMA 
   123  LATIN SMALL LETTER M
   124  REVERSE SOLIDUS 
   125  REVERSE SOLIDUS 
   126  COMMA 
   127  SPACE 
   128  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   129  LATIN SMALL LETTER H
   130  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
   131  COMMA 
   132  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   133  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
   134  COMMA 
   135  LATIN SMALL LETTER C
   136  LATIN SMALL LETTER H
   137  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
   138  COMMA 
   139  LATIN SMALL LETTER F
   140  SPACE 
   141  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   142  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
   143  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   144  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   145  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   146  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   147  HYPHEN-MINUS 
   148  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   149  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   150  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   151  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   152  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   153  SPACE 
   154  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
   155  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   156  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   157  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   158  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   159  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   160  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   161  HYPHEN-MINUS 
   162  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   163  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   164  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   165  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   166  SPACE 
   167  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   168  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   169  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   170  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   171  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   172  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   173  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   174  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   175  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   176  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   177  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   178  SPACE 
   179  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   180  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
   181  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   182  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   183  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   184  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   185  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   186  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   187  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   188  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   189  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   190  SPACE 
   191  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   192  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   193  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   194  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   195  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   196  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   197  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   198  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   199  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   200  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   201  SPACE 
   202  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   203  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   204  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   205  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   206  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   207  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   208  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   209  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   210  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   211  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
   212  SPACE 
   213  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   214  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   215  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   216  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   217  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   218  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   219  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   220  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   221  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   222  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   223  SPACE 
   224  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   225  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   226  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   227  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   228  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   229  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   230  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   231  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   232  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   233  SPACE 
   234  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   235  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   236  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   237  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   238  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   239  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   240  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   241  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   242  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
   243  SPACE 
   244  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   245  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   246  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   247  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   248  HYPHEN-MINUS 
   249  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   250  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   251  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   252  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   253  SPACE 
   254  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
   255  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   256  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   257  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   258  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   259  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   260  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   261  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   262  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   263  SPACE 
   264  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
   265  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   266  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   267  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   268  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   269  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   270  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   271  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   272  SPACE 
   273  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
   274  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   275  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   276  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   277  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   278  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   279  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   280  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   281  SPACE 
   282  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   283  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   284  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   285  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   286  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   287  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   288  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   289  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
   290  SPACE 
   291  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   292  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   293  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   294  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   295  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   296  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   297  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   298  SPACE 
   299  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   300  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   301  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   302  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   303  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
   304  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   305  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   306  SPACE 
   307  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
   308  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   309  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   310  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   311  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
   312  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   313  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   314  SPACE 
   315  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   316  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   317  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
   318  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   319  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   320  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   321  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   322  SPACE 
   323  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   324  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   325  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   326  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   327  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   328  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   329  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   330  SPACE 
   331  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   332  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   333  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   334  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   335  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   336  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   337  SPACE 
   338  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   339  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   340  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   341  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   342  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   343  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   344  SPACE 
   345  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
   346  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   347  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   348  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   349  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   350  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   351  SPACE 
   352  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   353  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
   354  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   355  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   356  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   357  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   358  SPACE 
   359  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   360  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
   361  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   362  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   363  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   364  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   365  SPACE 
   366  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   367  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   368  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   369  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
   370  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   371  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   372  SPACE 
   373  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
   374  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   375  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
   376  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   377  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   378  SPACE 
   379  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   380  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   381  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
   382  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   383  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   384  SPACE 
   385  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   386  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   387  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   388  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   389  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   390  SPACE 
   391  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   392  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   393  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   394  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   395  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   396  SPACE 
   397  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   398  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   399  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   400  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
   401  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   402  SPACE 
   403  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   404  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   405  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   406  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   407  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   408  SPACE 
   409  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   410  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   411  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   412  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   413  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
   414  SPACE 
   415  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   416  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   417  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   418  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
   419  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   420  SPACE 
   421  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   422  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   423  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   424  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   425  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   426  SPACE 
   427  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   428  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   429  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
   430  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   431  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   432  SPACE 
   433  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   434  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   435  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
   436  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
   437  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   438  SPACE 
   439  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
   440  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   441  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   442  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
   443  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   444  SPACE 
   445  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   446  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   447  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   448  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   449  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   450  SPACE 
   451  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   452  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   453  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   454  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   455  SPACE 
   456  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   457  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   458  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   459  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   460  SPACE 
   461  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   462  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   463  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   464  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   465  SPACE 
   466  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   467  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   468  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
   469  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   470  SPACE 
   471  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   472  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   473  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   474  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   475  SPACE 
   476  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   477  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   478  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   479  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   480  SPACE 
   481  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   482  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   483  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   484  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
   485  SPACE 
   486  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
   487  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   488  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   489  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
   490  SPACE 
   491  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   492  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
   493  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   494  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   495  SPACE 
   496  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   497  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   498  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
   499  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   500  SPACE 
   501  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
   502  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   503  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
   504  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   505  SPACE 
   506  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   507  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
   508  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   509  SPACE 
   510  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   511  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   512  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
   513  SPACE 
   514  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
   515  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
   516  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
   517  SPACE 
   518  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   519  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
   520  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
   521  SPACE 
   522  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   523  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   524  QUOTATION MARK 
   525  COMMA 
   526  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
   527  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   528  SEMICOLON 
   529  LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
   530  EQUALS SIGN 
   531  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
   532  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   533  DIGIT TWO 
   534  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   535  SEMICOLON 
   536  LATIN SMALL LETTER F
   537  LATIN SMALL LETTER O
   538  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   539  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   540  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
   541  EQUALS SIGN 
   542  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
   543  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   544  DIGIT ONE 
   545  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   546  SEMICOLON 
   547  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   548  PLUS SIGN 
   549  PLUS SIGN 
   550  LESS-THAN SIGN 
   551  DIGIT TWO 
   552  DIGIT SIX 
   553  SEMICOLON 
   554  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
   555  EQUALS SIGN 
   556  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
   557  QUOTATION MARK 
   558  LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   559  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
   560  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   561  COMMA 
   562  QUOTATION MARK 
   563  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   564  LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
   565  EQUALS SIGN 
   566  LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
   567  QUOTATION MARK 
   568  LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   569  LATIN SMALL LETTER J
   570  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   571  COMMA 
   572  QUOTATION MARK 
   573  SEMICOLON 
   574  LATIN SMALL LETTER F
   575  LATIN SMALL LETTER O
   576  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   577  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   578  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
   579  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   580  LATIN SMALL LETTER L
   581  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   582  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   583  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   584  LATIN SMALL LETTER X
   585  SPACE 
   586  LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
   587  SPACE 
   588  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
   589  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   590  DIGIT THREE 
   591  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   592  COMMA 
   593  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
   594  COMMA 
   595  QUOTATION MARK 
   596  COMMA 
   597  QUOTATION MARK 
   598  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   599  SEMICOLON 
   600  LATIN SMALL LETTER J
   601  PLUS SIGN 
   602  PLUS SIGN 
   603  LESS-THAN SIGN 
   604  DIGIT ONE 
   605  DIGIT TWO 
   606  DIGIT SIX 
   607  SEMICOLON 
   608  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   609  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
   610  EQUALS SIGN 
   611  LOW LINE 
   612  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   613  LATIN SMALL LETTER D
   614  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   615  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
   616  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   617  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   618  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   619  LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   620  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   621  LATIN SMALL LETTER F
   622  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   623  QUOTATION MARK 
   624  PERCENT SIGN 
   625  LATIN SMALL LETTER C
   626  QUOTATION MARK 
   627  COMMA 
   628  LATIN SMALL LETTER J
   629  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   630  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   631  EQUALS SIGN 
   632  LATIN SMALL LETTER J
   633  RIGHT CURLY BRACKET 
   634  LEFT CURLY BRACKET 
   635  LATIN SMALL LETTER F
   636  LATIN SMALL LETTER O
   637  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   638  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   639  LATIN SMALL LETTER K
   640  EQUALS SIGN 
   641  DIGIT ZERO 
   642  SEMICOLON 
   643  LATIN SMALL LETTER K
   644  PLUS SIGN 
   645  PLUS SIGN 
   646  LESS-THAN SIGN 
   647  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
   648  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
   649  SEMICOLON 
   650  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   651  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   652  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   653  LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   654  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   655  SPACE 
   656  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   657  EQUALS SIGN 
   658  LOW LINE 
   659  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   660  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
   661  LATIN SMALL LETTER H
   662  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   663  LATIN SMALL LETTER L
   664  LATIN SMALL LETTER E
   665  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   666  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   667  PLUS SIGN 
   668  PLUS SIGN 
   669  LESS-THAN SIGN 
   670  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
   671  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   672  LATIN SMALL LETTER L
   673  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   674  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   675  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   676  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
   677  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   678  LATIN SMALL LETTER D
   679  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   680  DOLLAR SIGN 
   681  LATIN SMALL LETTER K
   682  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   683  HYPHEN-MINUS 
   684  DIGIT THREE 
   685  DIGIT ONE 
   686  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   687  COMMA 
   688  LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
   689  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   690  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   691  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   692  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   693  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   694  LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   695  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   696  LATIN SMALL LETTER F
   697  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   698  LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
   699  EQUALS SIGN 
   700  LATIN SMALL LETTER W
   701  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   702  LATIN SMALL LETTER D
   703  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   704  LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
   705  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET 
   706  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   707  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   708  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   709  HYPHEN-MINUS 
   710  DIGIT SIX 
   711  DIGIT NINE 
   712  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET 
   713  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   714  QUOTATION MARK 
   715  SPACE 
   716  QUOTATION MARK 
   717  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   718  LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
   719  TILDE 
   720  SOLIDUS 
   721  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   722  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
   723  SOLIDUS 
   724  QUESTION MARK 
   725  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
   726  LATIN SMALL LETTER O
   727  LATIN SMALL LETTER U
   728  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   729  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
   730  LATIN SMALL LETTER E
   731  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
   732  LEFT PARENTHESIS 
   733  DOLLAR SIGN 
   734  LATIN SMALL LETTER K
   735  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   736  COLON 
   737  LOW LINE 
   738  RIGHT PARENTHESIS 
   739  RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
```

Just kidding ;D

```
BEGIN{split("i,Lv,Sv,ax,^x,[x,Q,O,tK,cK,V,qx,g,I,wu,X,by,b{,bz,bd,bp,br,b},bk,bl,bo,e,P,Rx,_x,Jx,Uv,M~, t`Y,ZX,c`Y,N\\,|s,m\\, thY,Ts,chY,f HYPHEN-MINUS GREATER-THAN PARENTHESIS EXCLAMATION COMMERCIAL CIRCUMFLEX APOSTROPHE SEMICOLON AMPERSAND LESS-THAN QUOTATION VERTICAL QUESTION ASTERISK CAPITAL SOLIDUS BRACKET REVERSE PERCENT ACCENT LETTER DOLLAR EQUALS SQUARE NUMBER DIGIT RIGHT THREE COLON TILDE COMMA CURLY SPACE SMALL SEVEN EIGHT GRAVE LATIN NINE FOUR PLUS FIVE LINE LEFT STOP MARK FULL SIGN ZERO TWO ONE LOW SIX AT",w);x=w[1];for(y=w[2];C++<26;x=x"nW],")y=y"nj],";for(split(x y w[3],b,",");j++<126;FS=_)d[sprintf("%c",j)]=j}{for(k=0;k++<NF;print i=_)while(i++<split(b[d[$k]-31],q))printf(z=w[d[q[i]]-69])" "(z~/TT/?toupper($k):_)}
```

Works with stdin/stdout.

More "readable":

```awk
BEGIN{

  # This string (508 bytes) holds a representation of the character names in 
  # the right order, plus a list of the used words.

    split("i,Lv,Sv,ax,^x,[x,Q,O,tK,cK,V,qx,g,I,wu,X,by,b{,bz,bd,bp,br,b},bk,bl,bo,
    e,P,Rx,_x,Jx,Uv,M~, t`Y,ZX,c`Y,N\\,|s,m\\, thY,Ts,chY,f HYPHEN-MINUS GREATER-T
    HAN PARENTHESIS EXCLAMATION COMMERCIAL CIRCUMFLEX APOSTROPHE SEMICOLON AMPERSA
    ND LESS-THAN QUOTATION VERTICAL QUESTION ASTERISK CAPITAL SOLIDUS BRACKET REVE
    RSE PERCENT ACCENT LETTER DOLLAR EQUALS SQUARE NUMBER DIGIT RIGHT THREE COLON
    TILDE COMMA CURLY SPACE SMALL SEVEN EIGHT GRAVE LATIN NINE FOUR PLUS FIVE LINE
     LEFT STOP MARK FULL SIGN ZERO TWO ONE LOW SIX AT",w);

  # Since the letters each appear 26 times I construct that part at runtime.
  # The array b will hold the coded combinations of which words need to
  # be printed for each input character.

    x=w[1];
    for(y=w[2];C++<26;x=x"nW],")
        y=y"nj],";

  # The array d is an ASCIICodeFromChar function replacement.
  # I set the field separator to empty, so each character of the input is
  # an input field. That's why using a BEGIN part was mandatory.

    for(split(x y w[3],b,",");j++<126;FS=_)
        d[sprintf("%c",j)]=j
}

  # Here I go through the element of b that matches the input and print
  # the requested words, using the input to produce a capital letter if
  # needed. I excluded these from the word list to save another 26 bytes

{
    for(k=0;k++<NF;print i=_)
        while(i++<split(b[d[$k]-31],q))
            printf(z=w[d[q[i]]-69])" "(z~/TT/?toupper($k):_)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## C++11, 739 bytes

```
#include<iostream>
#define D,"DIGIT "
#define G" SIGN",
int main(){std::string a=" BRACKET",s="SQUARE"+a,c="CURLY"+a,t="TION MARK",p="PARENTHESIS",l="LEFT ",r="RIGHT ",x="LATIN ",y="L LETTER ",z[]{"SPACE","EXCLAMA"+t,"QUOTA"+t,"NUMBER"G"DOLLAR"G"PERCENT"G"AMPERSAND","APOSTROPHE",l+p,r+p,"ASTERISK","PLUS"G"COMMA","HYPHEN-MINUS","FULL STOP","SOLIDUS"D"ZERO"D"ONE"D"TWO"D"THREE"D"FOUR"D"FIVE"D"SIX"D"SEVEN"D"EIGHT"D"NINE","COLON","SEMICOLON","LESS-THAN"G"EQUALS"G"GREATER-THAN"G"QUES"+t,"COMMERCIAL AT",l+s,"REVERSE SOLIDUS",r+s,"CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT","LOW LINE","GRAVE ACCENT",l+c,"VERTICAL LINE",r+c,"TILDE"};getline(std::cin,s);for(char c:s)std::cout<<(c<65?z[c-32]:c<91?x+"CAPITA"+y+c:(c-=32,c<65?z[c-26]:c<91?x+"SMAL"+y+c:z[c-52]))+"\n";}
```

Based on sweerpotato's solution, but modified heavily.

Comment: Nicely done :~)!

Answer (score 5):

### C++14, <strike>1043</strike> <strike>1000</strike> <strike>998</strike> <strike>996</strike> 972 bytes

Grotesque solution in C++14:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#define b cout
#define d string
#define e },{
using namespace std;char l='\n';d s[]{"DIGIT ","LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ","LATIN SMALL LETTER "};map<char, d> m{{' ',"SPACE"e'!',"EXCLAMATION MARK"e'\"',"QUOTATION MARK"e'#',"NUMBER SIGN"e'$',"DOLLAR SIGN"e'%',"PERCENT SIGN"e'&',"AMPERSAND"e'\'',"APOSTROPHE"e'(',"LEFT PARENTHESIS"e')',"RIGHT PARENTHESIS"e'*',"ASTERISK"e'+',"PLUS SIGN"e',',"COMMA"e'-',"HYPHEN-MINUS"e'.',"FULL STOP"e'/',"SOLIDUS"e':',"COLON"e';',"SEMICOLON"e'<',"LESS-THAN SIGN"e'=',"EQUALS SIGN"e'>',"GREATER-THAN SIGN"e'?',"QUESTION MARK"e'@',"COMMERCIAL AT"e'[',"LEFT SQUARE BRACKET"e'\\',"REVERSE SOLIDUS"e']',"RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET"e'^',"CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT"e'_',"LOW LINE"e'`',"GRAVE ACCENT"e'{',"LEFT CURLY BRACKET"e'|',"VERTICAL LINE"e'}',"RIGHT CURLY BRACKET"e'~',"TILDE"}};int main(){d str;getline(cin,str);for(char c:str){islower(c)?b<<s[2]<<(char)(c-32):isupper(c)?b<<s[1]<<c:isdigit(c)?b<<*s<<c:b<<m.at(c);b<<l;}}
```

*Thanks to kirbyfan64sos for golfing off two bytes*

Comment: Can you do `*s` instead of `s[0]`?

Comment: Sure can! Totally missed that

Answer (score 5):

## Common Lisp (SBCL), <del>52</del> 79

```
(map()(lambda(y)(format t"~:@(~A~)~%"(substitute #\  #\_(char-name y))))(read))
```

This is built-in and implementation-dependent, so you may want to ignore it when choosing the accepted answer. This is not enough to beat [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57158/903), unfortunately. The updated version conforms to the expected output (I have to replace underscores by spaces).

### Example

```
CL-USER> (map()(lambda(y)(format t"~:@(~A~)~%"(substitute #\  #\_(char-name y))))(read))
"(λ(r)(* 2 ᴨ r))"
LEFT PARENTHESIS
GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMDA
LEFT PARENTHESIS
LATIN SMALL LETTER R
RIGHT PARENTHESIS
LEFT PARENTHESIS
ASTERISK
SPACE
DIGIT TWO
SPACE
GREEK LETTER SMALL CAPITAL PI
SPACE
LATIN SMALL LETTER R
RIGHT PARENTHESIS
RIGHT PARENTHESIS
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 41

```
$from unicodedata import name as neg$Vz_N
```

Uses same builtin as [mbomb007's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57158/31625). Note that this cannot be executed online because the `$` operator is unsafe.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 517

```
l{i32-["SPACE""EXCLAMA""TION MARK":T+"QUOTA"T+"NUMBER DOLLAR PERCENT"{S/" SIGN"am*~}:H~"AMPERSAND""APOSTROPHE""LEFT PARENTHESIS":L"RIGHT ":R1$5>+"ASTERISK""PLUS"H"COMMA""HYPHEN-MINUS""FULL STOP""SOLIDUS":D"DIGIT "a"ZERO ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE"S/m*~"COLON""SEMI"1$+"LESS-THAN EQUALS GREATER-THAN"H"QUES"T+"COMMERCIAL AT""CAPITA"{["LATIN "\"L LETTER "]a'[,65>m*~L5<}:Z~"SQUARE BRACKET":Q+"REVERSE "D+RQ+"CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT""LOW LINE""GRAVE"2$A>+"SMAL"Z"CURLY"33$B>+:C+"VERTICAL LINE"RC+"TILDE"]=N}/
```

[Online version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%7Bi32-%5B%22SPACE%22%22EXCLAMA%22%22TION%20MARK%22%3AT%2B%22QUOTA%22T%2B%22NUMBER%20DOLLAR%20PERCENT%22%7BS%2F%22%20SIGN%22am*~%7D%3AH~%22AMPERSAND%22%22APOSTROPHE%22%22LEFT%20PARENTHESIS%22%3AL%22RIGHT%20%22%3AR1%245%3E%2B%22ASTERISK%22%22PLUS%22H%22COMMA%22%22HYPHEN-MINUS%22%22FULL%20STOP%22%22SOLIDUS%22%3AD%22DIGIT%20%22a%22ZERO%20ONE%20TWO%20THREE%20FOUR%20FIVE%20SIX%20SEVEN%20EIGHT%20NINE%22S%2Fm*~%22COLON%22%22SEMI%221%24%2B%22LESS-THAN%20EQUALS%20GREATER-THAN%22H%22QUES%22T%2B%22COMMERCIAL%20AT%22%22CAPITA%22%7B%5B%22LATIN%20%22%5C%22L%20LETTER%20%22%5Da'%5B%2C65%3Em*~L5%3C%7D%3AZ~%22SQUARE%20BRACKET%22%3AQ%2B%22REVERSE%20%22D%2BRQ%2B%22CIRCUMFLEX%20ACCENT%22%22LOW%20LINE%22%22GRAVE%222%24A%3E%2B%22SMAL%22Z%22CURLY%2233%24B%3E%2B%3AC%2B%22VERTICAL%20LINE%22RC%2B%22TILDE%22%5D%3DN%7D%2F)

I have tried different solutions but simply storing all the names in a huge array seems most efficient.

This is my first real CJam program by the way.

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure, 56 bytes

```
(doseq[c(read-line)](println(Character/getName(int c))))
```

Inspired by @peter's answer. Uses Clojure for the Java interop.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl - 894 bytes

Lovingly crafted by hand. First time golfing in Perl so any tips are appreciated.

```
$_=$ARGV[0];s/(.)/$1\n/g;s/([A-Z])/& CAPITAL' $1/g;s/([a-z])/& SMALL' \U$1/g;s/,/COMMA/g;s/& /LATIN /g;s/' / LETT, /g;s/&/AMP,SAND/g;s/'/APOSTROPHE/g;s/ \n/SPACE\n/g;s/\*/AST,ISK/g;s/-/HYPHEN-MINUS/g;s/\./FULL STOP/g;s/@/COMM,CIAL AT/g;s/~/TILDE/g;s/:/&/g;s/;/SEMI&/g;s/&/COLON/g;s/\|/V,TICAL&/g;s/_/LOW&/g;s/&/ LINE/g;s/\^/CIRCUMFLEX&/g;s/`/GRAVE&/g;s/&/ ACCENT/g;s/\//&/g;s/\\/REV,SE &/g;s/&/SOLIDUS/g;s/!/!&/g;s/"/"&/g;s/\?/?&/g;s/!/EXCLAMA/g;s/"/QUOTA/g;s/\?/QUES/g;s/&/TION MARK/g;s/#/NUMB,&/g;s/\$/DOLLAR&/g;s/%/P,CENT&/g;s/\+/PLUS&/g;s/</LESS-THAN&/g;s/=/EQUALS&/g;s/>/GREAT,-THAN&/g;s/&/ SIGN/g;s/\(/<&/g;s/\)/>&/g;s/&/ PARENTHESIS/g;s/\[/<&/g;s/\]/>&/g;s/&/ SQUARE'/g;s/{/<&/g;s/}/>&/g;s/&/ CURLY'/g;s/'/ BRACKET/g;s/</LEFT/g;s/>/RIGHT/g;s/0/&Z,O/g;s/1/&ONE/g;s/2/&TWO/g;s/3/&THREE/g;s/4/&FOUR/g;s/5/&FIVE/g;s/6/&SIX/g;s/7/&SEVEN/g;s/8/&EIGHT/g;s/9/&NINE/g;s/&/DIGIT /g;s/,/ER/g;print;
```

Answer (score 3):

### C++14 <s>716</s> <s>706</s> 704

```cpp
#include<iostream>
char*q,x,b[584],*t=b,a[]=R"(space}exclamation|mark}quot"-number|sign}dolla!apercent!mam"%sand}apostrophe}left|par%3hesis}righ"Wasterisk}plus*<comma}hy)#n{minus}full|stop}solid"Ldigit|zero!Tone!Gtw"kthre#&four!Uiv#&six!Heve>^!_e6r!ani,1colon}semi!Fless{than8Eequal:$grea<s$2quesMj>EJoial|at}lQ9n|capit"?let('|Jes+\re|bracket}r5urse|C5M?%2circumflex|acXR}low|l:bgrave#'0=smaNy0+curly*s/Ytic4z)$/\$itilde)",*s=a;int c,z,l='{';int main(){for(;x=*s++;)if(z=x-32,x>96)*t++=x<l?z:"- "[x%l];else for(c=z*95+*s++-32,q=t-c/13,x=3+c%13;x--;)*t++=*q++;while(std::cin.get(x)){for(s=b,z=0,c=x<65?x-32:x<91?z=33:x<97?x-57:x<l?z=40:x-82;c--;)while(*s++);auto&o=std::cout<<s;(z?o.put(x&~32):o)<<"\n";}}
```

[Live version](http://ideone.com/7iG4Vf).

With some whitespace:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// a is compressed using an LZ like compression scheme
char *q, x, b[584],
    *t = b,
    a[] =
        R"(space}exclamation|mark}quot"-number|sign}dolla!apercent!mam"%sand}apostrophe}left|par%3hesis}righ"Wasterisk}plus*<comma}hy)#n{minus}full|stop}solid"Ldigit|zero!Tone!Gtw"kthre#&four!Uiv#&six!Heve>^!_e6r!ani,1colon}semi!Fless{than8Eequal:$grea<s$2quesMj>EJoial|at}lQ9n|capit"?let('|Jes+\re|bracket}r5urse|C5M?%2circumflex|acXR}low|l:bgrave#'0=smaNy0+curly*s/Ytic4z)$/\$itilde)",
    *s = a;

int c, z, l = '{';

int main() {
    // Decompress from a into b
    for (; x = *s++;)
        if (z = x - 32, x > 96)
            *t++ = x < l ? z : "- "[x % l];
        else
            for (c = z * 95 + *s++ - 32, q = t - c / 13, x = 3 + c % 13; x--;) *t++ = *q++;

    // Process input a char at a time, performing a lookup into b for the c'th null separated string
    while (std::cin.get(x)) {
        for (s = b, z = 0,
            c = x < 65 ? x - 32 : x < 91 ? z = 33 : x < 97 ? x - 57 : x < l ? z = 40 : x - 82;
             c--;)
            while (*s++)
                ;
        auto& o = std::cout << s;
        (z ? o.put(x & ~32) : o) << "\n";
    }
}
```

The compressed string `a` decompresses to:

> space}exclamation|mark}quotation|mark}number|sign}dollar|sign}percent|sign}ampersand}apostrophe}left|parenthesis}right|parenthesis}asterisk}plus|sign}comma}hyphen{minus}full|stop}solidus}digit|zero}digit|one}digit|two}digit|three}digit|four}digit|five}digit|six}digit|seven}digit|eight}digit|nine}colon}semicolon}less{than|sign}equals|sign}greater{than|sign}question|mark}commercial|at}latin|capital|letter|}left|square|bracket}reverse|solidus}right|square|bracket}circumflex|accent}low|line}grave|accent}latin|small|letter|}left|curly|bracket}vertical|line}right|curly|bracket}tilde

And during decompression `}` is replaced with `\0`, `|` with   (space) and `{` with `-` and lowercase letters are converted to uppercase.

The string is compressed LZ style as either a literal `[a-~]` or a two character encoded offset/length to a match earlier in the string.

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 58 bytes

```
[ readln [ char>name "-"" " replace >upper print ] each ]
```

Pretty simple; does the exact same thing as the Java and Perl 6 answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](//golang.org), 145 bytes

```go
package main
import(."golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames"
."fmt")
func main(){r:='!'
for{_,e:=Scanf("%c",&r)
if e!=nil{break}
println(Name(r))}}
```

Some have address a concern with the above answer. I tried vendoring the code in
question, but my answer bypassed the 65,536 byte limit [1], so I think the above
answer is fine as is.

1. https://github.com/golang/text/blob/v0.3.6/unicode/runenames/tables13.0.0.go

Comment: From the question, `Internet and external libraries are not allowed, all necessary data should be in the code.`

Comment: When I run code myself, it says `cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames" in any of:
 /usr/lib/golang/src/golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames (from $GOROOT)
 /home/runner/go/src/golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: But it *is* my job to make sure that answers comply with the spirit and letter of the challenge. This runenames import appears to be an external library, which is disallowed.

Comment: Well, you keep insisting that it is a standard library, and I'm trying to figure out what reasoning you have behind it. I'd also like to note I have golfed with Go before, but am not entirely familiar with the import system. It's just pretty obvious which of the two libraries you are using is external and which is not.

Comment: Whether JoKing is a moderator or not is irrelevant here - any user should be able to check if an answer is valid by the rules. Obviously, not everyone is familiar with Go, so it is up to you to demonstrate that your answer follows all rules, including "Internet and external libraries are not allowed" If this answer requires the internet to work, then it isn't valid per the question. It'd be helpful if you could verify this or not, as you clearly know more about Go than either me or JoKing

Comment: [discussion in chat starting here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58544191#58544191)

Answer (score -1):

## PHP>=7, 54 Bytes

```
for(;a&$c=$argn[$i++];)echo"
".IntlChar::charName($c);
```

[IntlChar::charName](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.charname.php)