# Generate Dennis Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, palindrome

This challenge is a tribute to [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) user [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for winning the robbers' part of [The Programming Language Quiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54807/26997).

Looking at [Dennis' PPCG profile page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) we can see some pretty impressive stuff:

[image: Dennis' profile]

He currently has over sixty-eight *thousand* reputation, making him second in [rep overall](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), surpassing third place by almost thirty thousand. He recently [won](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5749/26997) our election for a new moderator and [got](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5846/26997) a shiny new diamond next to his name. But I personally think the most interesting part about Dennis is his PPCG user ID number: 12012.

At first glance `12012` almost looks like a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number), a number that reads the same when reversed, but it's a little off. It can become the palindrome `21012` if we swap the positions of the first `1` and `2`, and it can become the palindrome `12021` if we swap the last `1` and `2`. Also, following the convention that leading zeroes in a number are not written, swapping the first `1` and the `0` results in `02112` or rather `2112` which is another palindrome.

Let's define a **Dennis number** as a positive integer that is not palindromic itself but can be made into a palindrome by swapping the positions of at least one pair of any two digits. The **order** of a Dennis number is the number of distinct pairs of digits that can be swapped to make a (not necessarily distinct) palindrome.

So the order of `12012` is 3 since 3 distinct pairs of its digits (`12012`, `12012`, `12012`) can be swapped around to produce palindromes. `12012` happens to be the smallest order 3 Dennis number.

`10` is the smallest Dennis number and has order 1 because switching around the `1` and `0` gives `01` a.k.a. `1` which is a palindrome.

The imaginary leading zeroes of a number don't count as switchable digits. For example, changing `8908` to `08908` and swapping the first two digits to get the palindrome `80908` is invalid. `8908` is not a Dennis number.

Non-Dennis numbers could be said to have order 0.

## Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N and prints or returns the Nth smallest Dennis number *along with its order* in some reasonable format such as `12012 3` or `(12012, 3)`.

For example, `12012` is the 774th Dennis number so if `774` is the input to your program, the output should be something like `12012 3`. (Curiously, 774 is another Dennis number.)

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Here is are the first 20 Dennis numbers and their orders for reference:

```
N       Dennis  Order
1       10      1
2       20      1
3       30      1
4       40      1
5       50      1
6       60      1
7       70      1
8       80      1
9       90      1
10      100     1
11      110     2
12      112     1
13      113     1
14      114     1
15      115     1
16      116     1
17      117     1
18      118     1
19      119     1
20      122     1
```

[Here is the same list up to N = 1000.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2ZKcjwwP)

Comment: This has got to be added to OEIS

Comment: @Claudiu this [is](http://oeis.org/A263172) added to the OEIS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Pyth, 44 bytes

```
L/lf_ITs.e.e`sXXNkZYbN=N`b2,Je.f&!_I`ZyZQ0yJ
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%2Flf_ITs.e.e%60sXXNkZYbN%3DN%60b2%2CJe.f%26!_I%60ZyZQ0yJ&input=774&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%2Flf_ITs.e.e%60sXXNkZYbN%3DN%60b2%2CJe.f%26!_I%60ZyZQ0yJ&input=774&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&debug=0)

A stupid little bug (?) in Pyth ruined a 41 byte solution.

#### Explanation:

```
L/lf_ITs.e.e`sXXNkZYbN=N`b2
L                             define a function y(b), which returns:
                      =N`b       assign the string representation of b to N
        .e             N         map each (k=Index, b=Value) of N to:
          .e         N             map each (Y=Index, Z=Value) of N to:
              XXNkZbN                switch the kth and Yth value in N
            `s                       get rid of leading zeros
       s                         combine these lists
   f_IT                          filter for palindromes
  l                              length
 /                        2      and divide by 2

,Je.f&!_I`ZyZQ0yJ
   .f        Q0     find the first input() numbers Z >= 0, which satisfy
      !_I`Z            Z is not a palindrom
     &                 and 
           yZ          y(Z) != 0
  e                 get the last number
 J                  and store in J
,J             yJ   print the pair [J, y(J)]
```

Comment: And what is this 'stupid little bug (?)'

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Had to look up the Github history. It concerns `.f`. Here's the pull request that I made because of this question: https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/pull/151

Answer (score 44):

## CJam, 45 bytes

```
0{{)_s:C,2m*{~Ce\is_W%=},,2/:O!CCW%=|}g}ri*SO
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=MHt7KV9zOkMsMm0qe35DZVxpc19XJT19LCwyLzpPIUNDVyU9fH1nfXJpKlNP&input=Nzc0)

#### How it works

```
0          e# Push 0 (candidate).
{          e# Loop:
  {        e#   Loop:
    )_     e#     Increment the candidate and push a copy.
    s:C    e#     Cast to string and save in C.
    ,      e#     Get the length of C, i.e., the number of digits.
    2m*    e#     Push all pairs [i j] where 0 ≤ i,j < length(C).
    {      e#     Filter:
      ~    e#       Unwrap, pushing i and j on the stack.
      Ce\  e#       Swap the elements of C at those indices.
      is   e#       Cast to int, then to string, removing leading zeroes.
      _W%= e#       Copy, reverse and compare.
    },     e#     Keep the pairs for which = returned 1, i.e., palindromes.
    ,2/    e#     Count them and divide the count by 2 ([i j] ~ [j i]).
    :O     e#     Save the result (the order) in O.
    !      e#     Negate logically, so 0 -> 1.
    CCW%=  e#     Compare C with C reversed.
    |      e#     Compute the bitwise NOT of both Booleans.
           e#     This gives 0 iff O is 0 or C is a palindrome.
  }g       e#   Repeat the loop while the result is non-zero.
}ri*       e# Repeat the loop n times, where n is an integer read from STDIN.
           e# This leaves the last candidate (the n-th Dennis number) on the stack.
SO         e# Push a space and the order.
```

Comment: I've hit the rep cap already, but I *had to* post the first answer.

Comment: Ugh. How do I force myself to upvote a comment with 42 upvotes?

Comment: I got the 42nd upvote :P

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, 174 bytes

```
import Data.List
p x=x==reverse x
x!y=sum[1|(a,b)<-zip x y,a/=b]==2
o n|x<-show n=sum[1|v<-nub$permutations x,x!v,p$snd$span(<'1')v,not$p x]
f=([(x,o x)|x<-[-10..],o x>0]!!)
```

`p` checks whether a list is a palindrome.

`x!y` is `True` iff the lists `x` and `y` (which should have the same length) differ in exactly two places. Specifically, if `x` is a permutation of `y`, `x!y` determines whether it is a "swap".

`o n` finds the Dennis-order of `n`. It filters for swaps among the permutations of `x = show n`, and then counts how many of those swaps are palindromes. The list comprehension that performs this count has an extra guard `not (p x)`, which means it will return `0` if `n` was a palindrome to begin with.

The `snd (span (<'1') v)` bit is just `dropWhile` but one byte shorter; it turns `"01221"` into `"1221"`.

`f` indexes from a list of `(i, o i)` where `o i > 0` (i.e. `i` is a Dennis number.) There would normally be an off-by-one error here, as `(!!)` counts from 0 but the problem counts from 1. I managed to remedy this by starting the search from `-10` (which turned out to be considered a Dennis number by my program!) thereby pushing all the numbers into the right spots.

`f 774` is `(12012,3)`.

Answer (score 6):

### Rust, 390 bytes

```rust
fn d(mut i:u64)->(u64,i32){for n in 1..{let mut o=0;if n.to_string()==n.to_string().chars().rev().collect::<String>(){continue}let mut s=n.to_string().into_bytes();for a in 0..s.len(){for b in a+1..s.len(){s.swap(a,b);{let t=s.iter().skip_while(|&x|*x==48).collect::<Vec<&u8>>();if t.iter().cloned().rev().collect::<Vec<&u8>>()==t{o+=1}}s.swap(a,b);}}if o>0{i-=1;if i<1{return(n,o)}}}(0,0)}
```

The new Java? :/

Ungolfed and commented:

```rust
fn main() {
    let (num, order) = dennis_ungolfed(774);
    println!("{} {}", num, order);  //=> 12012 3
}

fn dennis_ungolfed(mut i: u64) -> (u64, i32) {
    for n in 1.. {
        let mut o = 0;  // the order of the Dennis number
        if n.to_string() == n.to_string().chars().rev().collect::<String>() {
            // already a palindrome
            continue
        }
        let mut s = n.to_string().into_bytes();  // so we can use swap()
        for a in 0..s.len() {  // iterate over every combination of (i, j)
            for b in a+1..s.len() {
                s.swap(a, b);
                // need to start a new block because we're borrowing s
                {
                    let t = s.iter().skip_while(|&x| *x == 48).collect::<Vec<&u8>>();
                    if t.iter().cloned().rev().collect::<Vec<&u8>>() == t { o += 1 }
                }
                s.swap(a, b);
            }
        }
        // is this a Dennis number (order at least 1)?
        if o > 0 {
            // if this is the i'th Dennis number, return
            i -= 1;
            if i == 0 { return (n, o) }
        }
    }
    (0, 0)  // grr this is necessary
}
```

Comment: [323 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZBNbsIwEIX3PcXAAmxhTEJRQQ7OJXqAyASnWErsyD@NqpCz0wks2lnY8vPTvE/PpxAfj8bClXQpghHp40C3JcGLpRMdG@fBgrGQcz62Oj5djg2sp5JkzPLoqhC9sV@EsnsQK3zcg5SB1zflA6Hc6288a9e2uo5CnD@f7pJQWphm0ZPV8EpRc0rG@cBbbclLu8ya2uR/KiLAjBDkwOvWWY27jUWIy0/UGFcEHgbVE8UutHAb2ZMQr0IglRCNd12VYnMiq0B5soNHI@XI01WtbmLVqVjfcMs6W1OqAqTTNJkGXJmNZitz5AVzzkevY/KWWObohIM1ZHSaO@yUQUYY3wBnJiU2dQycv2pPQWLHx@OBFs/vHluIrV2Q5TjBOC0Z/PMWALudLCHfZ/ke3t@mxy8)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 176

```
i=input()
n=9
c=lambda p:`p`[::-1]==`p`
while i:n+=1;x=`n`;R=range(len(x));r=[c(int(x[:s]+x[t]+x[s+1:t]+x[s]+x[t+1:]))for s in R for t in R[s+1:]];i-=any(r)^c(n)
print n,sum(r)
```

I can't imagine that my swapping code is particularly optimal, but this is the best I've been able to get. I also don't like how often I convert between string and integer...

For each number, it creates a list of a whether all of the swaps of two digits are palindromes. It decrements the counter when at least one of these values is true, and the original number is not a palindrome. Since `0+True` in python evaluates to `1` the sum of the final list works for the order of the Dennis number.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṚḌ=
=ċ0^2°;ḌÇ
DŒ!Qç@ÐfDL©Ṡ>Ñµ#Ṫ,®
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bma4biMPQo9xIswXjLCsDvhuIzDhwpExZIhUcOnQMOQZkRMwqnhuaA-w5HCtSPhuaoswq4&input=MTAw)

#### How it works

```
DŒ!Qç@ÐfDL©Ṡ>Ñµ#Ṫ,®  Main link. No arguments.

              µ      Combine the chain to the left into a link.
               #     Find; execute the chain with arguments k = 0, 1, 2, ...
                     until n values of k result in a truthy value, where n is an
                     integer read implicitly from STDIN. Return those n values.

D                      Decimal; convert k to the list of its digits in base 10.
 Œ!                    Generate all permutations of the digits.
   Q                   Unique; deduplicate the list of permutations.
      Ðf               Filter:
    ç@  D                Call the helper link on the second line with the
                         unpermuted digits (D) as left argument, and each
                         permutation as the right one.
                       Keep permutations for which ç returns a truthy value.
         L©            Compute the length (amount of kept permutations) and save
                       it in the register.
           Ṡ           Sign; yield 1 if the length is positive, and 0 otherwise.
            >Ṅ         Compare the sign with the result from the helper link on
                       the first line. This will return 1 if and only if the
                       length is positive and Ñ returns 0.
                Ṫ      Tail; extract the last value of k.
                 ,®    Pair it with the value in the register.


=ċ0^2°;ḌÇ              Helper link. Arguments: A, B (lists of digits)

=                      Compare the corresponding integers in A and B.
 ċ0                    Count the zeroes, i.e., the non-matching integers.
   ^2                  Bitwise XOR the amount with 2.
     °                 Convert to radians. This will yield 0 if exactly two
                       corresponding items of A and B are different ,and a
                       non-integral number otherwise.
      ;                Prepend the result to B.
       Ḍ               Convert the result from decimal to integer. Note that
                       leading zeroes in the argument won't alter the outcome.
        Ç              Call the helper link on the first line.


ṚḌ=                    Helper link. Argument: m (integer)

Ṛ                      Convert m to decimal and reverse the digits.
 Ḍ                     Convert back to integer.
  =                    Compare the result with m.
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 87

```
2↓⎕{⍺(2⊃⍵+K⌊~A∧.=⌽A)X,K←+/{⍵∧.=⌽⍵}¨1↓∪,{⍕⍎Y⊣Y[⌽⍵]←⍵⊃¨⊂Y←A}¨∘.,⍨⍳⍴A←⍕X←1+3⊃⍵}⍣{=/2↑⍺}3⍴0
```

The body of the loop returns a vector of 4 numbers: 1) its left argument `⍺` read from input, 2) count of Dennis numbers so far, 3) current value of `X` — the loop counter, and 4) its order `K` computed as sum of palindromes within 1-swap permutations.  It terminates when the first two elements become equal and last two are then returned as result.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 229

As usual, JavaScript shines for its ineptitude for combinatorics (or, maybe it's *my* ineptitude...). Here I get all possibile swap positions finding all binary numbers of the given length and just 2 ones set.

Test running the snippet below in Firefox (as MSIE is far from EcmaScript 6 compliant and Chrome is still missing default parameters)

```js
F=c=>(P=>{for(a=9;c;o&&--c)if(P(n=++a+'',o=0))for(i=1<<n.length;k=--i;[x,y,z]=q,u=n[x],v=n[y],!z&&u-v&&(m=[...n],m[x]=v,m[y]=u,P(+(m.join``))||++o))for(j=0,q=[];k&1?q.push(j):k;k>>=1)++j;})(x=>x-[...x+''].reverse().join``)||[a,o]

// TEST

function go(){ O.innerHTML=F(I.value)}


// Less Golfed
U=c=>{
  P=x=>x-[...x+''].reverse().join``; // return 0 if palindrome 
  
  for(a = 9; // start at 9 to get the first that is known == 10
      c; // loop while counter > 0
      o && --c // decrement only if a Dennis number found
      )
  {  
    o = 0; // reset order count
    ++a;
    if (P(a)) // if not palindrome
    {  
      n = a+''; // convert a to string
      for(i = 1 << n.length; --i; ) 
      {
        j = 0;
        q = [];
        for(k = i; k; k >>= 1)
        {
          if (k & 1) q.push(j); // if bit set, add bit position to q
          ++j;
        } 
        [x,y,z] = q; // position of first,second and third '1' (x,y must be present, z must be undefined)
        u = n[x], v = n[y]; // digits to swap (not valid if they are equal)
        if (!z && u - v) // fails if z>0 and if u==v or u or v are undefined
        {
          m=[...n]; // convert to array
          m[x] = v, m[y] = u; // swap digits
          m = +(m.join``); // from array to number (evenutally losing leading zeroes)
          if (!P(m)) // If palindrome ...
            ++o; // increase order count 
        }  
      }
    }
  }  
  return [a,o];
}

//////
go()
```

```html
<input id=I value=774><button onclick="go()">-></button> <span id=O></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 199

```awk
{for(;++i&&d<$0;d+=o>0)for(o=j=_;j++<l=length(i);)for(k=j;k++<l;o+=v!=i&&+r~s){split(t=i,c,v=s=r=_);c[j]+=c[k]-(c[k]=c[j]);for(e in c){r=r c[e];s=s||c[e]?c[e]s:s;v=t?v t%10:v;t=int(t/10)}}print--i,o}
```

### Structure

```awk
{
    for(;++i&&d<$0;d+=o>0)
        for(o=j=_;j++<l=length(i);)
            for(k=j;k++<l;o+=v!=i&&+r~s)
            {
                split(t=i,c,v=s=r=_);
                c[j]+=c[k]-(c[k]=c[j]);
                for(e in c)
                {
                    r=r c[e];
                    s=s||c[e]?c[e]s:s;
                    v=t?v t%10:v;
                    t=int(t/10)
                }
            }
    print--i,o
}
```

### Usage

Paste this to your console and replace the number after `echo`, if you want

```awk
echo 20 | awk '{for(;++i&&d<$0;d+=o>0)for(o=j=_;j++<l=length(i);)for(k=j;k++<l;o+=v!=i&&+r~s){split(t=i,c,v=s=r=_);c[j]+=c[k]-(c[k]=c[j]);for(e in c){r=r c[e];s=s||c[e]?c[e]s:s;v=t?v t%10:v;t=int(t/10)}}print--i,o}'
```

It gets slow at higher numbers ;)

### Ungolfed reusable version

```awk
{
    dennisFound=0

    for(i=0; dennisFound<$0; )
    {
        i++
        order=0

        for(j=0; j++<length(i); )
        {
            for(k=j; k++<length(i); )
            {
                split(i, digit, "")
                digit[j]+=digit[k]-(digit[k]=digit[j]) # swap digits

                tmp=i
                iRev=iFlip=iFlipRev=""

                for(e in digit)
                {
                    if(tmp>0)                        # assemble reversed i
                        iRev=iRev tmp%10
                    tmp = int( tmp/10 )

                    iFlip=iFlip digit[e]             # assemble flipped i

                    if(iFlipRev>0 || digit[e]>0)     # assemble reversed flipped i
                        iFlipRev=digit[e] iFlipRev   # without leading zeros
                }
                if(iRev!=i && 0+iFlip==iFlipRev) order++  # i is not a palindrome,
            }                                             # but flipped i is
        }
        if(order>0) dennisFound++
    }
    print i, order
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 156

```
->i{s=?9
(o=0;(a=0...s.size).map{|x|a.map{|y|j=s+'';j[x],j[y]=j[y],j[x];x>y&&j[/[^0].*/]==$&.reverse&&o+=1}}
o<1||s==s.reverse||i-=1)while i>0&&s.next!;[s,o]}
```

Uses the Ruby feature where calling `"19".next!` returns `"20"` to avoid having to convert types back and forth; we just use a regex to ignore leading `0s`. Iterates over all pairs of string positions to check for palindromic switches. I originally wrote this a recursive function but it busts the stack.

Output for 774 is `["12012", 3]` (removing the quotation marks would cost 4 more bytes but I think the spec allows them).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒÂÊ}ε©ā<2.Æε®DrèRyǝïÂQ}O‚}ʒθĀ}I<è
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSw4LDin3OtcKpxIE8Mi7Dhs61wq5EcsOoUnnHncOvw4JRfU/igJp9ypLOuMSAfUk8w6j//zc3NA) or [output the first \$n\$ Dennis numbers](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSw4LDin3OtcKpxIE8Mi7Dhs61wq5EcsOoUnnHncOvw4JRfU/igJp9ypLOuMSAfUnCo///MTAw).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞            # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ           # Filter it by:
  Â          #  Bifurcate the current number (short for Duplicate & Reverse Copy)
   Ê         #  Check that the reverse copy does NOT equal the number itself
 }ε          # After we've filtered out all palindromes: map over the remaining numbers:
   ©         #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    ā        #  Push a list in the range [1, length] (without popping)
     <       #  Decrease each by 1 to make the range [0, length)
      2.Æ    #  Get all possible pairs of this list
    ε        #  Map each pair of indices to:
     ®D      #   Push the number from variable `®` twice
       r     #   Reverse the stack order from [indices,nr,nr] to [nr,nr,indices]
        è    #   Get the digits of the number at these indices
         R   #   Reverse this pair
          y  #   Push the indices we're mapping over again
           ǝ #   And insert the reversed digits back into the number at the indices
     ï       #   Cast it to an integer to remove leading 0s
      Â      #   Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse Copy)
       Q     #   Check that the reverse copy equals the number itself,
             #   resulting in 1 if its a palindrome, and 0 if not
    }O       #  After the inner map: sum all truthy values together
      ‚      #  And pair it with the number
 }ʒ          # After the outer map: filter again:
   θ         #  Where the last value of the pair (the calculated order)
    Ā        #  Is not 0
  }I         # After the filter: push the input-integer
    <        # Decrease it by 1 (because 05AB1E uses 0-based indexing)
     è       # And get the pair at that index in the infinite list
             # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 151 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,x)=>(g=a=>(a=[...+a.join``+''])+''==a.reverse(k=0))(a=[...x+''])|a.map((p,i)=>a.map((q,j)=>k+=g(b=[...a],b[i]=q,b[j]=p)))|!k||--n?f(n,-~x):[x,k/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NDoIwEITvPsV6opuW@nMUVx@ENHHRQgBtEYwhEX113BgvszPJN5Nt@MnDua@7Rxrixc9zSSqYEemgKmJRptxaq9k2sQ6nk04ShyJEbHv/9P3gVUtrxD84/oCJ7Y07pTpTy9I/3E0jodVUqeLHsjNFXju6y2kcdYg4LdtpStNwLOWL9DPiLh9Nu9q6uYy9CkCwySDAnmC7FqM1wmsBcI5hiFdvr7GSHkgZMVu85y8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-alp`, 148 bytes

```perl
$_=9;while(!$o||--$F[0]){$o=0;if(++$_ ne reverse){for$i(0..(@a=/./g)){map{@b=@a;@b[$i,$_]=@b[$_,$i];$o+=($t=1*join'',@b)eq reverse$t}$i..$#a}}}say$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LTsMwFET39ytMe6UmJHHtlgBVZCkrdnxBFUUOcqmrNDaxA0Jpfh3TB8xqNnPOWNW3eUAjWEHmh8F5sjM9OQ6t17ZVxCvnHdEdMZ0i/dCBk9@z7C@z4rbwhjhlZS/9bUDepFMuYC02xddetyq6Q3M6ZRm@bFkVj1eb3kVJgjW5cNWn6p2Kx7MadcQojUoplnT5HsfjUdqxbEQpi7LZok6xrsSl1SnqqkCTiAi94PcHo7vFIi2bWH38E9FPqCnFuZym6fwcTQgcVrCGB8jhEZ7gGTbAGXAOfPVjrNemcyF7zSnjLGSytb8)

Output is on two lines.  First line is the order; second line is the number.