# Literally code golf

Tags: popularity-contest

In modern day standards *Golfing* translates to playing a game of *golf*, while *golf* itself translates to a car manufactured by Volkswagen.
So instead of the usual *golfing of code*, you will today be *coding a golf*.

### Challenge

Write a program (A) in language **A** which will output the source code of another program (B) of language **B**, which in it's turn will output `Vroom vrooom!` when executed.

### Rules

- The source code of program A is formatted into a nice ASCII car (not necessarily a volkswagen).
- Program A must be executable in the format you posted it in.
- Language A is ***NOT*** the same language as language B.
- The output of program B may or may not end with a new line.
- Program A takes no input.
- In non-obvious languages (esoteric) please explain program A.
- You must start your answer with `# Language A, Language B` eg. `# Brainfuck, Python`.
- Valid languages must have either an [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages), an [esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or a [Rosetta Code article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages) at the time this challenge was posted.
- Be creative :-)

### Scoring

This is a popularity contest. Whichever answer has the most upvotes by Oct 4, will be declared the winner.

### Example

## Brainfuck, Python 2

```
                   ++++++++++[>+++>
                ++++    ++>+++    ++++
              +++<        <<        -]>>>
     ++++++++++++.        ++        .------
   ---.+++++.++++++.<<++.++.>++++++++++++++
 ++++++++++++.>--.---..--.<<--.>>+++++++++.
 ----.---...--.----------------------------
  ---------------------------------------
     \--o--/                    \--o--/
      \-_./                      \+_./
```

This outputs the following code, which can be executed in Python 2;

```
print "Vroom vrooom!"
```

Comment: This is my first post on codegolf, feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure your golf's wheels can roll properly with this shape!

Comment: Heh, you're right. I'll have myself a sliding golf then.

Comment: Does program A have to run in the car format?

Comment: Yes. Edited my post to clarify

Comment: This question is too broad and focuses more on ASCII art skills than programming skills. In many languages, whitespace can be inserted at will, so this challenge boils down to an art contest.

Comment: While I agree with Dennis' comment, I'd like to point out that, if we ignore the nature of the question for a moment, this spec is quite well written for a first post. Good job :)

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your comments and I'll try to think of a more specific challenge next time. Also thanks for the nice words :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### evil, JavaScript (ES6)

```
                                        aeMeeeDDDeDDDwHwwwwwwDaeeaeae;.
                                  .eu@wa04QMMM4WHHWWM#404HGV#0B4aeee0HeHa
                               .ewD&M%e       aG##a       aa a@Q%Bwaaeeuu4.
                           .uwuwW&u          e&M&e        H  wB0B&uGMVBGuuGu
                          wuu@M0Bu           wW@4Be      ueu=w#H00%V%QG@W%eGa
               ...aa+aeeweWWaee#G&G%V@B@G0@B&00V0V0%4VB4%BQGeewwB%BwwwV0%HMwae
           eaeee&BQM%M@4B%Mu%4G@BMwaeeaeeaawwaeeeuuuuwaaaeewwwuueee&QBeweaeMQ4e
      ,w#QawaHBH4Veaaaawueueeawaaeeeeuuwue&%#eeaeewaaawueewaeaeawueaQBBeeeHVewe.
    .eeuu0waaeQMQ%0Waaaawaeaeeee+u<+<=<===->::w~<+<=~-:<><uuwaeeaee&@B&&uuwawaa.
   aaaaaweaaQ#@4%@4#Veuuu~><uuw<-ewaaeueeaweeeeueweaeewaaaee-weH#V#%BBQ@0ueeawea
   aeewuuu#QB4B4B&0W%QVeuweeeaeM4M%&0W&MG@M0QV%VB0M%W0M&#QQeae4%#G#Q%4#4Q#Vwu>uuw
  wQWGuuwMHWVVuue<e%eQ4M4#@0BBWVHVVQ#4HG4%B%#&H@M#BMM0G0MVW0WQ44uwue.eueHGG#waHBe
  e&H0ueeV%Heu0wu,GQu0BGWQVH40MM4@0H0BQMMHWW%weueeaawuuuuwuu#@4Hu@&w+MVw@4M%ueeB
   %B0V&QW%MaVee>uwH%BW%4aeeeeueeuweaeeeeBMBGM&%H0QG&44#Mwe&#%VaWeeee~&Qw#V%G&wu.
   eaeDD&WQ&eGu,.&&0H%04ewaeeaDeB%#HG&#H#BQQ#&#@0Vuw0HBMaD4H#G#eWDee%DaD.Ww
         .u%.ue.4aaa.@Mw                                    ,w&wDwwDwwue@a
           eeHueMwa@Ge                                       .uV&.eeDw.4u
            "ee00V0e'                                          "a@HB4wP
```

For the evil program, I used a similar method as I did for [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54833/4020). In summary, I generated an optimally short program (limited to [these four commands](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55428/4020)) that produced the desired JS, before mixing it with ignored characters to make a [Volkswagen golf](http://static.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/images/Auto/izmo/369081/2015_volkswagen_golf_sideview.jpg).

It prints out the following JS program, which in turn prints out `Vroom vrooom!` to the console:

```
       c=console
      o  =   x=>c
.log(x+"om!");O=o
Q="Vroom\x20vroo";
  (O)       (Q)
```

Answer (score 19):

## Common Lisp, BASIC (and Python)

I took inspiration from some nice [ASCII cars](http://www.retrojunkie.com/asciiart/vehicles/cars.htm).
Mine is a pickup truck seen from behind:

```
         (if'(
      (-----------------)  
    _(  _______________  )_ 
   (_( (               ) )_)
     ( (_______________) )
     (                   )
   (=======================)
   (( MY OTHER CAR        ))
   (( IS A CDR            ))
   (-----------------------)
    (  )               (  )
    (__)               (__))
(lambda()(format t"~&PRINT ~S~%""Vroom vroom!")))
```

Comment: +1 for the bumper sticker ;)

Comment: @ETHproductions It is an old joke, not mine, btw. It is [attributed to](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Erik_Naggum) Erik Naggum.

Comment: nice one. Liked the rear window

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, C++

My car is a [1988 Pontiac Trans Am](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontiac_Firebird_(third_generation)#1988). (I tried my best. :P)

```
                                 "#"e####===========_
                            "inclu"+               e#\
                          "de "   +           "<iostream>"+e#+--.____    __..
             N+N+"using"+" namespace "+"std;"+Ne#---" """""       """""  __'
      +N+"int "                                                    +"main()"+
 N+"{"+N+" "4*+"c"   +"out << \"Vr"+e#====================.--""  ""--.=======:
e#      [w] : /        \ : |========================|    : /        \ :  [w] :
"oom"+" vro"+            "oom!\";"+e#===============|    :|          |:   _-"
 N+"}"+e#___: \        / :_|=======================/_____: \        / :__-"
  e#--------'  ""____""  `-------------------------------'  ""____""
```

You can test this [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%23%22e%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22inclu%22%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22de%20%22%20%20%20%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%3Ciostream%3E%22%2Be%23%2B--.____%20%20%20%20__..%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20N%2BN%2B%22using%22%2B%22%20namespace%20%22%2B%22std%3B%22%2BNe%23---%22%20%22%22%22%22%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%22%22%20%20__'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2BN%2B%22int%20%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%22main()%22%2B%0A%20N%2B%22%7B%22%2BN%2B%22%20%224*%2B%22c%22%20%20%20%2B%22out%20%3C%3C%20%5C%22Vr%22%2Be%23%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D.--%22%22%20%20%22%22--.%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3A%0Ae%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bw%5D%20%3A%20%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%3A%20%7C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%7C%20%20%20%20%3A%20%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%3A%20%20%5Bw%5D%20%3A%0A%22oom%22%2B%22%20vro%22%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22oom!%5C%22%3B%22%2Be%23%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%7C%20%20%20%20%3A%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%3A%20%20%20_-%22%0A%20N%2B%22%7D%22%2Be%23___%3A%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%20%3A_%7C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2F_____%3A%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%20%3A__-%22%0A%20%20e%23--------'%20%20%22%22____%22%22%20%20%60-------------------------------'%20%20%22%22____%22%22).

### CJam

```
"#include <iostream>"N+N+"using namespace std;"+N+N+"int main()"N+"{"+N+" "4*+"cout << \"Vroom vrooom!\";"+N+"}"+
```

And you can test that, [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%22N%2BN%2B%22using%20namespace%20std%3B%22%2BN%2BN%2B%22int%20main()%22N%2B%22%7B%22%2BN%2B%22%20%224*%2B%22cout%20%3C%3C%20%5C%22Vroom%20vrooom!%5C%22%3B%22%2BN%2B%22%7D%22%2B).

### C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Vroom vrooom!";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

### BrainFuck, Golf Script, Glee, JQ, Lasso, Lang5 & many more

```
          ++++++++++
       [>+++     >+++++
     +++>++      +++++++++<
   <<-]>++       + +.>++++++.
  <>>>>>>><<<<<<<><><><><><><>
 >++++.---..--.<<--.>>+++++++--
 ++++.----.---...--.<<+.+.-----
       --              --
      |  |            |  |
       --              --
```

Output

> "Vroom vrooom!"

Which will be valid syntax for these language which will ouptut "Vroom vroom!"

Golf Script

Glee

<strike>J</strike>

JQ

Lasso

Lang5

m4

Ml/I

Salmon

TPP & many more

This list came from Rosetta code's Hello World Program

Comment: That source code doesn't look like any car I've ever seen!

Comment: @Fatalize. it was typo. And sorry for J

Answer (score 6):

## Java, Python

```
    public final class
Car{public static void main
(String    ...a    ){System
//CCCCC    CCCC    CCCCCCCC//
.out.println("print(\"Vroom"+
" vroom!\")");}}//HDBSKJBGIWE
      /////         /////
       ///           ///
```

(Sorry, the car's really bad)

Comment: That looks a lot more like a rain-cloud than a car :D

Comment: Yeah, it does. :)