# Unique multiplication by ten

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source

> People, it's a popularity contest, you have to do somthing cool here.
>   Think about cool ways of breaking the code in most languages, not about validating for everyting!

> Initially this challenge is NOT for esoteric languages. But I didn't disabled them as I expect voters to be fair enough to downvote answers based only on esoteric language syntax uniqueness.

> It's not too broad. I thought about code golf tag, but desided that it will be unnessesary limitation for the answers. I expect anwsers to be short and exploiting some language feature.

> By the way, I have an interesting solution for VB.NET and it is shorter than 8 chars :)

---

Write a statement that multiplies the (integer) variable by 10 and assigns result to the same variable. If your language has no integer type, you may assume that the value is an integer not greater then some limit (you can specify this limit yourself, but it defenitly have to be adequate).

The initial and resulting values have to be number. Using string as one of them (or both) is forbidden.

But you don't want the code to be protable, so you are going to write it in such way, that the code is valid for **as *few* programming languages as possible**. Ideally in the only language.

Example:

> You have variable
>
> ```
> int x = 77;
> ```
>
> and the answer is
>
> ```
> x *= 10;
> ```

Declaration is not the part of the answer, only `x *= 10;` is.
So this code is valid for C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript and probably some other languages.
It's defenity a bad answer in this challenge.
Just drop a semicolon to cut off C, C++, C# and Java, but VB.NET appears in this case.

Scoring system: it's a popularity contest. For now I'll define the answer score as number of votes, but I'll keep a right to change scoring system by including number of languages into it.

So you have to provide a statement and list of languages (ideally one language) it is valid in.

Comment: And some people just want to watch the world burn. I'd try to come up with a less subjective marking system, though.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find all languages a program is valid in.

Comment: @Lui, it's [tag:popularity-contest] ;) If you are ready to provide better scoring system, I'm ready to consider your proposal.

Comment: I'm downvoting because this essentially requires an answer to search through *every programming language ever* to see whether/how many others have the same behavior. [Here's a partial list, for reference.](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list)

Comment: Define "variable"; can I just change the value of an item in a stack?

Comment: @isaacg, it's popularity contest. You have not search for all programming languages in the world. Just do something cool to break the code correctness for the most typical things.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam, no objections.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54807/25180

Comment: @isaacg, initially this challenge is not for esoteric languages. But I didn't disabled them as I expect voters to be fair enough to downvote answers based only on language syntax uniqueness.

Comment: @isaacg, see an addition to the question.

Comment: Also, your `x *= 10` case also works for Mathematica.

Comment: The *anti-polyglot* idea may work as cops and robbers (polyglots are *cracked*), but there still is the problem that some languages (esoteric or not) will have a *very* easy time here. *I expect voters to be fair enough to downvote answers based only on esoteric language syntax uniqueness.* I don't understand that reasoning at all. The whole point of this challenge is exploiting syntax uniqueness.

Comment: @Dennis, the idea is simple. You have to do smth youself. Not find a language where plus sign by some reason means multiplication, and write `x+=10`. In fact I was to agressive with downvote, maybe just ignore. But definetly not upvote. You should do smth with typical solution in the language you chosen to prevent it correctness in other languages. I upvoted [Perl answer](/a/69332/32091) as it replaces multiplication by concatenation and uses the other feature - you can't programmly detect if the value is string or number - it's a rare feature. It's a good way.

Comment: @Dennis, so you should _find_ syntax or logical monents that will allow you to solve the challenge. It's not a collection like "how to multiply number by ten in different languases" where the language just provides you the unique way without any effort from your side. In fact, if you were making this task in normal life in the same language, I expect you to use the other solution. If they are the same - it's boring and shouldn't be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you can do:

```
$var .= 0;
```

because it is not typed.

or

```
$var =~ s/$/0/;
```

Regex that adds a zero at the end of line.

Comment: Does this code assigns a number to the variable? I trust that you can concatenate numbers, but what the result is? I expect it to be a string, then it's not ok. In this case you need some code to convert it back to number.

Comment: There are no type in Perl, integer and string are stored in same variables. The result for each is `770`

Answer (score 0):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 2 bytes

```
a*
```

Call this method through any normal means (00k or 0m). The top item of the stack will be multiplied by 10 (a in hexadecimal). This is very anti-polyglot because most stack based languages don't *have* methodology.