# Longest Common Prefix of 2 Strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program that takes 2 strings as input, and returns the longest common prefix. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the shortest amount of bytes wins.

```
Test Case 1:

"global" , "glossary"
"glo"


Test Case 2:

"department" , "depart"
"depart"

Test Case 3:

"glove", "dove"
""
```

Comment: Another good test case is `"aca", "aba"`.

Comment: Do you want a complete programs that inputs from STDIN and prints to STDOUT, or are functions OK?

Comment: Can we assume the input won't have newlines? Which characters will the input have?

Comment: General note: People using a regex based solution should not copy other people's regex answers without testing them yourself; this does not work in all regex engines. In particular, it gives different (both incorrect) answers in nvi and vim.

Comment: All of the examples given are in lowercase, but do we need to worry about case sensitivity? For example, should `global` and `GLOSSARY` return `glo` or `''`?

Comment: Are builtins allowed?

Comment: Can it return the length?

Answer (score 24):

## Python 3, 54 bytes

Thanks Python for having a built-in function for this task! :D

```
import os;print(os.path.commonprefix(input().split()))
```

Takes input as two words separated by a space such as `glossary global`.

Answer (score 23):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```haskell
(c:x)%(d:y)|c==d=c:x%y;_%_=""
```

Usage:

```
>> "global"%"glossary"
"glo"
```

Recursively defines the binary function `%` by pattern matching. On two strings with equal first letters, takes that first letters, and prepends it to the function of the remainder of the strings. On anything else, gives the empty string.

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
e@F._MQ
```

Thanks @isaacg for 1 byte off

Takes input quoted and comma separated, like `"abc", "acc"`. This exits on an error (but leaves stdout empty) when the result is the empty string. If that is unacceptable, add 2 bytes for `#e@F._MQq`

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e%40F._MQ&input=%22global%22%2C%22glossary%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22global%22%2C%22glossary%22%0A%22department%22%2C%22depart%22%0A%22glove%22%2C%22dove%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
e@F._MQ        : implicit Q = eval(input)
   ._MQ        : Map the prefix operator onto both inputs
 @F            : Fold the setwise intersection operator over those lists
e              : Take the last such element, the prefixes are always made from shortest
               : to longest, so this always gives the longest matching prefix
```

Comment: To make the result the empty string without error: `e|@F._M.z]k`.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I believe the thing I put in about surrounding it with `#...q` is one byte less than that, I'll edit in the full code, I guess that is confusing

Comment: Take input in the form `"abc", "def"` and you can use `Q` instead of `.z`

Answer (score 10):

### C++, <s>101</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```c
#include<iostream>
int i;main(){std::string s,t;std::cin>>s>>t;for(;s[i]==t[i];std::cout<<s[i++]);}
```

Reads two strings from `stdin`, prints the character at the current position from one of the strings while the character at the current position is equal to the character at the same position in the other string.

Thanks to [Zereges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43365/zereges) for saving one byte.

Comment: That is a beautiful and terrifying use of the `for` statement...

Comment: The loop would fail to terminate if the strings were equal.

Comment: Won't work for strings containing whitespaces. You can save one byte, by making `int i` in global space (so that it will be 0 initialized)

Comment: @JonTrauntvein I think that case is UB(?). It works™ for me though. (gcc-5.1)

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
l_q.-{}#<
```

This reads the strings on two separate lines with Unix-style line ending, i.e., `<string>\n<string>\n`.

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for -1 byte, and to @jimmy23013 for -2 bytes!*

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l_l.-X%2B%7B%7D%23%3C&input=department%0Adepart).

#### How it works

```
l_         e# Read a line (w/o trailing LF) from STDIN and push a copy.
  q        e# Read another line from STDIN (with trailing LF).
           e# The trailing linefeed makes sure that the lines are not equal.
   .-      e# Perform vectorized character subtraction. This yields 0 for equal
           e# characters, a non-zero value for two different characters, and the
           e# characters themselves (truthy) for the tail of the longer string.
     {}#   e# Find the index of the first truthy element.
        <  e# Keep that many characters from the first string.
```

Comment: Darn, I can't believe my very first answer was so close!

Comment: You can cheat a bit by assuming a trailing newline and use `l_q.-`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 That's standard for input on Unix-like OS's, so why not? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```
((map fst.fst.span(uncurry(==))).).zip
```

Usage example: `(  ((map fst.fst.span(uncurry(==))).).zip  ) "global" "glossary"` -> `"glo"`.

Zip both input string into a list of pairs of characters. Make two lists out of it: the first one with all pairs from the beginning as long as both characters are equal, the second one with all the rests. Drop the second list and extract all characters from the first list.

Answer (score 8):

## APL, 13

```
{⊃↓K/⍨=⌿K←↑⍵}
```

This is a function that takes an array of two strings, and returns the prefix:

```
      {⊃↓K/⍨=⌿K←↑⍵}'glossary' 'global'
glo
      {⊃↓K/⍨=⌿K←↑⍵}'department' 'depart'
depart
```

Comment: Is it really fair to say that the APL alphabet is an alphabet of byte-size characters? Or is that standard practice around here?

Comment: @Filipq Answers here use the encoding most natural to the language. APL has its own code page on which each character is a single byte.

Comment: this fails when there are matching letters after the longest common prefix, e.g. "string" "stronger" should give just "str", not "strng"

Answer (score 8):

## AppleScript, 215 Bytes

And I tried so hard... ;(

```
set x to(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned
set a to(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned
set n to 1
set o to""
repeat while x's item n=a's item n
set o to o&x's item n
set n to n+1
end
o
```

I wanted to see how well AppleScript could pull this off, and *man* is it not built for string comparisons.

Comment: AppleScript wasn't built for *anything*.

Comment: The only thing I use it for besides terrible golfs is `tell app "System Events" to <something>`. It _is_ interesting to see how it deals with this kind of stuff, though. @kirbyfan64sos

Answer (score 7):

## sed, 18

I had something much longer and more complicated in mind, so credit for [this idea goes to @kirbyfan64sos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62779/11259).

```
s/(.*).* \1.*/\1/
```

Includes +1 for the `-r` option to sed.

Comment: What was your original idea?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos It basically involved looping through characters one by one and stopping at a mismatch.  It was just an idea - no code behind it.

Answer (score 7):

### C#, <s>201</s> 147 bytes

```
using System.Linq;class a{static void Main(string[]a){a[0].Take(a[1].Length).TakeWhile((t,i)=>a[1][i]==t).ToList().ForEach(System.Console.Write);}}
```

I know it isn't terribly competitive. I just wanted to see what it would look like.

EDIT: Thanks Ash Burlakzenko, Berend, and Dennis_E

Comment: Just getting a C# answer under 250 bytes is competitive. Also, can't you just `using System.*`?

Comment: `.ForEach(x=>Console.Write(x))` could be shortened to `.ForEach(Console.Write)`

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic;` is unnecessary. Shave off one more byte by removing the space from `string[] a`.

Comment: 1-The `Contains` is unnecessary. 2-You can save a few bytes by removing `using System;` and saying `System.Console.Write;` 3-This code returns the wrong result ("a") for input "aab","aaab", because of `IndexOf`. The shortest fix I could think of is using `a[0].Take(a[1].Length)` This is 147 bytes long: "using System.Linq;class a{static void Main(string[]a){a[0].Take(a[1].Length).TakeWhile((c,i)=>a[1][i]==c).ToList().ForEach(System.Console.Write);}}"

Comment: Thanks for the comments when I get a break I'll take a good look at all of them especially Dennis_E's comment.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <strike>12</strike> <strike>8</strike> 26

```
r:AAr:B.=0#_W={;;ABe<}{<}?
```

[Try it Online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%3AAAr%3AB.%3D0%23_W%3D%7B%3B%3BABe%3C%7D%7B%3C%7D%3F&input=glowing%20glow)

(Got idea to use .= instead of .- after looking at Dennis's answer.)

With all the edge cases, it became to hard for a CJam beginner like me to keep it short. Hopefully, this at least works for all cases.

Answer (score 6):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 14 bytes

```
(.*).* \1.*/\1
```

[Live demo and test cases.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%28.*%29.*%20%5C1.*%2F%5C1&input=global%20glossary%0Adepartment%20depart%0Aglove%20dove)

This is pretty simple. It just matches the...longest common prefix and removes the rest of the string. If there is no longest common prefix, it just clears everything.

Answer (score 5):

### Common Lisp, 39

```
(lambda(a b)(subseq a 0(mismatch a b)))
```

Takes two string arguments, determines the index *i* where they differ, and returns a substring from 0 to *i*.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6, 52 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>[...a].filter((e,i)=>e==b[i]?1:b='').join``
```

Usage:

```
>> f("global","glossary")
"glo"
```

Comment: Does not work with `ada,aca`...

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Forgot to kill filtering after the strings no longer match.

Comment: You don't need to name the function, so you can leave out the `f=`

Comment: you can do it smaller with map `(a,b)=>[...a].map((e,i)=>e==b[i]?e:b='').join\`\``

Comment: `b` can be given `0` rather than `""`

Answer (score 5):

### Perl 5, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

19 bytes, plus 1 for the `-E` flag instead of `-e`:

```
say<>=~/^(.*).* \1/
```

This is copied shamelessly from [Digital Trauma](/u/11259)'s [sed answer](/a/62806). It assumes the input is a couple of words without spaces in them (or before the first) and with one space between them.

---

Update:

[ThisSuitIsBlackNot](/u/31388) suggested using `-pe` as follows, to save a byte (thanks!):

```
($_)=/^(.*).* \1/
```

And then [Luk Storms](/u/42827) suggested using `-nE` as follows to save another byte (thanks!):

```
say/^(.*).* \1/
```

(I'm counting `-E` as one byte instead of the standard `-e`, but `-n` or `-p` as two. My impression is that that's SOP around here.)

Comment: ["`-M5.010`, when needed, is free"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/31388). Per the same meta post, `-pe` or `-ne` would be 1 additional byte, not 2. So `perl -nE 'say/^(.*).* \1/'` would score 16 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 72

31 bytes saved thanks to FryAmTheEggman.
8 saved thanks to DSM.

```
r=''
for x,y in zip(input(),input()):
 if x==y:r+=x
 else:break
print(r)
```

Comment: What would Python programmers do without `zip`? :D

Comment: @BetaDecay Our fly would be open all the time.

Comment: You could put the `input()`s in the `zip` and save the `a` and `b` binding.

Comment: @DSM Ooo, good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 47

```python
def f(w):[print(end=c[c!=d])for c,d in zip(*w)]
```

A function that takes a list `w` of two words, and prints the common prefix before terminating with an error.

Python 3's `print` function lets you prints strings flush against each other with `print(end=c)` (thanks to Sp3000 for saving 3 bytes with this shorter syntax). This repeatedly take two letters from the words, and prints the first of the letters. The indexing `c[c!=d]` gives an out-of-bounds error where `c!=d`, terminating the execution when two unequal letters are encountered.

An explicit for loop is one char longer than the list comprehension:

```
def f(w):
 for c,d in zip(*w):print(end=c[c!=d])
```

Comment: Wow! I hadn't even thought about using a function! Nice one. +1

Comment: Only saw this now, but how about `print(end=c[c!=d])`?

Comment: @Sp3000 Wow, I never connected that the main argument to `print` being optional meant it could be called with only the end argument, and that could contain the string. That's a really useful trick in general. You should make a tip.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
y!=XdYpf)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v1LRNiIlsiBN8/9/9ZTUgsSiktzUvBJ1LignNUUdAA)

*(-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe)*

```
 y  % implicitly input the two strings, then duplicate the
    %  first one into the stack again
    %  stack: ['department' 'deported' 'department']
 !  % transpose the last string into a column vector
 =  % broadcast equality check - gives back a matrix comparing
    %  every letter in first input with the letters in the second
 Xd % diagonal of the matrix - comparison result of each letter with
    %  only corresponding letter in the other string
    %  stack: ['department' [1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 1; 0; 0;]]
 Yp % cumulative product (so only initial sequence of 1s remains
    %  1s, others become 0)
    %  stack: ['department' [1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;]]
 f  %  find the indices of the 1s
 )  % index at those elements so we get those letters out
    % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 14 bytes

Uses the same idea as [kirbyfan64sos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62779/34718). Unfortunately, despite Martin's claim that eventually Match mode will feature a way to print capturing groups, it hasn't been implemented yet. Otherwise, `(.*).* \1` could be used along with 2 bytes or so for some not-yet-existing configuration string option.

```
(.*).* \1.*
$1
```

Each line would go in its own file, with 1 byte added per additional file. Alternatively, run in a single file with the `-s` flag.

Comment: The equivalent regex fails to match in vim due to greediness (and a non-greedy regex will match the _shortest_ substring, i.e. blank), are you sure it works?

Comment: @Random832 Try using this [regex replace tester](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php), with the .NET option checked. Set the operation to "replace", and put the patterns in the correct boxes. It doesn't fail to match if there should be one. How could it possible *fail* due to greediness? That's the only reason it works. `\1` ensures that both words start with the same prefix. So no matter how greedy `(.*)` is, `\1` is the same.

Comment: In vim it refuses to match at all - I think it is finding a longer string for the first (.*), then failing to match it against \1, then not properly backtracking to shorter strings.

Comment: @Random832 Then you need to find something else to test your regexes on.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 27 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
Um$(X,Y)=>$A&&X==VgY ?X:A=P
```

(The strings go into the Input box like so: `"global" "glossary"`)

This code is exactly equivalent to the following JS:

```
A=10;(U,V)=>U.split``.map((X,Y)=>A&&X==V[Y]?X:A="").join``
```

I have not yet implemented anonymous functions, which is what the `$...$` is for: anything between the dollar signs is left untouched in the switch to JS. After I add functions, this 21-byte code will suffice:

```
UmXY{A&&X==VgY ?X:A=P
```

And after I implement a few more features, it will ideally be 18 bytes:

```
UmXY{AxX=VgY ?X:AP
```

Suggestions welcome!

---

So it turns out that this program is only 15 bytes in modern Japt:

```
¡A©X¥VgY ?X:A=P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39ooeOhlRGHloalRyrYR1g52gb8/6@UnpOflJijpABiFBcnFlUqAQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 62 bytes

```julia
f(a,b)=(c="";for(i,j)=zip(a,b) i!=j?break:(c*=string(i))end;c)
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(a::AbstractString, b::AbstractString)
    # Initialize an output string
    c = ""

    # Iterate over the pairs of characters in a and b,
    # truncated to the shorter of the two lengths
    for (i, j) in zip(a, b)
        if i == j
            # If they match, append to the output string
            c *= string(i)
        else
            # Otherwise stop everything!
            break
        end
    end

    return c
end
```

Fixed an issue (at the hefty cost of 14 bytes) thanks to xnor!

Answer (score 2):

## K, 24 bytes

```
{(+/&\=/(&/#:'x)#'x)#*x}
```

Find the minimum of the length of each string. (`(&/#:'x)`). Trim each string to that length (`#'x`). Then compare, smear and sum the resulting sequence:

```
  =/("globaa";"glossa")
1 1 1 0 0 1
  &\=/("globaa";"glossa")
1 1 1 0 0 0
  +/&\=/("globaa";"glossa")
3
```

Finally, take that many characters from the first of the strings provided (`#*x`).

In action:

```
 f: {(+/&\=/(&/#:'x)#'x)#*x};
 f'(("global";"glossary")
    ("department";"depart")
    ("glove";"dove")
    ("aaa";"aaaaa")
    ("identical";"identical")
    ("aca";"aba"))
("glo"
 "depart"
 ()
 "aaa"
 "identical"
 ,"a")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, 65 bytes

Compare the strings, shrinking the first until it either matches (print and exit) or the string is null and the loop terminates.

```
param($a,$b)while($a){if($b-like"$a*"){$a;exit}$a=$a-replace".$"}
```

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB, <s>50</s> 40 bytes

Defines a function that accepts 2 strings as input, outputs to command window

```
function t(a,b);a(1:find([diff(char(a,b)) 1],1)-1)
```

This solution will work for any string, outputs

```
ans =

   Empty string: 1-by-0
```

if no match is given.

Can be golfed by  using a script instead of a function (using local variables a, b) (-16 bytes).

so getting 34 Bytes

```
a(1:find([diff(char(a,b)) 1],1)-1)
```

The function style (which seems to be the accepted style), yields

```
@(a,b)a(1:find([diff(char(a,b)) 1],1)-1)
```

(Thanks @Stewie Griffin)

Comment: 40 bytes: `@(a,b)a(1:find([diff(char(a,b)) 1],1)-1)`. =)

Answer (score 2):

### C99, 73 bytes

```
main(int c,char *a[]){for(char *x=a[1],*y=a[2];*x==*y++;putchar(*x++));}
```

Similar to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62967/7464), but shorter and meets spec (takes input from stdin).

Comment: Spec doesn't say input has to come from stdin. This is actually longer than the other answer if you add `#include<stdio.h>`, which is necessary for the program to compile.

Comment: @AndrewCashner - It doesn't need to be on stdin, but it does need to take input. The other answer is hard-coded.  Also, gcc whines about the implicit usage, but it compiles fine without the include.

Comment: Much shorter without the temporaries: `main(int c,char**a){for(;*a[1]==*a[2]++;putchar(*a[1]++));}` (59 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 28 bytes

I came up with two that take their values from STDIN which are based on the Perl 5 answer.

```perl6
lines~~/(.*).*' '$0/;say ~$0
```

```perl6
lines~~/:s(.*).* $0/;say ~$0
```

The first requires exactly one space between the inputs, while the other requires at least one whitespace character between the inputs.

---

That is quite a bit shorter than the first thing I tried which takes the values from the command line.

```perl6
say [~] map ->($a,$b){$a eq$b&&$a||last},[Z] @*ARGS».comb # 58 bytes
```

or even the lambda version of it:

```perl6
{[~] map ->($a,$b){$a eq$b&&$a||last},[Z] @_».comb} # 52 bytes
```

Though this is much easier to adjust so that it accepts any number of input strings, at the cost of only one stroke.

```perl6
{[~] map ->@b {([eq] @b)&&@b[0]||last},[Z] @_».comb} # 53 bytes
#          ┗━┛ ┗━━━━━━━┛  ┗━━━┛
```

```perl6
my &common-prefix = {[~] map ->@b {([eq] @b)&&@b[0]||last},[Z] @_».comb}

say common-prefix <department depart>; # "depart"
say common-prefix; # ""
say common-prefix <department depart depot deprecated dependant>; # "dep"

# This code does not work directly with a single argument, so you have
# to give it an itemized List or Array, containing a single element.

say common-prefix $('department',); # "department"

# another option would be to replace `@_` with `(@_,)`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ø€ËγнÏ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I5HTWsOd5/bfGHv4f7//9Nz8pMSc7iAVHFxYlElAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWCy9EF/w/veNS05nD3uc0X9h7u/6/zPzpaKT0nPykxR0kHxCguTiyqVIrViVZKSS1ILCrJTc0rAcpAOGBxoKKyVJAQiAIJlGRkFisAUaJCSWoxSDFcIC@/JCO1CCIMUpmYlGyYkmppkQZUBGQbpaRamKcpxcYCAA).

Or alternatively:

```
ηR.ΔÅ?
```

Might be invalid, since it outputs `-1` instead of an empty string if the strings have no common prefix.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PYgvXNTDrfa//@fnpOflJjDBaSKixOLKgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6P9z24P0zk2JKD7cav@/Vud/dLRSek5@UmKOkg6IUVycWFSpFKsTrZSSWpBYVJKbmlcClIFwwOJARWWpICEQBRIoycgsVgCiRIWS1GKQYrhAXn5JRmoRRBikMjEp2TAl1dIiDagIyDZKSbUwT1OKjQUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ø      # Zip the two (implicit) inputs together, creating pairs
       #  i.e. "abc1de98f" and "abc2de87f"
       #   → ["aa","bb","cc","12","dd","ee","98","87","ff"]
 €Ë    # Check for each if all inner items (the two characters in this case) are the same
       #  → [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
   γ   # Split it into parts, grouping the same subsequent values together
       #  → [[1,1,1],[0],[1,1],[0,0],[1]]
    н  # Pop and only leave the first item
       #  → [1,1,1]
     Ï # Only leave the characters at the truthy indices in the (implicit second) input
       #  i.e. "abc2de87f" and [1,1,1] → "abc"
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

η      # Get the prefixes of the first (implicit) input
       #  i.e. "abc1de98f"
       #   → ["a","ab","abc","abc1","abc1d","abc1de","abc1de9","abc1de98","abc1de98f"]
 R     # Reverse this list
       #  → ["abc1de98f","abc1de98","abc1de9","abc1de","abc1d","abc1","abc","ab","a"]
  .Δ   # Then find the first item in this list which is truthy for:
       # (which will result in -1 if none are found)
    Å? #  Check if the second (implicit) input starts with the current prefix
       #   i.e. "abc2de87f" and "abc1d" → 0 (falsey)
       #   i.e. "abc2de87f" and "abc" → 1 (truthy)
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [Alt 6](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PZTkw632tee2/H/f3pOflkqVwqQAAA). This one outputs `[]` instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>6</s></sup> 4 bytes

```
→¤nḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbpENL8h7uWPz///@U1ILEopLc1LwSKLO0KBUA)

-2 bytes from Dominic Van essen.

Comment: [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbpENL8h7uWPz///@U1ILEopLc1LwSKLO0KBUA) using 'combin' (```¤```)...

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure/ClojureScript, 51

```
(defn f[[a & b][c & d]](if(= a c)(str a(f b d))""))
```

Pretty straightforward.  Unfortunately the spaces around the parameter destructuring are necessary (that's the `[a & b]` stuff).  Not the shortest but I beat some other answers in languages that like to brag about their terseness so I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 50 bytes

```
for a,b in zip(*input()):print(1/0if a!=b else a),
```

---

#### Input

The input is taken as two strings:

```
"global", "glossary"
```

---

#### Output

The output is each character followed by a space; which, hopefully, isn't a problem. However, if it is, I'll edit my answer.

```
g l o
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is invalid; the spec clearly gave the output format as a string without spaces.

Comment: Well yes, but the input was also given in the format `"global" , "glossary"` (two separate strings).. How many other answers follow that to the letter? @ThomasKwa

Comment: "takes two strings" is the language used by OP; usually when something like that is mentioned without any qualifiers, it refers to one of our [default I/O](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), which means we can take one string from the command line and one from STDIN, or an array of two strings, or whatever else follows those rules.

Comment: I think you're taking my answer a bit too seriously. This is just a fun submission and my best attempt at beating a built-in. If OP doesn't like the output format, so be it; I'll remove my answer. @ThomasKwa

Comment: How about `print(exit()if a!=b else a,end='')`? I don't know if that'll work or not, but it might

Comment: Oh wait, no mine would be shorter then :D

Comment: `end=''` only works for Python 3 because `print` is a function :P @BetaDecay

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about STDERR. I was originally experimenting with it, but I guess it just faded away, haha. Also, there are *many* properly working variations, but they're all 56-61 bytes (except xnor's). @FryAmTheEggman

Comment: Yeah my other version didn't actually work, hence the deleted comment :S Anyway the `1/0` thing should work

Answer (score 1):

## TeaScript, 16 bytes <s>20</s>

```
xf»l¦y[i]?1:b=0)
```

Takes each input separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

## , 25 chars / 39 bytes

```
ô⟦ï0]Ă⇀$≔ï1[_]?1:ï1=0)ø⬯)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin//interpreter.html?eval=true&input=%5B%27global%27%2C%27glob%27%5D&code=%C3%B4%E2%9F%A6%C3%AF0%5D%C4%82%E2%87%80%24%E2%89%94%C3%AF1%5B_%5D%3F1%3A%C3%AF1%3D0%29%C3%B8%E2%AC%AF%29)</kbd>

It barely looks like ES6.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 90 bytes

```
object S extends App{print(args(0)zip args(1)takeWhile{case(a,b)=>a==b}map(_._1)mkString)}
```

It takes to Strings as arguments and outputs to stdout.

Comment: This won't print a string to STDOUT, but a `Vector[Tuple2[Char,Char]]`

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

### ed, sed, 19 bytes

### ex, 18 bytes

### vim, 20 bytes

```
s/\(.*\).* \1.*/\1/
```

This also works with ex/vi (heirloom ex 050325), and the trailing slash is not required.

Oddly, this *should* work in vim, but mysteriously fails. It works if I add another unused capture group, something which should not change the semantics of the regex at all:

```
s/\v(.*)(.* \1.*)/\1
```

It fails and gives garbage answers in nvi and the results are downright mysterious:

```
:1
global glossary
:s/\(.*\)\(.*\) \1\(.*\)/\1{\2,\3}/
global{,ry}
```

NOTE: This expects the words on the current [last in the file] line [or every line for the sed script] separated by a space, and containing no space. To operate on every line in ex/vim, add % to the beginning. I don't think I'm the only program here to have constraints like these.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 52 bytes

Not spectacular but does the job:

```
$a=$argv;while($a[1][$i]==$a[2][$i])echo$a[1][$i++];
```

Takes two command line arguments:

```
php prefix.php department depart
```

Comment: PHP7 lets you save another byte `while(($a=$argv)[1][$i]==$a[2][$i])echo$a[1][$i++];` - Another PHP7 only solution (and best I could come up with @ 50 bytes) `<?=substr(($a=$argv)[1],0,strspn($a[1]^$a[2],~ÿ));` - Make sure your editor is in ascii mode, it's important the `~ÿ` does not get converted to unicode.

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB, 63 bytes

Defines a function that accepts 2 strings as input.

```
function f(a,b),c=1;try,while a(c)==b(c),c=c+1;end,end,a(1:c-1)
```

Had to include a try-statement for those cases where a would be **a** is a longer string than **b**.

- If we have the freedom to always supply the shorter string to **a**, then **8 bytes** can be removed.
- If it is allowed to define **a** and **b** in the workspace, then another **16 bytes** can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <strike>85</strike> <strike>83</strike> 77 bytes

```
def f(a:String,b:String)=a zip b takeWhile(a=>a._1==a._2) map(_._1) mkString
```

for example,

```
f("global" , "glossary")
```

returns

```
glo
```

Comment: (edited: the return type is made explicit by the last "mkString" invocation)

Answer (score 1):

### C# <strike>147</strike> 146

```
string l(string a,string b){var s="";for(int i=0;i<Math.Min(a.Length,b.Length);i++){if(a[i]==b[i])s+=a[i];else return a.Substring(0,i);}return s;}
```

Readable and ungolfed version

```
    string longestPrefix(string a, string b)
    {
        var s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length); i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[i]) s+=a[i];
            else return a.Substring(0, i);
        }

        return s;
    }
```

### How it works:

It loops until characters on the same index do not match. Every character that matches is added to **s** string, otherwise return a new string from zero index to current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 130 bytes

```
substr(x[1],1,which.max(apply(do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(x,''),`length<-`,nchar(x[1]))),2,function(i)!length(unique(i))==1))-1)
```

Usage:

```
x <- c('bubblegum','bubbafish')
```

Answer (score 1):

## brainfuck, 91 bytes

```
+[>>,>++++[<-------->-]<]<<[<<]>+[>>++++[>++++++++<-],]<[<]>>-<[>>[<+>>-<-]+>[<->,]<[<.,]>]
```

Requires an interpreter that either allows negative positions on the tape or wraps if you `<` from 0. Also requires `,` to return 0 every time you use it after input runs out. (In my experience these are both the most common behaviour.) Takes input as two words separated by a space.

This was a lot easier than I expected it to be! Usually I decide to write a brainfuck program and end up devoting quite a bit of time to it, but this one played nice. My first idea ended up working well and being rather short, especially for brainfuck.

This works by getting the entire first word and storing the characters in every second cell, then weaving in the second word (e.g. `gglloosbsaalr y`). Then, for each pair of characters `a` and `b`, it copies `a` a cell to the left and simultaneously replaces `b` with `b-a`. The cell `a` used to be in becomes `NOT (b-a)`. If that's true, `a` is printed and the loop continues to the next set of characters. Otherwise, nothing is printed and the loop terminates.

I only used two real golfing tricks in this program. The first was combining two unrelated loops while gathering input. The first word is initially stored with each of its bytes subtracted by 32, so that space becomes 0 and the loop can end. Rather than adding 32 to each of those bytes and then getting the second word, the program does both at the same time. The second trick I used was abuse of `,` when I know the input is empty. The idiomatic way of setting a cell to 0 is `[-]`. However, if you know that the program has already read the entire input, most interpreters will let you try to get a byte of input anyway and set the current cell to `NUL`, or 0. I use this twice in my program, saving 4 bytes.

**Ungolfed:**

```
+[>>,>++++[<-------->-]<]          get first word (minus 32 at each byte)

<<[<<]>                            go back to start

+[>>++++[>++++++++<-],]            get second word and add 32 to each byte of
                                   first word

<[<]>>-<                           go back to start and clean up a little bit

[                                  main loop

  >>[<+>>-<-]                        subtract letter from second word from
                                     letter of first word 

  +>[<->,]<                          logical NOT the result

  [<.,]>                             if the result is 1: print the letter
                                     else: the loop dies and execution is
                                     terminated 

]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript: 67 Bytes

```
(a,b)=>{for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){if(a[i]!=b[i])return a.slice(0,i)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MUMPS, 54 bytes

```
t(a,b) f i=$L(a):-1:0 s p=$E(a,1,i) q:p=$E(b,1,i)
    q p
```

Typically primitive stuff - it just compares successively-shorter prefixes of the strings until it hits a match.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 37 bytes

```
i:0( ?\
4*=?\$>1+{:8
+[r]\$1
?!;o>:{=
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=aTowKCA_XAo0Kj0_XCQ-MSt7OjgKK1tyXVwkMQo_ITtvPjp7PQ&input=ZGVwYXJ0bWVudCBkZXBhcnQ)

Input is via STDIN, and is expected without quotes, separated by a space. For example, `global glossary`.

After the input is read, the characters up to and including the space are reversed and pushed back onto the stack. For example, if the input were `global glossary`, the stack would be `glossary labolg`. The stack is then rotated to the left one step at a time. If the top two chars are the same, output. Otherwise, end.

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, 61 bytes

```
+
[
  ,[<+> >+<-]
  ++++[>--------<-]
  >
]
<<[<]
<+
[
  ,[>+>-<<-]
  >>[<]
  <[.>]
  <
]
```

Expects two words separated by a space.

[Try it online.](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1ssWzwrPj4rPC1dKysrK1s-LS0tLS0tLS08LV0-XTw8WzxdPCtbLFs-Kz4tPDwtXT4-WzxdPFsuPl08XQ&input=Z2xvYmFsIGdsb3NzYXJ5)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 76 bytes

```
(a,b)->{String m="";for(int i=0;i<a.length&&a[i]==b[i];)m+=a[i++];return m;}
```

Lambda that takes 2 `char[]` arguments. Loops through until the letters stop matching or we match them all, appending them to a blank string as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
¹Ƥ€f/Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzmNLHjWtSdN/uHPV////o9XTc/KTEnPUdRRArOLixKJK9VgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```rust
|a,b|a.chars().zip(b.chars()).take_while(|(a,b)|a==b).map(|v|v.0).collect()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCoMwFET3nuLXRfkfbOhasT1ED1B@JFFpjJKkltZ49lQLncXwBoYZ9/QhaQsD9xYJlgw2GRVAl6AtHn1wBexOcLrALbjetlCnyIWMLJqOnUcSn35C@U8kAj/U/dX1RmHErUmR61qSGHjCOMdZnEk0ozGqCUhpf6x@v9O2How9YL6U1zUvQGPemlGy2Xgn79m9c6IqW9MX)

Does unnecessary heap allocation for the result (idiomatic Rust code would return `&str` here as opposed to `String`), but it works so whatever. It's not like it matters.

This iterates over string characters as long as characters match and then collects matched characters into a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok) / [K4](http://kx.com/download), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(*x)@&&\=/(#,/x)$x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0OrQtNBTS3GVl9DWUe/QlOlwkpDKT0nPykxR8kaxCguTiyqVNL8/x8A)

**Explanation:**

Pad strings to combined length of the strings, check for equality, find matching indices, take minimum over resulting list, and index into first element of original input at these indices.

```
(*x)@&&\=/(#,/x)$x: / the solution
                 x: / save input as x
                $   / pad
          (    )    / do together
            ,/x     / flatten (,/) x
           #        / count (returns length)
        =/          / compare, equals (=) over (/)
      &\            / mins, min (&) scan (\)
     &              / indices where true
    @               / index into
(  )                / do this together
 *x                 / first (*) x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 55 bytes

Not-Lame Edition! (no builtin)

```
{zip(it).takeWhile{(a,b)->a==b}.fold(""){a,(f,_)->a+f}}

{zip(it)                                                 // zip first string with second
        .takeWhile{(a,b)->a==b}                          // take pairs while chars are equal
                               .fold(""){a,(f,_)->a+f}}  // fold into string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY47DsIwEET7nGLlai0SHyCSwwXoKCjRhthgxWyixFBg@ezGfETHNCPN29XMOAXvON/Jg21hHxbHZ4Ufl9B03wh0jg83owtSBRrN4eK8iUh1L5uOtO6TspMfUAgZqUZbH1/5xqaU7Y3hSo5RQqyg6N21BtCwGBp2jk1B2xaE@OGVh394LnMCln9lsZxJWaXcGzpNXBXjJw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
®å+Ãrf
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=ruUrw3Jm&input=WyJnbG9iYWwiLCJnbG9zc2FyeSJd)

Answer (score 1):

### x86-16 machine code, 6 bytes

```
00000000  56 A6 74 FD 4E C3                                 V.t.N.
```

Callable function.

Expects `[SI]` = address of first string, `[DI]` = address of second string.

Outputs as: `Top of stack` = start of memory slice, `SI` = end of memory slice (like the slice in Python).

Disassembly:

```
56            PUSH    SI    ; Store original SI onto stack
A6      LOOP: CMPSB         ; Compare [SI++] with [DI++]
74 FD         JZ      LOOP  ; If they're equal, jump to tag 'LOOP'
4E            DEC     SI    ; -- SI
C3            RET           ; Return to caller
```

### Example run

```
-d 0100
0B4A:0100  56 A6 74 FD 4E C3 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   V.t.N...........
0B4A:0110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0B4A:0120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0B4A:0130  67 6C 6F 62 61 6C 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   global..........
0B4A:0140  67 6C 6F 73 73 61 72 79-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   glossary........
0B4A:0150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0B4A:0160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0B4A:0170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
-r
AX=0000  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFEA  BP=0000  SI=0130  DI=0140
DS=0B4A  ES=0B4A  SS=0B4A  CS=0B4A  IP=0100   NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
0B4A:0100 56            PUSH    SI
-t

AX=0000  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFE8  BP=0000  SI=0130  DI=0140
DS=0B4A  ES=0B4A  SS=0B4A  CS=0B4A  IP=0101   NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
0B4A:0101 A6            CMPSB
...
-t

AX=0000  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFE8  BP=0000  SI=0133  DI=0144
DS=0B4A  ES=0B4A  SS=0B4A  CS=0B4A  IP=0105   NV UP EI PL NZ NA PE CY
0B4A:0105 C3            RET
-d ss:ffe0
0B4A:FFE0  00 00 00 00 30 01 4A 0B-AE 05 30 01 30 01 00 00   ....0.J...0.0...
0B4A:FFF0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
-rsp
SP FFEA
:
-
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
ᵃp=al
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fssfbm0usE3MWVKclFwMFVtw00IpPSc_KTFHSQHEKC5OLKpU4lJKSS1ILCrJTc0rAYpDOEBRoIKyVJAAiIIYAAA)

```
ᵃp=al
ᵃp      Non-deterministically choose a prefix of both inputs
  =     Check if the two prefixes are equal
   al   Find the last possible solution, which is the longest
```

Answer (score 0):

## K, 45 bytes

```
{*|(*v)@{&y~'x}.#[&/#:'v;]'v:{#[;x]'1+!#x}'x}
```

Takes input as a 2-element list.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 44 characters

```ruby
->a,b{i=0;i+=1while a[i]&&a[i]==b[i];a[0,i]}
```

Sample run:

```
2.1.5 :001 > ->a,b{i=0;i+=1while a[i]&&a[i]==b[i];a[0,i]}["global , "glossary"]
 => "glo"

2.1.5 :002 > ->a,b{i=0;i+=1while a[i]&&a[i]==b[i];a[0,i]}["department", "depart"]
 => "depart"

2.1.5 :003 > ->a,b{i=0;i+=1while a[i]&&a[i]==b[i];a[0,i]}["glove", "dove"]
 => ""
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift, 34 bytes**

`import UIKit
"global".commonPrefixWith("glossary")`

But with Swift 2 it is actually more like:
`"global".commonPrefixWithString("glossary",options:.CaseInsensitiveSearch)`

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 112 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){try{for(int i=0;a[0][i]==a[1][i];)System.Console.Write(a[0][i++]);}catch{}}}
```

Newlines and indentation for clarity:

```
class P{
    static void Main(string[]a){
        try{
            for(int i=0;a[0][i]==a[1][i];)
                System.Console.Write(a[0][i++]);
        }
        catch{}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Minkolang 0.10](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 21 bytes

```
(od" "=,)x(0gdo=?.O1)
```

Expects input as two words, space-separated, like so: `department depart`. [Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%28od%22%20%22%3D%2C%29x(0gdo%3D%3F%2EO1)&input=department%20depart)

#### Explanation

```
(od" "=,)      Loops through input until a space is encountered
x              Dumps extraneous space
(0gdo=   1)    Loops through second word and compares letters
      ?.O      Halts if two letters are not equal, outputs them otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/pb), 105 bytes

```
^w[B!32]{>}>w[B!0]{t[B]vb[1]<[X]w[B!0]{>}b[T]w[B!1]{>}b[0]^>}v<[X]<t[0]w[T=0]{>t[B]^t[T-B]v}w[B!0]{b[0]>}
```

Takes two words separated by a single space. (I can save a byte by using a tab instead but that feels like cheating.)

In pb, the area that can be written to is thought of as a 2D space, with (0, 0) in the upper left. Additionally, input is initially kept at Y=-1. This program copies the second word of the input to Y=0 (starting at (0, 0)). Then, each letter is compared to the letter immediately above it until one is found that doesn't match. The rest of the word is erased and the desired output is already on the canvas so it's printed when execution halts.

**Ungolfed:**

```
^w[B!32]{>}>       # Go to the first letter of the second word
w[B!0]{            # For each letter in the second word:
    t[B]             # Save the letter to T
    vb[1]            # Put a flag below that letter so it can be found later
    <[X]w[B!0]{>}    # Go to the first empty space on Y=0
    b[T]             # Write the contents of T
    w[B!1]{>}b[0]    # Go back to the flag and erase it
    ^>               # Restart loop from next letter
}

v<[X]<             # Go to (-1, 0)
t[0]               # Set T to 0
w[T=0]{            # While T is 0:
    >t[B]            # Save the next letter of the second word to T
    ^t[T-B]v         # Subtract the equivalent letter of the first word from T

    # If they were the same, T is 0 and the loop continues.
}

w[B!0]{b[0]>}      # Erase the rest of the second word
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 12 bytes

```
{⊥⍨⌽=⌿↑⍵}↑∊
```

That's two bytes less than the previous APL solution!

The overall function is `↑`, which takes *n* elements (characters) from the flattened (`∊`) argument, where *n* is the result of applying the function `{⊥⍨⌽=⌿↑⍵}` to the argument:

`↑⍵` convert list of strings to table (padding with spaces to form rectangle)
`=⌿` compare down (columns) giving boolean list
`⌽` reverse
`⊥⍨` count trailing trues*

---

*Literally it is a mixed-base to base-10 conversion, using the boolean list as both number and base:

`⊥⍨0 1 0 1 1` is the same as `0 1 0 1 1⊥⍨0 1 0 1 1` which is  `0×(0×1×0×1×1) 1×(1×0×1×1) 0×(0×1×1) 1×(1×1) + 1×(1)` which again is two (the number of trailing 1s).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 49 bytes

```
<?=substr($t=$argv[1],0,strspn($t^$argv[2],"\0"));
```

Replace `\0` with the actual byte.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 145 bytes

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a){for(char i=0,c;i<a[0].length();){c=a[0].charAt(i);if(c!=a[1].charAt(i++))break;System.out.print(c);}}}
```

Those pesky program-requirements instead of function..

**Ungolfed:**

```
class M{
  public static void main(String[] a){
    for(char i = 0, c; i < a[0].length(); ){
      c = a[0].charAt(i);
      if(c != a[1].charAt(i++)){
        break;
      }
      System.out.print(c);
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/2Meoxw)

Comment: Pretty sure you're allowed to assume 'programs or functions' unless full program is specified by OP

Comment: [see here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet)

Comment: @Xanderhall In the description it states "_Write a program that takes 2 strings as input.._"

Comment: If you'd looked at the link I posted, you'd see that the community consensus is that the default for a challenge is "program or function".

Comment: @Xanderhall I know the default is program or function, but in this question the OP states it should be a program. The question rules overrules that default rule...

Comment: AFAIK, the default rule is put in place to expand the case that the question only says 'program' to include 'program and function'. Most question-makers that want a full program will explicitly specify 'full program'. It's along the same lines as the I/O rules.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
.ps.p©å®Ï¤
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnBzLnDCqcOlwq7Dj8Kk&input=YmxhdGhhemFyCmJsYXI)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell + Regex, 48 bytes

```
$m=$args-join"`n"-match"(^.*).*`n\1";$Matches[1]
```

one line input strings only.

## Powershell pure, <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
param($a,$b)for($i=0;$a[$i]-eq$b[$i]){$c+=$a[$i++]};"$c"
```

Test script:

```
$f = {
param($a,$b)for($i=0;$a[$i]-eq$b[$i]){$c+=$a[$i++]};"$c"
}

"glo" -eq (&$f "global" "glossary")
"depart" -eq (&$f "department"  "depart")
"" -eq (&$f "glove" "dove")
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

## Regex, 12 bytes

```
(^.*).*$\n\1
```

each input string is separate line. https://regex101.com/r/bTf1ud/1

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 62 bytes

```cs
(a,b)=>Concat(a.Zip(b,(x,y)=>x==y?x:'$').TakeWhile(x=>x!='$'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BSgMxEIbveYq4CE0g5gFctx5ETwpChYK32XRcg9mkZrJlF@mzr0ltD4JgT5N8P9/8Y@jKkJkHsr7jlCBZw1cTJez1KsUMa/ZX9mj9p773Q48RWoc1Y8fcOCDizzF0EXr2dcK7YDf8CawXMsPjkofBmxs6tCj@ey75Ww55MwtQrWyWd8EbSAL0q92KVolRTZmOTTPdjteLy4XUL/CB63frUIw5uGgKlHN96soLKDjU62gT5utRlAJRdS604CrFy4sI4lRJ@a@1wS3E1KNPxfz5nePljh0elDKLsGf7@Rs)

`Zip`! This byte count includes only the lambda expression, and some necessary `using static` directives are not counted.

It is assumed that no word will contain the magical `char` value `$` (otherwise program may fail). Can use `\0` instead (but that is longer to type).

Answer (score 0):

## C, 59 bytes

```c
main(int c,char**a){while(*a[1]==*a[2]++)putchar(*a[1]++);}
```

Input from the command-line arguments.

Note - will overrun after printing the final null character if the input strings are identical.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 46 bytes

```sh
until [[ $1 = ${2%$~s}* ]] {s+=?;}
<<<${2%$~s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/NK8kM0chOlpBxVDBVkGl2khVpa64VkshNlahuljb1t66lsvGxgYm/v///5TUgsSiktzUvBIoEwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `a`, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
R÷ġṘ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a&code=R%C3%B7%C4%A1%E1%B9%98&inputs=pog%0Apogchamo&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
R÷ġṘ
R÷   # vectorise reverse over the input (wrapped in an array by the -a flag) and push contents onto the stack
  ġ  # Push the greatest common suffix
   Ṙ # and reverse it to get the prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>41</s></sup> 40 bytes

```
qqhYp$x@qq@qo<esc>j$@qo<esc>:%!awk 'a[$0]++'
jdG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwI7JApcKhsNChMN8mtTjZLksFxrJSVUwsz1ZQT4xWMYjV1lbnykpx//8/JbUgsagkNzWvhAvC/K9bBgA)

No regex.

Takes the strings on two separate lines. The awk command is from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26982021/4568534)

Once the matching prefixes are found, we delete everything except the first line.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Z€ạġhị
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWa6MeNa15uGvhkYUZD3d3LylOSi6GyizYrJSek5-UmKPEBWIUFycWVSpBpAA)

##### Explanation

```python
Z€ạġhị  # Implicit input
Z       # Zip them together
 €      # To each inner pair:
  ạ     #  Check if they're equal
   ġ    # Group consecutive items
    h   # Get the first group
     ị  # Corresponding filter
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

## Java, 152 bytes

```
String a="aa",b="ab";char[]c=a.toCharArray(),d=b.toCharArray();int e=0,f=Math.min(c.length,d.length);for(;e<f&&c[e]==d[e];e++);return new String(c,0,e);
```