# Reverse the truth

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program or function that:

1. takes in a string from stdio or arguments
2. replaces all occurrences of `true` with `false` and `false` with `true`
3. reverses it, but does not reverse `true` and `false`
4. returns or prints result

Examples (left side is input):

```
"true"                     "false"
"2false"                   "true2"
"true is false"            "true si false"
"false,true,undefined"     "denifednu,false,true"
"stressed-false"           "true-desserts"
"falstrue"                 "falseslaf"
"true false true x"        "x false true false"
```

Standard loopholes apply.
This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=63256,OVERRIDE_USER=20569;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: In Step 3, only one replacement is required, or all occurrences should be replaced? e.g.`true true false false` becomes `true true false false` or `true eslaf false eurt`?

Comment: Should `eurt` became `false` or `true`?

Comment: @Zereges It is not false or true before it's reversed, so: `eurt`->`true`

Comment: @HannesKarppila So, the rules are applied in order: `1 3 2 4 5`

Comment: Yes, isn't that obvious? (Fixed that, too)

Comment: Will the input string contain tabs?

Comment: Does this also mean that `trufalse -> trueurt`?

Comment: yes, it does (e.g. `"falstrue" -> "falseslaf"`)

Comment: I have a general proposition. We have the cases `trufalse` and `falstrue`. This means that if we do the string replacement in one order (e.g. true first, then false, or the opposite) we will make errors (most of the programs down there do one or the other). Most languages cannot do two replacement in one run (all regexps, for example)
One workaround can be introducing escaping characters (like `%` in my code), but that will also create invalid translations. i cannot imagine any other solution but 2 replacement at once, or escape chars. Is escaping acceptable in the solutions?

Answer (score 12):

## C# 6, 144 bytes

```c#
string R(string t)=>string.Concat(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("true|false").Replace(t,m=>m.Value[0]<'g'?"eurt":"eslaf").Reverse());
```

It uses a regular expression to match `true|false`, and if it matches `true` it will be replaced by `eslaf`, otherwise by `eurt`. `m.Value[0]<'g'` is a shorter way to say `m.Value[0]=="false"`, because the only possible values for `m.Value` are `"true"` or `"false"`, so if the char code of the first char is smaller than the char code of `'g'`, it's `"false"`.

#### Old version, 95 bytes

This one had a bug, it didn't return correct output for `falstrue`.

```c#
string R(string t)=>string.Concat(t.Reverse()).Replace("eurt","false").Replace("eslaf","true");
```

Comment: A C# solution under 100 bytes? Surely the end of days is upon us.

Comment: @AlexA. Haha, all thanks to version 6 ;P

Comment: @LegionMammal978, maybe you're confusing C# with .NET Framework?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez *facepalm* C# 4 then

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: @AlexA. Well, with the incorrect output for `falstrue` fixed, it's no longer <100 bytes... :(

Comment: While that is sad indeed, it means we no longer have to worry about the apocalypse. Software bugs have saved us all.

Answer (score 7):

### Bash+GNU, <s>45</s> <s>38</s> 73 bytes

**Edit:** works with both `trufalse` and `falstrue`

```
sed s/false/%eurt%/g\;s/true/%eslaf%/g|rev|sed "s/%\(true\|false\)%/\1/g"
```

**Old version**, 38 bytes (shortened, thanks to Digital Trauma):

```
rev|sed s/eurt/false/g\;s/eslaf/true/g
```

Comment: Combine the sed expressions into one, and remove the "-e" and quotes: `rev|sed s/eurt/false/g\;s/eslaf/true/g`

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: @feersum Good point, fixed. Also checked for `trufalse`.

Answer (score 7):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), <s>36</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
xv¡g("eurt|eslaf",#ln>4)
```

TeaScript is JavaScript for golfing.

Edits: Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Vɪʜᴀɴ. Fixed for input `falstrue` and saved a byte.

Old version (Invalid):

```
xv¡g("eurt",f)g(f.T¡v¡,t)
```

Explanation:

```
x    // Input
 v¡    // Reverse
   g("eurt",    // Global replace "eurt" with "false".
            f)    // f is predefined to false.
              g(f.T¡v¡, // Convert false to string, then reverse.
                       t) // t is predefined to true.
```

Comment: If you use `l` and `i` instead of `t` and `f`, you can ommit the `.`s. f is also predefined to `false` so you can get: `xv¡g(l="eurt",i=f+¢)g(iv¡,lv¡)`

Comment: Actually even better: `xv¡g("eurt",f)g(f.T¡v¡,t)`

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ Thanks for the help. didn't see that in the docs. Would it be possible to auto insert `(` after methods? Like `replace(/(\.[BcCdeE...])/g,"$1(")` or similar after inserting periods.

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: @feersum Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out. That was tricky.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, 59

As an anonymous function.

Note, replace is used just as a shorthand for match().map(). The replaced string is discarded, and the output string is made piece by piece backwards (so no need to reverse).

```js
s=>s.replace(/false|true|./g,x=>s=(x[1]?x<'t':x)+s,s='')&&s
```

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser.

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/false|true|./g,x=>s=(x[1]?x<'t':x)+s,s='')&&s

//test

console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

;[
 ["true","false"]
,["falstrue","falseslaf"]  
,["1false","true1"]
,["true is false","true si false"]
,["false,true,undefined","denifednu,false,true"]
,["stressed-false","true-desserts"]
,["true false true x","x false true false"]
].forEach(t=>console.log(t[0]+' -> '+f(t[0])))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Came on here to post amazing 62-byte solution...found incredible 59-byte solution. +1

Answer (score 5):

## Windows Batch, <s>184</s> 213 bytes

Fixed the bug, `falstrue -> falseslaf` and `trufalse -> trueurt`

Probably one of the less popular languages:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p Q=
set N=0
:L
call set T=%%Q:~%N%,1%%%
set /a N+=1
if not "%T%" equ "" (
set R=%T%%R%
goto L
)
set R=%R:eurt=false%
set R=%R:eslaf=true%
set R=%R:falstrue=falseslaf%
echo %R%
```

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: @feersum, fixed it :)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 94 bytes

Performs pattern matching on the input string, looking for "false" or "true" and appends the opposite to the result of applying the function on the remainder of the string. If true or false isn't found, it uses recursion to reverse the string in the same fashion.

```
f[]=[]
f('t':'r':'u':'e':s)=f s++"false"
f('f':'a':'l':'s':'e':s)=f s++"true"
f(x:s)=f s++[x]
```

Comment: Added now, sorry about that

Comment: Never mind. It seems I made some mistake when trying to test it. Maybe I simply printed out the string without managing to apply the function to it.

Comment: I believe you can take the top `f[]=[]` line and instead put `f x=x` at the bottom to save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>95</s> 93 bytes

Unnamed function. Add `f=` to the beginning to use it. Thanks Ismael! Also assumes that the input does not contain tabs.

```
x=>[...x[r="replace"](/false/g,"\teslaf")[r](/(\t)*true/g,"eurt")[r](/\t/g,"")].reverse().join``
```

Comment: You can use `.replace(/eurt/g,false).replace(/eslaf/g,true)`, since they will be converted to string. Try `true + ''` (should return `'true'`)

Comment: WAIT!!! Change `false` with `!1` and `true` with `!0`. There, a few bytes shorter

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel whoa thanks!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. And my name is Ismael, not Ishmael.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sorry, mobile autocorrect

Comment: I think you should also be able to use `[...x]` instead of x.split''

Comment: 67: `x=>[...x].reverse().join\`\`[r='replace'](/eurt/g,!1)[r](/eslaf/g,!0)`. I also changed the join param to an empty template string to make strip out array commas.

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: @feersum Thanks, working on it.

Comment: @ThomasKwa the latter is only valid in the case that true and false do not appear next to each other

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 46 bytes

```julia
s->replace(reverse(s),r"eurt|eslaf",i->i<"et")
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts a string and returns a string. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=s->...`.

The input is reversed using `reverse`. We match on the regular expression `eurt|eslaf` which matches `true` or `false` backwards. To the match we apply a function that returns `true` if the match is lexicographically smaller than `et` (i.e. `eslaf`) and `false` otherwise. The boolean literals are converted to string in the output.

Saved 9 bytes and fixed an issue thanks to Glen O!

Comment: I don't believe this works correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: It's using the same basic reasoning, so I'll offer it to you: `s->replace(reverse(s),r"eurt|eslaf",i->i<"et")` - uses a regex rather than doing it twice, and a function for the replace that evaluates to `true` if it was "elsaf" and to `false` if it was "eurt". 46 bytes.

Comment: Oh, and it also fixes the `falstrue` issue.

Comment: @GlenO That's great, thanks

Comment: @feersum Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 30 bytes

```
::_z"eurt""false""eslaf""true"
```

This reverses the input (`_z`), substitutes `"eurt"` for `"false"` and `"eslaf"` for `"true"`. Replacement is done using `:`.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3A%3A_z%22eurt%22%22false%22%22eslaf%22%22true%22&input=true+is+false&debug=0)

Comment: You can declare `"true"` and `"false"` as a variable: `=d"true"=k"false"::_z_dk_kd`, and use the reverse of it. It will save 3 bytes.

Comment: [`::_zJ"eurt"K"false"_K_J`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3A%3A_zJ%22eurt%22K%22false%22_K_J&input=false%2Ctrue%2Cundefined&debug=0) is 23 bytes.

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Answer (score 2):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 56 bytes

```
\t
+(.*\t)(.)(.*)/\2\1\3
\t/
eurt/fals\t
eslaf/true
\t/e
```

[Live demo and test cases.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%5Ct%0A%2B%28.*%5Ct%29%28.%29%28.*%29%2F%5C2%5C1%5C3%0A%5Ct%2F%0Aeurt%2Ffals%5Ct%0Aeslaf%2Ftrue%0A%5Ct%2Fe&input=true%0A1false%0Afalstrue%0Atrue%20is%20false%0Afalse%2Ctrue%2Cundefined%0Astressed-false%0Afalstrue)

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: @feersum Ugh...neither does the Pyth answer, FYI...

Comment: At least 7 answers have this problem that I have tested

Comment: @feersum Ok; I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 135 Bytes

```
function(s){return s.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/eslaf/i,'☺').replace(/eurt/i,'☻').replace(/☻/g,!1).replace(/☺/g,!1)}
```

### Test:

`=>`"false is the opposite of true"

`<=`"true fo etisoppo eht si false"

*Thanks ProgramFOX and edc65 for pointing out a bug!*

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! The question requests a full program or a function, so not just a code snippet that assumes that a variable `s` exists. Also, your code does not work for `falstrue`: it should output `falseslaf`, not `trueslaf`. Do you want to fix these issues? Thanks! :)

Comment: @ProgramFOX Thank you! I'll get right on that!

Comment: You can save a few bytes if you use ES6, it has this arrow-function syntax: `f=s=>s.split(""). ...`.

Comment: This is both overly complex and wrong. Test with 'false1' or 'true0' or 'true1'

Comment: @edc65 Why thank you, kind sir!

Comment: After the last clarification by OP, this is invalid as does not change all occurrencies (testcase 7). Easily solved changing the flags of regexp from i to g.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>162</s> <s>98</s> 92 bytes

Thanks (and sorry!~) to @DanielM. for telling me about StringBuffer and the fact that we can use functions!

[Because, you know, Java.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5829/44713)

```
s->(""+new StringBuffer(s.replaceAll("false","eurt")).reverse()).replaceAll("eurt","false");
```

Returns the correct, reversed string.

Ungolfed Version:

```
s->new StringBuilder(
    s.replaceAll("false","eurt"))
    .reverse().toString().replaceAll("eurt","false");
```

Basically, I replace all instances of "false" with a backwards "true", then reverse the entire string, and then replace the now backwards versions of "true" (not the ones I just replaced) with "false". Easy peasy.

Comment: StringBuffer is a byte shorter. Also, functions are allowed.

Comment: I'm preparing another answer in a different language, so you can keep this

Comment: The `return` is implicit when dealing with one-line lambdas

Comment: I didn't count it in the byte count, but I'll remove it. :D

Comment: Java beat Python? _Now_ surely the end is upon us

Comment: Instead of `x.toString()` you can use `(""+x)` which is 6 bytes shorter. You could have omitted the parentheses, if it was a parameter to a function or was the RHS, saving you 2 extra bytes, but unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: @GaborSch Nifty. :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>68</s> 100 bytes

I'm still golfing it, but it's fixed to the bug, so `falstrue -> falselsaf` and `trufalse -> trueurt`

Pretty straightforward:

```
print(input()[::-1].replace("eurt","false").replace("eslaf","true").replace("falstrue","falseslaf"))
```

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Comment: This can be easily remedied by switching the replace statements (`print(input()[::-1].replace("eslaf","true").replace("eurt","false"))`)

Comment: @BetaDecay, that will not work, because `trufalse` becomes `trufalse`, while it needs to be `trueurt`

Comment: @Adriandmen However, that's not one of the example I/Os so it will suffice for now :)

Comment: @BetaDecay Haha, they won't notice :)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

```
StringReverse@#~StringReplace~{"eurt"->"false","eslaf"->"true"}&
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 40 chars / 65 bytes

```
ô[…ïċ/false|true/g,⇏[…⬯+!שúa]ù⬮ø⬯)]ù⬮ø⬯)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=falstrue&code=%C3%B4%5B%E2%80%A6%C3%AF%C4%8B%2Ffalse%7Ctrue%2Fg%2C%E2%87%8F%5B%E2%80%A6%E2%AC%AF%2B!%D7%A9%C3%BAa%5D%C3%B9%E2%AC%AE%C3%B8%E2%AC%AF%29%5D%C3%B9%E2%AC%AE%C3%B8%E2%AC%AF%29)</kbd>

Thanks to @feersum for pointing out a bug!

### 21 chars / 43 bytes, non-competitive

```
ôᴙ(ïċ/⊭|⊨⌿,↪ᴙ(⬯+!ë$⸩⸩
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=asdfoiansfoinqwoiefnasdonaonfitrueaosdifnofalse&code=%C3%B4%E1%B4%99%28%C3%AF%C4%8B%2F%E2%8A%AD%7C%E2%8A%A8%E2%8C%BF%2C%E2%86%AA%E1%B4%99%28%E2%AC%AF%2B!%C3%AB%24%E2%B8%A9%E2%B8%A9)</kbd>

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 102 bytes

```
h('t':'r':'u':'e':s)="eslaf"++h s
h('f':'a':'l':'s':'e':s)="eurt"++h s
h(x:s)=x:h s
h[]=""
r=reverse.h
```

The replacement of "true" by "false" and vice-versa is quite lengthy with the pattern-matching, but at least it deals correctly with "falstrue" and the like. And besides, I suspect that a correct regex-based version would be a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>28</s> 22

```
Amr`!dZ2jHjLGcR_Hc_z_G
```

6 bytes thanks to Jakube

Works correctly for `falstrue`, as shown in the suite below.

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Amr%60%21dZ2jHjLGcR_Hc_z_G&input=falstrue&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=true%0A2false%0Atrue+is+false%0Afalse%2Ctrue%2Cundefined%0Astressed-false%0Afalstrue%0Atrue+false+true+x&debug=0)

Comment: No, I think I made a mistake. You 22 byte solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3 - <strike>108</strike> 92 bytes

```
import re
print(re.sub("eslaf|eurt",lambda m:repr(len(m.group(0))>4).lower(),input()[::-1]))
```

Uses a regex to match on "true" or "false" and uses a lambda to process matches and choose what to use as a replacement string. Using repr gets the string representation of (len(match)>4) which gives "True" when "false" is matched and vice versa (and use .lower() because repr(bool) gives a capitalized string) to get the inverse of the match and finish up by reversing the replacement and then the processed input using [::-1]

Managed to get the length down 16 bytes from TFelds suggestions.

Edit: Python is back in front of java, no need for alarm.

Comment: We require here that programs work for all inputs, not just for the given test cases.

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by reversing the string first, and then replacing (saving one `[::-1]`)

`print(re.compile("eslaf|eurt").sub(lambda m:repr(m.group(0)!="eurt").lower(),input()[::-1]))`

Comment: You can also get away with not using re.compile

`print(re.sub("eslaf|eurt",lambda m:repr(m.group(0)!="eurt").lower(),input()[::-1]))`

Change `m.group(0)!="eurt"` to `len(m.group(0))>4` (for 1 more)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 26 bytes

**Note:** This may be invalid, as it requires bug fixes made after this challenge was posted.

```
Uw r"eurt|eslaf",X=>X<"et"
```

Try it in the [online interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)! (Arrow function requires ES6-compliant browser, such as Firefox.)

#### How it works

```
             // Implicit: U = input string
Uw r         // reverse U, then replace:
"eurt|eslaf" // occurrences of either "eurt" or "eslaf"
X=>X<"et"    // with "false" or "true", respectively
             // Implicit: output last expression
```

Here's a version that worked before the bug fixes: (38 bytes)

```
Uw $.replace(/eurt|eslaf/g,X=>X<"et")$
```

Answer (score 1):

### Gema, 43

```
*=@a{@reverse{*}};a:eurt=false;a:eslaf=true
```

([Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/new/index.shtml) is an obscure macro language.)

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 225 bytes

```
p(X):-string_to_list(X,L),reverse(L,B),q(B,C),string_to_list(Z,C),write(Z),!.
q([],[]).
q([101,117,114,116|T],[102,97,108,115,101|L]):-q(T,L).
q([101,115,108,97,102|T],[116,114,117,101|L]):-q(T,L).
q([H|T],[H|L]):-q(T,L).
```

Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Run by querying in the following way:

```
p("falstrue").
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ôr`laf|e¨t`Èøf
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1HJgg2xhZnxlqHRgyPhm&input=WwoidHJ1ZSIKIjJmYWxzZSIKInRydWUgaXMgZmFsc2UiCiJmYWxzZSx0cnVlLHVuZGVmaW5lZCIKInN0cmVzc2VkLWZhbHNlIgoiZmFsc3RydWUiCiJ0cnVlIGZhbHNlIHRydWUgeCIKXS1tUg)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 55 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/true|false/){$&[?t]?:eslaf: :eurt}.reverse}
```

Test:

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/true|false/){$&[?t]?:eslaf: :eurt}.reverse}["false,true,undefined"]
=> "denifednu,false,true"
```

Comment: [53 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3TXXtiquL9dKLS5M09DVKikpTNWvSEnOKU_U1q1UM7a1Si3MS06wUrFJLi0pq9YpSy1KLilNrIZr3FZSWFCu4RSuBNeiANOuU5qWkpmXmpaYoxUIULVgAoQE)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 68 bytes

67 plus 1 for `-E` instead of `-e`

```
%a=(false,eurt,true,eslaf);say~~reverse<>=~s/false|true/$a{$&}/gr
```

Answer (score 0):

## OpenSCAD, 178 bytes

(Note that this uses the [String Theory library](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:526023), as OpenSCAD doesn't exactly have a standard library. Additionally, this is a function because the only allowed input is to hard-code it.

```
use <Strings.scad>;function f(a)=contains(g(a),"eurt")?replace(g(a),"eurt","false"):g(a);function g(a)=contains(reverse(a),"eslaf")?replace(reverse(a),"eslaf","true"):reverse(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 260 bytes

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){var y=Console.ReadLine();char[] n=y.ToCharArray();Array.Reverse(n);var s=new string(n);if(s.Contains("eslaf")){s=s.Replace("eslaf","true");}if(s.Contains("eurt")){s=s.Replace("eurt","false");}Console.WriteLine(s);}}
```

Comment: This is my first (real) post - I've seen someone using c# above didn't include: using system;  class P{ }, static void main(), Console.WriteLine(); or Console.ReadLine();. These obviously take on a lot of bytes for me - if there is a way of golfing that or if it is excluded from code-golf - let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 60 bytes

Simple, reverses the string first, then replaces the reversed versions with their respective swaps.

"falstrue" becomes "eurtslaf" becomes "falseslaf".

```
<?=strtr(strrev($argv[1]),{'eurt'=>'false','eslaf'=>'true'})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5.10, 54 bytes

```
$_=reverse<>;s/(eurt)|(eslaf)/$1?"false":"true"/eg;say
```

Reverse, then replace. A different way of doing it besides the hash table used for the other Perl answer, which ends up being shorter!

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/TZ7kPL)

Answer (score -1):

## Pyth - 18 bytes

Can be golfed a lot more.

```
Amr`!dZ2::_z_GH_HG
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Amr%60%21dZ2%3A%3A_z_GH_HG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=true%0A1false%0Atrue+is+false%0Afalse%2Ctrue%2Cundefined%0Astressed-false&debug=0).

Comment: This does not work correctly for the input `falstrue`.