# Square side pinpointing

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Welcome to my first code-golf challenge! :) Let's hop right into it.

**Challenge:**

Given two floating point vectors, **O** (origin) and **T** (target), you have to create a program to print the values **L** and **R** to STDOUT.

1. **O** is one corner of the square
2. **T** is one corner of the square that is located opposite to **O**
3. **L** is the 2D point (corner) that marks the other point of the uncomplete square
4. **R** is the 2D point (corner) that is opposite to **L**

**Rules**

5. Values for **O** and **T** have to be read from STDIN (see example inputs).
6. Again, **L** and **R**'s values has to be printed to STDOUT.

**Scoring and bonuses**

7. Count the bytes of your program.
8. If your program draws lines that connect between **O** to **L** to **T** to **R**, subtract 15 bytes from the byte count.

**Examples**

First line covers inputs (first square brackets for **O** and next brackets for **T**) and other line represents expected output.

- [0, 0] [3, 3]
  Expected: [0, 3] [3, 0]
- [0, 0] [-2, -2]
  Expected: [-2, 0] [0, -2]
- [1, -1] [4, 2]
  Expected: [1, 2] [4, -1]
- [0, -1] [0, 1]
  Expected: [-1, 0] [1, 0]

**NOTICE**: inputs and outputs can be floating points!

**Important information!**

- Values **O** and **T** can be taken in any format, as long as they come from STDIN (ex. Inside [] or ()...), use whatever format you want.
- **L** and **R** can be printed in any order.
- Remember: when (O->L->T->R->O) are connected, each side must have the same length!

**Winning**

- This is code-golf so fewest byte answer wins!
- Winner answer will be accepted at sunday 15.11.2015  20:00-22:00 (Finland time) (If I'm not wrong, that date is written like 11.15.2015 in the US, don't get confused).

Happy golfing!

Comment: In case you're not aware of it, let me recommend [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478) for future challenges, where you can get feedback and polish your challenge before it goes live (and before changes might invalidate existing answers).

Comment: Can we take input as a list of two complex numbers?

Comment: @ThomasKwa sure you can take it as a list. Isn't an input a complex number when it's given...? I mean you don't have to personally know the value yourself for computer to compute it, right?

Comment: When you say "point of the square", it looks like you mean a corner? There are a lot of other points in a square.

Comment: @RetoKoradi You're right. I do mean a corner with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 11 bytes

A port of my TI-BASIC answer. Calculates `mean(X)+i*(X-mean(X))`.

```
,;Σ½;)±+ï*+
```

Explanation:

```
,           Read input
;           Duplicate
Σ½          Half the sum (the mean) of the top copy
;           Copy the mean
)           Rotate stack to the left
            Now there's a copy of the mean on the bottom
±+          Negate mean and add to input list
ï*          Multiply by i
+           Add to mean
```

Input as a list of two complex numbers: `[1-1j,4+2j]`, and output in the same format: `[(4-1j), (1+2j)]`.

Comment: I'm so proud...

Comment: After this answer was posted, Mego added `æ` for list mean, and caused `î` (multiply-by-i) to vectorize, allowing a non-competing 9-byte solution. Seriously is starting to become a seriously good language.

Comment: A "Seriously" good language. @ThomasKwa

Comment: Isn't `Σ` 2 bytes?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Seriously seems to use the [CP437 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), where `Σ` has the code point 0xF4.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko What Dennis said is correct. Every character in Seriously is a single byte, whose ordinal is in the range [1,255].

Answer (score 6):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 25 bytes

`,i││-++½)+-+½)++-½)±+++½)`

Takes input as a list: `[x1,y1,x2,y2]`

Same strategy as my Python answer, but in Seriously!

Explanation:

```
,      get input
i      flatten list
││     duplicate stack twice, so that we have 4 copies of the input total
-++½)  calculate the first x-value using the formula (x1-y1+x2+y2)/2, and shove it to the end of the stack
+-+½)  calculate the first y-value using (x1+y1-x2+y2)/2, and shove it to the end of the stack
++-½)  calculate the second x-value using (x1+y2+x2-y2)/2, and shove it to the end of the stack
±+++½) calculate the second y-value using (-x1+y1+x2+y2)/2, and shove it to the end of the stack
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c69b3b32d2b2bab292b2d2bab292b2b2dab29f12b2b2bab29&input=1,-1,4,2)

Comment: This is *seriously* cool! (Pun intended.)

Answer (score 4):

### TI-BASIC, 16 bytes

For a TI-83+ or 84+ series calculator.

```
Input X
i∟X+.5sum(∟X-i∟X
```

Unless I misunderstood, OP said they were fine with taking input and output as complex numbers. The `i` here is the imaginary unit, not the statistics variable.

TI-BASIC has a `mean(` function, but annoyingly it doesn't work with complex lists, throwing an `ERR:DATA TYPE`.

Input in the form `{1-i,4+2i}` for `[[1,-1],[4,2]]`. Output is in the form `{4-i 1+2i}` for `[[1,2][4,-1]]`.

Comment: This reminds me how TI-BASIC does not support lists of strings. That would probably be the one thing I would add to TI-BASIC :P

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, <s>51</s> <s>45</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

Now the input is expected in one column vector: `[x0;y0;x1;y1]` (ouput in the same format) I just modified it to be a full program.

```
z=eye(4);disp((.5-z([2:4,1],:))*input(''))
```

Or alternatively

```
z=[1,1;-1,1];disp([z',z;z,z']*input('')/2)
```

Old solution:

The input expects column vectors, e.g. `f([0;0],[3;3])`

```
@(a,b)[0,1;-1,0]*(b-a)*[.5,-.5]+(b+a)*[.5,.5]
```

It also returns two column vectors (as a 2x2 matrix).

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
1o5 mZ=>$eval$(Uq'+)/2-UgZ%4
```

Note that the arrow functions require an ES6-compliant browser, such as the newer versions of Firefox. Input goes in as a 4-item array, e.g. `[1,-1,4,2]`.

#### How it works

```
         // Implicit: U = input array
1o5      // Create a range of integers from 1 to 5. Returns [1,2,3,4]
mZ=>     // Map each item Z in this range to:
$eval$(  //  evaluate:
 Uq'+    //   U joined with "+" (equivalent to summing U)
)/2      //  divided by 2,
-UgZ%4   //  minus the item at Z%4 in the input. This translates to [y₁,x₂,y₂,x₁],
         //  which in turn tranlsates to:
         //   [(x₁-y₁+x₂+y₂)/2, (x₁+y₁-x₂+y₂)/2, (x₁+y₁+x₂-y₂)/2, (-x₁+y₁+x₂+y₂)/2]
         //  which is [Lx,Ly,Rx,Ry], or [Rx,Ry,Lx,Ly], depending on the situation.
         // Implicit: Output last expression
```

#### How it was golfed

I first tried simply copying @Mego's Python approach. This left me with this 48-byte monster:
(Note: the input should not currently be wrapped in an array.)

```
[U-V+W+X /2,(U+V-W+X /2,(U+V+W-X /2,(V+W+X-U /2]
```

Since each of these items needs to be divided by 2, it's shorter to map the entire array with `mY=>Y/2`:

```
[U-V+W+X,U+V-W+X,U+V+W-X,V+W+X-U]mY=>Y/2
```

Now what? Well, the array is now simply adding three of the inputs and subtracting the fourth, following the pattern `1,2,3,0`. So, we could pack the inputs into an array, then add them together, divide by 2, and subtract the necessary item:

```
[1,2,3,0]mZ=>(Ug0 +Ug1 +Ug2 +Ug3)/2-UgZ
```

Nice, saved a byte! But is it possible to shrink the array at the beginning? Let's try packing it into a string, then splitting it back into an array with `a`:

```
"1230"a mZ=>(Ug0 +Ug1 +Ug2 +Ug3)/2-UgZ
```

Look at that, another byte saved. But is there an even better way? Well, we can use the fact that `[1,2,3,0] ≡ [1,2,3,4] mod 4`:

```
1o5 mZ=>(Ug0 +Ug1 +Ug2 +Ug3)/2-UgZ%4
```

Another two bytes! Now we're going somewhere. But that `Ug0 +Ug1 +Ug2 +Ug3` is hogging a lot of space. What if we reduce the array with addition?

```
1o5 mZ=>Ur(X,Y =>X+Y /2-UgZ%4
```

Wow, that really helped! Now we're down to 29 bytes. And thanks to @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ, I was even able to golf another byte off the reduction. But if we could use a built-in to sum the array, it'd be way shorter:

```
1o5 mZ=>Uu /2-UgZ%4
```

19 bytes! Amazing! Unfortunately, Japt does not yet have any such built-ins. I'll add this in when I get a chance. Suggestions are welcome, for either the program or the language!

---

Well, as of v1.4.4, I've implemented quite a few more features into Japt than I had originally planned. Starting with the original plan for the shorter version:

```
1o5 mZ=>Uu /2-UgZ%4
```

First we need to change a few things: Functions are defined with `{`, and the sum function is `x`. This version works as-is:

```
1o5 mZ{Ux /2-UgZ%4
```

Now, `@` is a shorthand for `XYZ{`, allowing us to save a byte by switching from `Z` to `X`. Also, `£` is a shortcut for `m@`, saving another byte:

```
1o5 £Ux /2-UgX%4
```

Recently I implemented a feature where a `U` at the beginning of the program can usually be left out. Due to an implementation mistake, however, this also works with functions:

```
1o5 £x /2-UgX%4
```

Finally, the `g` function now wraps if the index is past the end of the string, allowing us to remove the `%4` for a total of **13 bytes**:

```
1o5 £x /2-UgX
```

And I thought 19 was amazing ;-) [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=MW81IKN4IC8yLVVnWA==&input=WzEsIC0xLCA0LCAyXQ==)

Comment: You can probably save some bytes by using the Japt equivalent of `eval(U.join\`+\`)`.

Comment: I love this language :D

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ Thanks, even though I haven't added an `eval` equivalent yet, that actually saves a byte!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript(Node.js/ES6), 154 bytes

```
process.stdin.on('data',s=>(s=s.toString().split(','),a=s[0]-0,b=s[1]-0,x=s[2]-0,y=s[3]-0,console.log([a+(c=(a+x)/2-a)+(d=(b+y)/2-b),b+d-c,a+c-d,b+d+c])))
```

Getting stdin is the longer part of the code. The input should be the points comma separated :

```
echo "0,0,3,3" | node square.js
```

Comment: Is this a full program...? Which outputs the points to STDOUT...? Doesn't seem like that.

Comment: You're right. Damn, this will add a lot of bytes,

Comment: Voilà, fixed. almost 3 times longer now :(

Comment: Hmm :/ I still think that the point is to make beautiful code art that functions well. And the code you provided is very complex looking & handsome art. :) thanks for participating!

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 30 bytes

```
q~_:.+\:.-(W*+_2$.+@@.-].5ff*`
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_%3A.%2B%5C%3A.-(W*%2B_2%24.%2B%40%40.-%5D.5ff*%60&input=%5B%5B0%20-1%5D%20%5B0%201%5D%5D)

This takes input as a list of lists, e.g. for the last example:

```
[[0 -1] [0 1]]
```

Explanation:

```
q~      Get and interpret input.
_       Make a copy.
:.+     Reduce the list of two points with vector sum operator.
\       Swap copy of input to top.
:.-     Reduce the list of two points with vector difference operator.
(W*+    Turn (x, y) into orthogonal (y, -x) by popping off first element, inverting
        its sign, and concatenating again. We now have center and offset vector.
_2$     Create a copy of both...
.+      ... and add them.
@@      Rotate original values to top...
.-      ... and subtract them.
]       Wrap the two results...
.5ff*   ... and multiply all values by 0.5.
`       Convert list to string.
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 29 chars / 43 bytes

```
ô(ѨŃ(1,5)ć⇀ë(ïø`+`⸩/2-ï[$%4]⸩
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=%5B3%2C3%2C0%2C0%5D&code=%C3%B4%28%D1%A8%C5%83%281%2C5%29%C4%87%E2%87%80%C3%AB%28%C3%AF%C3%B8%60%2B%60%E2%B8%A9%2F2-%C3%AF%5B%24%254%5D%E2%B8%A9)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

## ngn APL, 21 bytes

```
⎕←F.5 0J.5×(F←+/,-/)⎕
```

This takes the input as a pair of complex numbers (e.g., `1J¯1 4J2`) and prints the output in the same way (e.g., `4J¯1 1J2`). Try it online in the [ngn/apl demo](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%u2395%u2190F.5%200J.5%D7%28F%u2190+/%2C-/%29%u2395).

Comment: Works for all the positive inputs, however, it doesn't output anything when I enter negative numbers. Am I entering them in a wrong format? 1J1 3J3 works. 0J-1 0J1 does not. I also tried to use the upper minus symbol to declare number negativity.

Comment: @TuukkaX The high minus in the way to go. I get output `1 ¯1` for input `0J¯1 0J1`, which is the correct answer. What are you getting?

Comment: Oh, now I got it working. I just had to remove the tiny whitespace before the high minus sign. It works and qualifies.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
.jL.OQ-R.OQQ
```

This takes the input as a pair of complex numbers (e.g., `1-1j, 4+2j`) and prints the output as an array (e.g., `[(4-1j), (1+2j)]`). [Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.jL.OQ-R.OQQ&input=1-1j%2C+4%2B2j)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 102 bytes

```python
g=lambda a,b,c,d:((a-b+c+d)/2,(a+b-c+d)/2,(a+b+c-d)/2,(d+b-a+c)/2)
print(g(*map(float,input().split())))
```

Input is taken in the form `x1 y1 x2 y2`, on a single line.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/Vz1bbh)

Comment: You do something wrong, your byte count went up with each edit, but I try to bring the bytecount *down* with each edit=P

Comment: @flawr I am the anti-Dennis

Comment: I believe all answers need to be full programs, taking input from STDIN (or closest alternative). Does this qualify?

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog, 118 bytes

```
p([A,B],[C,D]):-read([E,F,G,H]),I is(E+G)/2,J is(F+H)/2,K is(G-E)/2,L is(H-F)/2,A is I-L,B is J+K, C is I+L, D is J-K.
```

Slightly more readable:

```
p([A,B],[C,D]):-read([E,F,G,H]),
                        I is(E+G)/2,
                        J is(F+H)/2,
                        K is(G-E)/2,
                        L is(H-F)/2,
                        A is I-L,
                        B is J+K, 
                        C is I+L, 
                        D is J-K.
```

To start the program:

```
p(X,Y).
```

Example input when the known corners are [1, -1] [4, 2]:
[1,-1,4,2]
Example output, where X and Y will contain the unknown corners:
X = [1.0, 2.0],
Y = [4.0, -1.0]

Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/)


**Edit:** Changed to read input from STDIN

Comment: Does this read from STDIN and print to STDOUT...?

Comment: @TuukkaX: Probably not. It takes input in the form of a query. I read the part that said that input could be whatever format we wanted. I missed the part about STDIN. Not even sure what STDIN in Prolog is. Would reading input from user be OK?

Comment: STDIN stands for standard input. So reading from user is the way to go :) and by format I mean the way user inputs the values. Ex [x, y] [x, y] or {x, y}...

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 56 bytes

```
i=input()
s=sum(i)/2.0
print s-i[1],s-i[2],s-i[3],s-i[0]
```

Input can be `x1,y1,x2,y2` or `(x1,y1,x2,y2)`