# Calculate the Gamma function for half-integer arguments

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

[Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is defined as

[image: Gamma function definition]

It is a well-known fact that for positive integers it coincides with a properly shifted factorial function: `Γ(n) = (n - 1)!`. However, a less famous fact is

> Γ(1/2) = π<sup>1/2</sup>

Actually, the Gamma function can be evaluated for all half-integer arguments, and the result is a rational number multiplied by π<sup>1/2</sup>. The formulas, as mentioned in Wikipedia, are:

[image: Gamma function for half-integer arguments] (for n > 0)

In this challenge, you should write code (program or function) that receives an integer `n` and returns the rational representation of **Γ(1/2 + n) / π<sup>1/2</sup>**, as a rational-number object, a pair of integers or a visual plain-text representation like `15/8`.

The numerator and denominator don't need to be relatively prime. The code should support values of `n` at least in the range -10 ... 10 (I chose 10 because 20! < 2<sup>64</sup> and 19!! < 2<sup>32</sup>).

Test cases (taken from Wikipedia):

```
Input | Output (visual) | Output (pair of numbers)
0     | 1               | 1, 1
1     | 1/2             | 1, 2
-1    | -2              | -2, 1
-2    | 4/3             | 4, 3
-3    | -8/15           | -8, 15
```

Comment: What kind of built-ins are allowed/forbidden? Gamma function? Pi function?

Comment: All built-ins are allowed (it's the default, isn't it?): gamma-function, factorial, whatever.

Comment: Can I use the letter `r` instead of `/`?

Comment: Yes (just because I want to know how that would give you an advantage).

Comment: J uses `r` (rational) as fraction separator.

Comment: This is a subset of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63887/gamma-function-golf

Comment: @Mego Except that this requires exact rational output.

Comment: @user202729 Hence why I just commented (nearly a year ago), rather than closing it as a dupe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,0_.!÷/
```

[Try it online!](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=LDBfLiHDty8&input=&args=LTI) or [verify all test cases](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=LDBfLiHDty8&input=&args=MCwgMSwgLTEsIC0yLCAtMw).

#### Trivia

Meet M!

M is a fork of Jelly, aimed at mathematical challenges. The core difference between Jelly and M is that M uses infinite precision for all internal calculations, representing results symbolically. Once M is more mature, Jelly will gradually become more multi-purpose and less math-oriented.

M is very much work in progress (full of bugs, and not really *that* different from Jelly right now), but it works like a charm for this challenge and I just couldn't resist.

#### How it works

```
,0_.!÷/  Main link. Argument: n

,0       Pair with 0. Yields [n, 0].
  _.     Subtract 1/2. Yields [n - 1/2, -1/2].
    !    Apply the Π function. Yields [Π(n - 1/2), Π(-1/2)] = [Γ(n + 1/2), Γ(1/2)].
     ÷/  Reduce by division. Yields Γ(n + 1/2) ÷ Γ(1/2) = Γ(n + 1/2) ÷ √π.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, 27 bytes

```
@(n)rats(gamma(n+.5)/pi^.5)
```

Built-ins all the way.

Test suite on [ideone](http://ideone.com/NkkEtR).

Comment: If you have `rats` I think you'll need a `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Too cumbersome for my liking. Also, implicit input seems not to work with `W`. Uses the <s>second to last</s> first form listed above.

```
_W<QZ,.!yK.aQ*^*4._QK.!K
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_W%3CQZ%2C.%21yK.aQ%2a%5E%2a4._QK.%21K&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A-1%0A-2%0A-3%0A11%0A-11&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>20</s> <s>17</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

Saved 3 bytes using @Dennis's technique in his M, and another! This is a tacit verb.

```
x:@%&!/@(0.5-~,&0)
```

(Previous answers: `x:@%/@(!@-&0.5@,&0)`, `x:%/(!@-&0.5@,&0)`, `x:((%:o.1)%~!@-&0.5)`)

(Note that instead of being `-a/b`, it's `_arb`.)

Test cases:

```
   gamma =: x:@%&!/@(0.5-~,&0)
   gmR0  =: gamma"0    NB. apply to 0-cells of a list
   gamma 0
1
   gamma 1
1r2
   gamma 2
3r4
   gamma -1
_2
   gamma -2
4r3
   i:2
_2 _1 0 1 2
   gmR0 i:2
4r3 _2 1 1r2 3r4
   gmR0 i:5
_32r945 16r105 _8r15 4r3 _2 1 1r2 3r4 15r8 105r16 945r32
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
(#-1/2)!/√π&
```

Uses factorial function since `gamma(n + 1/2) = (n - 1/2)!`.

There are only 12 characters now but it needs 15 bytes to be represented. The bytes are counted using UTF-8. `Sqrt = √` is 3 bytes from 5 bytes with `@` (2 bytes saved, thanks to @[CatsAreFluffy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51443/catsarefluffy)) and `Pi = π` is 2 bytes (equal).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>81</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```
import Data.Ratio
p=product
f n|n<0=1/(p[n+1%2..0-1])|0<1=p[1%2..n-1]
```

This seems bloated, but I'm not sure where to golf this from here. Any golfing suggestions are welcome.

**Edit:** Used the fact that the default step of range `[x..y]` is 1, and moved `product` to `p=product` to save two bytes.

**Ungolfing:**

```
import Data.Ratio
gamma_half n | n < 0     = 1 / ( product [ n + 1%2 .. (-1) ] )
             | otherwise = product [ 1%2 .. n-1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>80</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<0?(-1)**n/f[-n]:(1..n).reduce(1){|z,a|z*(a-1r/2)}}
```

Any golfing suggestions are welcome.

**Ungolfing:**

```ruby
def half_gamma(n)
  if n < 0
    return (-1) ** n / f(-n)
  else
    # Is there an golfier way to write product([1/2,3/2..(2*n-1)/2])?
    return (1..n).reduce(1) {|z, a| z * (a - 1r/2)}
  end
end
```