# Parenthifiable Binary Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, binary, balanced-string

If you express some positive integer in binary with no leading zeros and replace every `1` with a `(` and every `0` with a `)`, then will all the parentheses match?

In most cases they won't. For example, 9 is `1001` in binary, which becomes `())(`, where only the first two parentheses match.

But sometimes they will match. For example, 44 is `101100` in binary, which becomes `()(())`, where all the left parentheses have a matching right parenthesis.

Write a program or function that takes in a positive **base ten** integer and prints or returns a [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997) value if the binary-parentheses version of the number has all matching parentheses. If it doesn't, print or return a [falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997) value.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

[Related OEIS sequence.](https://oeis.org/A014486)

Truthy examples below 100:

```
2, 10, 12, 42, 44, 50, 52, 56
```

Falsy examples below 100:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
```

Comment: [More OEIS](https://oeis.org/A063171)

Comment: There's a sequence for everything...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 9 [bytes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) <s>16 18 20 22 24</s>

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
!x÷W(n,¢)
```

Woah. That's short. Uses @xnor's approach. This will use the recursive replace function (`W`) which will replace all `10` equal to `()` with nothing. If the string is blank it is balanced.

---

Using a version of TeaScript made after this challenge was posted this could become **7 bytes:**

```
!x÷W(n)
```

#### Ungolfed

```
!xT(2)W(n,``)
```

#### Explanation

```
!      // NOT, returns true if empty string, else false
 xT(2)   // To binary
 W(n,``) // n is 10, reclusive replaces 10 or (), with nothing.
```

Comment: Excellent! Two things that might help: 1) If it's falsy when going up, it's already been falsy going down, so you shouldn't need the first tilde. 2) I believe `~--c` is falsy in exactly the same scenario as `c--`.

Comment: @ETHproductions awesome, thanks! Now I'm down to 16 bytes

Comment: My smartphone thinks the 16 18 20 22 24 in the post is a phone number!

Answer (score 14):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
!uscG`T.BQ
```

Try [this test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21uscG%60T.BQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A10%0A12%0A42%0A44%0A50%0A52%0A56%0A1%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A11%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A22%0A23%0A24%0A25%0A26%0A27%0A28%0A29%0A30%0A31%0A32%0A33%0A34%0A35%0A36%0A37%0A38%0A39%0A40%0A41%0A43%0A45%0A46%0A47%0A48%0A49%0A51%0A53%0A54%0A55%0A57%0A58%0A59%0A60%0A61%0A62%0A63%0A64%0A65%0A66%0A67%0A68%0A69%0A70%0A71%0A72%0A73%0A74%0A75%0A76%0A77%0A78%0A79%0A80%0A81%0A82%0A83%0A84%0A85%0A86%0A87%0A88%0A89%0A90%0A91%0A92%0A93%0A94%0A95%0A96%0A97%0A98%0A99&debug=0) in the Pyth Compiler.

#### How it works

```
              (implicit) Store the evaluated input in Q.
       .BQ    Return the binary string representation of Q.
 u            Reduce w/base case; set G to .BQ and begin a loop:
     `T         Return str(10) = "10".
   cG           Split G (looping variable) at occurrences of "10".
  s             Join the pieces without separators.
              Set G to the returned string.
              If the value of G changed, repeat the loop.
              This will eventually result in either an empty string or a
              non-empty string without occurrences of "10".
!             Return (and print) the logical NOT of the resulting string.
```

Comment: I came up with the equivalent `!u:G\`Tk.BQ`. Arguably easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a more natural choice.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```js
n=>![...n.toString(d=2)].some(c=>(d+=c*2-1)<2)*d==2
```

Saved bytes thanks to [@Vɪʜᴀɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40695/v%C9%AA%CA%9C%E1%B4%80%C9%B4) and [@xsot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45268/xsot)!

### Explanation

```js
n=>
  ![...n.toString(    // convert the input to an array of binary digits
    d=2)]             // d = current depth (+2)
      .some(c=>       // iterate through the digits
        (d+=c*2-1)    // increment or decrement the parenthesis depth
          <2          // if the depth goes negative, return false
      )*
        d==2          // if we finished at a depth of 0, return true
```

Comment: You can save two bytes by removing the not needed `f=`. You can also use use `+c` instead of `c|0` to case to an integer. You can also use `(+c?d++:d--)` which is even shorter

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ OK. Is there some kind of guide as to when I need to use `f=`? Because a lot of other JavaScript answers on the site name their functions.

Comment: Typically you only need to give the function a name if the challenge requires you to do so. Otherwise it's safe to assume that unnamed functions are fine.

Comment: In Firefox, running this for `11`, returns `true` when it should return `false`

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ My bad I messed up an edit. I'll change it back.

Comment: I don't know javascript, but I attempted to cut a few bytes and it works in chrome: `n=>![...n.toString(d=2)].some(c=>(d+=c*2-1)<2)*d==2`

Comment: @xsot Nice optimisiation **:)**

Comment: @xsot wait Chrome supports Arrow functions??

Comment: @xsot now does Chrome support spread `...` ?

Comment: 51 `n=>![...n.toString(d=2)].some(c=>(d-=1-c-c)<2)&d==2`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I've been using Chrome since I came to this site and so far the only thing I've seen which hasn't worked is default arguments.

Answer (score 9):

## Python2, 87 bytes

```
try:exec"print 1,"+"".join(["],","["][int(c)]for c in bin(input())[2:])
except:print 0
```

A terrible implementation that abuses syntax errors.

Comment: This is code golf. Terrible is a compliment.

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2, 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i*n>0<f(n/2,i+(-1)**n)or n<i<2
```

A recursive function. Reads binary digits of `n` from the end, keeping a count `i` of the current nesting level of the parens. If it falls below `0`, reject. When we reach the start, checks whether the count is `0`.

Actually, we start the count at `i=1` to make it easy to check if it has fallen to `0`. The only terminal success case is `n==0` and `i==1`, checked with `n<i<2`. We force this check to happen if `n==0`, or if `i` falls to `0`, in which case it automatically fails.

feersum saved two bytes by restructuring the non-recursive cases with inequalities to short-circuit.

Comment: Needs more conditional abuse. `f=lambda n,i=1:n>0<i*f(n/2,i+(-1)**n) or n<i<2`, at least, saves 1.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
ri2b"}{"f=~
```

This is a tad unclean: For parenthifiable numbers, it will print one or more blocks. For non-parenthifiable numbers, it will crash without printing anything to STDOUT. If you try this online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri2b%22%7D%7B%22f%3D~&input=56), keep in mind that it doesn't distinguish between STDOUT and STDERR.

Since non-empty/empty strings are truthy/falsy in CJam and printed output is always a string, it arguably complies with the rules. At the added cost of 3 more bytes, for a total of **14 bytes**, we can actually leaves a truthy or falsy *string* on the stack that will be printed:

```
Lri2b"}{"f=~]s
```

This still crashes for non-parenthifiable numbers, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781).

#### Test runs

```
$ cjam <(echo 'ri2b"}{"f=~') <<< 52 2>&-; echo
{{}{}}
$ cjam <(echo 'ri2b"}{"f=~') <<< 53 2>&-; echo

$ cjam <(echo 'ri2b"}{"f=~') <<< 54 2>&-; echo

$ cjam <(echo 'ri2b"}{"f=~') <<< 55 2>&-; echo

$ cjam <(echo 'ri2b"}{"f=~') <<< 56 2>&-; echo
{{{}}}
```

#### How it works

```
ri          e# Read an integer from STDIN.
  2b        e# Push the array of its binary digits.
    "}{"f=  e# Replace 0's with }'s and 1's with {'s.
          ~ e# Evaluate the resulting string.
            e# If the brackets match, this pushes one or more blocks.
            e# If the brackets do not match, the interpreter crashes.
```

---

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
ri2bs_,{As/s}*!
```

Try [this fiddle](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri2bs_%2C%7BAs%2Fs%7D*!&input=56) in the CJam interpreter or [verify all test cases at once](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q'%2C-~%5D%7B%0A%20%20Ri2bs_%2C%7BAs%2Fs%7D*!%0A%7DfR&input=2%2C%2010%2C%2012%2C%2042%2C%2044%2C%2050%2C%2052%2C%2056%0A1%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%206%2C%207%2C%208%2C%209%2C%2011%2C%2013%2C%2014%2C%2015%2C%2016%2C%2017%2C%2018%2C%2019%2C%2020%2C%2021%2C%2022%2C%2023%2C%2024%2C%2025%2C%2026%2C%2027%2C%2028%2C%2029%2C%2030%2C%2031%2C%2032%2C%2033%2C%2034%2C%2035%2C%2036%2C%2037%2C%2038%2C%2039%2C%2040%2C%2041%2C%2043%2C%2045%2C%2046%2C%2047%2C%2048%2C%2049%2C%2051%2C%2053%2C%2054%2C%2055%2C%2057%2C%2058%2C%2059%2C%2060%2C%2061%2C%2062%2C%2063%2C%2064%2C%2065%2C%2066%2C%2067%2C%2068%2C%2069%2C%2070%2C%2071%2C%2072%2C%2073%2C%2074%2C%2075%2C%2076%2C%2077%2C%2078%2C%2079%2C%2080%2C%2081%2C%2082%2C%2083%2C%2084%2C%2085%2C%2086%2C%2087%2C%2088%2C%2089%2C%2090%2C%2091%2C%2092%2C%2093%2C%2094%2C%2095%2C%2096%2C%2097%2C%2098%2C%2099).

#### How it works

```
ri               Read an integer from STDIN.
  2b             Push the array of its binary digits.
    s            Cast to string.
     _,          Push the string's length.
       {    }*   Do that many times:
        As/        Split at occurrences of "10".
           s       Cast to string to flatten the array of strings.
              !  Push the logical NOT of the result.
```

Comment: darn, you barely beat me again....

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 51 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval("'0b'==bin(n)"+".replace('10','')"*n)
```

An anonymous function. Evaluates to an expression that looks like

```python
'0b'==bin(n).replace('10','').replace('10','').replace('10','')...
```

Each replacement removes all `10`, which correspond to `()`. After all replacements have been made, the function returns whether what's left is just the binary prefix `0b`. It more than suffices to make `n` replacements, since a `k`-digit number takes at most `k/2` steps, and its value is most `2**k`.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 40

```
->i{n='%0b'%i;1while n.slice!'10';n<?0}
```

Simple string manipulation.  Drops '10' until there is none left.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¤eA
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=pGVB&input=Mg)

```
¤eA     :Implicit input of integer
¤       :To binary string
 e      :Recursively replace
  A     :  10
        :Implicit output of logical NOT of final string (the empty string is falsey, all others are truthy)
```

Comment: One question: *how*

Comment: Explanation added, @Razetime

Answer (score 4):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 17 bytes

```
,;2@¡@`""9u$(Æ`nY
```

Outputs `0` for false and `1` for true. [Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/eyJjb2RlIjoiLDsyQMKhQGBcIlwiOXUkKMOGYG5ZIiwiaW5wdXQiOiI0NCJ9).

Explanation:

```
,      get value from stdin
;      dupe top of stack
2@¡    pop a: push a string containing the binary representation of a (swapping to get order of operands correct)
@      swap top two elements to get original input back on top
`""9u$(Æ` define a function:
  ""     push empty string
  9u$    push "10" (push 9, add 1, stringify)
  (      rotate stack right by 1
  Æ      pop a,b,c: push a.replace(b,c) (replace all occurrences of "10" in the binary string with "")
n      pop f,a: call f a times
Y      pop a: push boolean negation of a (1 if a is falsey else 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, 23 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
Us2 a e@+X?++P:P-- &&!P
```

This reminds me just how far Japt has yet to go compared to TeaScript. After revamping the interpreter in the next few days, I'd like to add in "shortcut" chars like Vɪʜᴀɴ's.

#### How it works

```
       // Implicit: U = input number, P = empty string
Us2 a  // Convert U to base 2, then split the digits into an array.
e@     // Assert that every item X in this array returns truthily to:
 +X?   //  If X = 1,
 ++P   //   ++P. ++(empty string) returns 1.
 :P--  //  Otherwise, P--. Returns false if P is now -1.
&&!P   // Return the final result && !P (true if P is 0; false otherwise).
       // Implicit: output final expression
```

---

Shortly after this challenge, @Vɪʜᴀɴ (now known as @Downgoat) helped me implement a recursive-replace feature, like `W` in the TeaScript answer. This means that this challenge can now be done in just 5 bytes:

```
!¢eAs  // Implicit: U = input integer, A = 10
 ¢     // Convert U to binary.
  eAs  // Recursively remove instances of A.toString().
!      // Return the logical NOT of the result (true only for the empty string).
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=IaJlQXM=&input=NTY=)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES5, <s>118</s> <s>87</s> <s>85</s> <s>82</s> 77 bytes

Interesting technique in my opinion. Minus a whole heck of a lot, thanks to @ETHproductions, and @NotthatCharles

```
function p(x){x=x.toString(2);while(/10/.test(x))x=x.replace(10,"");return!x}
```

### JavaScript ES6, <s>77</s> <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes

-21 bytes to ETHproductions.

```
x=>[...x=x.toString(2)].map(_=>x=x.replace(10,""))&&!x
```

Comment: I like the translation to parentheses. However, if you leave it as 1s and 0s, it's a good bit shorter: `function p(x){x=x.toString(2);r=/10/;while(x.search(r)>=0){x=x.replace(r,"")}return!x}`

Comment: @ETHproductions Good point! I think I'll leave the other code at the bottom, I really like the algorithm ^_^ Thanks mate!

Comment: The ES6 version can still be golfed a bunch: `x=>([...x=x.toString(2)].map(_=>x=x.replace(/10/,"")),!x)` The trick is to move the while loop into a `.map`, since there are never more '10's in an input than its length.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks again ^_^ Nice trick with `map`.

Comment: No problem :) BTW, another byte can be saved with a trick edc65 uses all the time: `x=>[...x=x.toString(2)].map(_=>x=x.replace(/10/,""))&&!x` IDK if it can get shorter though.

Comment: @ETHproductions I'm glad I posted this answer, I'm learning so much :D I love the short-circuit trick. I conjecture that 56 is the minimum in ES6 afaik. Can't wait until ES7, though.

Comment: One more for ES5: `{x=x.replace(r,"")}` can be replaced with `x=x.replace(r,"");`, the space in `return !x` can be removed, and I think `>=0` can be replaced with `+1`.

Comment: @ETHproductions You are my endless fount of golfing. Thanks much!

Comment: Why not replace `while(x.search(r=/10/)+1)` with `while((r=/10/).test(x))`?

Comment: @NotthatCharles Thanks for showing me `.test`. +1 from me.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I also think that if you don't bother declaring `r` you actually save a byte.  And what about `while(/10/.test(x=x.replace('10',''));`?

Comment: @NotthatCharles Oh, right. Nice catch.

Comment: Think you could save a few more by replacing `x=x.toString(2);while(/10/.test(x))` with `for(i in x=x.toString(2))`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
TrueQ[And@@#~IntegerDigits~2//.1&&0:>1>0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z@kqDQ1MNoxL8XBQbnOM68kNT21yCUzPbOkuM5IX1/PUE3NwMrO0M4gVu1/QFFmXkl0cGpOanJJdFBiXnqqg6GBgY5CWmzsfwA)

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

```
(#~IntegerDigits~2//.{x___,1,0,y___}:>{x,y})=={}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19Duc4zryQ1PbXIJTM9s6S4zkhfX6@6Ij4@XsdQx0CnEsiotbKrrtCprNW0ta2uVfsfUJSZVxIdnJqTmlwSHZSYl57qYGhgoKOQFhv7HwA)

Comment: I can't read Mathematica. Explanation, please? :)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Convert the number into base 2 (as a list), then repeatedly remove `1,0` from the list, and test if the result is an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

### C++, <strike>104</strike> 94 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int n,c;int main(){for(std::cin>>n;n&c>=0;n>>=1)c+=n&1?-1:1;std::cout<<!c;}
```

Run with [this compiler](http://ideone.com), must specify standard input before running.

**Explanation**

- Declarations outside of main initialize to 0.
- Reading a decimal implicitly converts to binary, because this is a computer.
- We check bits/parenthesis *right to left* because of `n>>=1`.
- `c+=n&1?-1:1` keeps count of open parenthesis `)`.
- `n&c>=0` stops when only leading 0s remain or parenthesis close more than they open.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>60</s> <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
n=input()
i=1
while i*n:i+=1|n%-2;n/=2
print i==1
```

Thanks to xnor for saving two bytes and feersum for bringing the final byte count to 49!

#### Explanation

The input number, `n`, is processed from its least significant bit. `i` is a counter that keeps track of the number of 0's and 1's. Note that it is initialised to `1` to save a byte. The loop will abort before `n` reaches 0 if the number of 1's exceed the number of 0's (`i<=0`).

For the parentheses to be balanced, two conditions are required:

- The number of 0's and 1's are equal (i.e. `i==1`)
- The number of 1's never exceeds the number of 0's during this process
  (i.e the loop doesn't abort prematurely so `n==0`). Edit: I realised that this condition isn't necessary as `i` must be non-positive if `n!=0` so the previous condition is sufficient.

Comment: If `i` and `n` are nonnegative then `i==n==0` is `i+n==0`.

Comment: `i` can be negative if the loop aborts prematurely.

Comment: Actually, `i|n==0` should always work.

Comment: Great suggestion, that line looks better now.

Comment: `while i*n` should work

Comment: Good catch. I feel silly now.

Comment: `1|n%-2` is shorter than `1-n%2*2`.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 48 bytes

```
@(a)~((b=cumsum(2*dec2bin(a)-97))(end)|any(b<0))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```
0#l=l==1
_#0=2<1
n#l=div n 2#(l+(-1)^n)
f=(#1)
```

Usage example: `f 13` -> `False`.

I'm keeping track of the nesting level `l` like many other answers. However, the "balanced" case is represented by `1`, so the "more-`)`-than-`(`" case is `0`.

PS: found the nesting level adjustment `l+(-1)^n` in xnor's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64018/34531).

Comment: The `signum` seems too complicated, how about just `_#0=1<0`?

Comment: @xnor: yes, thanks.

Comment: Why not `l>0` instead of `l==1`?

Comment: @MichaelKlein: because only `l==1` is balanced. If `l>1`, the parentheses are unbalanaced.

Comment: @nimi I see, I misinterpreted how it works

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
k/τk/ṘǑǒ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%2F%CF%84k%2F%E1%B9%98%C7%91%C7%92&inputs=%5B2%2C%2010%2C%2012%2C%2042%2C%2044%2C%2050%2C%2052%2C%2056%2C%201%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%206%2C%207%2C%208%2C%209%2C%2011%2C%2013%2C%2014%2C%2015%2C%2016%2C%2017%2C%2018%2C%2019%2C%2020%2C%2021%2C%2022%2C%2023%2C%2024%2C%2025%2C%2026%2C%2027%2C%2028%2C%2029%2C%2030%2C%2031%2C%2032%2C%2033%2C%2034%2C%2035%2C%2036%2C%2037%2C%2038%2C%2039%2C%2040%2C%2041%2C%2043%2C%2045%2C%2046%2C%2047%2C%2048%2C%2049%2C%2051%2C%2053%2C%2054%2C%2055%2C%2057%2C%2058%2C%2059%2C%2060%2C%2061%2C%2062%2C%2063%2C%2064%2C%2065%2C%2066%2C%2067%2C%2068%2C%2069%2C%2070%2C%2071%2C%2072%2C%2073%2C%2074%2C%2075%2C%2076%2C%2077%2C%2078%2C%2079%2C%2080%2C%2081%2C%2082%2C%2083%2C%2084%2C%2085%2C%2086%2C%2087%2C%2088%2C%2089%2C%2090%2C%2091%2C%2092%2C%2093%2C%2094%2C%2095%2C%2096%2C%2097%2C%2098%2C%2099%2C%20170%2C%20172%2C%20178%2C%20180%2C%20184%2C%20202%2C%20204%2C%20210%2C%20212%2C%20216%2C%20226%2C%20228%2C%20232%2C%20240%2C%20682%2C%20684%2C%20690%2C%20692%2C%20696%2C%20714%2C%20716%2C%20722%2C%20724%2C%20728%2C%20738%2C%20740%2C%20744%2C%20752%2C%20810%2C%20812%2C%20818%2C%20820%2C%20824%2C%20842%2C%20844%2C%20850%2C%20852%2C%20856%2C%20866%2C%20868%2C%20872%2C%20880%5D&header=%CE%BB&footer=%3Bz)

Fortunately, Vyxal has a remove-substring-until-fixed-point builtin. Unfortunately, it only works on strings.

```
k/τ         Convert input to base "/\". (only string constant of length 2)
      Ǒ     Until it is no longer present as a substring, remove
   k/       "/\"
     Ṙ      reversed.
       ǒ    Is the result empty?
```

Originally did some fancy dancing with stack rotations in Vyxal `r`, but it turned out the same length flagless to just use `k/` twice. I'm not having the best luck putting a solution together without replacement, but it doesn't seem like it could come out shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>[6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/260196/1)</sup></s> 5 bytes

```
Π₀øo¬
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBIiwiIiwizqDigoDDuG/CrCIsIiIsIjJcbjEwXG4xMlxuNDJcbjQ0XG41MFxuNTJcbjU2XG4xXG4zIFxuNFxuNSBcbjYgXG43XG45NlxuOTdcbjk4XG45OSJd)

```
Π     # push the binary of the input
 ₀    # push 10
  øo  # remove ^ until no change
    ¬ # logical NOT
```

Answer (score 2):

## D, <s>209</s> 170 bytes

```
import std.stdio;import std.format;import std.conv;void main(char[][]a){string b=format("%b",to!int(a[1]));int i;foreach(c;b){i+=c=='1'?1:-1;if(i<0)break;}writeln(i==0);}
```

This does exactly what it is supposed to do without any additions or benefits.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 67 bytes

```
n;main(i){for(scanf("%d",&n);n*i;n/=2)i+=1-n%2*2;putchar(48+!~-i);}
```

Pretty much a port of my python submission.

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog, 147 bytes

```
b(N,[X|L]):-N>1,X is N mod 2,Y is N//2,b(Y,L).
b(N,[N]).
q([H|T],N):-N>=0,(H=0->X is N+1;X is N-1),q(T,X).
q([],N):-N=0.
p(X):-b(X,L),!,q(L,0).
```

**How it works**

```
b(N,[X|L]):-N>1,X is N mod 2,Y is N//2,b(Y,L).
b(N,[N]).
```

Converts decimal number N to it's binary representation as a list (reversed). Meaning:

```
b(42,[0,1,0,1,0,1]) is true
```

Then:

```
q([H|T],N):-N>=0,(H=0->X is N+1;X is N-1),q(T,X).
q([],N):-N=0.
```

Recurses over list [H|T] increasing N if head element is 0 otherwise decreasing it.
If N at any point becomes negative or if N in the end is not 0 return false, else true.
The cut in

```
p(X):-b(X,L),!,q(L,0).
```

Is there to prevent backtracking and finding non-binary solutions to b(N,[N])

**Testing**
Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/)
Run it with a query like:

```
p(42).
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 106 Bytes

```
param($a)$b=[convert]::ToString($a,2);1..$b.Length|%{if($b[$_-1]%2){$c++}else{$c--}if($c-lt0){0;exit}};!$c
```

<sub>Not going to win any shortest-length competitions, that's for sure. But hey, at least it's beating Java?</sub>

Uses the very long .NET call `[convert]::ToString($a,2)` to convert our input number to a string representing the binary digits. We then for-loop through that string with `1..$b.length|%{..}`. Each loop, if our digit is a `1` (evaluated with `%2` rather than `-eq1` to save a couple bytes), we increment our counter; else, we decrement it. If we ever reach negative, that means there were more `)` than `(` encountered so far, so we output `0` and `exit`. Once we're through the loop, `$c` is either `0` or some number `>0`, so we take the logical-not `!` of it, which gets output.

This has the quirk of outputting `0` if the parens are mismatched because we have more `)`, but outputting `False` if the parens are mismatched because we have more `(`. Essentially functionally equivalent falsy statements, just interesting. If the parens all match, outputs `True`.

Comment: Okay, sure. (Well, if I can fix the nagging doubt that I'm solving the wrong problem, I will).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
B-*ÄṀoṪƊ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//Qi0qw4ThuYBv4bmqxorCrP/ItzIsw4dLxorigqxZ/w)

```
B            Convert to binary.
 -*          Raise -1 to the power of each digit.
   Ä   Ɗ     For the cumulative sums of the resulting list:
     o  ¬    neither
    Ṁ        is its maximum non-zero
      Ṫ      nor is its last element.
```

Replacement came out a bit longer:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
B¬œṣØ.Ẏ$ÐLṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//QsKsxZPhuaPDmC7huo4kw5BM4bmG/8i3MizDh0vGiuKCrFn/)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```powershell
for($t=[convert]::ToString("$args",2);$r-ne($t=$t-replace10)){$r=$t}
!$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3dToNAEIWv2adYmtFAAg00xYs2JCZ9AI30rmkaXIe2BlmcHfwJ8uw4mKoXJ/NzznzT2nckd8K6jo0lHKHK@7GyFADnO2ObNyTer1ZbWzCdm2Mwg5KObhYtwjVQ3OCUA44J27o0mCZh2APJZlA@8DgoBUwdnz51rheRThOR1OWkZaQzmTPpsxul0vk8TZKvq155gB8tGsYnuYKDjs@NvmDEI3RdzeL4fnANlQRC5e3ui03n2L7cPT7L5V7fCsYrOmPQuYnyR4zxVV8Ya4ls0fGmdPjzaVo8/OL/Q4Maxm8)

### Explanations

```powershell
for(
    $t=[convert]::ToString("$args",2); # converts the given argument to a binary string
    $r-ne($t=$t-replace10)){$r=$t}     # Until we can't find occurences of 10, remove them from the string
!$t                                    # Returns a truthy value if empty string
```

-2 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY3dToNAEIWv2adYmtFAAg00xYs2JCZ9AI30rmkaXIe2BlmcHfwJ8uw4mKoXJ/NzznzT2nckd8K6jo0lHKHK@7GyFADnO2ObNyTer1ZbWzCdm2Mwg5KObhYtwjVQ3OCUA44J27o0mCZh2APJZlA@8DgoBUwdnz51rheRThOR1OWkZaQzmTPpsxul0vk8TZKvq155gB8tGsYnuYKDjs@NvmDEI3RdzeL4fnANlQRC5e3ui03n2L7cPT7L5V7fCsYrOmPQuYnyR4zxVV8Ya4ls0fGmdPjzaVo8/OL/Q4Maxm8 "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")?

Answer (score 1):

### Java, <s>129</s> 131 bytes

```
boolean T(int i){int j=0,k=0;for(char[]a=Integer.toString(i,2).toCharArray();j<a.length&&k>=0;j++){k+=a[j]=='1'?1:-1;}return k==0;}
```

Probably can be shortened. Explanation to come. Thanks to Geobits for 4 bytes off!

Comment: Is it possible to combine `int k=0;` with `int j=0;`?

Comment: No, j is an inner variable in the for loop and cannot be referenced outside it.

Comment: You should be able to combine the other way, though: `int k=0,j=0;for(...` Then you could put the `char[]` declaration inside the loop initializer to save a semicolon, too.

Comment: The bigger problem is that this gives false positives. It returns true for 9, 35, 37, 38, [for example](http://ideone.com/xbeO8a).

Comment: @Geobits oops, I didnt even realize that, will fix when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Sed (with eval extension), 27

```
s/.*/dc -e2o&p/e
:
s/10//
t
```

Sed doesn't really have a defined idea of truthy and falsey, so here I am claiming that the empty string means truthy and all other strings mean falsey.

If this is not acceptable, then we can do the following:

## GNU Sed (with eval extension), 44

```
s/.*/dc -e2o&p/e
:
s/10//
t
s/.\+/0/
s/^$/1/
```

This outputs 1 for truthy and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## (ESMin), 21 chars / 43 bytes

```
ô⟦ïßḂ]Ĉ⇀+$?⧺Ḁ:Ḁ‡)⅋!Ḁ)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=10&code=%C3%B4%E2%9F%A6%C3%AF%C3%9F%E1%B8%82%5D%C4%88%E2%87%80%2B%24%3F%E2%A7%BA%E1%B8%80%3A%E1%B8%80%E2%80%A1%29%E2%85%8B!%E1%B8%80%29)</kbd>

Note that this uses variables predefined to numbers (specifically 2 and 0). There are predefined number variables from 0 to 256.

### 19 chars / 40 bytes, non-competitive

```
⟦ïßḂ]Ĉ⇀+$?⧺Ḁ:Ḁ‡)⅋!Ḁ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=10&code=%E2%9F%A6%C3%AF%C3%9F%E1%B8%82%5D%C4%88%E2%87%80%2B%24%3F%E2%A7%BA%E1%B8%80%3A%E1%B8%80%E2%80%A1%29%E2%85%8B!%E1%B8%80)</kbd>

Decided to implement implicit output... However, previous output forms are still supported, so you get several output options!

Comment: because everyone measures by char count

Answer (score 1):

## (very noncompetitve), 6 chars / 8 bytes

```
!ïⓑĦⅩ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=11&code=!%C3%AF%E2%93%91%C4%A6%E2%85%A9)</kbd>

I've decided to revisit this challenge after a very, very long time.  has gotten so much better.

The reason this is a separate answer is because the 2 versions are almost completely different.

## Explanation

Converts input to binary, recursively replaces instances of 10, then checks if result is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 61 bytes

I think the current C++ answer is wrong: it returns a truthy value for all even numbers, e.g. 4. Disclaimer: I was not able to use the mentioned compiler, so I used g++ 4.8.4. The problem lies in the use of the binary AND operator instead of the logical AND which is used to break early when the number of closing parentheses exceed the number of opening parentheses. This approach could work if `true` is represented as a word with an all true bit pattern. On my system, and probably most other systems, `true` is equivalent to `1`; only one bit is true. Also, `n/=2` is shorter than `n>>=1`. Here is an improved version as a function:

```
int f(int n,int c=0){for(;c>=0&&n;n/=2)c+=n&1?-1:1;return c;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
¬ωoσḋ2øḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Ca853555sf7ug2OrwDSP7//9/QEAA) or [Verify first 100 results](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f9qip8eGOxYYGBv8PrTnfmX@@@eGObqPDO4Dk//8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

-4 bytes by making things tacit

```
~#(""/"10"\)/,/$2\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY9LSgRREAT3niJohVFQ@tW/yrPMelwIcwSv3j7IVS4yIn@/nj/P63p8/72@H8d5yDruH@fn@ab363FTZCGK7zixCCXy5XETjF2QFM0gghjiSCCJFNLIoAsVVFFDHQ000UIbHWxhe0kxwxwLLLHCGht84YJvUOCJF974EEIYsfFBFNHEkIsUUkkjndxqSRbZ5FCLEkopo5wKapsX1dTQixZaaaOdDjrpfazpYRYjjDLGOBNMMsXs33P9Aw)

- `2\` convert (implicit) input integer to base-2 representation
- `,/$` convert the base-2 representation to a string
- `(""/"10"\)/` run a converge-`/`, splitting on instances of "10", joining with "" (in effect replacing instances of "10" with "")
- `~#` check if there are any unmatched parentheses left

Answer (score 1):

### Lua (96 bytes)

```
function g(n)function f(m)return m>0 and f(m//2)..m%2 or""end return f(n):gsub("%b10","")==""end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 56 bytes

```
{for(a=$++b;a;a=int(a/2))(d+=a%2?-1:1)<0?b=0:0}1,$0=b*!d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPRVkVbO8k60TrRNjOvRCNR30hTUyNF2zZR1che19DKUNPGwD7J1sDKoNZQR8XANklLMeX/f0MjAA)

The general idea here is the code runs through all the binary bits of the number, from the least significant digit to the most significant digit.  At each point the parenthetical "depth" is calculated.  The result is truthy if the final depth after all the digits have been considered is `0` and as long as intermediate depth is never negative.

```
 for(a=$++b;a;a=int(a/2))
```

This loop processes each bit.  The initialization `a=$++b` is just a golfed version of `a=$1; b=1` setting `a` to the number requested and the default result "are all interim depths OK" variable `b` to `1`.

It stops when all the bits have been process, which is when `a` is falsy.

And the end of loop shifts the number we're working down on bit with `a=int(a/2)` since I can't think of a short way to do integer math in AWK...

```
                     (d+=a%2?-1:1)<0?b=0:0
```

The body of the loop is just one statement.  It either increments of decrements the "depth count" variable depending on whether or not the current bit is set using `d+=a%2?-1:1`.

And then it sets the "does the depth ever go negative" variable `b` to `0` if the depth dips below zero with, which is this part of the statement `(...)<0?b=0:0`.

One we've run through all the bits, the only thing left is to decide if the number met the two success factors for the test,

```
                                               1,$0=b*!d
```

If both tests pass, then `b*!d` will be `1`.  Setting `$0` to that means AWK will print `1` or `0` since the `1,` bit at the front means the test will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
bTõ:õQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/KeTwVqvDWwP//7c0NAEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@xyd3PXknhUdskBSV7v/9JIYe3Wh3eGvhf5z8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
b       # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary-string
 Tõ:    # Keep replacing 10 with "" as long as it's possible
    õQ  # Check if what remains is an empty string ""
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 56 bytes

Not an innovative solution, but the previous Java answer really needed an outgolfing.

It converts the integer parameter in binary classically (using modulo and division by 2), and since we are **converting from right to left**, it considers `0` as a `+1` and `1` as a `-1` in a score variable.
The score gets "stuck" forever at `-1` if it ever reaches this value (if a `(` is encountered before having encountered its matching `)`), or can increase indefinitely if there are too many `)` without their matching `(`.

So at the end, the only acceptable score is `0` if the binary is perfectly "balanced".

```java
n->{int r=0;for(;n>0;n/=2)r+=r<0?0:1-n%2*2;return r==0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZExT8MwEIX3/oojEpJDG5NkbEiZQEIqU9igg5s6qYtzqc5OparKbw8XyIQQEsKT9d7zu@/kgzqp6LB7H47d1poSSqucg2dlEC6zGYBBr6lSpYY1C8Bn27ZWK4RKPLFXawIMM3b6Me688tyyBgv5gNHqwu@B8jirWhIZruIMb/M0pHlOd/F9vEwivE5v0oy07wg5ydF@yMaqCWhqPLVmBw1jicKTwfp1A4pqF05Qxdl53ci28/LItrcoghfq/P4My@ATD@DAq8rOGyudJ60ayfzF140U1lokiySOQ1kZyzsLE62srIQJWWnpQZX7Ufo@SJh5sIAgnGb8xPGGwS/uo7LuX5BXf6Xkj@qHDw)

---

Really close alternative solution using inline Stream (**61 bytes**, requires an Integer as parameter for the trick of calling the static `toString` on `n`, which wouldn't work with a primitive int) :

```java
n->n.toString(n,2).chars().reduce(0,(a,b)->a<0?a:a+b*2-97)==0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
`)(BøB
```

##### Explanation

```python
`)(BøB  # Implicit input
`)(     # Two character string ")("
   B    # Convert input to base ")("
    øB  # Are the brackets balanced?
        # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 82 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xa8MwEIV3/4pDdJAgGHt1KkMyFDp0Kp1Kh5MiJ1dUKZwuqUPwb3dFOr6Px/de8Rhxze47eIE3pAT3BuAQJvipQSMfywA7Zrx9vgtTOn6ZAT4SCdhHE0D3cElCEfquM@1EUQLrGewIk55NJZkD@pOe7XiuAolJF/U0g/AlKGOqY2maK0aYBnhNYsd9zjFgqgMr2fF@RQZnqZW8p4R8@7@x/T1RDNq1PiepT4tWfVd1zrqWwzmiDy/ERR54o5TZumfVqWVd1j8)

```scala
i=>{var b=i.toBinaryString;while(b.contains("10"))b=b.replaceFirst("10","");b<"0"}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BSsQwEEDv/YoheEhASnotdsE9CHvYk4gH8ZCN2e0sMVkmU@0i/fYa0qKCxwlv3rwka7yZ53g4O8uwNxjgqwJ4c0d4z4M0dEot3BOZ68sjE4bTq2rhKSBDV0gA2cAQGD00Wqv6iJ4dyRG6DWDaYjB0fUbu48CNlqPKRCRnbC/HbnPJQvZBJnEzAtPghFLZOVVrwn8BtrALnBO2MXpnwk/FhyE4FDg/Yc1x2VyaC/HZo3cgF6i2MXD@YJKi0fnqaoFfx8qRu3hj3QNS4sLeghCqwFP1Z@EOhBalfarm@Rs)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (1 until 100).filter(x => isBinaryWithout10(x)).foreach(x=>println(s"$x true"))
  }

  def isBinaryWithout10(i: Int): Boolean = {
    var binary = i.toBinaryString
    while (binary.contains("10")) {
      binary = binary.replaceFirst("10", "")
    }
    binary < "0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C# 98 bytes

```
bool f(int m){int i=0;foreach(char s in Convert.ToString((m),2)){if(s=='1')i+=2;i--;}return i==0;}
```

open for any suggestions. i like this challange even tho it is old-ish

Answer (score 0):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 7 bytes

```
Ƃ£E∫Ɔž≥
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FuuPNR1a7PqoY_WxtqP7HnUuXVKclFwMlVtwU9-Iy9CAy9CIywSITLhMDbhMjbhMzbgMuYy5TLgMLbiMzLmMLbnMTbgsDLgszLgg-gA)

```
Ƃ£E∫Ɔž≥
Ƃ           Convert to base-2
 £E         Power of -1
   ∫        Cumsum
    Ɔ       Split into the initial part and the tail
     ž      Check if the tail is zero
      ≥     Check if the initial part is greater than or equal to the tail
```