# Shortened words

Tags: code-golf, string

My cell phone carrier charges a cent per character in a text! I need a program to shorten the words for me, while still being understandable. I will be texting this program to my friends, so it needs to be as short as possible.

Your program will take a String (a word is separated by a non-alphanumeric character) of words from `STDIN` (or closest alternative) reduce any similar (`a` and `A` are similar, `b` and `a` are not, `1` is similar only to itself) consecutive alphanumeric characters down to one character, and remove all the vowels (`aeiou`), and print it to `STDOUT` (or closest alternative), only letters, numbers, and spaces are kept: everything else is removed at the end. The first character of a word must remain the same, and only shorten the word if the resulting shortened word is 4 or more characters long.
Examples:

```
homework -> hmwrk
llamas -> llamas (lms<4 characters)
botany -> btny
y3333llow -> y3lw
shorten -> shrtn
aabcddde -> abcd
abb'bbc -> abbbbc (abb -> abb and bbc -> bbc = abb'bbc --(remove non-alphanumeric-space characters)-> abbbbc)
SHARRRKnado -> shrknd (or with capitalization bonus: SHrKnd)
abracadabra -> abrcdbr
everything is awesome! -> evrythng is awsm
you can't break what is already broken -> you cant break what is alrdy brkn
the person's cat's bed's blanket's poka-dots are orangy-yellow -> the prsns cats beds blnkts pokadots are orngyyellow
```

-5% bonus if kept `a i o`  or `u` at end of word

```
sharknado -> shrkndo
abracadabra -> abrcdbra
```

-10% bonus if kept capitalization of non-consecutive characters

```
aAbCDdDE -> abCd
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: What characters can the string contain? (Ex. can it contain spaces?) Why the restriction to STDIN/STDOUT instead of allowing, say, a function? Is `y` a vowel?

Comment: @Doorknob does this edit answer all your questions sufficiently?

Comment: If the input can contain multiple words, you should include some test cases that demonstrate this. Also, you still don't seem to allow functions that take input via arguments and output via return values; this is typically frowned upon as it's simply an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: All your non-bonus examples have words consisting solely of lowercase letters. Can we expect the input to be like this?

Comment: `"a word is separated by a non-alphanumeric character"`, meaning a word contains A-Za-z0-9. Considering this, should `'` be treated as a word character or should the program split on that?

Comment: ① Will `rrrrrremove` remain as is since `rmv` is only 3 chars? Or ② Shouldn't `SHARRRKnado` be `SHRKnd` instead of `SHrKnd`?

Comment: @helix it seems the bonus only applies to non-repeated letters.

Comment: Ok, fixed yellow, everything and added y333llow

Comment: You say *reduce any consecutive letters down to one letter*, yet you reduce the *digits* in `y3333llow` (and don't remove the `o`). Should all consecutive equal *characters* get collapsed?

Comment: Fixed: I was in a rush and didn't notice my mistake. Also reworded to reducing alphanumeric.

Comment: It is recommended to use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get issues with challenges fixed before posting them to main :)

Comment: What happened to the `o` in `orangy-yellow` in the last test case? Were we not supposed to maintain the first letter? And could you also explain the behaviour of handling hyphens?

Comment: Surely "*reduce any consecutive alphanumeric characters down to one character, and remove all the vowels (aeiou)*" means that e.g. *homework* should be reduced to either one character or zero (depending on whether the one character left after the reduction is a vowel or not)?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ The o was deleted by legion in an edit,  and hyphens act as a word separator, until the end, where it is removed, as a hyphen is not alphanumeric or a space.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think that _consecutive character_ refers to the same character, i.e. `ll`

Comment: What is the correct output for `abcdedfgh`? Is it `abcddfgh` because the reduction applies before the vowel removal, or `abcdfgh` because the vowel removal applies before the reduction?

Comment: Why does f.x. `poka-dots` get to keep its vowels?

Comment: poka and dots are two words, both when shortened are less than 4 characters `pk` and `dts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 54 bytes

```
qelS/" ,"*__eu&S-A,s-NerN%{_(\"aeiou"-+e`1f=_S-Z>\@?}/
```

Try [this fiddle](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qelS%2F%22%20%2C%22*__eu%26S-A%2Cs-NerN%25%7B_(%5C%22aeiou%22-%2Be%601f%3D_S-Z%3E%5C%40%3F%7D%2F&input=y3333llow) or [this test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%0A%20%20QelS%2F%22%20%2C%22*__eu%26S-A%2Cs-NerN%25%7B_(%5C%22aeiou%22-%2Be%601f%3D_S-Z%3E%5C%40%3F%7D%2F%0AN%7DfQ&input=homework%0Allamas%0Abotany%0Ay3333llow%0Ashorten%0Aaabcddde%0Aabb'bbc%0ASHARRRKnado%0Aabracadabra%0Aeverything%20is%20awesome!%0Ayou%20can't%20break%20what%20is%20already%20broken%0Athe%20person's%20cat's%20bed's%20blanket's%20poka-dots%20are%20orangy-yellow) in the CJam interpreter.

#### How it works

```
qel        e# Read all input and cast to lowercase.
S/" ,"*    e# Replace spaces with " ,". This way, we don't have to consider
           e# spaces word delimiters, which will make them easier to preserve.
__eu       e# Push two copies and convert the second one to uppercase.
&          e# Intersect the copies. This will keep only non-letters.
S-A,s-     e# Remove spaces and digits from the non-letters.
Ner        e# Replace their occurrences in the input with linefeeds.
N%         e# Split at linefeeds.
{          e# For each resulting chunk:
  _(\      e#   Push a copy and shift out the first character.
  "aeiou"- e#   Remove all vowels from the tail.
  +        e#   Concatenate the result with the first character.
  e`       e#   Perform run-length encoding.
  1f=      e#   Select all characters.
  _S-      e#   Push a copy and remove spaces.
           e#   This is for the length check; spaces don't actually form part
           e#   of the word.
  Z>       e#   Discard the first three characters.
  \@?      e#   If there are characters left, pick the modified word; else
           e#   pick the unmodified one.
}/         e#
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 57 bytes <s>58 80 88 90 95 98</s>

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
Uv qS m@(A=Xg0 +Xs1 r"(.)\\1+",@Y r"[aeiou]",P)g3 ?A:X)qS
```

Uses RegExp to do most of the work.

[Try it online](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/40695)

### Explanation

This explanation is old but the method used is still generally the same.

```
UqS       // Splits input 
   m@     // Loops through words
     Xr"(.)\\1+","$1"     // Removes consecutive sequences
      r"[aeiouAEIOU]",P   // Removes vowels
   m@     // Loops again
     Xl >3?               // If length of word is greater than 3
           X[0]==UqS [Y][0]?  // If first letter is right, keep it
              X
           :UqS [Y][0]+X      // Otherwise, use the correct first letter
     :UqS [Y]  qS v       // Otherwise return the original word
```

Comment: Hey, my language is in use :D BTW, two spaces in a row can be replaced with a right-paren. I may have some more golfing tips tomorrow, but right now I'm tired and need some rest...

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh yeah, I remember reading that in the docs but I guess it slipped out of mind, thanks for the tip!

Comment: In response to your other question, you could use `A-J` (predefined to different numbers), since you aren't using them anywhere else.

Comment: Let's see... you can replace `[Y]` and the following space with `gY)`. There is also a string remove function `k`, but it currently only removes the first occurance, and doesn't do regex anyway. I think `"$1"` could be replaced with `@Y`, too.

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks! With some more golfing, I'm down to 58 bytes. Hopefully I can beat 54

Comment: Holy cow, that's way shorter! Let me have a minute to look through it and figure out how my own language works... ;)

Comment: There's not much room for golfing that I can see, but I think `l >3?` could be replaced with `[3]?`.

Comment: @ETHproductions oh that's right, thanks yet again! I've used `g4`, but I think it means the same as `[4]`.

Comment: Yep, it functions identically, except that you can't do `Ug3 =7`. It is usually the same length as well, unless you have another space afterward that you can combine into a right-paren. I think that for v0.2, `<array><number>` should compile to `<array>[<number>]`. This will save 1 byte in most scenarios, and even 2 in some.

Comment: Aww man, this would've been 50 bytes if we'd implemented `String.prototype.e` in the current version! `Uv qS m@(A=Xe".(.)\\1+",@Y r"[aeiou]",P)g3 ?A:X)qS` Wait, maybe that's not right... BTW, it should be `g3`, not `g4`. `botany` currently returns `botany` instead of `btny`.

Answer (score 4):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 60 [bytes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) <s>64 58 63 70</s>

```
xL¡l»(b=l0+lS(1)g(/(.)\1+/,"$1")g`[aeiou]`)n>3?b:l,ø)O`a-z `
```

I should be able to use the unique function to get rid of repeated characters but for now I'm using a regex.

I believe this should work fine. I'll be heading off to sleep so notify me if anything is wrong and I'll address it next morning.

#### Ungolfed

```
xL()l(#(b=l0+lS(1)g(/(.)\1+/,"$1")g`[aeiou]`)n>3?b:l,` `)O`a-z `
```

Comment: @Dennis Pretty sure it's all good now, I've tested with the test cases and it seems to work.

Comment: The last test case should print `pokadots` and probably `orngyyellow`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `y3333llow`. I think you need to add `0-9` at the O function.

Answer (score 2):

## C# - 404 bytes

```
using System;using System.Text;using System.Text.RegularExpressions;class j{static bool v(char l){return l=='e'||l=='a'||l=='o'||l=='i'||l=='u';}static void Main(){string a=Console.ReadLine();string z=Regex.Replace(a,"[^a-zA-Z ]","");string[]b=z.Split(' ');string c="";foreach(string d in b)    {if(d.Length>4){foreach(char e in d.ToCharArray()){if(!v(e))c+=e;}}else{c+=d;}c+=' ';}Console.WriteLine(c);}}
```

It takes input from Console.ReadLine(). I used a regex to find the non alphanumeric characters and spaces and I calculated if the size is less than 4. I tested using the final example.

## C# - 279 bytes (from LegionMammal798)

```
using C=System.Console;class j{static void Main(){var c="";foreach(var d in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(C.ReadLine(),"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]",c).Split(' ')){if(d.Length>4){foreach(var e in d)if(!"aeiou".Contains(e.ToString()))c+=e;}else c+=d;c+=' ';}C.Write(c);}}
```

Thank you for the golfing tips!

Comment: [Various golfs](http://pastebin.com/D80SEXnT)

Comment: Thank you! Is it alright if I edit my post with one of those golfs?

Comment: Hmm. This can be colfed by using C# 6.0. You can just do:    static bool v(char l)=>...    . No return statements have to be written

Comment: @Admin3X Sure, was providing suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

## , 57 chars / 97 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
Ɱ(ï,↪(a=$ù⬮ċ/⊙\1+⌿,`⑴”ċ/[ᶌ]⌿,⬯⸩Ꝉ>3?a⎖0≔$⎖0?a:$⎖0+a:$,⬭,⬭)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=everything%20is%20awesome!&code=%E2%B1%AE%28%C3%AF%2C%E2%86%AA%28a%3D%24%C3%B9%E2%AC%AE%C4%8B%2F%E2%8A%99%5C1%2B%E2%8C%BF%2C%60%E2%91%B4%E2%80%9D%C4%8B%2F%5B%E1%B6%8C%5D%E2%8C%BF%2C%E2%AC%AF%E2%B8%A9%EA%9D%88%3E3%3Fa%E2%8E%960%E2%89%94%24%E2%8E%960%3Fa%3A%24%E2%8E%960%2Ba%3A%24%2C%E2%AC%AD%2C%E2%AC%AD%29)</kbd>

Uses regex aliasing and other syntax made after the challenge was posted.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>187</s> 176 bytes

Adhering to written description, not given examples:

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Char
f=filter
d w@(_:_:_:_)=map head$groupBy(\a b->toLower a==toLower b)w
d w=w
s=unwords.map(f isAlphaNum.d.(\(h:t)->h:f(`notElem`"aeiou")t)).words
```

Call `s`.

Improved late after vote reminded me of its existence.