# String Zip and Sort

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a list of strings, output a single string formed by taking a character from each string at each position, sorting them by ASCII ordinal, and appending them in order to the output string. In other words, for `n` input strings, the first `n` characters of the output will be the first characters of each of the inputs sorted by ordinal, the second `n` characters of the output will be the second characters of each of the inputs sorted by ordinal, and so on. You may assume that the strings are all of equal length, and that there will be at least one string. All strings will be composed of only ASCII printable characters (ordinals 32-127).

Reference implementation in Python ([try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/HDvjKH)):

```python
def stringshuffle(strings):
  res = ''
  for i in range(len(strings[0])):
    res += ''.join(sorted([s[i] for s in strings],key=ord))
  return res
```

Examples:

```
"abc","cba" -> "acbbac"
"HELLO","world","!!!!!" -> "!Hw!Eo!Lr!Ll!Od"
```

#### Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins

## Leaderboard

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the leaderboard from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 64526; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 45941; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 4 bytes

```
*Ü■/
```

This reads the strings from STDIN, separated by linefeeds.

The source code uses the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) encoding. [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=KsOc4pagLw&input=SEVMTE8Kd29ybGQKISEhISE)

#### Test run

```
$ xxd -r -ps <<< '2a 9a fe 2f' > zip-sort.gs2
$ echo -e 'HELLO\nworld\n!!!!!' | gs2 zip-sort.gs2 
!Hw!Eo!Lr!Ll!Od
```

#### How it works

```
*       Split the input into the array of its lines.
 Ü      Zip the resulting array.
  ■     Map the rest of the program over the resulting array.
   /        Sort.
```

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```
import Data.List
(>>=sort).transpose
```

Usage example: `((>>=sort).transpose) ["HELLO","world","!!!!!"]` -> `"!Hw!Eo!Lr!Ll!Od"`.

Transpose the list of strings, map `sort` over it and concatenate the resulting list of strings (`>>=` in list context is `concatMap`).

Comment: i came up with exactly this!

Comment: I did not; I keep forgetting to exploit the Monad instance for things like lists.  (+1)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

Zips(`C`) the input(`Q`), `M`aps `S`ort, then `s`ums.

```
sSMCQ
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sSMCQ&input=%22abc%22%2C%22cba%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abc%22%2C%22cba%22%0A%22HELLO%22%2C%22world%22%2C%22%21%21%21%21%21%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

```
_t¡ßlp¡)µ
```

TeaScript has all the right built-ins implemented in all the wrong ways.

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)

### Ungolfed

```
_t()m(#lp())j``
```

### Explanation

```
_t()        // Transposes input array
    m(#     // Loops through inputs
       lp() // Sorts characters by char code
     )
j``         // Joins back into string
```

Comment: @intrepidcoder works fine for me. Perhaps your browser has cached some files? Perhaps clearing your cache might work. I'm using Safari though. I'll try refreshing the files

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```
a=>a[0].replace(/./g,(c,i)=>a.map(w=>w[i]).sort().join``)
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 5 bytes

```
q~z:$
```

Try it [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~z%3A%24&input=%5B%22abc%22%20%22def%22%20%22cba%22%5D).

Comment: I beat you by like 14 seconds ;P.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
lambda x,y=''.join:y(map(y,map(sorted,zip(*x))))
```

*Thanks to @xnor for -2 bytes!*

Comment: You can save `"".join` to a variable.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 3 bytes

```
∩vs
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwi4oipdnMiLCIiLCJbXCJIRUxMT1wiLFwid29ybGRcIixcIiEhISEhXCJdIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 15 bytes

```
@(a)sort(a)(:)'
```

**Example:**

```
octave:1> (@(a)sort(a)(:)')(["abc";"cba"])
ans = acbbac
octave:2> (@(a)sort(a)(:)')(["HELLO";"world";"!!!!!"])
ans = !Hw!Eo!Lr!Ll!Od
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 10 bytes

```
,/{x@<x}'+
```

Join (`,/`) the sort of (`{x@<x}`) each (`'`) of the transpose (`+`) of a list of strings.

In action:

```
  ,/{x@<x}'+("HELLO";"world";"!!!!!")
"!Hw!Eo!Lr!Ll!Od"
```

Simple, but K is hurt a bit here by not having a single-character sort function and instead dividing the operation into a scatter-gather index operator `@` and a primitive which yields the permutation vector which would sort a list `<`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
LMFop
```

<sub>So close to LMNOP :(</sub>

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=LMFop&i=abc%0Acba%0A%0AHELLO%0Aworld%0A%21%21%21%21%21&a=1&m=1)

Put all inputs into one list of strings (`L`), and transpose this list (`M`). For each resulting string (`F`), sort (`o`) and print (`p`) it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
SS*Zg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZLg4O1otIhbKjQ7mglD1cfH38lHQWl8vyinBQQQxEElGKhSgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 12 bytes <s>20</s>

```
Ny m_q n q)q
```

[Try it online!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

### Explanation

```
Ny       // Transpose inputs
  m_     // Maps through each new string
    q    // Split string
    n    // Sort string
    q    // Join
)q       // Join again
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 46 bytes

```julia
x->(j=join)(map(i->j(sort([i...])),zip(x...)))
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an array of strings and returns a string. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=x->...`.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function zipsort{T<:AbstractString}(x::Array{T,1})
    # Splat the input array and zip into an iterable
    z = zip(x...)

    # For each tuple consisting of corresponding characters
    # in the input array's elements, splat into an array,
    # sort the array, and join it into a string
    m = map(i -> join(sort([i...])), z)

    # Take the resulting string array and join it
    return join(m)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 15 chars / 30 bytes

```
Ѩťªï)ć⇀ѨŌ$ø⬯)ø⬯
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=%5B%22HELLO%22%2C%22world%22%2C%22!!!!!%22%5D&code=%D1%A8%C5%A5%C2%AA%C3%AF%29%C4%87%E2%87%80%D1%A8%C5%8C%24%C3%B8%E2%AC%AF%29%C3%B8%E2%AC%AF)</kbd>

Just realized that Lodash's sortBy function works on strings, too.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 152 bytes

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
[](auto s){for(int i=0;i<s[0].size();++i){auto r=""s;for(auto k:s)r+=k[i];std::sort(begin(r),end(r));std::cout<<r;}};
```

Not using any advantage of map+zip (guess why)

Ungolfed + usage

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](auto s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s[0].size(); ++i)
        {
            auto r = ""s;
            for (auto k : s)
                r += k[i];
            std::sort(begin(r), end(r));
            std::cout << r;
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::string> data = { "HELLO", "world", "!!!!!" };
    lambda(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
""<>SortBy@ToCharacterCode/@Transpose@Characters@#&
```

String manipulation in Mathematica is expensive...

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 33 bytes

```perl6
{[~] flat ([Z] @_».comb)».sort}
```

Example usage:

```perl6
say {[~] flat ([Z] @_».comb)».sort}(< abc cba >) # acbbca

my &code = my $code = {[~] flat ([Z] @_».comb)».sort}

say code "HELLO","world","!!!!!"; # !Hw!Eo!Lr!Ll!Od

say ((<cba abc>),(<testing gnitset gttseni>)).map($code);
# (acbbac ggtentiststteisenngit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ZṢ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q4c5Fj5rW/H@4c8bDnbMfNcxR0LVTeNQw98Q6IPfQ1sPtD3e2cB1uByqBSP//H62UmJSspKOUnJSoFKsTreTh6uPjD@SX5xflpABpRRAAy6CK6EBVxgIA)

Only valid if considered as a [full program](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q4c5Fj5rW/P//XykxKVlJRyk5KVEJAA): the resulting value is a list of strings, but when it's printed Jelly [implicitly flattens it](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwJKaUo60Uo5QAIIlBKVYmNjdZRKlEBEKojMA0mnpijFAgA).

```
  €    Map
 Ṣ     sort
Z      over the columns of the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>92</del> 91 bytes

```php
for($argv[0]='';$a=array_column(array_map(str_split,$argv),$i++|0);print join($a))sort($a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSi9LLog1ibdXVrVUSbROLihIr45Pzc0pz8zQgnNzEAo3ikqL44oKczBIdsHpNHZVMbe0aA03rgqLMvBKFrPzMPKBJmprF@UUlIIb1////PVx9fPz/l@cX5aT8VwQBAA)

I'm confident this could be done shorter by not trying to use PHP's built-in array functions, but had to try!

#### Or 85 bytes

@Night2's swing, done shorter by not trying to use PHP's built-in array functions:

```php
for(;''<$argv[1][$i++];print join($a))for($a=[];''<$a[]=$argv[++$$i][$i-1];sort($a));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKzV1W1UEovSy6INY6NVMrW1Y60LijLzShSy8jPzNFQSNTVBqlQSbaNjIUqjY20h6rW1VVQyQXp0DWOti/OLSsCqrf///@/h6uPj/788vygn5b8iCAAA)

Comment: @Night2 nicely done!  You should post that one as your own.  It's too bad that `array_column` won't work on an array of strings otherwise it'd be quite a bit more useful for CG. And of course having to skip `$argv[0]` is always a pain too...

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Õmñ
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=1W3x&input=WyJIRUxMTyIsIndvcmxkIiwiISEhISEiXQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```powershell
-join(($a=$args)[0]|% t*y|%{$a|% c*rs($i++)|sort})
```

*-6 bytes thanks to mazzy*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP1fNys/M09DQyXRViWxKL1YM9ogtkZVoUSrska1WiURyEzWKirWUMnU1tasKc4vKqnV/F/LxaUG1K3k4erj46@koFSeX5STAqQVQUAJIpeYlAwUSU5KVPoPAA)

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP1fNys/M09DQyXRViWxKL1YM9ogtkZVoUSrska1WiURyEzWKirWUMnU1tasKc4vKqnV/F/LxaUG1K3k4erj46@koFSeX5STAqQVQUAJIpeYlAwUSU5KVPoPAA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 34 bytes

```factor
[ flip [ natural-sort ] map-flat ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JY0xDsIwFEN3TmHYy4xgRoBUwYCYKobf8AsRaZKmiTpUPQlLFzgAt-ltSKkX-_tZ-q9PQcIb1w98OR-OuzVqrgJrwTVq47zUdwhTWqnYLYOXSnoZ0ZOdZgVpUDXYzGZt9BaUC4ic0P2v_TZNT2iMUzfMR8W-ewdfJKthkaFQ0iKDJh8cqWR8hitKskmhKMZp-Y1FXFkn9YiZxGMCfT_5Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 39 bytes

```
x~strfor{flip$x}{y~y sort>}crush-with""
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJmPXh+c3RyZm9ye2ZsaXAkeH17eX55IHNvcnQ+fWNydXNoLXdpdGhcIlwiOyIsImYgJCAoXCJIRUxMT1wiLFwid29ybGRcIixcIiEhISEhXCIpIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript, 8 bytes

```
~zip{$}%
```

Try it online on [Web GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyAnWyJIRUxMTyIgIndvcmxkIiAiISEhISEiXScgIyBTaW11bGF0ZSBpbnB1dCBmcm9tIFNURElOLgoKfnppcHskfSU%3D).

#### How it works

```
~         # Evaluate the input.
 zip      # Zip it.
    {$}%  # Map sort ($) over the resulting array.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Minkolang 0.13](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 46 bytes

```
$od0Z2:$zIz:$xd0G2-[i1+z[di0c*+c$r]xz$(sr$Ok].
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/old?code=%24od0Z2%3A%24zIz%3A%24xd0G2-%5Bi1%2Bz%5Bdi0c%2A%2Bc%24r%5Dxz%24%28sr%24Ok%5D%2E&input=%22HELLO%22%22world%22%22%21%21%21%21%21%22) Expects input like `"HELLO""world""!!!!!"` (so no commas).

#### Explanation

```
$o     Read in whole input as characters
d      Duplicate top of stack (the ")
0Z     Count how often this appears in the stack
2:     Divide by two
$z     Store this in the register (z)
Iz:    Length of stack divided by z (k)
$x     Dump one element from the front/bottom of stack
d      Duplicate top of stack (which is k)
0G     Insert it at the front/bottom of stack
2-     k-2

  [                              Open for loop that repeats k-2 times
   i1+                           Loop counter + 1 (i)
      z[                         Open for loop that repeats z times
        d                        Duplicate top of stack (which is i)
         i                       Loop counter (j)
          0c                     Copy k from front of stack
            *                    Multiply (j*k)
             +                   Add (j*k + i)
              c                  Copy character at position j*k+i to the top
               $r                Swap top two elements of stack (so i is on top)
                 ]               Close for loop
                  x              Dump the top of stack (dump i)
                   z$(           Start a new loop with the top z elements
                      s          Sort
                       r$O       Reverse and output the whole (loop) stack as characters
                          k      Break - exits while loop
                           ].    Close for loop and stop
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure/ClojureScript, 43 bytes

```
#(apply str(mapcat sort(apply map list %)))
```

Creates an anonymous function.  Written in a ClojueScript REPL, should also be valid Clojure.

Enter it [here](http://clojurescript.net/), then call via `(*1 ["HELLO" "world" "!!!!!"])`.  Or do `(def f *1)` and then use `(f ["abc" "cba"])`.

Answer (score 0):

### Ceylon, 166

`String z(String+l)=>String(expand(t(l).map(sort)));[T+]n<T>(T?+i)=>[for(e in i)e else nothing];{[X+]*}t<X>([{X*}+]l)=>l[0].empty then{}else{n(*l*.first),*t(l*.rest)};`

While Ceylon has a [`zip` function](http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/index.html#zip), it takes only two iterables instead of an iterable of them. [`unzip`](http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/index.html#unzip), on the other hand, takes an iterable of tuples, and I don't want to convert my strings into tuples. So I implemented my own transpose function, inspired by a Haskell implementation which Google [found for me somewhere](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream-0.4.7.2/docs/src/Data-Stream.html#transpose).

```
// zip-sort
//
// Question:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64526/2338
// My answer: ...

// Takes a list of strings (same length), and produces
// a string made by concatenating the results of sorting
// the characters at each position.
String z(String+ l) =>
        String(expand(t(l).map(sort)));

// Narrow an iterable of potential optionals to their non-optional values,
// throwing an AssertionError if a null is in there.
[T+] n<T>(T?+ i) =>
        [for (e in i) e else nothing];

// Transpose a nonempty sequence of iterables, producing an iterable of
// sequences.
// If the iterables don't have the same size, either too long ones are
// cut off or too short ones cause an AssertionError while iterating.
{[X+]*} t<X>([{X*}+] l) =>
        l[0].empty
        then {}
        else { n(*l*.first), *t(l*.rest) };
```

The types of `n` and `t` could be defined much more general, but this is Codegolf ;-) (`n` is a special case of what [I proposed as `assertNarrow` two weeks ago](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-compiler/issues/2422#issuecomment-154812667)).

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 85 bytes

```red
func[b][repeat c length? b/1[foreach a sort collect[foreach m b[keep m/:c]][prin a]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYkxDsIwDEV3TmFygYq1CxMSQyUkVsuD4zgUkSaVCeL4Ie3AX97Xe6ah3TUgxbHFTxb0hKarcgWBpPlR5zP44YSxmLLMwPAu1mNJSaX@9QIeX6orLMMoRLjaMwMTUdtehQjo2IsDJ54dHfa@2@tlmm7df4ul0Hnc5qj9AA)

Answer (score 0):

### Brev, <s>53</s> 41 bytes

```
(as-list flatten(over(sort args char<?)))
```

Example:

```
((as-list flatten (over (sort args char<?))) "HELLO" "world" "!!!!!")
```