# Make a Math Competition Grader

Tags: code-golf, string

I enjoy participating in math competitions run by Mu Alpha Theta, a mathematics honor society in the United States. At competitions, I take a 30-question multiple choice test. There are five choices per question, labeled A through E.

My score on a test is four points for each correct answer, zero points for a question left blank, and negative one points for each wrong answer.

Write a program that grades a test according to the above scoring system. There should be two components to the input: an answer key followed by responses. Questions left blank are to be inputted as blank spaces. The first input must contain only the letters A-E (or a-e, your choice), and it can be assumed that there is no whitespace in the input. The second input must only contain blank spaces and the letters A-E (or a-e). Inputs not implementing 30-question tests must print `Invalid test` as output.

The output should be the grade or `Invalid test`.

*Bonus*

If your program prints the number right, number left blank, and number wrong after the final score as `(aR bB cW)`, take off 20 bytes.

**Sample input**

```
CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA    //answer key
CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA    //responses
```

**Sample output**

*No bonus*

```
73
```

*Bonus*

```
73 (20R 3B 7W)
```

---

Standard rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: What should we do with spaces in the first line?

Comment: @ThomasKwa There shouldn't be spaces in the first line. `Invalid test`.

Comment: It appears you changed the rules after answers were posted, which invalidated at least 2 of them. Please do no make changes which could invalidate answers after a challenge is posted. It's a good idea to use the Sandbox to get feedback prior to posting.

Comment: I think this would have been more interesting as [tag:underhanded]

Comment: how about case sensitivity? also, what if my language is... unpleased by whitespace? can i specify whitespace in the input should be underscores instead?

Comment: @sysreq There shouldn't be any whitespace in the input to begin with. Tests don't have blank spaces in their answer keys.

Comment: does the input have to only have abcde, or can it accept any char?

Comment: I was quite sure that the check of the range for input (A...E or space and no more) was requested, but doubt it now. Changing the rules is always a mess

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, <s>53</s> 51

```
?&!-sJ.z+d<G5&FqR30lMJ+sm?qFd4_1CJ/eJd"Invalid test
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%26%21-sJ.z%2Bd%3CG5%26FqR30lMJ%2Bsm%3FqFd4_1CJ%2FeJd%22Invalid+test&input=cabbdcabecdbacdbeaacaddbbbedda%0Acabeddabdc+bacdbbaade++cbbedda&debug=0)

The checks are done by seeing if the entire input contains any characters when all of the spaces and `a-e` are removed, and by checking if both strings have length `30`.

The score calculation is done by zipping the two lines together, then by mapping each pair to: `(letters are equal) ? 4 : -1`. Then simply summing the values, and adding the number of spaces in the second line back to the score.

Comment: No errors. (Currently fewer bytes than Dennis's answer...)

Answer (score 7):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 86 bytes

````
,`;l5╙¬=);' UΣS" ABCDE"=(**;l`Mi@)=YWé"Invalid test"0WX@Z```i@;(=5*(' =D+`(;l@)5╙¬=IMΣ
````

Takes input like `"CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA", "CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA"`

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c603b6c35d3aa3d293b272055e45322204142434445223d282a2a3b6c604d6940293d59578222496e76616c6964205465737422305758405a60606069403b283d352a2827203d442b60283b6c402935d3aa3d494de4&input=%22CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA%22,) (you will have to manually enter the input because permalinks don't like quotes)

<s>Working on the bonus now.</s> Nope, adding the bonus would cost more than 20 bytes.

I knew I was forgetting something... `Invalid Test` wasn't being printed in the event of an error. There go my hopes of out-golfing Dennis.

Comment: Does it? Seriously? Then I have to upvote it

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 134 bytes

**Edit:** The question requirements changed. This answer is from when the program needed to make sure each answer character is A-E, each response character is A-E or space and they both have lengths of 30, else return `Invalid test`.

```js
(a,r)=>[...a].map((q,i)=>q>"E"|q<"A"?x=1:(c=r[l=i])==" "?0:c>"E"|c<"A"?x=1:c==q?s+=4:s--,s=x=0)&&x|l!=29|r.length!=30?"Invalid test":s
```

### Explanation

```js
(a,r)=>                   // a = answer string, r = responses string
  [...a].map((q,i)=>      // iterate over answers, q = answer, i = question number
    q>"E"|q<"A"?x=1:      // x = 1 if answer is invalid
    (c=r[l=i])==" "?0:    // c = question response, l = answer length, add 0 for space
    c>"E"|c<"A"?x=1:      // x = 1 if response is invalid
    c==q?s+=4:s--,        // add 4 if correct, subtract 1 if incorrect
    s=x=0                 // s = total score, x = is invalid
  )&&
    x|l!=29|r.length!=30? // check input lengths for validity
      "Invalid test":
      s                   // return the score
```

### Test

```html
<input type="text" id="answers" value="CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA" /><br />
<input type="text" id="responses" value="CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA" /><br />
<button onclick='result.innerHTML=(

(a,r)=>[...a].map((q,i)=>q>"E"|q<"A"?x=1:(c=r[l=i])==" "?0:c>"E"|c<"A"?x=1:c==q?s+=4:s--,s=x=0)&&x|l!=29|r.length!=30?"Invalid test":s

)(answers.value,responses.value)'>Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 60 bytes

```
2{l_,30=\N?}*_2$|S'F,65>+-!@2$.{=4W?}@' f=+:+"Invalid test"?
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2%7Bl_%2C30%3D%5CN%3F%7D*_2%24%7CS'F%2C65%3E%2B-!%402%24.%7B%3D4W%3F%7D%40'%20f%3D%2B%3A%2B%22Invalid%20test%22%3F&input=CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA%0ACABEDDABDC%20BACDBBAADE%20%20CBBEDDA).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (Firefox 31+), 86 bytes

```
(x,y)=>(r=i=0,[for(l of y)x[i++]==l?r+=4:r-=l!=' '],i!=30|i-x.length?'Invalid test':r)
```

Uses array comprehension which is proposed for ES7. Thus support is limited to Firefox for the moment.

### With bonus, 106 bytes (126 - 20)

```
(x,y)=>[r=w=i=0,[for(l of y)x[i++]==l?r++:w+=l!=' '],`${r*4-w} (${r}R ${i-r-w}B ${w}W)`,'Invalid test'][i!=30||i-x.length?3:2]
```

**Edit:** Previously my solution only checked answer or question length, now checks both.

```js
F=(x,y)=>(r=i=0,[for(l of y)x[i++]==l?r+=4:r-=l!=' '],i!=30|i-x.length?'Invalid test':r)
G=(x,y)=>[r=w=i=0,[for(l of y)x[i++]==l?r++:w+=l!=' '],`${r*4-w} (${r}R ${i-r-w}B ${w}W)`,'Invalid test'][i!=30||i-x.length?3:2]

var score = () => result.innerHTML = (bonus.checked ? G:F)(questions.value, answers.value);

questions.oninput = answers.oninput = bonus.onchange = score;
score();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

hr {
  clear: both;
}

.input-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}

#result, #error {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#error {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script  type="text/javascript">
  window.onerror = () => {
    var inputEls = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputEls.length; i++) {
      inputEls[i].disabled = true;
    }
    error.style.display = 'block';
    output.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
<label for="questions">Q:</label>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="questions" type="text" value="CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA"/>
</div>
<label for="answers">A:</label>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="answers" type="text" value="CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA"/>
</div>
<label for="bonus">Bonus:</label>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="bonus" type="checkbox" checked/>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="output">
  Result: <span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div id="error">
  ERROR: Unsupported browser! Try Firefox 31+
</div>
```

Comment: You can omit the `f=` at the beginning and say that this generates a lambda function.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks I always forget it's on their from testing -_-

Comment: This would be significantly shorter without the bonus. 86 bytes: `(x,y)=>(r=i=0,[for(l of y)x[i++]==l?r+=4:r-=l!=' '],i!=30|i-x.length?'Invalid test':r)`

Comment: @user81655 True, thanks... I got a little caught up in it... the template string alone is 34 bytes

Comment: I have a very similar answer, but I did not copied this one (my first attempt is precedent, but I deleted it as I was not checking the lengths). That said: this is not valid notwithstanding 3 upvotes,as does not check the range A...E

Comment: @edc65 That was edited out of the question before this was answered. See the note on the other JavaScript answer which states it was before the requirements change.

Comment: No. Question as it is now: The second input **must** only contain blank spaces and the letters A-E (or a-e). Inputs not implementing 30-question tests must print Invalid test as output. The check for blank spaces in the first input was edited out

Comment: Just see the other answers...

Comment: @edc65 Just look at the edit history, this was removed... `Inputs containing other characters or inputs not implementing 30-question tests must print Invalid test as output`. Stating what the input is doesn't mean it needs to be validated.

Comment: @edc65 Also your current answer doesn't pre-date this one. And none of your previous edits look similar to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32177/discussion-between-edc65-and-george-reith).

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <strike>162</strike> <strike>154</strike> <strike>148</strike> 134 bytes

```c#
string g(string k,string a)=>k.Length!=30||a.Length!=30?"Invalid Test!":Enumerable.Range(0,30).Sum(e=>a[e]==' '?0:k[e]==a[e]?4:-1)+"";
```

Usage

```c#
g("CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA", "CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA")
```

Test

http://csharppad.com/gist/15f7c9c3c8cfce471ff2

Comment: You could change it to `int s=0,i=0;for(;...` to save 3 bytes.

Comment: This wont work if I input 29 chars for first input and 31 for second.. it should print "invalid test" but will actually try to grade.

Comment: @noisyass2: string x(string k,string a)=>k.Length!=30||a.Length!=30?"Invalid Test!":Enumerable.Range(0,30).Sum(e=>a[e]==' '?0:k[e]==a[e]?4:-1)+""; (134 chars) and considers Johans input.

Comment: +1 for solution, but does this qualify? OP said full program.

Comment: Johan nice catch!
@StephanSchinkel thanks for the idea on using the delegate and the Enum.range bit. I was able to shave of 3 more chars changing the condition to 30==(k.Length&a.Length)

Comment: nevermind, realized bitwise and of 30 and 31 is 30 so it wouldnt work. Went with Stephan's input

Comment: This just checks the input len, but does not print "Invalid Test" if there are characters out of range A...E. I think it should

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>144</s> 138 bytes

```hs
a%b|map length[a,b]==[30,30]&&"ABCDE"!a&&"ABCDE "!b=show$sum$zipWith(?)a b|0<1="Invalid test"
l!s=all(`elem`l)
_?' '=0
x?y|x==y=4|0<1=0-1
```

Would be about 50 without the validation. *sniff*.

Usage: `"ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE" % "AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEEAAAAA"`

Comment: `!` can be defined as ``all(`elem`l)s``, saving 6 bytes.

Comment: ... or go pointfree: `g=all.flip elem`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 71 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
Ul ¥30©Vl ¥30«(U+V k"[A-E ]+" ?U¬r@VgZ ¥Y?X+4:VgZ ¥S?X:X-1,0 :`InvÃ. È.
```

The two `.`s at the end should be the unprintable Unicode chars U+0017 and U+0099, respectively.

#### How it works

```
Ul ==30&&Vl ==30&&!(U+V k"[A-E ]+" ?Uq r@VgZ ==Y?X+4:VgZ ==S?X:X-1,0 :"Invalid test
                    // Implicit: U = first input, V = second input
Ul ==30&&Vl ==30&&  // If both input lengths are 30, and
!(U+V k"[A-E ]+"?   // removing all ABCDE and spaces from (U+V) results in an empty string:
Uq r@            ,0 //  Reduce U with this function, starting with a value of 0:
VgZ ==Y?            //   If the matching char in V is equal to this char, 
X+4                 //    return previous value + 4.
:VgZ ==S?X          //   Else if the matching char in V is a space, return previous value.
:X-1                //   Else (if it's wrong), return previous value - 1.
:"Invalid test      // Else, return "Invalid test".
                    // Implicit: output last expression
```

I hope there's a shorter way to make sure both lengths are equal to 30. Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2.7, <s>131, 116, 109</s>, 139

I tried to do a "short" python solution... Well here it is, suggestions are more than welcome

```py
lambda c,d:d.count(' ')+sum([-1,4][a==b]for a,b in zip(c,d)if b!=' ')if not set('ABCDE ')^set(c+d)and len(c)==len(d)==30 else'Test Invalid'
```

Adding a few more characters makes it far more readable...

```py
def m(c, d):
    if len(c)==len(d)==30:return d.count(' ')+sum((a==b)*4+(a!=b)*-1 for a,b in zip(c,d)if b!=' ')
    return'Test Invalid'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <del>183</del> 169 bytes

This was a nice bit of Java 8 practice:

```java
String f(String a,String r){return a.length()==30&r.length()==30?""+IntStream.range(0,30).map(i->a.charAt(i)==r.charAt(i)?4:r.charAt(i)!=' '?-1:0).sum():"Invalid test";}
```

Comment: I'm not a Java Golfer, but I think you can save the `String.valueOf` by just adding the int to an empty string (`""+IntStream....`) - I also believe Java allows non-short-circuiting and, so you can remove one of the `&` and save a byte.

Comment: @VisualMelon Great tips, thanks. It was annoying me how many bytes String.valueOf took up!

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 81 characters

```ruby
->t,s{r=0;30.times{|i|r+=t[i]==s[i]?4:s[i]>' '?-1:0};t.size==30?r:'Invalid test'}
```

Sample run:

```
2.1.5 :001 > ->t,s{r=0;30.times{|i|r+=t[i]==s[i]?4:s[i]>' '?-1:0};t.size==30?r:'Invalid test'}['CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA','CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA']
 => 73 

2.1.5 :002 > ->t,s{r=0;30.times{|i|r+=t[i]==s[i]?4:s[i]>' '?-1:0};t.size==30?r:'Invalid test'}['CCCATCH','CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA']
 => "Invalid test"
```

Answer (score 2):

## brainfuck, 354 bytes

```
+[--[>]<<+>-],----------[[<<<]>>->[>>>],----------]<<<[<<<]>>+[<-[-------<+>]<.+[---<+>]<.++++++++.[-<+++>]<-.+++++++++++.---.-----.-[---<+>]<-.---[-<++++>]<.+++[-<+++>]<.[---<+>]<----.+.>]>[[>,----------->+++++++[<---<<+++>>>-]<[<<+[>>+<<-]]>[>]<<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[>>>]>----<<<<[<<<]>>[-]]>[>-<-]>[>>[>>>]>-----<<<<[<<<]>[-]]>>]----[>+++<--]>--.<]
```

Requires an interpreter that allows you to go left from cell 0. Output is a signed byte. For example, the byte `0x49` is printed for the example input, and `0xFF` is printed for input with the same first line but the second line replaced with "C" and 29 spaces.

The score starts at 0, and as the second line of input is read these changes are made to it:

- Input is correct: Do nothing
- Input is incorrect: Subtract 5
- Input is a space: Subtract 4

Finally, 120 is added. This is functionally the same as assuming a perfect score and applying penalties, rather than starting at 0.

With comments:

```
+[--[>]<<+>-]                          Get 29

,----------[[<<<]>>->[>>>],----------] Get first line of input; for each char sub one
                                       from the 29

<<<[<<<]>>+                            Add one to the cell that originally held 29

[                                      If the cell that originally held 29 is nonzero:

  Write "Invalid test"
  <-[-------<+>]<.+[---<+>]<.++++++++.[-<+++>]<-.+++++++++++.---.-----.-[---<+>]<-.---[-<++++>]<.+++[-<+++>]<.[---<+>]<----.+.

>]

>[                                     If the cell to the right is nonzero:

  This block is only ever entered if "Invalid test" isn't written!

  [                                      For all 30 characters of the first input:

    >,                                     Get char from second input to the right

    ----------                             Subtract 10 for consistency

    -                                      Subtract one more

    >+++++++[<---<<+++>>>-]                Subtract 21 (plus above lines = 32)

    <[                                     If it's nonzero:

      <<+[>>+<<-]                            Add 22 to the character

    ]

    >[>]<<<[                                 If the above block wasn't entered:

      >[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]                   Make a copy of the character from input 1

      >[>>>]>----                            Subtract 4 from the score

      <<<<[<<<]>>[-]                         Go to the cell just before first character

    ]

    >[>-<-]                                Subtract input 1 char from input 2 char

    >[                                     If the result is nonzero:

      >>[>>>]>-----                          Subtract 5 from the score

      <<<<[<<<]>[-]                          Go back to the result and set it to 0

    ]

    >>                                     Move on to next character

  ]

  ----[>+++<--]>--                       Add 120 to score (perfect score)

  .                                      Print score

  <                                      Go to an empty cell to kill loop

]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>187 179 175 165 155</s> 151

```py
lambda a,b:(['Invalid test',sum([-1,4][i==j]for i,j in zip(a,b))+b.count(' ')][len(a)==len(b)==30and set(a)^set('ABCDE')==set(b)^set('ABCDE ')==set()])
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES7, 102

As usual, the bonus is not worth the effort.

```js
(k,h,t=i=0)=>[for(x of h)t+=k[i++]==x?4:1-x?0:-1]|/[^ A-E]/.test(k+h)|i-30|k.length-i?"Invalid test":t
```

Checking for invalid spaces in first input (as this makes sense to me) **112**

```js
(k,h,t=i=0)=>[for(x of h)(y=k[i++])>' '?t+=y==x?4:1-x?0:-1:k=h+h]|/[^ A-E]/.test(k+h)|i-30|k[i]?"Invalid test":t
```

Comment: Ugh, the validation took up half of my code when I tried: `(k,r,s=0)=>/^[A-E]{30}$/.test(k)&&/^[ A-E]{30}$/.test(r)?Object.keys(k).map(i=>k[i]==r[i]?s+=4:s-=r[i]!=' ').pop():'Invalid Test'` is 129 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### C# 6.0 --> <strike>(270 - 20 = 250)</strike> 246 - 20 = 226 bytes

```c#
void m(string b,string c){if((b+c).Length==60){var a=new int[3];int s=0;for(int i=0;i<30;i++){if(b[i]==c[i]){a[0]++;s+=4;}else if(c[i]==' ')a[2]++;else{a[1]++;s--;}}Console.Write(s+$" ({a[0]} {a[2]} {a[1]})");}else Console.Write("Invalid test");}
```

Readable & ungolfed version:

```c#
    void m(string b, string c)
    {
        if ((b+c).Length==60)
        {
            var a = new int[3];
            int s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                if (b[i]==c[i])
                {
                    a[0]++;
                    s+=4;
                }
                else if (c[i] == ' ')a[2]++;
                else
                {
                    a[1]++;
                    s--;
                }
            }
            Console.Write(s+$" ({a[0]} {a[2]} {a[1]})");
        }
        else Console.Write("Invalid test");
    }
```

Really wanted to get the bonus :D

Comment: Nice work! A few of general tricks that apply here, you can declare `i` along with `s` outside the for loop. You can use `var` to declare `a`, saving 1 byte (hurrah!). You don't need many of the curly braces `{}` in your code, which is always a good way to trim bytes, and it's always worth looking at an ASCII table when comparing chars (you can knock a byte off `c[i]==' '` somewhat by using an inequality). You should also consider counting through the strings backwards - in this case you can save at least 1 byte by rejigging the for loop somewhat.

Comment: Unfortunately, your submission is currently not complicit with the criteria, as it is unable to recognise invalid inputs.

Comment: @VisualMelon Ahh, I feel so dumb. I wrote this submission at school so I forgot to add the 'invalid test' things etc. I'll add them :)

Comment: @VisualMelon Yeah, this was submitted and written in school at the end of the class, I'll edit it. Thanks for the tricks :)

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 165 bytes

More than half the bytes are for the invalid tests check.

**Code:**

```
p(X,X,4).
p(_,32,0).
p(_,_,-1).
A*B:-length(A,30),length(B,30),subset(A,`ABCDE`),subset(B,`ABCDE `),maplist(p,A,B,L),sum_list(L,S),write(S);write('Invalid Test').
```

**Explained:**

```
p(X,X,4).                                       % If corresponding elements are equal, 4p
p(_,32,0).                                      % If answer is 'space', 0p
p(_,_,-1).                                      % Else, -1p
A*B:-length(A,30),length(B,30),                 % Check that input is of correct length
     subset(A,`ABCDE`),subset(B,`ABCDE `),      % Check that input has correct characters
     maplist(p,A,B,L),sum_list(L,S),write(S);   % Create a list of scores (L) and print sum
     write('Invalid Test').                     % If anything failed, write Invalid Test
```

**Example:**

```
`CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA`*`CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA`.
73
```

Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/XkOWpXBJ.pl)

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB, <strike>92</strike> 90 bytes

Thanks to Tom Carpenter for helping me to reduce my answer by 2 bytes!

```
function c(q,a),if nnz(q)~=30,t='Invalid test';else s=q-a;t=5*nnz(~s)-sum(s<9);end,disp(t)
```

Function can be called by assigning the answer sheet to *q* and the submitted answers to *a*. e.g.:

```
c('CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA','CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA')
```

The answer is simply printed to the screen. **8 bytes** could be saved if it is allowed to print *ans = 73*

Comment: You could save 2 bytes by replacing ```numel(q)``` with ```nnz(q)```.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy 2.4.5, 107 bytes

Just a simple translation of the earlier [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64861/39490).

```
f={a,b->a.length()==30&b.length()==30?(0..29).collect{a[it]==b[it]?4:b[it]!=' '?-1:0}.sum():'Invalid test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 273 - 20 = 253 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int c,char**v){char*p=v[1],*q=v[2],*s=" ABCDE",r[]={0,0,0};if(strspn(p,s+1)!=30||p[30]||strspn(q,s)!=30||q[30])puts("Invalid test");else{for(;*p;++q)++r[(*p++!=*q)+(*q==' ')];printf("%d (%dR %dB %dW)",4**r-r[1],*r,r[2],r[1]);}}
```

I've taken the bonus, even though it cost me 23 bytes just to print it.  :-(

### Explanation

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int c,char**v)
{
    char *p=v[1], *q=v[2],      /* arguments */
        *s=" ABCDE",            /* valid chars */
        r[]={0,0,0};            /* results - right, wrong, blank */

    if (strspn(p,s+1) != 30     /* validity check - answer key begins with [A-E]{30} */
        || p[30]                /* and ends there */
        || strspn(q,s) != 30    /* same for answers, but allow space, too */
        || q[30])
    {
        puts("Invalid test");
    } else {
        for ( ;  *p;  ++q)      /* for each answer */
            ++r[(*p++!=*q)+(*q==' ')]; /* increment the appropriate counter */
        printf("%d (%dR %dB %dW)",4**r-r[1],*r,r[2],r[1]); /* print result */
    }
}
```

There's twice as much code to check for invalid input as there is to count the answers - the real meat of the challenge is in the `for` loop near the end.  In fact here's a version that assumes the input is always valid, in 163-20 = 143 bytes:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int c,char**v){char*p=v[1],*q=v[2],r[]={0,0,0};for(;*p;++q)++r[(*p++!=*q)+(*q==' ')];printf("%d (%dR %dB %dW)",4**r-r[1],*r,r[2],r[1]);}
```

And one that makes the same assumption and prints only the score, in 133 bytes:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int c,char**v){char*p=v[1],*q=v[2],r[]={4,-1,0};for(c=0;*p;++q)c+=r[(*p++!=*q)+(*q==' ')];printf("%d",c);}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **SAS** 9.4, 291-20 = 271 bytes(with bonus), or 231 bytes(without bonus)

With bonus:

```
data a;k='CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA';r='CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA';c=0;b=0;w=0;if length(k) ne 30 then put "Invalid test";do i=1 to 30;if substr(k,i,1)=substr(r,i,1) then c=c+1;else if substr(r,i,1) =' ' then b=b+1;else w=w+1;end;a=cat(c*4-w,' (',c,'R ',b,'B ',w,'W)');put a;run;
```

Without bonus:

```
data a;k='CABBDCABECDBACDBEAACADDBBBEDDA';r='CABEDDABDC BACDBBAADE  CBBEDDA';c=0;if length(k) ne 30 then put "Invalid test";do i=1 to 30;if substr(k,i,1)=substr(r,i,1) then c=c+4;else if substr(r,i,1)ne' ' then c=c-1;end;put c;run;
```

Sas does not really have an input/output, so you would need to replace the k='..' with the key, and r='..' with the response.  The output is printed to the log.