# Count sums of two squares

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics, number-theory

Given a non-negative number `n`, output the number of ways to express `n` as the sum of two squares of integers `n == a^2 + b^2` ([OEIS A004018](https://oeis.org/A004018)). Note that `a` and `b` can be positive, negative, or zero, and their order matters. Fewest bytes wins.

For example, `n=25` gives `12` because `25` can be expressed as

```
(5)^2  + (0)^2
(4)^2  + (3)^2
(3)^2  + (4)^2
(0)^2  + (5)^2
(-3)^2 + (4)^2
(-4)^2 + (3)^2
(-5)^2 + (0)^2
(-4)^2 + (-3)^2
(-3)^2 + (-4)^2
(0)^2  + (-5)^2
(3)^2  + (-4)^2
(4)^2  + (-3)^2
```

Here are the values up to `n=25`. Be careful that your code works for `n=0`.

```
0 1
1 4
2 4
3 0
4 4
5 8
6 0
7 0
8 4
9 4
10 8
11 0
12 0
13 8
14 0
15 0
16 4
17 8
18 4
19 0
20 8
21 0
22 0
23 0
24 0
25 12
```

Here are the values up to `n=100` as a list.

```
[1, 4, 4, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 4, 4, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 8, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 12, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 16, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 8, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 0, 12]
```

Fun facts: The sequence contains terms that are arbitrarily high, and the limit of its running average is π.

**Leaderboard:**

```js
    var QUESTION_ID=64812,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/64812/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
    body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Wait, what?? "The sequence contains terms that are arbitrarily high, and the limit of its running average is π."

Comment: @StewieGriffin The two statements are consistent. Consider the sequence `1,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,...`. Cutting the sequence off after any nonzero number, the average so far is 1. And, the runs of 0's have less and less impact later in the sequence.

Comment: I know it's consistent.. =) I had checked the 10.000 first numbers when I posted the comment. What I don't get is: Why on earth does it equal Pi?

Comment: @StewieGriffin The sum of the terms up to N corresponds to the points (a,b) with a^2+b^2<=N. These are the lattice points in the circle of radius sqrt(N), whose area is πN.

Comment: @xnor and there goes the magic:(

Comment: @xnor damn, nice connection there.

Answer (score 20):

### Python (<strike>59 57</strike> 56 bytes)

```
lambda n:0**n+sum((-(n%(x-~x)<1))**x*4for x in range(n))
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/nwd5fE)

As with my CJam answer, this uses Möbius inversion and runs in pseudoquasilinear time.

Thanks to [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000) for 2 bytes' savings, and [feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30688/feersum) for 1.

Comment: Those parentheses are annoying.

Comment: @ThomasKwa, tell me about it. The thing which really surprised me, in one of the versions I passed through on the way to the first one I posted, was that `-1**x` is always `-1`. I expected the `-1` to be a single integer literal token rather than a low-precedence unary minus followed by a one.

Comment: Congrats on the bounty! Your code is shorter than anything I had come up with. Your solution is based on a totally new and unexpected mathematical idea, and it brings me joy to that this is possible even in such a straightforward-looking challenge .The Mobius-inverse result is quite pretty and I took the pleasure of deriving a proof for myself.

Comment: 1 byte can be saved by moving the multiplication by 4 to after `**x`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Can you elaborate how your algorithm works/can you point me to a resource? I cannot quite see how you can apply the möbius inversion to number of sums of suqares problem.

Comment: @flawr, I haven't worked through the details, but (as mentioned in my CJam answer), the relationship is given in OEIS. MathWorld's discussion of the [relevance of primes equal to 1 and 3 mod 4](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) probably provides enough ammunition to tackle the proof.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you very much!

Comment: If Python's boolean/number parsing works like JS's, `+!n` should work in place of `0**n`.

Comment: @ETHproductions, Python is quite idiosyncratic. It has `and` instead of `&&`, `not` instead of `!`, doesn't have `++` or `?:`...

Answer (score 16):

## Python 2, 44 bytes

```
f=lambda n,x=1:+(x>n)or(n%x<1)-f(n,x+2)/4<<2
```

This is almost the same as xsot's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65077/2537) (which is based on Peter Taylor's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65326/2537)), but saves 8 bytes by simplifying the way signs are handled.

Note that for a full program, we can save 2 bytes in the function without incurring a cost outside the function:

```
f=lambda n,x=1:x>n or(n%x<1)-f(n,x+2)/4<<2
print+f(input())
```

Two additional bytes for a full program this way:

```
n=input()
f=lambda x:x>n or(n%x<1)-f(x+2)/4<<2
print+f(1)
```

For `n > 0` there is a very legible 40-byte solution:

```
f=lambda n,x=1:n/x and(n%x<1)*4-f(n,x+2)
```

Comment: Congrats for winning the bounty! The recursive subtraction is a clean and short way to express the alternating sum for odd divisors without needing to extract a sign from the divisor itself. Also, credit to xsot for streamlining Peter Taylor's solution to a recursive one with clever handling of n=0.

Answer (score 15):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

If built-ins are allowed, this is how to do it in Mathematica.

```
2~SquaresR~#&
```

---

For 0 < = n <= 100

```
2~SquaresR~# & /@ Range[0, 100]
```

> {1, 4, 4, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 4, 4, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 8, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 12, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 8,
> 0, 0, 0, 4, 12, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 16, 0, 0,
> 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 8, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 0, 12}

Comment: Because of course Mathematica has a built-in for this.

Answer (score 12):

### J, 16 bytes

```
+/@,@:=+&*:/~@i:
```

This is a monadic verb (in other words, a unary function).
[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloK3voONgZautpmWlX@eQafU/NTkjXyFNwcj0PwA) or [see it pass all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloK3voONgZautpmWlX@eQafU/NTkjX0FDR08hTclAUyFTT8HI7D8A).

### Explanation

```
+/@,@:=+&*:/~@i:  Denote input by n
              i:  The array of integers from -n to n
           /~@    Take outer product wrt the following function:
       +           the sum of
        &*:        squares of both inputs
                  This results in a 2D array of a^2+b^2 for all a, b between -n and n
      =           Replace by 1 those entries that are equal to n, and others by 0
   ,@:            Flatten the binary matrix
+/@               Take its sum
```

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
/sM^^R2}_QQ2Q
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FsM%5E%5ER2%7D_QQ2Q&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0)

```
/sM^^R2}_QQ2Q
                 Q = eval(input())
       }_QQ      Inclusive range from -Q to Q (all possible a and b)
    ^R2          Map to their squares
   ^       2     Form all pairs
 sM              Sum pairs
/           Q    Count occurances of Q
```

Comment: Late, but I don't think you need the last `Q`.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>69</s> <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
f=lambda n,x=1:+(x>n)or(2-x%4)*(n%x<1)+f(n,x+2)/4<<2
```

This is a recursive function based off [Peter Taylor's excellent solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65326/45268).

Comment: This is a great improvement. But, there is still a way to make it shorter, and I encourage you to look for it.

Comment: @xnor Another byte down. I hope you don't have any more tricks up your sleeves.

Comment: Whoa, that operator precedence. I don't have this trick but I have a different, bigger one.

Comment: I don't know whether I should make an answer of it, it's just your solution plus one trick: `f=lambda n,x=1:+(x>n)or(n%x<1)-f(n,x+2)/4<<2`. Also, I guess we don't care about exceeding the default maximum recursion depth?

Comment: (For positive `n`, can simplify `f=lambda n,x=1:n/x and(n%x<1)*4-f(n,x+2)`)

Comment: @xnor Is that the same idea as yours?

Comment: @MitchSchwartz I think that's an incredible improvement worthy of the bounty and likely the final optimisation xnor had in mind.

Comment: @MitchSchwartz Yes, that's the optimization I was thinking of! And xsot's `/4<<2` trick makes it shorter than what I had.

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 40 bytes

```julia
n->n>0?4sum(i->(n-i^2)^.5%1==0,1:n^.5):1
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(n)
  if n==0
    return 1           # Handle special case of n=0
  else
    m=0                # Start the counter at zero
    for i=1:sqrt(n)    # Loop over the values (i) whose squares are
                       # less than n (except zero)
      k=sqrt(n-i^2)    # Find k such that n=k^2+i^2
      if k==floor(k)   # if k is an integer, we've found a pair
        m+=4           # Add one for each of k^2+i^2, (-k)^2+(-i)^2, and the other two
      end
    end
    return m           # Return the resulting count
  end
end
```

Note that the loop doesn't include `i==0`, because when `n` is a square, it's already included by `i=sqrt(n)`, and there are only four, not eight, for that form (`0^2+k^2, 0^2+(-k)^2, k^2+0^2, (-k)^2+0^2`).

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
Zri:R#Ym*{Rf-Yf#:+R=},,
```

This is a theoretical solution that requires **O(9<sup>n</sup>)** time and memory for input **n**.

At the cost of one extra byte – for a total of **24 bytes** – we can reduce the complexity to **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**:

```
ri:R)Y*Ym*{Rf-Yf#:+R=},,
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmk6UikyKlltKntSZi1ZZiM6K1I9fSws&input=MjU)

#### How it works

Either

```
Z                  Push 3.
 ri:R              Read an integer from STDIN and save it in R.
     #             Compute 3**R.
```

or

```
ri:R               Read an integer from STDIN and save it in R.
    )Y*            Add 1 and multiply by 2.
```

Then

```
Ym*                Take the second Cartesian power, i.e., compute all pairs.
   {          },   Filter the pairs:
    Rf-              Subtract R from each.
       Yf#           Square the differences.
          :+         Add the squares.
            R=       Compare with R.
                   If = pushed 1, keep the pair.
                ,  Count the kept pairs.
```

Comment: And at a saving of one byte it's possible to get the complexity down to Õ(n)

Comment: Yes, I saw. That's amazing.

Answer (score 7):

### CJam (<strike>25 24 22</strike> 21 bytes)

```
{:X!X{X\2*)%!4*\-}/z}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=17%2C%0A%0A%7B%3AX!X%7BX%5C2*)%25!4*%5C-%7D%2Fz%7D%0A%0A%25%60)

This runs in pseudoquasilinear time* and uses the statement from the OEIS that

> Moebius transform is period 4 sequence [ 4, 0, -4, 0, ...]. - Michael Somos, Sep 17 2007

The input `0` is obviously a special case (Möbius tranforms and annihilators don't go well together), but ended up only costing one char.

* Pseudo- because it's quasilinear in the value of the input, not the size of the input; quasi because it does `Theta(n)` operations on integers of size on the order of `n`; a `b`-bit mod operation should take `b lg b` time, so overall this takes `Theta(n lg n lg lg n)` time.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>42</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
V=Un oU+1;Vr@X+(Vf_p2 +Y*Y¥U)l ,0
```

#### How it works

```
           // Implicit: U = input number
V=Un oU+1  // Set variable V to range(-U, U+1). Ends up like [-U,-U+1,...,U-1,U]
Vr@    ,0  // Reduce each item Y in V with this function, starting at 0:
X+(     l  //  Return the previous value X + the length of:
Vf_p2      //   V filtered by items Z where Z*Z
+Y*Y==U)   //    + Y*Y equals U.
           // This ends up as the combined length of all fitting pairs of squares.
           // Implicit: return last expression
```

Perhaps there's a better technique; suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 42 bytes

```
f n|q<-[-n..n]=sum[1|a<-q,b<-q,a*a+b*b==n]
```

Usage exapmle:

```
*Main> map f [0..25]
[1,4,4,0,4,8,0,0,4,4,8,0,0,8,0,0,4,8,4,0,8,0,0,0,0,12]
*Main>
```

Comment: Binding `q` in a guard is clever, I'll remember this trick.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3, <s>68</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
lambda n:0**n+4*sum(i**.5%1+(n-i)**.5%1==0for i in range(n))
```

Using two nested list comprehensions is too expensive. Instead, this checks if both coordinates on the circle of radius sqrt(n) are integers.

*Peter Taylor has beaten this with a [Moebius-inversion based approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65326/39328).*

Comment: Well done. I was tinkering with a recursive function but couldn't resolve `n=0` elegantly.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>89</s> <s>79</s> 63 bytes

```julia
g(x)=cos(π*x^.5)^2÷1
a(n)=(n==0)+4sum([g(i)g(n-i)for i=1:n])
```

This is a named function `a` which accepts an integer and returns a float. It calls a helper function `g`.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function g(x::Integer)
    floor(cos(π*sqrt(x))^2)
end

function a(n::Integer)
    (n == 0) + 4*sum([g(i)*g(n-i) for i=1:n])
end
```

The approach here uses a simplification of Wesley Ivan Hurt's formula listed on OEIS. The simplification was found by Glen O, the very same person who shaved 26 bytes off of this answer!

Comment: Use `x^.5` rather than `sqrt(x)` to save 3 bytes. And `(n==0)` saves 2 bytes over `1÷(n+1)`. And you can save 4 more characters by using `cos(π*sqrt(x))^2÷1` rather than `floor(cos(π*sqrt(x))^2)`. Also, use `1:n/2` rather than `1:n÷2`, because there's no harm using a float in `g(x)` and it'll be locked to the integers for `i` anyway. And `sum(i->g(i)g(n-i),1:n/2)` will shave some more characters, too.

Comment: @GlenO Great suggestions, thanks. The `sum` trick fails for `n=0` though, so I kept array comprehension.

Comment: So, it can be recovered - if you let the `i=0` case happen in the sum, you can switch the sign on `4g(n)`. So `(n==0)-4g(n)-4g(n/2)+8sum(i->g(i)g(n-i),0:n/2)`, which will not run into the error. But you can do even better, by noting the symmetries - `(n==0)+4sum([g(i)g(n-i)for i=1:n])`

Comment: @GlenO That simplification is *seriously* genius. I recommend you submit that as an alternative formula for the sequence on OEIS!

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, 28 bytes

```
@(n)nnz((a=(-n:n).^2)'+a==n)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
lfqQs^R2T^}_QQ2
```

Try it online in the [Pyth Compiler](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lfqQs%5ER2T%5E%7D_QQ2&input=25&debug=0).

#### How it works

```
lfqQs^R2T^}_QQ2

          }_QQ   Compute the inclusive range from -Q to Q (input).
         ^    2  Take the second Cartesian power, i.e., compute all pairs.
 f               Filter; for each T in the list of pairs:
     ^R2T          Compute the squares of T's elements.
    s              Add the squares.
  qQ               Compare the sum with Q.
                 If q returned True, keep T.
l                Count the kept pairs.
```

Answer (score 4):

### TI-BASIC, 23 bytes

```
sum(seq(Σ(X²+Y²=Ans,X,-Ans,Ans),Y,-Ans,Ans
```

Pretty straightforward. `Σ(` is summation.

Strangely, `sum(seq(sum(seq(` throws an `ERR:ILLEGAL NEST`, and so does `Σ(Σ(`, but `sum(seq(Σ(` is fine. I chose to put the `Σ(` on the inside to save a close-paren.

Comment: What's the difference between `sum` and `Σ`?

Comment: @alephalpha Σ( takes a summation, adding up all of the `X²+Y²=Ans` from values of X between `-Ans` and `Ans`. sum( is sum of a *list*, so we need to create the list first using seq(...,Y,-Ans,Ans

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> 60 bytes

```js
n=>eval("for(r=0,a=~n;a++<n;)for(b=~n;b++<n;)r+=a*a+b*b==n")
```

6 bytes saved thanks to [@edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65)!

### Explanation

```js
n=>eval(`              // use eval to allow for loops in an unparenthesised arrow function
  for(r=0,             // r = number of pairs
    a=~n;a++<n;        // a = first number to square
  )
      for(b=~n;b++<n;) // b = second number to square
        r+=a*a+b*b==n  // add one to the result if a^2 + b^2 == n
                       // implicit: return r
`)
```

### Test

```html
n = <input type="number" oninput='result.innerHTML=(

n=>eval("for(r=0,a=~n;a++<n;)for(b=~n;b++<n;)r+=a*a+b*b==n")

)(+this.value)' /><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: 60: `n=>eval('for(r=0,a=~n;a++<n;)for(b=~n;b++<n;)r+=a*a+b*b==n')`

Comment: @edc65 Nice! I didn't think of using `eval` to put the `for` loops into an arrow function without parentheses. I also forgot about the `~` operator haha.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>93</s> <s>62</s> 69 bytes

Itertools wasn't working so I used two ranges again, but moved the range out to save bytes.

**Edit:** Previous code didn't actually work, since I defined range over n before I defined n.

```
lambda n:sum(i*i+j*j==n for i in range(-n,n+1)for j in range(-n,n+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL, <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
{+/⍵=∊∘.+⍨×⍨0,,⍨⍳⍵}
```

Explanation:

```
{+/⍵=∊∘.+⍨×⍨0,,⍨⍳⍵}        Monadic function:
                 ⍳⍵          1 2 3 ... ⍵
               ,⍨            Duplicate
             0,              Concatenate to 0
          ×⍨                 Square everything
      ∘.+⍨                   Make an addition table
     ∊                       Flatten
   ⍵=                        1s where equal to the input
 +/                          Sum up the 1s
```

Other than the fact that APL doesn't have J's `i:` (numbers from -n to n) function, this works pretty much like the J answer.

We can't use a train because getting the `-\⍳2×⍵` to not parse as `(-\) ⍳ (2×⍵)` would cost three bytes; similarly with other pair of atops. All those parentheses make the regular function shorter.

Try it [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%7B+/%u2375%3D%u220A%u2218.+%u2368%D7%u23680%2C%2C%u2368%u2373%u2375%7D%A80%2C%u2373100%29%u22611%204%204%200%204%208%200%200%204%204%208%200%200%208%200%200%204%208%204%200%208%200%200%200%200%2012%208%200%200%208%200%200%204%200%208%200%204%208%200%200%208%208%200%200%200%208%200%200%200%204%2012%200%208%208%200%200%200%200%208%200%200%208%200%200%204%2016%200%200%208%200%200%200%204%208%208%200%200%200%200%200%208%204%208%200%200%2016%200%200%200%208%208%200%200%200%200%200%200%208%204%200%2012&run). The output of `1` means all values match.

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP, <s>34</s> 28 bytes

Using generating functions:

Saved 6 bytes thanks to [Mitch Schwartz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2537/mitch-schwartz).

```
n->sum(i=-n,n,x^i^2)^2\x^n%x
```

---

Using built-ins, 33 bytes (saved 1 byte thanks to [Mitch Schwartz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2537/mitch-schwartz).):

```
n->if(n,2*qfrep(matid(2),n)[n],1)
```

> qfrep(q,B,{flag=0}): vector of (half) the number of vectors of norms from 1 to B for the integral and definite quadratic form q. If flag is 1, count vectors of even norm from 1 to 2B.

---

Comment: `matid(2)` saves a byte.

Comment: And down to 28 for the generating function approach: `n->sum(i=-n,n,x^i^2)^2\x^n%x`

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab 41 bytes

Even smaller as the previous answers

```
@(n)nnz(~mod(sqrt(n-(1:n^.5).^2),1))*4+~n
```

Essentially Agawa001's answer with power and sqrt replaced

Answer (score 2):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

Input pushed onto stack initially

<s>`~TbAT1C(sWs+Aeh)Z`</s>

`~T0C(sWs+Aeh)Z`

```
peekA    # copy arg from stack to register A
range2   # create double sided range on stack, -A, 1-A, ... A-1, A
digit0   # prefix argument to 'cart', 
cart     # cartesian product of current stack(0), and other stack(0)
while    # while stack not empty
  sqr    # pop and square and push
  swap   # swap two stack elements
  sqr    # pop and square and push
  add    # pop and pop and add and push
  pushA  # push original argument
  equal  # equality test 0/1
  popAddZ  # Z := Z + pop
endwhile
pushZ    # push Z onto stack, will be output to stdout on termination
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 28

```
qi_mF{3a>},{~)\4%2-&}%4+:*1?
```

Not really short, but efficient. E.g. the result for 15625 is instantly 28. Uses the factorization-based formula from OEIS.
[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi_mF%7B3a%3E%7D%2C%7B~)%5C4%252-%26%7D%254%2B%3A*1%3F&input=15625)

**Explanation:**

```
qi       read input and convert to integer
_        make a copy (will be used to handle the 0 case at the end)
mF       factorize into [prime exponent] pairs
{…},     filter the array of pairs
  3a>    with the condition that the pair is greater than [3]
          which means the prime factor must be ⩾3
{…}%     transform each pair as follows:
  ~      dump the prime factor and exponent onto the stack
  )      increment the exponent
  \      swap with the prime
  4%     get the remainder mod 4 (it will be 1 or 3)
  2-     subtract 2 (resulting in -1 or 1)
  &      bitwise AND with the incremented exponent (see below)
4+       append a 4 to the array
:*       multiply all
1?       if the input was 0, use 1, else use the above result
```

Some details about the calculation:

- if the prime is 1 mod 4, the code calculates `(exponent + 1) & -1`, which is `exponent + 1`
- if the prime is 3 mod 4, the code calculates `(exponent + 1) & 1`, which is 0 if the exponent is odd, and 1 if even

All these values multiplied together and multiplied by 4 are exactly the OEIS formula.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 68 bytes

```
def x(n):r=range(-n,n+1);print sum(a*a+b*b==n for a in r for b in r)
```

Defines a function called `x()` that takes a number n.

Try it online.
http://ideone.com/aRoxGF

Comment: You are missing a `print` or `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot.  The link has the print statement though.  I edited my code while I was making the code.

Comment: Ok, no worries. But this also seems to give incorrect results for `n=0` and `n=1` (0 and 2 instead of 1 and 4). Maybe the range limits need adjusting?

Comment: @Zgarb Yeah, they should end at `n+1`.

Comment: This looks pretty short, but knowing xnor I don't think it'll be this simple.

Comment: I tested it (the new version) for all of the values he gave, that is 0-25.  They were all correct.  I haven't tested it for anything else though.

Comment: I've tested a version of this, slightly modified to run on Python 3, from 0 to 101 (values provided by the OEIS). It works for all of them.

Comment: @RikerW I wasn't questioning the validity; I was saying xnor's bounty means there's a shorter but hard-to-find solution.

Comment: I'll look for it.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>41</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FQ*F%2B4m.%26tt%25ed4hhdr-PQ2%208%201&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A21%0A65%0A362880&debug=1)

**Edit:** Thanks to [isaacg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/115644/isaacg), I got `m` and `*F` to work! YES!

```
?Q*F+4m.&tt%ed4hhdr-PQ2 8 1
                                (implicit) Q = input()
?Q                              If Q != 0
      m                           Map to d (exponent, prime) from ...
                  r-PQ2 8         run-length-encoded(PQ with 2's removed)
       .&                           Bitwise and
           %ed4                       d[-1] % 4
         tt                           -2
                hd                  with d[0]
               h                      +1
    +4                            Append 4 to the resulting array
  *F                              Then multiply it all together
                          1     Else 1
```

**Edit:** Put the bitwise and back in for more byte savings! Also I removed all the "Formerly" stuff. It was starting to get cluttered.

Thanks to [aditsu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7416/aditsu) and his CJam solution, and to [maltysen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/138131/maltysen) and his tips (One day I will get `m*Fd` to work. One day...)

```
J4Vr-PQ2 8=J*J.&tt%eN4hhN;?QJ1
                                (implicit) Q=input()
J4                              J=4
    -PQ2                        Remove all 2's from the prime factorization of Q
   r     8                      run-length encode (exponent, prime factor)
  V                      ;      For N in range( the above ):
          =J*J                      J = J * ...
                tt%eN4                N[-1] mod 4 -2 
                      hhN             (exponent + 1)
              .&                    bitwise and
                          ?QJ1  if Q != 0 print(J) else print(1)
```

Note that,

- if the prime is 1 mod 4, we get `-1 & (exponent + 1)`, which is `exponent + 1`
- but if the prime is 3 mod 4, we get `1 & (exponent + 1)`, which is `0` if the exponent is odd, and `1` if even

Multiply it all together (times 4 at the beginning) and we get the number of sums of two squares that add up to our input.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 57 bytes

Nice challenge. Unfortunately I'm not getting it shorter than this at the moment.

```
lambda n:0**n+sum(2-d%4for d in range(1,n+1)if d%2>n%d)*4
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 72 bytes

```
n=input('');m=fix(sqrt(n));m=(-m:m).^2;disp(nnz(bsxfun(@plus,m,m')==n))
```

Comment: You [don't need `disp` in this challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/how-do-we-treat-default-output-formats-such-as-ans-etc) Luis! =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! But in this case it's a program, not a function. So according to the accepted answer in your link it's needed, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, <s>63</s> 50 bytes

```
@(y)nnz(~mod(sqrt(y-power((1:sqrt(y)),2)),1))*4+~y
```

---

- This does beat the other same-entitled code, thus I put it :D.
- The program finds the positive integer solutions then multiply by 4 to encompass negative ones.
- It can perform all 25 first test cases

  ```
  for i=1:25 ans(i)
  end

     1

     4

     4

     0

     4

     8

     0

     0

     4

     4

     8

     0

     0

     8

     0

     0

     4

     8

     4

     0

     8

     0

     0

     0

     0

     12
  ```

Comment: You [don't need `disp` in this challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/how-do-we-treat-default-output-formats-such-as-ans-etc)! =)

Comment: thanks @StewieGriffin i did include it just as a fair-game relating to luis' one

Comment: Tips: When you're planning on posting the results from MATLAB, use `format compact` =)

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <s>133</s> 129 bytes

```
from itertools import*
n=input()
l=[];s=0
for i in range(-n,n+1):l.append(i**2)
for j in product(l,l):
 if sum(j)==n:s+=1
print s
```

This demonstrates the use of itertools cartesian product. [Try it online](http://ideone.com/iq0N9h)

Comment: @Mego I tried, I don't think there is anything to further golf. I will take that part out if you insist.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 89 bytes

```
n=prompt()
p=Math.pow
for (x=c=(+n?0:1);x<=n;x++)if(x&&p(n-p(x,2),.5)%1===0)c+=4
alert(c)
```

I know this isn't the shortest JavaScript answer even if I were to remove the i/o lines, but I do think it is the best performing JS answer giving me the result for a million within a few seconds (ten million took about a minute).

Comment: Can you use == instead of ===?

Comment: I could, just using best practices, ha ha.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 80 Bytes

```
for($m=-$a=1+$argv[1];++$m<$a;)for($n=-$a;$n++<$a;)$c+=$a-1==$m**2+$n**2;echo$c;
```

Comment: `$c+=condition;` instead of `if(condition)$c++;` (-4) Do you feel stalked? :D pre-increment on `$m` and `$n` will improve speed a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 70 bytes, not competing

```
for($x=-1;$x++<=$n=$argv[1];)$s+=(-($n%($x-~$x)<1))**$x*4;echo$n?$s:1;
```

algorithm stolen from one of the Python answers ... I forgot which one; wanted to at least partially understand what´s happening before I posted.

Comment: `for(;$x<=$n=$argv[1];)$s+=(-($n%(2*$x+1)<1))**$x++*4;echo$n?$s:1;` saves 5 Bytes. `$x-~$x` is equal to `2*$x+1` and you can now start without assigning the variable.

Answer (score 1):

## ASP, 53 + 4 = 57 bytes

```
#show N:N=#count{o(A,B):k=A**2+B**2,A=-k..k,B=-k..k}.
```

[Answer Set Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming) is a logical language, similar to prolog.
I use here the [Potassco implementation](https://potassco.org), *clingo*.

Input is taken from parameters (`-ck=` is 4 bytes long). Call example:

```
clingo -ck=25
```

Output sample:

```
12
```

You can try it in your [browser](https://potassco.org/clingo/run/) ; unfortunately, this method doesn't handle call flags, so you need to add the line `#const k=25` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 31 bytes

```
D,f,@,.5^1+iR2€Ω^d0BFB]d‽+A€=¦+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQUfPNM5QOzPI6FHTmnMr41IMnNycYlMeNezVdgSK2B5apv2/KDEvPdXKyIzLDczS4eJMyMxLSa0AMjJ1DYFkCoybUJRaAqRU0uxgIv5Akf8A)

### How it works

This defines a function, \$f\$, that takes the input, \$x\$, as an argument and returns the correct output. We start by yielding \$y := \lfloor\sqrt{x}+1\rfloor\$. We then push the range \$a := [1, 4, ..., y^2]\$, the list of square numbers up to the smallest square number larger than \$x\$. We then duplicate this array and push \$0\$ to the stack. At this point, the stack looks like this, for an input of \$25\$:

```
[[1 4 9 16 25 36] [1 4 9 16 25 36] 0]
```

We then collect these values into a single list, which yields the list of \$n^2\$ for each \$n \in [-y, y]\$. We then duplicate this list and operate the *table* operator over the addition command. The *table* operator takes a dyad, \$g(p, q)\$, and two arrays, \$A\$ and \$B\$. It then takes the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of \$A\$ and \$B\$ and iterates \$g(a, b)\$ over each pair \$(a, b)\$ where \$a \in A\$ and \$b \in B\$.

In this code, this yields the array \$\big[a^2+b^2 \: | \: a, b \in [-y, y]\big]\$. We then compare each element of this list with the input, yielding a boolean array. Finally, we count the number of \$1\$s in this array by taking its sum, and returning that total.

Most of the code should be understandable when paired with the explanation. A few of the overlooked commands:

- `Ω` : The *reverse* operator. Takes a dyad and reverses the order of the arguments
- `‽` : The *table* operator, as described above.
- `¦` : The *fold* operator. Takes an array and a dyad and reduces by the dyad. `¦+` is an alias for sum.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╤■mæ²Σk=Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1CWPpi3IPbzs0KZzi7Ntzy3@/9@Ay5DL0IDLyJTL0hLIMAAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╤         # Take the (implicit) input-integer, and push a list in the range [-input, input]
 ■        # Take the cartesian product of this, creating a list of all possible pairs
  mæ      # Map these pairs to, using the following four commands:
    ²     #  Take the square of both values in the pair
     Σ    #  Sum those
      k=  #  And check whether it's equal to the input-integer (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
  Σ       # After the map, sum the list
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
(ŸãnOQO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f4@iOw4vz/AP9//83MgUA) or [verify the test cases in the range \$[0,100]\$](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@x6dgkP3slhUdtkxSU7P1c/msc3XF4cZ6/X6D/f53/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
(        # Get the negative of the (implicit) input-integer
 Ÿ       # Push a list in the range [(implicit) input-integer, -input]
  ã      # Get the cartesian product of this list, creating all possible pairs
   n     # Square each value in each pair
    O    # Sum each inner pair
     Q   # Check for each sum whether it's equal to the (implicit) input-integer
         # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
      O  # And sum those
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õUn)ï £¶Xx²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9VVuKe8go7ZYeLI&input=MjU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
rNp`²§ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/IryDh0KZDy490/zcyPbrb@nC7yqOmNe7/AQ)

### How it works

```
rNp`²§ċ - Main link. Takes n on the left
 N      - Yield -n
r       - Take the range [-n, -n+1, ..., -1, 0, 1, ..., n-1, n]
   `    - Use this list for both arguments for:
  p     -   Cartesian product
    ²   - Square each number
     §  - Take the sums of each pair
      ċ - Count the number of times n appears
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 52 bytes

56 bytes:

```
$n=pop;for$a(@a=-$n..$n){map$i+=$_*$_+$a*$a==$n,@a}say$i
```

If output can be in base 1, then 52 bytes:

```
$n=pop;for$a(@a=-$n..$n){print$_*$_+$a*$a==$n for@a}
```

Comment: Why waste so many bytes using an array? You can do the `-$n..$n` in the `for` statement...

Comment: @WouterVerheist I use `@a` twice, and wouldn't save bytes writing `-$n..$n` twice. However, presumably I can incorporate the assignment to `@a` into the first time it's used, which will save 3 bytes. If I have an opportunity to test it and remember to do so, I'll do so and revise this answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed that. I must be blind.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst But thanks for the tip: you saved me three bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, <s>76</s> 74 bytes

I'm sure this can be golfed more, but I need to get back to work.

```
lambda n:sum([1for a in range(-n,n+1)for b in range(-n,n+1)if a*a+b*b==n])
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/mLUeBU)

Thanks to @mathmandan for taking off 2 bytes.

Comment: Quick note: `a*a+b*b` is shorter than `a**2+b**2`.  Also the square brackets aren't required here, so you can get down to 72 bytes.  (FYI, it looks like `def f(n):r=range(-n,n+1);print sum(1for j in r for i in r if i*i+j*j==n)` is also the exact same score.)

Comment: Thanks. The `a*a` is almost obvious - stupid I didn't see that. The brackets are needed for the comprehension to work. So it's down to 74. Also putting `lambda n,r=range` results in the same length. Too bad...

Comment: Without the square brackets, it won't make a list, but it'll make a generator, which works fine with `sum`.  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions (Removed square brackets and tested fine in 2.7.4.)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>66</s> <s>58</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
->n{r=-n..n;r.map{|x|r.count{|y|n==x*x+y*y}}.reduce:+}
```

Thanks to sherlock9.

**56 bytes**

```
->n{r=-n..n;r.map{|x|r.count{|y|n==x**2+y**2}}.reduce:+}
```

**58 bytes**

```
->n{c=0;r=(-n..n);r.map{|x|c+=r.count{|y|n==x**2+y**2}};c}
```

**66 bytes**

```
->n{c=0;(-n..n).each{|x|c+=n.downto(-n).count{|y|n==x**2+y**2}};c}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
-> n {
  r = -n..n
  r.map { |x|
    r.count { |y|
      n == x*x + y*y
    }
  }.reduce:+
}
```

**Usage:**

```
->n{r=-n..n;r.map{|x|r.count{|y|n==x*x+y*y}}.reduce:+}[25]
=> 12
```

Comment: You can shave two bytes by using `x*x+y*y`

Answer (score 0):

### C, <strike>224</strike> <strike>219</strike> <strike>182</strike> <strike>175</strike> 158 bytes

Non-golfed version (with descriptive variables):

```
#include <math.h>

main (argc, argv) 
    char **argv;
{

    int n, count, max, i, j;
    n = atoi (argv[1]);
    count = 0;
    max = sqrt ((float) n);

    for (i = -max; i <= max; i++)
        for (j = -max; j <= max; j++)
            if (i * i + j * j == n)
                count++;

    printf ("%d", count);
}
```

Golfed version (with short variables):

```
#include<math.h>
main(c,v)char**v;{int n,o,x,i,j;n=atoi(v[1]);o=0;x=sqrt((float)n);for(i=-x;i<=x;i++)for(j=-x;j<=x;j++)if(i*i+j*j==n)o++;printf("%d",o);}
```

**Update** Sorry about the multiple edits, I'm learning how to abuse K&R-style C ;)

Comment: You can remove the sqrt and just set the forloop bounds to -n and +n. This calculates a lot more but is shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 175 bytes

```
#include<iostream> using namespace std; int main() {int i,j,k=0,n; cin>>n; for(i=1;i<n;++i) for(j=1;j<n;++j) if(i*i+j*j==n) ++k; for(i=1;i<=n;++i) if(i*i==n) ++k; cout<<4*k;}
```

Ungolfed

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i,j,k=0,n;
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<n;++i)
 for(j=1;j<n;++j)
  if(i*i+j*j==n)
   ++k;
for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
 if(i*i==n)
  ++k;
cout<<4*k;
}
```

Comment: I hope it's okay now.

Comment: Not quite. 1. Given input of `0`, it gives output of `0`. That's a special case, and should be `1`. 2. It doesn't compile as is. The `#include` needs a newline before the following statement. 3. Some tips: you can remove 11 chars just by cutting out unnecessary whitespace. You can remove more with some basic transformations like `for(i=1;i<n;++i)` being equivalent to `for(i=0;++i<n;)`. If you change the range of the loop over `j` then I think you can eliminate the second loop over `i` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 2.0, <s>110</s> <s>108</s> 107 bytes

```
var n=Int(readLine()!)!,c=0;for(var i = -n;i<=n;i++){for(var j = -n;j<=n;j++){if i*i+j*j==n{c++}}};print(c)
```

First attempt

Comment: I think you could save many bytes by removing whitespace.

Comment: I can only remove two but thanks!

Comment: What about when you create the variables?

Comment: The online swift compiler gives errors in that cases, dont have a mac close atm

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom 115 bytes

```
g(n)==(v:INT:=truncate(sqrt(n)::Float);c:=0;for i in -v..v repeat for j in -v..v repeat if i^2+j^2=n then c:=c+1;c)
```

ungolfed

```
gg(n:NNI):NNI== 
   v:NNI:=truncate(sqrt(n)::Float)
   c:NNI:=0
   for i in -v..v repeat
      for j in -v..v repeat
          if i^2+j^2=n then c:=c+1
   c
```

results

```
(5) -> [i,g(i)]  for i in 0..25
   Compiling function g with type NonNegativeInteger -> NonNegativeInteger
   (5)
   [[0,1], [1,4], [2,4], [3,0], [4,4], [5,8], [6,0], [7,0], [8,4], [9,4],
    [10,8], [11,0], [12,0], [13,8], [14,0], [15,0], [16,4], [17,8], [18,4],
    [19,0], [20,8], [21,0], [22,0], [23,0], [24,0], [25,12]]
                                      Type: Tuple List NonNegativeInteger
```

dobious results

```
(13) -> g(10018)
   (13)  8
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(14) -> g(10019)
   (14)  0
                                                 Type: NonNegativeInteger
(15) -> g(10020)
   (15)  0
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 81 bytes

```c++
#define F(x) for(int x=~n;x++<n;)
void f(int n,int&r){r=0;F(a)F(b)r+=a*a+b*b==n;}
```

Returns via reference parameter. Simply two ranges over `[-n,n]`, so it works for `n=0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
#¹´×+m□ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr//8jwrnCtMOXK23ilqHhuaH///8xMA) or [Verify first 25 values](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr/23igoHFgDI2/yPCucK0w5crbeKWoeG5of//)

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
#¹mṁ□π2ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr//8jwrlt4bmB4pahz4Ay4bmh////MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṄIDṖ²ʂ=
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU4NElEJUUxJUI5JTk2JUMyJUIyJUNBJTgyJTNEJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MjUmZmxhZ3M9Uw==)

##### Explanation

```python
ṄIDṖ²ʂ=  # Implicit input
ṄI       # Push [-input..input]
  DṖ     # Cartesian product
    ²ʂ   # Square and sum
      =  # Equals input?
         # Sum the list
         # Implicit output
```