# Find ranges of True values in a list

Tags: code-golf, array

## Challenge:

Write a function or program that accepts a list of boolean values and returns all of the ranges of True's.

## Test Cases:

```
f [F]                               = []
f [T]                               = [[0,0]]
f [T,T,F,T]                         = [[0,1],[3,3]]
f [F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T]                 = [[1,2],[5,7]]
f [F,T,T,F,F,F,T,T,T,T]             = [[1,2],[6,9]]
f [T,T,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F] = [[0,1],[5,14]]
f [F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T] = [[2,3],[12,19],[33,54],[93,94]]
```

## Rules:

- You may choose how input is encoded, e.g. a list, array, string, etc.
- The output must be encoded as a list-like of list-likes or a string showing such, so arrays, lists, tuples, matrices, vectors, etc.
- The boolean values must be encoded as constants, but otherwise any simple conversion of T/F to desired constants is allowed
- EDIT: *eval* or similar during runtime IS allowed.
- Don't to forget to explain how input is passed to the program/function and give its input/output for the test cases
- Conversion to desired input format not counted
- [Standard loopholes are disallowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- If your language has a function to do this, it's not allowed
- I will not accept my own submission
- EDIT: Output format is flexible. If not printing a list or similar, range values must be separated by one non-numeric character and separate ranges as well.

## Scoring:

- Score is in bytes, unless unfit to your language (such as codels in Piet)
- Lowest score wins

There's a good bit of flexibility in input and output, but solutions where T/F are replaced with functions that do all the work are disallowed.

## Debugging:

If you write yours in Haskell or can call it from Haskell, the following will check your function/program:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

tf = cycle [True,False]
gen l = foldl (++) [] $ map (\i -> [tf!!i | x<-[1..i]]) l
putIn (a,b) l = zipWith (||) l [(a <= p) && (p <= b) | p <- [0..length l]]
putAllIn rs len = foldr putIn [False|i<-[1..len]] rs
main = print $ quickCheck (check functionNameGoesHere)
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see a description of how a range is represented in the output.

Comment: Can the output be 1-indexed?

Comment: Can the ranges be half-exclusive?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Only if your language default is 1-indexed, for example Mathematica

Comment: @ThomasKwa Nope, that seems too different for "edge" cases

Comment: Can the output be 0-indexed if the language is 1-indexed? [Edit: Turns out I don't need it anyway, but someone else might.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, <strike>17</strike> 16 bytes

```
fT.b*Y,~+ZNtZrQ8
```

Uses some fancy post-assign counter magic together with run length encoding.

Takes input as an array of `0`s and `1`s, e.g. `[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]`. Outputs like in the challenge, e.g. `[[0, 1], [3, 3]]`.

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fT.b%2aY%2C~%2BZNtZrQ8&input=%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C0%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%5D&debug=0)

Comment: I added a test suite. If the edit is approved and no one snipes, you have the shortest valid answer.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
CxR.:++~Zkz02_B_`T
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=CxR.%3A%2B%2B~Zkz02_B_%60T&input=%0A0%0A1%0A1101%0A01100111%0A0110001111%0A1100011111111110%0A00110000000011111111000000000000011111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000011&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A1101%0A01100111%0A0110001111%0A1100011111111110%0A00110000000011111111000000000000011111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000011&debug=0)

True is represented as `1`, False as `0`.

Ranges are represented inclusively.

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: Sure, sometime else.

Comment: spoiler alert - it's been 5 years and he never posted it

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/issues), <s>82</s> <s>34</s> 27 bytes

```
\b(?<=(.)*_?)
$#1
_+

S_`:
```

The empty line should contain a single space.

Input is a flat string of `_` for true and `:` for false. Output is space-separated pairs, each on a separate line.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGIoPzw9KC4pKl8_KQokIzEKXysKIApTX2A6&input=Xzo6X186Ojo6Ojo6Ol9fX19fX19fOjo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ol9fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX186Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ol9f)

#### Explanation

The heavy golfing from 82 down to 27 bytes was possible by clever choice of the representation of true and false. I've picked a word character, `_`, (that isn't a digit) for true and a non-word character, `:`, (that doesn't need escaping) for false. That allows me to detect the ends of ranges as word boundaries.

```
\b(?<=(.)*_?)
$#1
```

We match a word boundary. We want to replace that boundary with the corresponding index of the truthy value. In principle that is quite easy with Retina's recent `$#` feature, which counts the number of captures of a group. We simply capture each character in front of that position into a group. By counting those characters we get the position. The only catch is that the ends of the range are off by one now. We actually want the index of the character *in front* the match. That is also easily fixed by optionally matching a `_` which isn't captured, thereby skipping one character when we're at the end of a range.

```
_+
<space>
```

Now we replace all runs of underscores with a space. That is, we insert a space between the beginning and end of each range, while getting rid of the underscores.

```
S_`:
```

That leaves the colons (and we still need to separate pairs). We do that by splitting the entire string into lines around each colon. The `S` actives split mode, and the `_` suppresses empty segments such that don't get tons of empty lines when we have runs of colons.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 17 <s>18</s> <s>20</s> bytes

```
j'T+'1X32X34$2#XX
```

Uses [current version (9.1.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/9.1.0) of the language/compiler.

Input is a string containing characters `T` and `F`. Output is a two-row table, where each column indicates a range using 1-indexing, which is the language default.

Thanks to [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin) for removing 2 bytes.

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > j'T+'1X32X34$2#XX
 >
> FTTFFFTTTT
2 7
3 10
```

#### Explanation

It's based on a simple regular expression:

```
j         % input string
'T+'      % regular expression: match one or more `T` in a row
1X3       % predefined string literal: 'start'
2X3       % predefined string literal: 'end'
4$2#XX    % regexp with 4 inputs (all the above) and 2 outputs (start and end indices)
          % implicitly display start and end indices
```

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 69 bytes

```python
p=i=0
for x in input()+[0]:
 if x-p:b=x<p;print`i-b`+';'*b,
 p=x;i+=1
```

Example output:

```python
2 3; 7 16; 18 18;
```

A direct approach, no built-ins. Tracks the current value `x` and the previous value `p`. When these are different, we've switched runs. On switching `0` to `1`, prints the current index `i`. On switching `1` to `0`, prints the current index minus one followed by a semicolon.

The `if` is pretty smelly. Maybe recursion would be better,

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>34</s> <s>31</s> 25 bytes

Trying a new approach really worked out this time.

```
V=[]Ur"T+"@Vp[YY-1+Xl]};V
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Vj1bXVVyIlQrIkBWcFtZWS0xK1hsXX07Vg==&input=IkZURkZUVFRGVCI=)

Input is an string with `F` for `false` and `T` for `true`. Output is an array of arrays; the string representation makes it look like a single array.

#### How it works

```
          // Implicit: U = input string
V=[]      // Set V to an empty array. (Why don't I have a variable pre-defined to this? :P)
Ur"T+"    // Take each group of one or more "T"s in the input,
@         // and map each matched string X and its index Y to:
Vp[       //  Push the following to an array in V:
Y         //   Y,
Y-1+Xl    //   Y - 1 + X.length.
]};       //  This pushes the inclusive start and end of the string to V.
V         // Implicit: output last expression
```

Note: I now see that several people had already come up with this algorithm, but I discovered it independently.

#### Non-competing version, 22 bytes

```
;Ur"T+"@Ap[YY-1+Xl]};A
```

In the [latest GitHub commit](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt/commit/0e43c90f2853308f4f7f7aca7759dd29a1eac1a5), I've added a new feature: a leading `;` sets the variables `A-J,L` to different values. `A` is set to an empty array, thus eliminating the need to create it manually.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 43 Bytes

```
@(x)reshape(find(diff([0,x,0])),2,[])-[1;2]
```

`find(diff([0,x,0]))` finds all the positions where the input array changes between true and false. By reshaping this into a 2-by-n matrix we achieve two things: The changes from true to false, and from false to true are divided into two rows. This makes it possible to subtract 1 and 2 from each of those rows. Subtracting 1 from row one is necessary because Octave is 1-indexed, not zero-indexed. Subtracting 2 from row two is necessary because the `find(diff())` finds the position of the first false value, while we want the last true value. The subtraction part is only possible in Octave, not in MATLAB.

```
F=0;T=1;
x=[F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T]

reshape(find(diff([0,x,0])),2,[])-[1;2]
ans =    
    2   12   33   93
    3   19   54   94

x=[T,T,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F]
reshape(find(diff([0,x,0])),2,[])-[1;2]
ans =    
    0    5
    1   14
```

Comment: Nice use of broadcasting!

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
0qe`{~~{+}{1$+:X(]pX}?}/;
```

Expects input like `TTFTFT`. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0qe%60%7B~~%7B%2B%7D%7B1%24%2B%3AX%28%5DpX%7D%3F%7D%2F%3B&input=FFTTFFFFFFFFTTTTTTTTFFFFFFFFFFFFFTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFTT).

#### Explanation

```
0                               Push 0, to kick off index
qe`                             Push input and run length encode
                                e.g. FFFFTTTFT -> [[4 'F] [3 'T] [1 'F] [1 'T]]
{                 }/            For each pair in the RLE...
 ~                                Unwrap the pair
  ~                               Evaluate T -> 0 (falsy), F -> 15 (truthy)
   { }{         }?                 Ternary based on T/F
    +                                If 'F: add count to index
       1$+:X(]pX                     If 'T: output inclusive range, updating index
;                               Discard the remaining index at the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
0J0p¯T⁽‹ẇ2ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0J0p%C2%AFT%E2%81%BD%E2%80%B9%E1%BA%872%E1%BA%87&inputs=%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Translation of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214394/98955).

### Explanation

```
0J0p¯T⁽‹ẇ2ẇ
0J             Append 0
  0p          Prepend 0
    ¯         Deltas
     T        Truthy indices
      ⁽ ẇ     Apply to even indices
       ‹        Decrement
         2ẇ   Split into chunks of 2
```

*-1 byte thanks to lyxal*

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0J0p%C2%AFT%E2%81%BD%E2%80%B9%E1%BA%872%E1%BA%87&inputs=%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=) for 11 bytes

Comment: @lyxal Thanks! For some reason I didn't find `p` when searching for "prepend".

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 74 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
map(\l->(fst$l!!0,fst$last l)).wordsBy(not.snd).zip[0..]
```

Usage example: `map(\l->(fst$l!!0,fst$last l)).wordsBy(not.snd).zip[0..] $ [True,False,True,True,False]` -> `[(0,0),(2,3)]`.

How it works:

```
                               -- example input: [True,False,True,True,False]

zip[0..]                       -- pair each element of the input with it's index
                               -- -> [(0,True),(1,False),(2,True),(3,True),(4,False)]
wordsBy(not.snd)               -- split at "False" values into a list of lists
                               -- -> [[(0,True)],[(2,True),(3,True)]]
map                            -- for every element of this list
   (\l->(fst$l!!0,fst$last l)) -- take the first element of the first pair and the
                               -- first element of the last pair
                               -- -> [(0,0),(2,3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 39

```
->s{s.scan(/T+/){p$`.size..s=~/.#$'$/}}
```

Sample invocation:

```
2.2.3 :266 > f=->s{s.scan(/T+/){p$`.size..s=~/.#$'$/}}
 => #<Proc:0x007fe8c5b4a2e8@(irb):266 (lambda)> 
2.2.3 :267 > f["TTFTTFTTTFT"]
0..1
3..4
6..8
10..10
```

The `..` is how Ruby represents inclusive ranges.

The one interesting thing here is how I get the index of the end of the range. It's weird. I dynamically create a regular expression that matches the last character of the range, and then all subsequent characters and the end of the string in order to force the correct match. Then I use `=~` to get the index of that regex in the original string.

Suspect there might be a shorter way to do this in Ruby using the -naF flags.

Answer (score 3):

### J, 26 bytes

```
[:I.&.|:3(<`[/,]`>/)\0,,&0
```

This is an unnamed monadic verb (unary function) that returns a 2D array or integers.
It is used as follows.

```
  f =: [:I.&.|:3(<`[/,]`>/)\0,,&0
  f 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0  1
5 14
```

### Explanation

```
[:I.&.|:3(<`[/,]`>/)\0,,&0
                       ,&0  Append 0 to input
                     0,     then prepend 0.
        3(         )\       For each 3-element sublist (a b c):
               ]`>/           Compute b>c
          <`[/                Compute a<b
              ,               Concatenate them
                            Now we have a 2D array with 1's on left (right) column
                            indicating starts (ends) or 1-runs.
[:I.&.|:                    Transpose, get indices of 1's on each row, transpose back.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>12</strike> <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
;0ŻIT’Ðes2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/a4Ohuz5BHDTMPT0gtNvr//3@0gY6BjiEQGqBBQzRogBMakgANqAiB5sUCAA)

Accepts a list of zeros and ones. Outputs a list of 1-based ranges.

### Explanation

Using [1,1,0,1] as an example.

```
;0ŻIT’Ðes2   Main monadic link
;0           Append a zero: [1,1,0,1,0]
  Ż          Prepend a zero: [0,1,1,0,1,0]
   I         Increments: [1,0,-1,1,-1]
    T        Indices of truthy alements: [1,3,4,5]
      Ðe     Apply to even indices:
     ’         Decrement: [1,2,4,4]
        s2   Split into groups of two: [[1,2],[4,4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
m-VdU2cx1aV+ZQ+QZ2
```

Explanation:

```
             implicit: Q=input
m            map lambda d:
  -V         Vectorized subtraction by [0,1]
     d
     U2     
c            split every 2 elements
  x            find all indexes of
    1          1s
    aV         in vectorized xor:
       +ZQ     Q with a 0 on the front
       +QZ     Q with a 0 on the end
  2
```

Try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2Chdtedcx1aV%2BZQ%2BQZ2&input=1%0A0%0A0010%0A10011000%0A1001110000%0A0011100000000001%0A11001111111100000000111111111111100000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111100&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+1%5D%0A%5B0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59

An anonymous function, input as a string of `T` and `F`, returning output as an array of arrays

```js
x=>x.replace(/T+/g,(a,i)=>o.push([i,a.length+i-1]),o=[])&&o
```

**TEST**

```js
f=x=>x.replace(/T+/g,(a,i)=>o.push([i,a.length+i-1]),o=[])&&o

// TEST

arrayOut=a=>`[${a.map(e=>e.map?arrayOut(e):e).join`,`}]`

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[
  'F','T','TTFT','FTTFFTTT','FTTFFFTTTT','TTFFFTTTTTTTTTTF',
  'FFTTFFFFFFFFTTTTTTTTFFFFFFFFFFFFFTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFTT'
].forEach(t=>console.log(t+'\n'+arrayOut(f(t))+'\n'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Wow, I just came up with the same solution in Japt and was about to translate it to JS. Nice one :)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 47 bytes

```
s/F*(T*)(T)F*/[$-[0],$+[1]],/g;chop$_;$_="[$_]"
```

With the following perlrun options `-lpe`:

```
$ perl -lpe's/F*(T*)(T)F*/[$-[0],$+[1]],/g;chop$_;$_="[$_]"' <<< 'TTFFFTTTTTTTTTTF'
[[0,1],[5,14]]
```

Alternative where output is line separated (34 bytes):

```
$ perl -pE's/F*(T*)(T)F*/$-[0] $+[1]\n/g;chomp' <<< TTFFFTTTTTTTTTTF
0 1
5 15
```

Answer (score 2):

## , 18 chars / 28 bytes

```
ïħ`T+`,↪ᵖ[_,$Ꝉ+‡_]
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=TTFT&code=%C3%AF%C4%A7%60T%2B%60%2C%E2%86%AA%E1%B5%96%5B_%2C%24%EA%9D%88%2B%E2%80%A1_%5D)</kbd>

## Explanation

```
ïħ`T+`,↪ᵖ[_,$Ꝉ+‡_] // implicit: ï=input
ïħ`T+`,            // for each T-sequence...
       ↪ᵖ[_,$Ꝉ+‡_] // push [start index of sequence, end index of sequence] to the stack
                   // implicit stack output
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 62 bytes

```haskell
f l|s<-zip3[0..](0:l)$l++[0]=zip[i|(i,0,1)<-s][i-1|(i,1,0)<-s]
```

Takes as input a list of 0's and 1's.

Given the list `l`, pads it with 0 on both sides and computes the indexed list of consecutive pairs. For example

```haskell
l = [1,1,0]
s = [(0,0,1),(1,1,1),(2,1,0),(3,0,0)]
```

Then, extract the indices corresponding to consecutive elements `(0,1)` and `(1,0)`, which are the starts of blocks of 0 and 1, subtracting 1 from the starts of 0 to get the ends of 1, and zips the results.

Comment: Wow, that bends syntax more than I thought Haskell would take. Is it equivalent to "f l=let s=zip3[0..](0:l)(l++[0]) in zip[i|(i,0,1)<-s][i-1|(i,1,0)<-s]"?

Comment: @MichaelKlein Yes, I learned of the trick of binding in guards [from nimi here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64846/20260). It's also equivalent to the longer binding-via-lambda `f l=(\s->zip[i|(i,0,1)<-s][i-1|(i,1,0)<-s])$zip3[0..](0:l)$l++[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

### APL, 17 chars

```
{(↑,↑∘⊖)¨⍵⊂⍵×⍳⍴⍵}
```

In `⎕IO←0` and `⎕ML←3`.
In English:

- `⍵×⍳⍴⍵`: zero out the elements of the index vector as long as the argument where the argument is false
- `⍵⊂`: cut at the beginning of each run of truths and throw away the false's
- `(↑,↑∘⊖)¨`: take the first and last element of each subarray

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell: 123 bytes (Example, cannot win)

```
f l=[(s,e)|let m=length l-1,let r=[0..m],s<-r,e<-r,and[l!!x|x<-[s..e]],s<=e,let(#)p=not$l!!p,s==0||(#)(s-1),e==m||(#)(e+1)]
```

Less golfed:

```
f l = [(start,end) | start <- [0..max], end <- [0..max], allTrue start end, start <= end, notBelow start, notAbove end]
  where
    max = (length l) - 1
    allTrue s e = and (subList s e)
    subList s e = [l !! i | i <- [s,e]]
    notBelow  s = (s == 0) || (not (l !! (s-1)))
    notAbove  e = (s == m) || (not (l !! (e+1)))
```

Comment: Even when not golfing:  `allTrue s e = and (subList s e)` or maybe  `allTrue = (and.) . sublist`.

Comment: Ok, for a reason I don't remember, I thought that was more "clear" when I was ungolfing... (Edited)

Comment: Oh, sure, opinions differ on what's "clear". I also think `all (==True) (subList s e)` is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 108 bytes

```
l=input();l+=[0];o=[];s=k=0
for i,j in enumerate(l):s=j*~k*i or s;~j*l[i-1]and o.append([s,i-1]);k=j
print o
```

Test cases:

```
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[0]
[]
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[-1]
[[0, 0]]
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[-1,-1,0,-1]
[[0, 1], [3, 3]]
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[0,-1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1]
[[1, 2], [5, 7]]
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[0,-1,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1]
[[1, 2], [6, 9]]
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[-1,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0]
[[0, 1], [5, 14]]
$ python2 rangesinlists2.py
[0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1]
[[2, 3], [12, 19], [33, 54], [93, 94]]
```

Surely there's a shorter solution than this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 30 bytes

```
0l~0++2ewee{1=$2,=},{~0=-}%2/`
```

Input as a CJam-style array of `0`s and `1`s. Output as a CJam-style array of pairs.

[Run all test cases.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7BS%2F1%3D%22FT%2C%22%2201%20%22er%3AL%3B%0A%0A0L~0%2B%2B2ewee%7B1%3D%242%2C%3D%7D%2C%7B~0%3D-%7D%252%2Fp%0A%0A%5Do%7D%2F&input=f%20%5BF%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Af%20%5BT%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C0%5D%5D%0Af%20%5BT%2CT%2CF%2CT%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B3%2C3%5D%5D%0Af%20%5BF%2CT%2CT%2CF%2CF%2CT%2CT%2CT%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B5%2C7%5D%5D%0Af%20%5BF%2CT%2CT%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B6%2C9%5D%5D%0Af%20%5BT%2CT%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CF%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%2C14%5D%5D%0Af%20%5BF%2CF%2CT%2CT%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CT%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CF%2CT%2CT%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5B2%2C3%5D%2C%5B12%2C19%5D%2C%5B33%2C54%5D%2C%5B93%2C94%5D%5D) (Takes care of the conversion of the input formats.)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 27 bytes

```
A=[];Ur"T+"@Ap[YXl +´Y]};A·
```

There has to be a way to golf this down...

Anyway, it's the same as my  answer.

Comment: Wow, I just came up with this solution myself.... Nice algorithm!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
§zeW<om←W>`:0Θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DyqtRwm/zcR20Twu0SrAzOzfj//3@0gY6BjiEQGqBBQzRogBMakgANqAiB5sUCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 19 bytes

```
+&:'+{y&~x,z}.'-3':
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KW81KXbu6Uq2uQqeqVk9d11jd6n@auoZBkrUhEBkaAEkDIAXEMBaICZGDMCEAqMEAIg0GcGFkYIgVGBAFgFZq/gcA)

Uses `-n':` (window) so the inner `{y&!x,z}` function has access to the previous (`x`), current (`y`), and next (`z`) value in the input boolean list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
TI’kƊ.ịⱮ$ḢẠ?U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/E81HDzOxjXXoPd3c/2rhO5eGORQ93LbAP/X@4/VHTmqOTHu6c8f9/NBdntEGsjgJ@oKxgqxAdC1RqSJzSaAMdg1iweh1DHQMdfLpg6oFqoo11jMG6gDywPgiNTTdEl6GOEVCXqY45mi6oPgydyLrMdCyRXIikBwWCggbZhaY6hiZQy5CtQ0AMA3BCQxKgARUhKFigfjIChrdOtKGRjqElKPSNdUxNgLSlsY4lyJOxAA)

+4 bytes to handle the all `0`s test cases. Without that, a much cleaner [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/E81HDzOxjXXoPd3c/2rgu9P/h9kdNa45Oerhzxv//0Vyc0YaxOgr4gbKCrUJ0tIGOQWwsSL2OoY6BDj5dMPVANdHGOsZgXUAeWB@ExqYbostQxwioy1THHE0XVB@GTmRdZjqWSC5E0oMCDYAmILvQVMfQBGoZsnUIiGEATmhIAjSgIgQFC9RPRsDw1ok2NNIxtASFvrGOqQmQtjTWsQR5MhYA). This uses 1 indexing, which is Jelly's default.

### How it works

```
TI’kƊ.ịⱮ$ḢẠ?U - Main link
T             - Indices of truthy elements
    Ɗ         - Group the previous links into a monad f(T):
 I            -   Increments
  ’           -   Decrement
   k          -   Partition T at truthy indexes in the decremented increments

                This returns [[]] for [0] (and repeats) and
                [[a, b], [c, d, e], ...] for every other input

           ?  - If:
          Ạ   -   Condition: All truthy?
        $     -   If:
       Ɱ      -     For each partition:
     .ị       -       Take the 0.5th element
         Ḣ    -   Else: Return []

                For non-integer left argument, x, Jelly's ị atom takes
                floor(x) and ceil(x) and returns [floor(x)ịy, ceil(x)ịy]
                As Jelly's indexing is 1-based and modular:
                  0ị returns the last element
                  1ị returns the first element
                  .ị returns [0ị, 1ị]

            U - Reverse, as the ranges yielded by .ị are "reversed"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
m§e←→ġo=→ηf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fQ8tRHbRMetU06sjDfFkid2572////aAMdAx1DIDRAg4Zo0AAnNCQBGlARAs2LBQA)

```
m§e←→ġo=→ηf
         ηf     # get truthy indices
     ġo=→       # group runs of adjacent values
m               # then, for each group
 §e←→           # get the first & last elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Uses `0/1` for `F/T`.

```
Åγ.¥ü2sÏ€εN-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5zXqHlh7eY1R8uP9R05pzW/10//@PNtAx0DEEQgM0aIgGDXBCQxKgARUh0LxYAA)

`Åγ` run-length encodes the input, pushing the chunk elements and the chunk lengths.
`.¥` takes the cumulative sum of the chunck lengths and prepends a 0.
`ü2` creates pairs of all adjacent numbers in this list.
`s` swaps to the list of chunk elements.
`Ï` selects each pair which is at the same index as a truthy chunk. The selected pairs are now the half-inclusive truthy range `[a, b)`.
`€ε` iterates over every number in every range, and `N-` subtracts the 0-based index from each number to get the inclusive ranges.

[Try it with step-by-step output!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5zQpAoKQABkGlebo5qXnpJRkKqXnJ@SmpVgpK9pouCcX2SgqJeSlAjk5RAheX3qGlSJqAwLk0tzQnsSSzLFWhuDQXpMmWi@vwHiNUVY4pWYnJqXklCgWJmUXFUFXFh/vBqoJTc1KTSxQSSxRKikpLMioVkjNK87Jhqh41rTm31U@3Fm5acGlSSVEiUENmXkpmcipE3f//0YY6hjoGYGiIBRrEAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ẏ‡?iŻv₍gG
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuo/igKE/acW7duKCjWdHIiwiIiwiWzAsMSwwLDEsMSwxLDAsMV0iXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 82 bytes

```powershell
("$args"|sls 't+'-A).Matches|%{if($_){'{0},{1}'-f$_.Index,($_.Index+$_.Length-1)}}
```

Regex solution, using [MatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.aspx) object's properties.

## Example

```
PS > .\BoolRange.ps1 'F'


PS > .\BoolRange.ps1 'T'
0,0

PS > .\BoolRange.ps1 'TTFFFTTTTTTTTTTF'
0,1
5,14
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
SequencePosition[#,{True..},Overlaps->False]&
```

Not particularly interesting; uses a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

**Clojure, 109 chars**

```
#(first(reduce(fn[[r i]p](let[e(+(count p)i)][(if(first p)(conj r[i(dec e)])r)e]))[[]0](partition-by not %)))
```

The first thing that came to my mind, based on `reduce` and `partition-by`.

Simple test case (maps `T` to `true` and `F` to `false`):

```
(def f #(first(reduce(fn[[r i]p](let[e(+(count p)i)][(if(first p)(conj r[i(dec e)])r)e]))[[]0](partition-by not %))))
(f (map #(= 'T %) '[F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of bits.

```
ð òÈnYÉÃmg[TJ]
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8CDyyG5ZycNtZ1tUSl0&input=WzAsMCwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMV0KLVE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>181</s> <s>169</s> 121

```
a->{int f=-1,p=0;for(int c:a.toCharArray()){if(c<49&f>=0){System.out.println(f+","+~-p);f=-1;}f=c>48&f<0?p:f;p++;}};
```

#### Execute:

```
java T 1100011111111110
```

#### Output:

```
0,1
5,14
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc9Na8MwDAbgc/wrTA/FJo1xoIe1TjJGzzv1WHrQ3HhzltjGUQolZH89S9iHTpIQL48auEPW3D5n2wUfkTbLLAa0rTCD02i9Eyfv@qGroyJEt9D39BWsoyNJSNIjoNX076I4Y7TuvaKmJDNk1WgdLn2W70IplfGRrQt9BIH@9AHxJUZ4MM5Ha5gu9oetqUrJx/Ojx7oTfkARljxsHTPpZrdJv7LA1ZqnJlPqav@0NYV8DkejQpqqaVJzEoa3dhH9wu7e3mi3cNmP7HKlwFd6sv4gjACt64AMLvLKFUkmMpF5znMpZf5f8hs)

#### Explained

```
  int f=-1,                               // index of first '1' of current range
      p=0;                                // current position in the input array
  for(int c:a[0].toCharArray()){          // loop over the input from the command line (int & char are exchangeable here
    if(c<49&f>=0){                        // 48='0'; current=0 and we had a '1' range 
      System.out.println(f+","+~-p);      // print first and current-1
      f=-1;                               // we are no longer in a 1 range
    }  
    f=c>48&f<0?                           // 49='1'; if current='1' and is first of new range, 
        p                                 // let f start here
        :f                                // otherwise f unchanged
    p++;                                  // increase current index counter
  }                                       // end of for loop
};                                        // end of function
```

#### Edits:

181 -> 169 : interface instead of class; f==-1 -> f<0

169 -> 121 : added suggestions of @ceilingcat and reduced it to a function

121 -> 116 : small, nice improvements, thanks @ceilingcat

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
Tḟ+¥ⱮØ+Z
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list and yields a list of start, end pairs of truthy runs (1-indexed, as Jelly is).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/k4Y752oeWPtq47vAM7aj///9HG@gY6oCwIYSOBQA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/k4Y752oeWPtq47vAM7aj/h9uPTnq4c4Zm5P//0dEGsVw60YZgQsdQx0AHzARSYA6ERhOCCuogaUISRIEGEJ3IehEQQzFOaEgCNKAiBPsxFgA).

#### How?

```
Tḟ+¥ⱮØ+Z - Link: list, A
T        - Truthy indices of A -> t
     Ø+  - [1,-1]
    Ɱ    - map (for n in [1,-1]) with:
   ¥     -   last two links as a dyad f(t, n):
  +      -     t add n (vectorises)
 ḟ       -     t filter discard those
       Z - transpose
```

i.e. get a pair of lists of:

1. indices of truthy values with no truthy value to their right (run starts); and
2. indices of truthy values with no truthy value to their left  (run ends)

...and transpose that to a list of `[run start, run end]` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

## Knight, <sup>62</sup> 61 bytes

```c
;=i 0;=s T;W;=i+i 1=nP;=nEn&|&s n&!s!n;O Is i-i 1=s!s&!sO-i 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4qxU9gavySS4Kq2EDJFspCijkAWkssH8CVClkG18tgnybAccH89193zopFtcpe7DVWSZqZfn@np7nHi4U0cf3@VijhbTpK9opyk89e3o6Y9k6XXtam4fFgkK0R5Km5qU2U6kzSTZJqKhGUZy@bihh5NM/vp9PMH5lXDi0/nzK@Gfzs4ZzvV8Oj0HfulGp5/Zl5FfHRyYdGefj6xSD@ffji4@KtTcObgo8P@5f2Fm9WDC1ArF@PbKGc9XjHYVGCrETEasZ1q7fTwCy4KWCSPnhh@7@2t0KAaokE3gSbLOBLWaN6enZ0QET72ycld9M0y5Py9JAB@y9a7KFsmnF@KMW82yQ/YlctxeN4@PDtyvgdhytwgLNin4At891PmheJjEIpD0XnqFEx0WkVLBGfsuGDpEFeLVgFzZ/j9nYOMdiDF9kBuEs1YiAqCZhOsWER5kTicPTYbqShZGjQbMEsWDVhvuhQxzBBzDONythgUC3Hpj8NHd@A@g4xGCuKIHt4uTrx5g@LTBbu/TcukWERx0mzAd5Y4MA/sjjRjwNpX5ZW4ml7l7PH5cuzw3VdtTqY00ilzjLUh677qciZF6NkWzF4JmO735QzY2UiyIrEnnqU58W0S/86m85yJ5ew6yQtlD3PSYpLepKWWCtrRHW9gPJLvHvNc1mc9ZXm/z9mQdd0uqEBLU87ypFzmgukYkmwURsGqDXdRnkbXWaKtACOy@X2SOzHo04awpyemjYtpFBMQX7tcwZNucD0NvQHsUWimV6zDU6miF0jEZLlwcEuZwnTIYLRusMwRhZQmzbjqdiub2l25acAMHhijGAiBnALfYNkiKkpW3iYgLMpLIFYb0NOI4obGHD3RxlpH7UVj4elx2uhGBQaZj6FbpnMBZmPEumMwLdaIFMvFAgHnOqr0jA2/HX8AuwU2ytChvBAQx5DfMHKV5RKVT12TBOTEEU5grtvFHIdm6iCj9ChdddBuNDXKsnns7LgDj6ODOG2cIAfFMsui/MF2tNqfc2t7PnaNZaRQ8S/FCjep8FCFSgqbPD04fPvu22@tk1/PLIdtsdfpRrn@utxWTfD744sXJJZJTiIjMWH/WEZ6iGLvbBXb6yokAO@7BovjDVgQ806duU7zTKkyXwrcoUDl6F45LxydK@kAQGiXacxo9Xo5vfR3xsoOudEdSg/GgGIBx6qcOkAK/m9l2aSt8w7VqAEKWRUAh8IIkNVP6q/R7TFvu@4nOo@xuM/aZb5M2hCDZh5DEuanEWQQXGhjZLUrENBP9F2VKYLj69v5PIOV6zoCL/paufUjh3o/75Ft5vWamRnaKP5UGyFoy3mWObapA@YOoEL8DyaLNZOxCn84@Hg6wFosAw2Gx5ee67oQTuAKDPWoSP@ZfC0ZvgIrRi1vEQEYDfDh03M79HRJxwyHVR1f9PTlaxsIjo5PDntsCskxaJjQVvowDcfRYpAlgjoACyvdRUnM4Ny9BMYqI9YmLG1YcJyUegmoxXuERQBFJcVFkzfi2WJlBwikdFylEIQpHaOa4j4t41unB8isNV2AEVP/YqxT3YPuLkMtkiBEQLFtgyzMO@SUEq8ax1rI8oCqcEVB3WmZY@miBvVyzB@rMIMGinK7VHwOiuuyc8h4Du@4f0zxX0X5EShBqsToJikz6C2dDu1lB3cIS@QkFTxIp45D@4kNQXyboy0DiFPO5TaHbrDRVnhxagOkvkOpT3aOmA0UIIG2F0FSubOy8m3lj6Q3K@@qFeS0ITY034AGowHiL1zMF4lwLMWDdt6mVgGsCmeyUkI8hr678wvNq@bCkR3JFEyfoFPQwkHIDrC/A3LoHWiEOkC1Di8HJlk/pFYITyxQcgU3yCFdBDVK6IXMt3uWCsbKk9/Ak@QPaOPwtK/52artOl0hWpjJ1ghP1sIDtGR1XCzyX7u7qk/cEMgm86kK1D6lttjBGsR1ERqNdnjVWK6lQ816Qc2hs1UgY/0wrDMDnND62Hohk/J2RaoXsLwkkVBiXyphqmbZO6Byi0LhrEIBD4a8@CBocj9r0LFOh@5dwyGSjmWbe0XtdkObtfW6V4A9Dow400ctt8xfloXefRMTsteTBvWNQZQnIV9iSsbQsrZHdtON@m7LSyxSQ9/PdCz5cs@x/6XDIDeAqHAaT3movfT55lCNo1K/VNfp9SuYuP5GWRy60QG9S5UjlF/Dtei0oh1b9bq9kqlX7c4GFFbL8wYcems4yH3dhMJsg2s9ogltIcQANcihDBl2r@CSh0TBcEjyFFBUMlc3WiJa1k7/mx8C82YzMFs/ZNrazPR3QrPmkLw60Jxvexko2CXqIRt6BmWiBeg9OGdDD86YZxP7P0m9B@mxRhuGSEp6d/WMqyEnoP2Rq7D2ObUrvZDwb64eCFokV@COQAkWSwx845XhNsmTbsHEHHroNCtTwe6jB8CNTeZwJy2TmyQHnsVcJKJMI7xFwEmes/uE3UZ3CRAqQUheslkklhA@D69xFr27RsQBCkKiWGYl/mhAyk3C0yRDm0arXIHM5jMkK@JR3suU7suGGLK9GpVL9/Mow9r4AF6LSZZM2LfK7G9GyiN@ycbMUlI5M0Jhw6EecyJvKNKeZfqzyYN7FKwrhQ@TXi0vhvWsuM/sw79nHwNk3VU/z3WYJNhntUaRJgfMyoYow5WcuuT6sg4gbSuEamN1QSM4lBha88l8l82SWbzAMBNs9G3//3Vl9Ce4MtKutDb4EipflCv7L6MvtW4wGZf3WY3ANxS@LqCtTXZWA@Oezjy2AGNep0p/6Mum2rBvc6pUYvif/ht@lYMsMYY/6O7a1LU2d5U2rLJuffmnLzK6t61uMkjXqN1mTCokGpQ4DmvcVppEDqTo9w2bNPkLuCd/9bIbzZp3zO5dFNtxvWtHUot/39/dtmB5L68ModVh9e0CtH5HEuriMTBnYbvW0F5IoFeEBqslz99U8ra56QN8w71Dk/@hIULD8I1bEZvm37RDdm/kg4eote9hk0QNgox/uUgvouirkwDaJ8k0giQJnukOMxWwmE7oR6QoLqFMdbfiLvacOMPZC7dYFGZqIHSD6oeEWZQKbFZZlN/EAxLa68H3Hcefq@h@if/b47hkTf0a9/zda7rw59Gf@vo3)

*-1 thanks to Steffan*

Uses 1 indexing.

### how

```c
;=i 0          # Set i = 0
;=s T          # Set s (for "searching for a 1" to true)
;W;=i+i 1=nP   # While reading a line of input "n" and 
               # storing it in n, and incrementing i...
;=nEn          # Coerce "n" to a number, so we can use
               # it as a boolean (string "1" would be false)
&|&s n &!s !n  # If we're "searching" and found a 1 or
               # are not searching and found a 0...
;O Is i-i 1    # output the current index when searching, 
               # or the current index - 1 otherwise.
=s!s           # and toggle "searching" status
&!sO-i 1       # if we end on a 1, output again the
               # final index - 1
```

Comment: You can use `E` (evaluate) instead of `+0`.