# Prime Challenge

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, primes

*CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?*

```
6779686932717976703238326711110010511010332671049710810810111010310111558327311032116111100971213911532991049710810810111010310144321211111173910810832981013297115107101100321161113211211410511011632116104101321021111081081111191051101033211810111412132115112101991059710832657868321161141059910712132657868321159711610511510212110511010332801141051091013278117109981011144646463332651141013212111111732103111108102101114115321141019710012163
```

**Your task is to output this 442-digit Prime Number**

**Rules**

Your code must not contain any odd decimal digits. So numbers 1,3,5,7,9 (ASCII 49,51,53,55,57) are forbidden.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest code in bytes wins.

So... what is so special about this prime number anyway?
You may find this out yourselves. If you don't, I'll tell you next week!

**EDIT**
Since this challenge is going to close, I will give a hint to my friend @xnor:
The challenge IS the number (this is why it is called "Prime Challenge")

Comment: Whatever is special about this number presumably helps in shortening the code.  Once an answer finds out the others can do the same. So I don't see the point in hiding that information in the challenge

Comment: @LuisMendo I believe this happens in many challenges. One user may find a shortcut which other users may use...Also this information is part of the puzzle and it is not guaranteed that it will lead to the shortest answer..

Comment: I think challenges like this that are partly a puzzle in disguise are both a bad idea for the reasons Luis Mendo said, and likely off-topic for the site.

Comment: @xnor one week ago, a same question about a random number "Print a Ternary Value" was not treated this way. At least this one is a meaningful number

Comment: @J42161217 Right, I think the key difference is that the ternary number is indeed random and has nothing secret up its sleeve. I've seen a number of attempts at challenges that start as basically "solve the puzzle of what pattern I made", and I remember them having been downvoted.

Comment: @xnor This challenge is about this site. It's not a "pattern". I gave some effort to make this. If you feel like downvoting it, please do so.

Comment: Maybe stuff like this about figuring out puzzles/patterns would work better in a Cops and Robbers challenge instead. Just a thought.

Comment: As per the comments above, I think that this type of challenges should be avoided in general. Please [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19231/36398) as you see fit. @xnor I borrowed your very graphic expression "a puzzle in disguise"

Comment: @LuisMendo many challenges have hidden math formulas and after the first one who finds it, everybody else state "this is a port of that answer...". Am I right?

Comment: @J42161217 There are different degrees of "lack of information". If there is just one possible formula or pattern and the challenge hides it, I argue that's not interesting here. If there are several approaches, not all of which are suggested in the challenge, that's fine. For instance, [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88732/36398) states some basic characterizations, but some answers found golfier ones. That's different. No essential information was hidden on purpose by the challenge writer, and the challenge could be well solved with the information provided

Comment: @LuisMendo I bet that someone can solve this one like a `kolmogorov` and do better than the existing answers. I think you should try ;-)

Comment: Now that Guiseppe has solved the puzzle and revealed the pattern, I have to say I'm disappointed in the task that remains. Like, perhaps the puzzle was interesting for Guiseppe or anyone who wants to solve it, but for a golfer it's now basically "hardcode/compress this fixed string". It's cool that you found a prime that's produced this way, but it being prime doesn't matter at all for golfing. I was hoping there would be something special mathematically about this prime, but as is, I think the challenge text's emphasis on it being prime makes this even more a chameleon challenge.

Comment: @xnor how do you know there isn't anything cool mathematically about this prime? Remember the "taxi number".?

Comment: D'you know what? Against my better judgement, I'm gonna throw you a `+1` based purely on the work you must've put into it.

Comment: @J42161217 Are you saying there is something mathematically cool? Is it something that helps for golfing?

Comment: @xnor Every number is cool but we must try hard to find that coolness. Give it a try!

Comment: Given the "secret" the forbidden characters seem a bit non-sequitur-y.

Comment: @gastropner how do you know that a solution like `224^226 + 0!` (this is just an example) doesn't really exist?

Comment: @J42161217 If such a solution existed, then it must have been known in advance. It would be a dear coincidence to have the number be both such a specific string, as well as having such a numerical solution. All is possible, I suppose, especially since I suspect that aspect will never be known.

Comment: I can't change my upvote unless this post is edited :(

Comment: I personally prefer this challenge to stay open, it's a simple number compression challenge (which forces you to compress it by disabling some numbers).

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive I'd say this is a simple `CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?` compression challenge

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Not really. I highly suspect there are some kind of integer compression method better than two-digits-a-character, like what the OP stated.

Comment: Now this question have a score of -2... But it's +10/-12, so enough people supports the OP. I'm happy to see this.

Answer (score 16):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 195 bytes

(SPOILER IF YOU WANT TO FIGURE IT OUT YOURSELF)

> ```r
> cat(utf8ToInt("CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"),sep="")
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCoJAFEV/5eYiFcR1BBGiFUFki35g1KcOjjPyZizm6y2DdofL4R5ellq4aHbt7mmu2kVBXhYnXMrbGVvkppG6Q94LpUh3ZPe4ajjTCB9a1P85gTdzqBQqgrADNV8FE0vt4HpCa5Qy7/XoRexhJ6qlUMjuBRzLevA/tMJJ2/pVe7AcCfd5rIjTNN0gY1oT6IxqiS2YROOPQZxYmg5BEC/LBw)

Not the golfiest language to use for [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity), but it does the trick.

Comment: Well done! But -sigh- (**SPOILER**) then the challenge not only hides the pattern; it also tries to mislead the reader with red herrings in the title (the key idea is not related to _prime numbers_) and in the rules (not being able to use _odd digits_ doesn't add any difficulty)

Answer (score 5):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 206 bytes

Binary:

> ```
> 00000000: be24 01b1 aaac d40a 5086 e0d4 0a05 3030  .$......P.....00
> 00000010: 86e0 3c30 7402 cd29 86e0 cd29 5804 30cd  ..<0t..)...)X.0.
> 00000020: 29e2 e2c3 434f 4445 2047 4f4c 4620 2620  )...CODE GOLF &
> 00000030: 436f 6469 6e67 2043 6861 6c6c 656e 6765  Coding Challenge
> 00000040: 733a 2049 6e20 746f 6461 7927 7320 6368  s: In today's ch
> 00000050: 616c 6c65 6e67 652c 2079 6f75 276c 6c20  allenge, you'll
> 00000060: 6265 2061 736b 6564 2074 6f20 7072 696e  be asked to prin
> 00000070: 7420 7468 6520 666f 6c6c 6f77 696e 6720  t the following
> 00000080: 7665 7279 2073 7065 6369 616c 2041 4e44  very special AND
> 00000090: 2074 7269 636b 7920 414e 4420 7361 7469   tricky AND sati
> 000000a0: 7366 7969 6e67 2050 7269 6d65 204e 756d  sfying Prime Num
> 000000b0: 6265 722e 2e2e 2120 4172 6520 796f 7520  ber...! Are you
> 000000c0: 676f 6c66 6572 7320 7265 6164 793f       golfers ready?
> ```

Listing:

> ```
> BE 0124   MOV  SI, OFFSET TXT     ; string offset
> B1 AA     MOV  CL, 170            ; string length
>       CHAR_LOOP:
> AC        LODSB                   ; AL = next char
> D4 0A     AAM                     ; AL = AL % 10, AH = AL / 10
> 50        PUSH AX                 ; save units digits
> 86 E0     XCHG AH, AL             ; swap digits
> D4 0A     AAM                     ; AL = AL % 10, AH = AL / 10
> 05 3030   ADD  AX, '00'           ; ASCII convert
> 86 E0     XCHG AH, AL             ; swap digits
> 3C 30     CMP  AL, '0'            ; is highest digit a '0'?
> 74 02     JZ   TWODIG             ; if so, don't display leading zero
> CD 29     INT  29H                ; display hundreds digit
>       TWODIG:
> 86 E0     XCHG AH, AL             ; swap digits
> CD 29     INT  29H                ; display tens digit
> 58        POP  AX                 ; restore units digit
> 04 30     ADD  AL, '0'            ; ASCII convert
> CD 29     INT  29H                ; display units digit
> E2 E2     LOOP CHAR_LOOP          ; loop until end of string
> C3        RET                     ; return to DOS
>       TXT:
>           DB 'CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today',27H,'s challenge, '
>           DB 'you',27H,'ll be asked to print the following very special '
>           DB 'AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?'
> ```

[image]

Comment: The trick with multi-line spoilers is to put two spaces at the end of every line. Otherwise it all gets garbled onto one line.

Comment: Hmm. Both ASM listing and machine code contain odd numbers, which were forbidden.

Comment: @gastropner, no the challenge specifically forbids `ASCII 49,51,53,55,57`.  Codepoint `\x01` != `'1'` :)

Comment: @640KB Ah, I see! I saw the 1 in the text, which corresponds to 0xB1. My bad!

Answer (score 4):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 186 bytes

> ```
> "CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"foreach(print)
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3RCoIwGEZf5auLLAgfoJsQrQhCe4W5/dPh3GSbxZ5@qdDd4ePwHWVT2pdNdcOjed1xQGmFMh3KnmlNpiN/wdMgWMFi5sH/8xnRzpnWaAnMDyQWBZNTJiD0BGm1tt/16EMuwk/EFdMo6grBKT7EDT0Lysu4am@nRkI9jy25PM93KBytCXRWS3IejpiI1720C/D@uKVOKf0A)

### Explanation

> Io's default syntax for defining strings actually defines a "sequence", that is basically a list of ord codes.

> During foreach, Io treats every character of the sequence as it's respective ord code (don't believe it? try [`"abc"at(0)`](https://tio.run/##y8z//18pMSlZSSGxRMNAU6GgKDOvJCfv/38A))

> ```
> "..."               // The big string, from other answers
>      foreach(     ) // For every codepoint in this string:
>              print  //     output this codepoint without a newline
> ```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 93 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
”›ˆ‚³...!€™”‘€ƒ‘D”Âïªï:€†”‘ƒËŠˆ‘“ÿ & ÿƒÜ's›Ý,€î'll€ï‹Ð€„…¢€€„—‚ÒƒÑ ÿÐËy ÿËØing ÿ€îŠˆersŽä?“ÇJ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw27Trc9aph1aLOenp7io6Y1j1oWgYVnANnHJgFpFyD3cNPh9YdWHV5vBVLQsACi4Nikw91HF4B0z3jUMOfwfgU1hcP7gYJz1IuBph6eqwNUfHidek4OiF7/qGHn4Qlg7fMeNSw7tAjEhPKmAO0/PAmocyLQgMMTDndXgujuwzMy89KBLLAxIItSi4qP7j28xB5kW7vX//8A)

**Explanation:**

> ```python
> ”›ˆ‚³...!€™”  # Push (titlecased) dictionary string "Prime Number...! Are"
> ‘€ƒ‘D         # Push (uppercased) dictionary string "AND" and duplicate it
> ”Âïªï:€†”     # Push (titlecased) dictionary string "Coding Challenges: In"
> ‘ƒËŠˆ‘        # Push (uppercased) dictionary string "CODE GOLF"
> “ÿ & ÿƒÜ's›Ý,€î'll€ï‹Ð€„…¢€€„—‚ÒƒÑ ÿÐËy ÿËØing ÿ€îŠˆersŽä?“
>               # Push (regular) dictionary string "ÿ & ÿ today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special ÿ tricky ÿ satisfying ÿ you golfers ready?",
>               # where the ÿ are automatically filled with the strings on the stack
> Ç             # Convert each character to its codepoint integer
> J             # And join all those together
>               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
> ```

> [See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”›ˆ‚³...!€™”` is `"Prime Number...! Are"`; `‘€ƒ‘` is `"AND"`; `”Âïªï:€†”` is `"Coding Challenges: In"`; `‘ƒËŠˆ‘` is `"CODE GOLF"`; and `“ÿ & ÿƒÜ's›Ý,€î'll€ï‹Ð€„…¢€€„—‚ÒƒÑ ÿÐËy ÿËØing ÿ€îŠˆersŽä?“` is `"ÿ & ÿ today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special ÿ tricky ÿ satisfying ÿ you golfers ready?"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>202</s> 196 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to [Manish Kundu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77516/manish-kundu)!!!

> ```python
> print(*map(ord,"CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"),sep='')
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFAV/5diFtVK6cSeIlPpAEPUX0ua2DU2TcBOVfH21grvDMMxxMfTWbKbJsTJhtR6FW1mWeVLdD0ec79cTlqisVKZD1QutyXTkt7gYBCtFTD2aP84R7TPVGjVB@IHkV8Gvi9ATWqu1fc@hF3GEd9QooVHeDgismiH@phdB@TbO2oPVSLg9x5q4KIoFSqb5Ap3VLbEHk5Bxn2S5J7dL02yaPg)

Port of [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)'s [R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209807/9481).

Comment: 196 bytes with Python 3 https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFAV/5diFtVK6cSeIlPpAEPUX0ua2DU2TcBOVfH21grvDMMxxMfTWbKbJsTJhtR6FW1mWeVLdD0ec79cTlqisVKZD1QutyXTkt7gYBCtFTD2aP84R7TPVGjVB@IHkV8Gvi9ATWqu1fc@hF3GEd9QooVHeDgismiH@phdB@TbO2oPVSLg9x5q4KIoFSqb5Ap3VLbEHk5Bxn2S5J7dL02yaPg

Comment: @ManishKundu Sweet - tihanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 133 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

As will be the case with every solution to this, all credit here belongs to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209807/58974)!

```
`CODE GOLF & CoÜA Câ%s: In Üþs å¡e, y'¥ ¼ k  pÎC e èÄg vy special AND Éky AND Ñsfyg PÎX Num¼r...! A y goÓÈs Î%y?`mc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YENPREUgR09MRiAmIENv3EEgQ%2bKKCCVzOiBJbiCR3P5zIOWQoQVlLCB5jCelILwghmuCIJEgcM5DIJBlIOiEjcRnIHaAeSBzcGVjaWFsIEFORCDJjmt5IEFORCDRi3NmeYhnIFDOWCBOdW28ci4uLiEgQZwgeYwgZ2/TyHMgziV5P2BtYw&input=IkNPREUgR09MRiAmIENvZGluZyBDaGFsbGVuZ2VzOiBJbiB0b2RheSdzIGNoYWxsZW5nZSwgeW91J2xsIGJlIGFza2VkIHRvIHByaW50IHRoZSBmb2xsb3dpbmcgdmVyeSBzcGVjaWFsIEFORCB0cmlja3kgQU5EIHNhdGlzZnlpbmcgUHJpbWUgTnVtYmVyLi4uISBBcmUgeW91IGdvbGZlcnMgcmVhZHk/Ii5tKCJjIik)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>118</s> 175 bytes

```
jkCM"CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBTsMwDP0Vw4Fd0BQnTdJwQVMHCAkGv9Ct2VaWtVPbgfr1xU4L7IIb1Zb97PfsU9/th@HjkL1eZ2/LB3h6e3mEG8jqoqx2kO3zEHy18@0dPFfQ1UXez1rY/KRvoa/PsxBg7SFvD74gCJyasuqg23vY1iHUXzzo0zc9tCe/KfMAi9USuqbcHPoYtnlXttueYe9NefSwOh/XvpnP51ewaDxTwK4OW9@00Pi86O@HwVjrTGqckhats8YKJVWqpLFIJgQKTQ6FiimROPql8eGYj4HW1GIVZZRENGMrQSUqR1UlnfunN0moQ2I0S@AIIDyDyJEKjcJyh/idzZ5eMmlDMxZEEntQxHEjE5u72AFxZE9YmuThFAhkeTrKozW1TU06cTEHF@MqFyUGM6WO@uIGfySpmMQJFxVZ0kGznZu4E8Of4pPqiMTLG0g@zLSAnMTyCUckixQENuob)

<sub>Due to a rushed answer, my original source didn't give the correct number. I was only checking the first and last numbers and assumed the rest was correct.</sub>

Comment: Pyth uses (the wholly inadequate) Schocco for string compression, too?

Comment: @Shaggy Not a clue XD I picked it up yesterday afternoon and just seeing what works.

Comment: Your code does not print the right number

Comment: It looks like Pyth _doesn't use Schocco to me but, even if it did, you're missing a good few characters from the string - your total byte count should be 3 greater than mine.

Comment: Hm from some digging, it appears Pyth does have some methods to compact strings and numbers - I just can't get any of them to work.
I'm giving up for now and just settling for a mediocre score.

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>177</s> 141 bytes

```
`CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In nL;'s r⊂;, you'll be 0⑵; to a⑱; the 1⟱; 0K; 4∀; AND ⬨⑺; AND Q&; Prime Number...! Are you :G;ers 1⑾;?`÷^(ⁿ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wdnfxVXB3d/HTUFNwTk/JTMvXcE5IzEnJzUvPbXYSsEzTyHPx1q9WKHoUVeTtY5CZX6pek6OQlKqgsGjiVutFUryFRIfTdwIZGSkKhg@mg9kGXhbK5g86miwVnD0c1F4tGbFo4m7IOxANWuFgKLM3FQFv9LcpNQiPT09RQXHolSQqQpW7tapRcVAMybus7ZPOLw9TuNR4369////6ybnAgA)

Yeah, it the same technique as everyone else. Now with string compression.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 202 bytes

```python
print''.join(`ord(x)`for x in"CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?")
```

Spoiler tag misinterprets the backticks and anyway, it's probably not necessary any more.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwEEV/5dqFrSBduHQj0qoIon5CYzNtozFTJvGRr69WcHe5HM7pY@jYLYahF@NCmuZXNi6rWHT2nlUNC94wLilO5Qa702GLKQrWxrUoOmUtuZb8EnuHwFrF1KP@33NEfqTW4kJQ/kb6i@BXQegIDVvLr1H0JInwPdVGWayPJYKY@hZ/06tgfBNH7CzmTjg@7heSPM8nWAuNCbRsGxIPIaXjKpkNwwc)

Comment: This is same as Noodle9's initial Python answer.

Comment: @ManishKundu Noodle9's original answer wasn't there by the time I posted this :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 1442 bytes

```
{{i}ddddd}iiiicicciicdddciicddciiicddddddcdciiiiicddddddciiiiiiciicddcdcic{d}iiiciiicdciciiiiicdddddcdciiiicicddddddccccdccicdciiiiicddddccdcicdciiiccdciiiicicddddddcdciiiiciiiiicddcddddddcdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdcicccdcicdciiicddcdciccciiiicciiicdddddcdciiiiicddddcddccdciiicdcdcciiiiicdddddccccdcc{i}dcddcddddddcicdciiciiiiiic{d}iicciiiicddcdc{i}dddcc{d}iicdciiiiciiiiicddcddddddcdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdcicccdcicdciiicddcdciciiiccdcdcdcicdcccccciiiiiicddddciiiiiic{d}iicdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdc{i}ddcdddddcdc{i}dddcdc{d}iiicdciciicdc{i}dddcddcddddddcciiiicddddcdc{i}dddcddddddcdciccdcciiicdcdcciiiiicdddddccciicdcdccicdcciiicdddcdciiiiicddddccdcicciiiiicdddcdcdcciiiiicdddddcdciiiicdddcdciciicdcdcdciicdccccdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdc{i}ddc{d}iiiccccc{i}ddc{d}iicdciiiiicddddccdcicdciiiccdcdcc{i}dddc{d}iiicdciccciiicdddcicdciicdcdcciiiicddddccicdcdcic{i}ddcc{d}iicdciiiiiciiiicddcddddddcdc{i}ddcdddddcdciiiicdciicicddciicdddddcdcdcciiiiicdddddcciiicdddcdciiiiiciiiicc{d}iicdc{i}dddcddddddcicdciicdciiiicdciicicddciicdddddcdcdcciiiiciiiicddcddddddcciiiiicdddddcdciiiiicddddcciiiicddddcdciicdcicdccdciiiiicddddccdcicdciiiccdciiiiiic{d}iicicciiicdddcdciiiiicddddcdc{i}dc{d}iicdciciicdciiiiicic{d}iiicciiiiiicddddddcdc{i}dccdc{d}iiicdciccciiicciicddciicddciicdddcccdciiiicdcddddcciiicdddcdciciicdcdcicdcccccciiiiiicddddcdcdcdciiicddccccdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdciicdcdciccciiicdddcciiiicddcdcdcciiicdddcdcic{i}ddcddcddddddcdccicicdciiiiicdddc{d}{d}i{c}cc
```

Comment: Sorry, that's TIO's fault. Removed.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>213</s> <s>211</s> <s>210</s> 211 bytes

```c
f(){for(char*s="CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?";*s;)printf("%d",*s++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/RSsNAFESfzVeMAW2S1nyAQaSkKoK0/sJ2926ydJMt926VpfTbY1PwbRgOcxj91Gk9TbYozzZwoXvFlbzk7W7zho/d1zse0Qbjxg5tr7ynsSN5xueIGIxKC4H@r1dI4bTwHnuCkgOZK4IjuzEi9gQbvA@/89APcYIcSTvlsd5uENnpQ7pFUdGJTTP2zW4gbE/Dnriu63usmWYFuuAtsYBJmfSaN5U05c1ji/zB5KtKlsuyuUyDcmNRZufs7vquyS7THw)

Comment: [211 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY9RasMwEET/fYqpoY3tpD5ATSjBaUuhJL2CIq1sEVkKu06LCDm7Gwf6NwyPeYx@7rSeJluUFxu50L3iStZ5u9@@4WP/9Y4ntNG40KHtlfcUOpIXfAaM0ai0EOj/eoUUzwvvcSAoOZK5ITixCyPGnmCj9/F3HvohTpATaac8NrstRnb6mO5R1OjEphn7ZjcQdufhQFzX9QM2TLMCXfSWWMCkTHrNm0qa8u6xRf5o8lUly2XZXKdBuVCU2SUDbvea7Dr9AQ).

Comment: @Noodle9 Yeah, just changed to the same.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 237 bytes

> ```bash
> s="CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?";o=o
> for((i=0;i<${#s};i++));do printf %d \'"${s:$i:${#o}}";done
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BSsNAGITvPsWYRtNSCZ4Tg5S0iiCtD@Blk/03WbrdLftvlaXk2WMiehtmPmamEdyPI1dJfdju8Hp4f8E9aie17VD3whiyHXGBN4vgpIgZo/23HxDdJTMGDUHwkeSE4Oy1DQg9QTlj3Pdc9EU@gs/UamGw2W8RvG6P8VeyCJpVnLEPr0@E/eXUkM/z/BYbT/MEOmcUeYYnIeNzUrrK3Sjnl0tdPZb6Kb0ueCj1er1alfLvgcKdxGeWpFcuUl1MiBuGZIotjeMP)

Port of [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)'s [R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209807/9481).

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 200 bytes

> ```
> while($c=ord("CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"[$i++]))echo$c;
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3RisIwFER/ZVbKqij9AHeXIlWXBdF9Fx9ictsEr024iUq@vlrBl@EwHGaCDf13FZ55t45pUugfL2YyqverNX732w0@UXvjuha1VczUtRQX@OuQvFF5HKHf9RzZX8fMOBFUPJN5KgjiuoRkCY1n9vdh6EaSEQNppxjL3QpJnD7nF0aVXGzyoP2LuxB218uJpCzLDyyFhgu0nhuSCCFlcjU6FG42O06npK0v9FffPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 121 bytes

> ```
> '€ƒuð.ø’CODE GOLF & Cod±µ Cí¤ÁÛ¡¾: In ƒÜ's ›Ý, €î'½ž €ï ‹Ð €„ …¢ €€ „— ‚Ò ƒÑÿÐËyÿËØ±µ PØ†e NuîÐ²¡...! A‚™ €î Šˆ²¡s Žä?’ÇJ
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY67DgFhEIVfZTS2kX0Ajci6hIj1CoRCQ7FR6H4iFJq1UbgHEZV7IkGCZE5W4y3@F1n/ruqcbyZzztStYqla8TxNtncfp4GTjpsUY8NMJClt5lIUJqNe5jNfycCeN2hhyit@RSlTo4@DmWaRFA/MI6QScND46b4Ce1TzO2zfS7FQsOV1AO2dgoUUQyUTOH7KAG/Y6DeV9DEK2goYSbGsUL6BA2y@8ErX9RDF1Y3srP9l5C6/XX9lkfvEJqYeRy/reT8)

> ```
> '€ƒuð.ø’...’ÇJ  # trimmed program
> '€ƒ             # push "and"...
>    u            # uppercase...
>      .ø         # surrounded by...
>     ð           # spaces
>                 # (ÿ in the long compressed string gets implicitly replaced with this)
>              J  # join...
>             Ç   # charcodes of...
>        ’...’    # "CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"
>                 # implicit output
> ```

<sub>The hardest part of this wasn't writing the code, it was trying to get the Markdown to work.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 190 bytes

> `say"CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"=~s/./ord$&/ger`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BSgNBEEWv8g2SbLQnLrIRJISJiqCJV@hM10yaVLqGqo7SG49u6wjuHp/HfyMpr2o1X2btfvuI5/3rE@ZoJcQ0oD16ZkoD2T1eErIEXxaG7n@@QZHLghkHgrcThV8Fo8aUkY@EXpjlczr6IC2wkbroGZvdFlljdyp/aD5H68ukvWs8E3aX84HUOXeFjdKUwCDckxqUfCjr2cOXNa4RDdfzZiCt9VvGHCVZvX1bueXd8gc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 108 bytes

> `¬⋎ »₅⇧ & ⟩₆ →ṗ: In ¬¾'s ɾṖ, λ•'ll be •₇ to ⟑Ẇ λλ ∧ṫ ƛ² ¬∪ AND ¦Ṡy AND ¶⊍ing ʁ꘍ ƛṅ...! λ∆ λ• »₅ers €æ?+Cṅ`
> Needed to optimize the string little to compress it well

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%C2%AC%E2%8B%8E%20%C2%BB%E2%82%85%60%E2%87%A7%60%20%26%20%E2%9F%A9%E2%82%86%20%E2%86%92%E1%B9%97%3A%20In%20%C2%AC%C2%BE%27s%20%C9%BE%E1%B9%96%2C%20%CE%BB%E2%80%A2%27ll%20be%20%E2%80%A2%E2%82%87%20to%20%E2%9F%91%E1%BA%86%20%CE%BB%CE%BB%20%E2%88%A7%E1%B9%AB%20%C6%9B%C2%B2%20%C2%AC%E2%88%AA%20AND%20%C2%A6%E1%B9%A0y%20AND%20%C2%B6%E2%8A%8Ding%20%CA%81%EA%98%8D%20%C6%9B%E1%B9%85...!%20%CE%BB%E2%88%86%20%CE%BB%E2%80%A2%20%C2%BB%E2%82%85ers%20%E2%82%AC%C3%A6%3F%60%2BC%E1%B9%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 195 bytes

> ```
> ;=s" CODE GOLF & Coding Challenges: In today's challenge, you'll be asked to print the following very special AND tricky AND satisfying Prime Number...! Are you golfers ready?"W=sGsT LsO++''As'\'
> ```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv2@vwLmphYh0rSc6XQnkmmP4ziZTBM5G7vN7EpKDIKQxJoiFT5sqxL3r3fvBV@gXk7zIUMBB/eFcx/wH@yBxTzy5slRELriL@6zOCa/Bt5kmlxFURgR8ZSIwI2J/LXMcsAnFsWiua@cKVGf0yDxZs/jbpJIsNmSh0GcRClPwkhndJlMvdiKwzTiwmYZ7HjzL1MvEfGccaEX@zOW8Kl@/FUfDEfDwTCG9aw7Mlb/HHwdBqO2PgxWLyhtH9NsLsQ97EYiSaOAKMIHndFqFaS@n@XCHJPbHbr0RUKY7VjiSXBdgdNeIQKP2LbNzvGjq0Js5duKUwds1xmosXwRTJIpNdmAj2iWhOC4F0y2WpVlMhzk9j@frm7swaiXh@p35qdiGScs8TiZ4y3oDl061kZ4emOI4gOLwIdOj51KMYX@HjOM3D9uy/UBG1mlrJ431jkt7OGZ4msWpYEMexQ@kkA85ozIXOGkky3rO7yTQqx6E3D9dOaIaAeu3ATc6zD0BQt2AKvdrGDVBwhGxPyKeHno1kgWp3OUbkpR31yWMOBa7qiiZIszxe/63DZPit9N0IYb5YIKE999NK9AMOKB1SzgIhznXituHB4qxgMf868yCii8CkERkg3@lFyvs@n27YgOLo7@O2ofmycV5dnhIV4wytS1Ww210cxNZ/PKmbvSmRcyPzN6l/nJtHbloLb18JA1rm2i4oiKO2gCs5zM8zSe6rhKe3mqXPV/f//5uv/xqn9rL7MiYd67IkjWOPCc@wN29Oe3Ef7fOXr1DUKwHgApFIzN9rHJQxCwqRkfedQbe4DLQ5TjMFBgrjcJUI7iyaDGjCpq5gbvQGEGP4SeSzoHeD@l5b06QdW6rN/9FtwH4WNAvMoy0mqY1rprxly6QMv4KtH9UXoNXWMzpBDQIl0YXSdVsVFzirmuwpXyfM0Zgymlg2ZQg/fCj5rwWervhbebcNd7UL2st/AmGpdQivrIkqkFvAm4IvUY/N51SdolC4IwIaAK7oQ4C/KniEINTA3dv6m7VvgTe1YfiE/9UNE3Dx/366vFr1YHOjvt0B9yvt3@Ae/F0zwMkKQsEdIgkoRQGwMxAb49CALGiQiM9HdUklP13nbWm7MGqkH8mvZ9aIj7ea9U74r4/aKk0pzzKKRRQsoKgu12LQc0BOtU29cZpLzC@WdCycMZmCnkEUurgvE3T6nBwbUyOtAcnw0OUsixmdJztNaIwhwXD29G7XM6PDk2X0paYTSAWY5KJNCAw0o@xDArH@4QrLWwLfHVqqW18IPWLtVDKxY9sGrmBcAkl3xPQyCUCHiY4rJwu@TFkmV321q6tL@ZR@ZJh65WnbWaVQwI@2oWOnFXAAqFm6UHQbUuKxJzwaD3qBXoGcZXo9Zexlco9VJhseiucIq5N4uAd1lmR@J76kVC18axRs0ljshyy1G2@NTz3W/zKOQiRtTb3/qXt@@v@zd1b34LNWBfa1ZYkl8wTOaVmIGjdDp508qs2lN4dd6VWWesLHqcM0bgPI3zMf5wYT52T3k5G7vlbDy2pUVWaQoqOxjvoNNHD3p3MCEsmqQzHDheLF3jJCOghIzRS@ioDjbSnsgDO6aZcscYCJ2bjinWRgpY4mtjBYqzWf4dsJmwnfwbVMc235xd5QHdsqwKVVWWvIprqD3xwkDXjEpqFR6HlCOnPMoMWzOJZjhWLqPq4oa2UZuunT8ETywvlvw1YVzKxoUqEomJFydCukiXENoT7FXlA2ntLaFrfTCJzFIY8hxI1CfGE39BoBcQPmUR/IKZxQ@DCdSkXk0QNrIdRSMEpupc6tUWSQYvUN1R8oCqtaceo/L3Rm8rDbR@SB5QMhTK1HfRVqnCPYBaqWQVBpyaVQi0T5qpU/useJJpmunYr9PxWEQW8/2Q6zCAuyEGiekdYEQHJnITKO/Ak5I6YPh9jxvg6iNknNBPoAvLHfmSszC3vniQ@Now0CjlNrdi34MXYsckR/VkX1YaTjPVss@5ZY3WPfZD8PXnl69@fvXLv16@@qUtVyMWuOEMw6aev9JMZp9hyFgjtDWkddFCSJXoeXgLqxy1u4EB56WZuSRrHIWzS2DAZejCoFm8nWi3NFe9TosXuIsEZzbVyNfSSKYuXeZLxeNS/q9u38ntqg81ndvhqPZveagoiJZ48taruII9qBTIt1bzAdRAfqiQ6LFqSJlMKvoNcuusGt8awS4tixM3TBPrMYLGDQLzPKcma8Tsuimo1lpI04ZD@TwsyAZMO98hv2QjQGh3K@YOe@M/7qhZzUyqJQZQFItIfV3YaAvfGs4fbSDxXbAN2d5AYl/ehjzeQMrXwBbkT5syw@12ft1Ayql7C/K0QlZUKY/gRFAdUc@c7T4z2XXmfPcZLPlbzxxWZ3RW5nXj7zTnxbFuI/NWzx5jXWczI3vKsXzX3BYwW4E1ags@aVcrUKk875uJzKzife7YlX6nIfxLJXyJ3bPXSNoeXUu3rWR@n4uApm@fsa3B4pu@v1MOyaDVdptO45FmYvlXfpYVjJV/pUQhq5WmNaN2UyhwpYry0DOqXNvd1FyBy1aPY/05M2CqLE2ADkcNbtQmGS724rph/K@lVrzm0x1wEJ2yisDE8jB4CZ3wL/jXs2ONXF6/uSLvrj@8JYcEmgGObNA/fLRFxF0QCC9Kly1aMQ4W@bJJFmHagtcedHMW38NzAR6dc3AjgbFIwIQHLfoRBT2IaEHiueAe88lF/w0BX/n9Qn7GMNXG4wXCPkXwrCr@MghT2QG5gAcVqCCT0IeWHxMctBfn2hc7fhffkg/xtWG0Whdxa9j6Pw)