# Find all integer pairs that produce a given Loeschian number

Tags: code-golf, math, integer

Inspired by and drawns from [Is this number Loeschian?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88732/85527)

> A positive integer \$k\$ is a **Loeschian number** if
>
> - \$k\$ can be expressed as \$i^2 + j^2 + i\times j\$ for \$i\$, \$j\$ integers.
>
> For example, the first positive Loeschian numbers are: \$1\$ (\$i=1, j=0\$); \$3\$ (\$i=j=1\$); \$4\$ (\$i=2, j=0\$); \$7\$ (\$i=2, j=1\$); \$9\$ (\$i=-3, j=3\$)<sup>1</sup>; ... Note that \$i, j\$ for a given \$k\$ are not unique. For example, \$9\$ can also be generated with \$i=3, j=0\$.
>
> Other equivalent characterizations of these numbers are:
>
> - \$k\$ can be expressed as \$i^2 + j^2 + i\times j\$ for \$i, j\$ non-negative integers. (For each pair of integers \$i, j\$ there's a pair of non-negative integers that gives the same \$k\$)
> - There is a set of \$k\$ contiguous hexagons that forms a tesselation on a hexagonal grid (see illustrations for [\$k = 4\$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keJqMl.png) and for [\$k = 7\$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj0lKl.png)). (Because of this property, these numbers find application in [mobile cellular communication networks](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr04/cellplan/reuse.htm).)
> - See more characterizations in the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A003136) of the sequence.

The first few Loeschian numbers are

```
0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12, 13, 16, 19, 21, 25, 27, 28, 31, 36, 37, 39, 43, 48, 49, 52, 57, 61, 63, 64, 67, 73, 75, 76, 79, 81, 84, 91, 93, 97, 100, 103, 108, 109, 111, 112, 117, 121, 124, 127, 129, 133, 139, 144, 147, 148, 151, 156, 157, 163, 169, 171, 172, 175, 181, 183, 189, 192...
```

<sup>1</sup>while (\$i=-3, j=3\$) produces 9, stick to non-negative integers, so (\$i=0, j=3\$).

Loeschian numbers also appear in [determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619)

### The challenge

Given a **non-negative integer** \$k\$, output all pairs of non-negative integers \$i, j\$ such that \$i^2 + j^2 + i\times j=k\$. If none are found (i.e. \$k\$ is not Loeschian) then return nothing or some suitable flag *other than* \$(0, 0)\$ since that produces the first Loeschian number, \$0\$.

For reversed order pairs like \$(0, 4)\$ and \$(4, 0)\$ either include both, or one member of the pair, but it should be the same for all cases (i.e. not sometimes one and other times both).

The program or function should handle (say in less than a minute) inputs up to \$100,000\$, or up to data type limitations.

This is code golf so shortest code wins.

### Test cases

```
 in       out
 0      (0, 0)
 1      (0, 1), (1, 0)
 3      (1, 1)
 4      (0, 2), (2, 0)
 9      (0, 3), (3, 0)
 12     (2, 2)
 16     (0, 4), (4, 0)
 27     (3, 3)
 49     (0, 7), (3, 5), (5, 3), (7, 0)
 147    (2, 11), (7, 7), (11, 2)
 169    (0, 13), (7, 8), (8, 7), (13, 0)
 196    (0, 14), (6, 10), (10, 6), (14, 0)
 361    (0, 19), (5, 16), (16, 5), (19, 0)
 507    (1, 22), (13, 13), (22, 1)
 2028   (2, 44), (26, 26), (44, 2)
 8281   (0, 91), (11, 85), (19, 80), (39, 65), (49, 56), (56, 49), (65, 39), (80, 19), (85, 11), (91, 0)
 12103  (2, 109), (21, 98), (27, 94), (34, 89), (49, 77), (61, 66), (66, 61), (77, 49), (89, 34), (94, 27), (98, 21), (109, 2)
```

Comment: I've specified *distinguishable* so that for example `(0, 4)` and `(4, 0)` should both appear. This is my first question here and I don't know how to handle this; as long as `i≠j` we know the reverse pair will be a solution, so it wouldn't be necessary to list both, and I'd feel bad excluding a particularly nice answer that is ruined (gets much longer) by having to list both. What should I do, leave as is? Allow both?

Comment: Nice first challenge! For output, it's fine how it is, although allowing both is probably  better choice.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms ya it's not really central to the problem, and actually the third option of *always excluding* one member of mirror pars is might be more elegant.

Comment: I think the best option is to just leave it undefined (as in answers pick how they handle it). Most challenges here tend not to be too strict with I/O stuff.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms done, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `(2,109)` be included for `12103`?

Comment: @KjetilS. Yes of course that's right. I started from a big pool but obviously when I got greedy and looked for ten pairs it exceeded what my pool covered. *Thanks!* I'll fix that momentarily. https://pastebin.com/H3dQibp0

Comment: @LuisMendo done, thanks!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks! omg I didn't realized Mathjax was here; tried it but didn't check for the dollar sign trapping.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>11</strike> 9 bytes

*<sup>Thanks to @ovs for -2!</sup>*

```
ÝãʒãÀ¦POQ
```

Oh my, I am getting in the hang of code golfing!

Prints a list of all the valid pairs (e.g `[[1, 0], [0, 1]]`). If there are none, the list is empty (`[]`). Also outputs both of any reverse integer pairs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9vc2FiaWX//8Odw6PKksOjw4DCplBPUf//OQ)

### How?

You may count this as a port of the other answers, but I took a look only at the Husk answer before writing the program!

```
Ý             # Push a list of all numbers from 0 to the input.
 ã            # Push the cartesian power of lists. (Basically, finding all possible pairs)
  ʒ           # For each pair...
   ãÀ¦        # Find all other permutations of the pair.
      P       # Multiply each permutation.
       O      # Add the products.
        Q     # If the result is not equal to the input, yeet (throw) them from the list.
              # Automatically print the pairs not yeeted.
```

Comment: `ã` (Cartesian power) can replace `Dâ`. Using the same builtin, `ãÀ¦PO` is one byte shorter than `DPsnO+`.

Comment: @ovs Nice one! (How did I not see `ã` in info.txt right beside `â`)

Comment: Nice answer! Just a small FYI, the `DPsnO+` could also have been `PynO+`. Although I like the current `ãÀ¦PO` of _@ovs_ more. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Żp`ḋÄ$=¥Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7oKEhzu6D7eo2B5aeqz9/@H2R01rjk56uHPG//8GOgqGOgpGOgrGOgomOgqmQNISAA)

Outputs `[]` for non-Loeschian numbers

-1 byte [thanks to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212300/find-all-integer-pairs-that-produce-a-given-loeschian-number/212310?noredirect=1#comment500552_212310) [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)

Not particularly efficient, but that can be fixed for an additional [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//w4bCvcW7cGDCslMrUMayPcKlxof///84Mjgx).

Uses the fact that a Loeschian number can be expressed as \$i\times i + j\times(i+j)\$ by using Jelly’s vectorisation and cumulative sum.

### How it works

```
Żp`ḋÄ$=¥Ƈ - Main link. Takes n on the left
Ż         - Yield [0, 1, ..., n]
 p`       - Cartesian product with itself, yielding [[0, 0], [0, 1], ..., [n, n]]
       ¥Ƈ - Filter the pairs, keeping those where the following is true:
     $=   -   The pair equals n after the following is done:
    Ä     -     Cumulative sum. Yield [i, i+j]
   ḋ      -     Dot product with [i, j]; Yields i×i + j×(i+j)
```

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining why they cast their vote? This is a perfectly valid answer

Comment: Nice answer. You can do `Żp\`ḋÄ$=¥Ƈ` for 9.

Comment: @Sisyphus Very nice, I knew Jelly had a shorter way to multiply-then-sum! That should also let me save a byte on my answer to the other Loeschian numbers question

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s><sup>15</sup></s> 13 bytes

```
fo=¹§+Πṁ□π2…0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr//9mbz3CucKnK86g4bmB4pahz4Ay4oCmMP///zE5Ng)

-2 bytes from Zgarb.

Outputs `[]` for non-Loeschians.

### Explanation

```
fo=¹§+Πṁ□π2…0
           …0 range from 0..n
         π2   create all possible pairs using 0..n
fo            filter by the following two functions:
    §         f: fork: § f g h x = f (g x) (h x)
     +           add
       ṁ□        sum of squares
      Π          and fold by multiplication
  =¹          g: is that equal to 1?
```

Comment: `F*` can be `Π` and `´×e` can be `π2`

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 46 bytes

```hs
f x|l<-[0..x]=[(i,j)|i<-l,j<-l,i*i+j*j+i*j==x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoIwFEV/5cU4AH2QtmiBhPoFOjk2jWHQ0FqQCMYO/HutYTn35iyn7@bn3bkQHuBX1@aKFoXXUiUGbbqaNndo/zCZITazxGRWSq/D0JkRJAzddLnB9Fmuy/s8gkrm/vUFnwIhsAN5iohvs3uIjXT1W4RxTYhiAnmFhwbZoUIm4jYCS8HwSCvklNdY85oh44yWWocf)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ô ï f@¶Xx²+X×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9CDvIGZAtlh4sitY1w&input=MTIKLVE)

```
ô ï f@¶Xx²+X×     :Implicit input of integer U
ô                 :Range [0,U]
  ï               :Cartesian product
    f             :Filter by
     @            :Passing each X through the following function
      ¶           :  Is U equal to
       Xx         :  X reduced by addition
         ²        :  After squaring each
          +X×     :  Plus X reduced by multiplication
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
Solve[i^2+j^2+i*j==#&&i>=j>=0,{i,j},Integers]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYq9CsIwGEVfRRAy6IXmzyQdUrq6CY6iECTEL9gKNbiUPnvMcDnnwJ1CecUpFHqGmny9ft6/eKOHPOY2OmTv94zR4PPgOVZC3nCeS0xx@d5ZvSw0l103pm5cOQQUNHoICWEgLXRzbVs09gbKCJy4heTSwUkn2lNwtdX6Bw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```scala
k=>0.to(k)flatMap(i=>0.to(k)filter(j=>i*i+j*j+i*j==k)map(i->))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcoxC8IwEAXgvb/ixlyrUlERhQQcHTo5ikOsKVwa09geIoi/PbZTyfa@995Qa6djd7emZqg0eTAfNv4xwCkE@GZv7aA5wtkzSAUX87qKMS@mAm8gYytVueJOtNg4zZUOguaGHJteWKkop8LmtqDcStnic7otFWIMPXl2XjSiRMxmrRNtEm0THdIt5a7cj/7FPw)

Thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) for -2

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>81</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```perl
sub{map{$i=$_;grep{$k==$i**2+$i*$_+$_**2&&($_=[$i,$_])}$i..$k}0..($k=pop)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVTbbqMwEH3PV1iRlULrRrYBY5e6yg/s275RhHZVEtE2ASWptFGUb8@OB0i4EAkP4zNnzvEE6mL/HV23J0LX9nr4@Xve/qnPtLQ0Tzb7AsIva2n5@Cif4E7zJ5pDvFh4NLcpLRnNM/9Cy@WSfl34cukBvK5q/3JNZj@HgvwuDseXl1/Vvkhm0GN1hGfrzQhcKeFuIfYNwpQzwjMCP9ZuiuGmyBhJxRgU9EDCgfqb4ZBBOgY5ZjBDUOBAwUSLvIOkYxpsqgFD6BjCMYOM76DAtRkINQOGuNUQuTVqNcUTTWHc1yREi8JqIaYqzeA4O1LtVt2VTZ0bNShDdwoCjnhIKQwmhgMlBoWmNSMavGrtCTMujHjcH6mUnbBGspTjMUsude8gQpQooYHEVmE4PgottehJM6I7MX2TpNFeAJHCXAhRhHQREIdoRrnRYKRvBnXUTcKI6Z9I8OCmU3AskAAzOAMJwzCoPQDF2nRtY5yMApxCAQoEqGbYcSdFAy7AWuPcYoWBocrGGjesfwJ@MltXew/fRf@Mqe3Jo@WuZrT4V/t2Be9@myYryNjmQ0DzlGev1q0iu6wc9g7bVEe7oGuk8W9peFpXdu6S5Pn5jcyXn1W58x7IA4PPzDxtOFlDmc2Zo2mry0P@URT198l7d1n27pQwJATEZfZR7YrcWSh3m@T6Hw)

A bit ungolfed:

```perl
sub f {
  my $k=pop;                      #gangnam style, k=pop from input
  grep { $k==pop@$_ }             #pop last of three elems
                                  #...in the candidate array
                                  #...and return as result
                                  #...if last = i*i+i*j+j*j = k
  map  {                          #two loops from 0 to sqrt $k
    my $i=$_;                     #outer loop var
    map {
      my $j=$_;                   #inner loop var
      [$i, $j, $i*$i+$i*$j+$j*$j] #result candidate
    }
    0..sqrt$k                     #or  $i..sqrt$k  to return only i<=j
  }
  0..sqrt$k
}
```

Note: Saving bytes by removing the two sqrt makes it run A LOT slower, but it will still return the correct result.

Comment: Can you make the inner loop go from `0` to `i` (inclusive) instead? That might also make your code faster.

Comment: Yes, that halves the result sets and the runtime. Still ok though.

Comment: Well, I was thinking it also makes your code shorter, which is good, given that this is [tag:code-golf]...

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```scala
| =>for(i<-0 to|;j<-0 to|if| ==i*i+j*j+i*j)yield(i,j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcnNCgIhGIXh/VzFt1RnAqMi@jFo2aJVy2hhMwqfiNqMRNF07WYQhLvznHdopZXJX41qIxwlOlCPqFw3wD4EeFV3aUGv4eAiiB2c1O1M8m6@B72ASGO@te8Jbiccoh835jdQ5ySQYW2YqZEZ@kRlO4KNoSn06KJ1RBNOafXXtNCs0LzQqmwlF3yZ/U4f)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 75 bytes

```c
i,j;f(x){for(i=j=x;~j;i-=!i?j--,-x:1)i*i+j*j+i*j-x||printf("(%d,%d)",i,j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFET3/YprpJA0iVjEjWnqt0hi9AZtSx8QaOuvx6i4mmE4nDHyZkyMKLxyNLDZtT1F7XVQL69Q6g2evZRChlPJsEDuC8@x8DIsS9djMzpKaG5FbhkRScLUGrfYmMdkr1ANo8V2d6@zBMLzgg1lMGfw/UgLgoYSVMoKjvtUOEdgCYC/Oj9Y0DUkNVNpdvSX3TQOlJBPX7M1vgE)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3 - <s>79</s> 70 Bytes

Just the trivial solution to get started with Python 3

```
k=9  # not counted
```

```
def f(k):
    a=range(k);return [(i,j) for i in a for j in a if k==i*i+j*j+i*j]
```

```
print(f(k))   # not counted
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy7DoAgDAB3vqIjDzcnTfgS42AiaEtSSIODX4/o5o2Xy5W7npnH1pKf1B4iRJ3MrKAjoV7CsGgcyEDMAgjIIBsfoUefoZ/BCMl7tOjIkkNLqyqCXPU7Na09)

---

**Thanks to @Jakque**

lambda, testing framework in TIO, spaces, `k+1`, factorization

```
lambda k:[(i,j)for i in range(k+1)for j in range(k+1)if(i+j)*i+j*j==k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJBcoMwDLznFT6axAdkjGNnxi@hHNJpaIEUMoQc@npqCQw4HLBYaaVd4cff@NN32VS5j@l@/f38urL2UvBaNEnVD6xmdceGa/d94@0JCGpiqK54fWqSo38dG@fachpvz/HJXHFg/ilSwegpuI/SpCzFjMMeh0QwDlE@W/OA@RVXe55Enox4dp/PMJ/Fc6VY8hL5G67FxlPIUxFPnkM@w76bHrvjnZd5OZ75Mv8cz1dzI5oPsBQQEeBNkRXbhkIrg6cJjDdvVu8YZMIDkFKphzQFsa9Mw45jF@Ewl@rFCtiIk6fBAyqWQcmsUcrof8lUGhH8KtIkfVtJA5SKHBtpQAQtFsJOzKrBkJXMR5owXH5OnXLfU5F6jXunyKyOTB52bddbVh7wNreCDbfn6z7iraabeyEt/Wt8vEbmWMXbhJDHUHcjx0/nZopA9lyYHKZ/)

Comment: Yon need to use `range(k+1)` otherwise you don't pass the test for k=0 and k=1.
You can also gain some bytes by removing some useless space :
`def f(k):a=range(k+1);return[(i,j)for i in a for j in a if k==i*i+j*j+i*j]` works perfectly and is cheaper ;-)

Comment: You can also do better with an anonymous lambda function : 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJBcoMwDLznFT5C4gOyDbEzw0soh3QaWkMKGeIc@npqCQw4vtistNKu0OPP/Qy9nJryY7pffz@/rqy7VInlbdoMI7PM9my89t@3pDsBQW0M2YZ1ZWmP9tQe25M9tvXkbk/3ZGV1YP5UGWd0qsS/srSu@YzDHoeUswSiuFzjgPEVV3ueQJ6IeGYflxiXcV/Bl7hA/oYXfOMp5KmIJ84hLrHupsfseOelX453vvQ/x/3VXIj6AywJRAR4U2T4NqFQSuOtA@PNmyl2DDLhAcgo1UMFPWJfsoAdxyzCYU4tFitgIk6eBQ@oWAQls0Yhov8lMqF58KtIk/BlBTVQKnKshQYetBgIM9GrBk1WpH8VhOHwc6qU@5qK1Bc4d3rp1ZHOw6zNumX1Ade542y8PV93h2tNm3shLcPLPV6OlaxJupSQx2h7l@BnWc4Ujuw5MT1M/w "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: by foctorizing `i*i+j*j+i*j` you can have `(i+j)*i+j*j`. It doesn't gain any byte in itself but now you can remove the space after the `if` like that : `if(i+j)*i+j*j==k` to save one byte

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 57 bytes

Prints the pairs \$(x,y),\:x\le y\$.

```javascript
n=>{for(y=n+1;x=y--;)for(;x--;)x*x+y*y+x*y-n||print(x,y)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwDIbve4ocdqhaReumlVJvu@4FxkCRuTmkFRVpUZ/dpbcdEr7/S0K@9VJPzdgNc7jwo5WHkuXa6pFYqYJEGGnDUHhOCOPI@Cawvg2Mb0O1bcPYqZkYar39EI@YQkIhpXChUCAzrIwCy9G4fMmdcFSgTjNcvsboWMw4Bc544o6SOH2eInx5q5sPUSBLWKHRatL9K@r1m1R3kHBe1V55AlqisP@PMe7e8QM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＮθＦ⊕₂θＦ⊕ι¿⁼θ⁻Ｘ⁺ικ²×ικＩ⟦ικ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYy7CgIxFER7vyLlDURw13JLsdjCJaidWMSYxWAe5ibRz493wc5iYDhzGP1QqKNyrY3hVctU/c0gJD6s5ogMxqDReBOKucMpVYXmGGOhnXP2J1iCdmawJ9FlSIIdbKgZZPzQp3RUrWBPLlhPOVtvfmB5k2hDgZ3KBS4LvHI@tNb13Wbb1m/3BQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Only outputs those pairs where `i>=j`. `₂` speeds the code up so that the larger test cases complete within a minute, but it is not needed for smaller test cases. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `k`.

```
Ｆ⊕₂θ
```

Loop `i` from `0` to `√k` inclusive.

```
Ｆ⊕ι
```

Loop `j` from `0` to `i` inclusive.

```
¿⁼θ⁻Ｘ⁺ικ²×ικ
```

If `k=(i+j)²-ij`, then...

```
Ｉ⟦ικ
```

Output `i` and `j` on separate lines.

Just for fun, here's a 73-byte [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1.0 answer that only finds nontrivial solutions (i.e. neither `i` nor `j` is zero):

```
.+
*
L$w`^((_)+)(?=(?<-2>\1)+(?(2)$.)(_(_)*)(?<-4>\1\3)*$(?(4).))
$.1 $.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4vLR6U8IU5DI15TW1PD3lbD3kbXyC7GUFNbw17DSFNFT1MjHiinpQmSMAFKxBhraqkA5Uw09TQ1uVT0DBVU9Iz//zc1MAcA) Very slow, so don't try anything over about 500.

Comment: Wow, running *Try it* seems incredibly fast compared to several other answers here, certainly part of that is due to the efficiency of this approach but is that all of it or is Charcoal also inherently faster somehow? I'm new here and I don't really understand how TIO works or implements the languages.

Comment: @uhoh Charcoal is written in Python 3 so any Python answer should beat it. It's not trying to be an efficient approach but it doesn't have to allocate memory like a Cartesian product approach would.

Comment: @uhoh Also, it's much much slower without the `₂` of course.

Comment: I'm intrigued, will read up on this. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
Array[(+##)^2-##&,{#,#}+1,0]~Position~#-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvLCoMwEIXh/bzGgLQ4gVysl0VL@wZCl2IhSKVZqJBmU8S8ejrZzf9xZrHh815scJNN8zU9vLe/4VQinl9aIBa0I@FRKpJj7LevC25bIwpVpN67NQwobvMdxyI@J7vGHSSBItAEhqAi6Dg5VM3WsOSumgz56phNzfuLZNNStwStblV@UtLAkf4)

Gets slow on larger inputs.

```
Array[          (* Create a table of *)
(+##)^2-##&,    (* (i+j)^2-i j *)
{#,#}+1,0]      (* for i,j = 0...k *)
~Position~#-1   (* and find where that expression equals k *)
```