# How many ways to write numbers as sums of squares?

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, combinatorics

## Task

Given two integers \$d\$ and \$n\$, find the number of ways to express \$n\$ as a sum of \$d\$ squares. That is, \$n = r_1^2 + r_2^2 + ... + r_d^2\$, such that \$r_m\$ is an integer for all integers \$1 ≤ m ≤ d\$. Note that swapping two **different** values (e.g. \$r_1\$ and \$r_2\$) is considered different from the original solution.

For instance, the number 45 can be written as a sum of 2 squares 8 different ways:

$$\begin{align}
& 45 \\
& = (-6)^2 + (-3)^2 \\
& = (-6)^2 + 3^2 \\
& = (-3)^2 + (-6)^2 \\
& = (-3)^2 + 6^2 \\
& = 3^2 + (-6)^2 \\
& = 3^2 + 6^2 \\
& = 6^2 + (-3)^2 \\
& = 6^2 + 3^2
\end{align}$$

## Rules

- Built-in solutions are allowed but non-competing (ahem, [*Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquaresR.html))
- Standard loopholes are also forbidden.
- The inputs may be reversed.

## Example I/O

```
In:   d, n

In:   1, 0
Out:  1

In:   1, 2
Out:  0

In:   2, 2
Out:  4

In:   2, 45
Out:  8

In:   3, 17
Out:  48

In:   4, 1000
Out:  3744

In:   5, 404
Out:  71440

In:   11, 20
Out:  7217144

In:   22, 333
Out:  1357996551483704981475000
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so submissions using the fewest bytes win!

Comment: Why did you delete [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126856/48934) and posted a new one while you can edit the post you deleted?

Comment: @LeakyNun My browser threw errors when I tried to edit that, even before deleting it.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64812/36398)

Comment: If d is 0, why would it return 1?

Comment: No, n is 0, not d.

Comment: _swapping the values (e.g. r_1 and r_2) is considered different_ even if the two values are equal?

Comment: Can you verify your last testcase?

Comment: @LuisMendo nope. I'll fix that.

Comment: @LeakyNun On Mathematica, `SquaresR[22, 333]` yields `1357996551483704981475000`.

Comment: @DeadPossum For `1, 0` test case, there is `1` way to express `0` as a sum of `1` square: `0 == 0^2`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 125 bytes

```python
n,d=eval(input())
W=[1]+[0]*n
exec("W=[sum(-~(j>0)*W[i-j*j]for j in range(int(i**.5)+1))for i in range(n+1)];"*d)
print(W[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxDsIgFAB3voJ0eo@2pi1xMvU3GAhDY1Eh9pUgNbr460gn17vLhU@6ryRzpmYe7Wt6gKOwJUBkatS9qXVnBDH7theoCnluC7Rf8OcOhdKu9cKb6xq55454nOhmyyCBE@JwxLpH3KX7SyrMnCoxIwtxL5UmgzlLKZth@AE)

Finishes the last testcase in 0.078 s. Naive complexity is O(*d* *n* <sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 8 bytes, non-competing

```
SquaresR
```

Comment: Like this was even needed...doesn't add anything new to the question. :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Blame the question; it states explicitly it's allowed.

Comment: Those moments where non-built-in solutions nearly beat built-in solutions :D

Comment: @JollyJoker My point is, answers should *add* something to the question, otherwise why even post them? *shrug\* :P

Comment: @DavidMulder I at first missed "nearly" and was shocked for a bit...

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Nr⁸²ṗS€ċ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@v6FHjjkObHu6cHvyoac2RbiDv////Bv8NAQ)

Takes `n` and `d` in this order.

Comment: How many years would it take for the last testcase?

Comment: @LeakyNun I dunno, it's beyond my comprehension...

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
y_t_&:Z^U!s=s
```

Inputs are `n`,  then `d`. Some of the test cases run out of memory.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vzK@JF7NKiouVLHYtvj/f0NzLmMA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `17`, `3`.

```
y     % Implicit inputs. Duplicate from below
      % STACK: 17, 3, 17
_     % Negate
      % STACK: 17, 3, -17
t_    % Duplicate. Negate
      % STACK: 17, 3, -17, 17
&:    % Two-input range
      % STACK: 17, 3, [-17 -16 ... 17]
Z^    % Cartesian power. Gives a matrix where each Cartesian tuple is a row
      % STACK: 17, [-17 -17 -17; -17 -17 -16; ...; 17 17 17]
U     % Square, element-wise
      % STACK: 17, [289 289 289; 289 289 256; ...; 289 289 289]
!s    % Transpose. Sum of each column
      % STACK: 17, [867 834 ... 867]
=     % Equals?, element-wise
      % STACK: 17, [0 0 ... 0] (there are 48 entries equal to 1 in between)
s     % Sum. Implicit display
      % STACK: 48
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
0#0=1
d#n=sum[(d-1)#(n-k*k)|d>0,k<-[-n..n]]
```

Just your basic recursion. Defines a binary infix function `#`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30DZwNaQK0U5z7a4NDdaI0XXUFNZI083WytbsybFzkAn20Y3WjdPTy8vNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoaxgrKCobnmfwA)

### Explanation

```hs
0#0=1            -- If n == d == 0, give 1.
d#n=             -- Otherwise,
 sum[            -- give the sum of
  (d-1)#(n-k*k)  -- these numbers
  |d>0,          -- where d is positive
   k<-[-n..n]]   -- and k is between -n and n.
```

If `d == 0` and `n /= 0`, we are in the second case, and the condition `d>0` causes the list to be empty.
The sum of the empty list is 0, which is the correct output in this case.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

```
d->n->sum(i=-n,n,x^i^2)^d\x^n%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9F1y5P1664NFcj01Y3TydPpyIuM85IMy4lpiIuT7Xif0FRZl6JRpqGoaaGgaYmFxLXCIlrhME1MUXiG2tqGJoj6wZpBxr3HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
Ð(Ÿ²ã€nOQO
```

Takes the arguments as n, then d. Has problems solving the bigger test cases.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8ASNozsObTq8@FHTmjz/QP///01MuYwA)

#### Explanation

```
Ð(Ÿ²ã€nOQO   Arguments n, d
Ð            Triplicate n on stack
 (           Negate n
  Ÿ          Range: [-n ... n]
   ²ã        Caertesian product of length d
     €n      Square each number
       OQ    Sum of pair equals n
         O   Total sum (number of ones)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
‘ṬUµJ²fJ[0]ẋ;€ḤSḣL+µ⁹¡Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//4oCY4bmsVcK1SsKyZkpbMF3huos74oKs4bikU@G4o0wrwrXigbnCoeG5qv///zMzM/8yMg)

Port of my [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126865/48934). Finishes the last testcase in 2.977 s.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
Count[Tr/@Tuples[Range[-#,#]^2,#2],#]&
```

Pure function taking the inputs in the order `n`, `d`. `Range[-#,#]^2` gives the set of all possibly relevant squares, with positive squares listed twice to make the count correct; `Tuples[...,#2]` produces the `d`-tuples of such squares; `Tr/@` sums each `d`-tuple; and `Count[...,#]` counts how many of the results equal `n`.

The first few test cases terminate quickly, but I estimate this would take about half a year to run on the test case `1000,4`. Replacing `Range[-#,#]` by the (longer but) more sensible `Range[-Floor@Sqrt@#,Floor@Sqrt@#]` speeds up that computation to about 13 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ŒRṗ²§ċ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xZJS4bmXwrLCp8SL4oG4////MTf/Mw)

Very inefficient; fails to finish within a minute for the last 4 test cases.

### How it works

```
ŒRṗ²§ċ⁸ - Main link. Takes n on the left, d on the right
ŒR      - Yield [-n, -n+1, ..., 0, ..., n-1, n]
  ṗ     - Yield all sublists of this range of length d
   ²    - Square each number
    §   - Take the sum of each list
     ċ  - Count the occurrences of...
      ⁸ - ...n
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 138

Very inefficient solution with my beloved eval. Why not?
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RYtBCoMwEEX3nmIQJDNJFlbtpuANPEIXpk1sA3EUtYVSevZUlNLNh/f/@@NruQ9cxKY@x2D6izXA2p4sGLZQSfc0AbdIUQTH@EahhM9mLaRVIqeVumGCtQHPMBm@OWTaRt/B7kpZqF2va/6QoCxV7fIYg8P9YEmW1JIOw9WEGYniOHleoMHqqAtKfnTQ@R9KXVISvw)

```
lambda n,d:d and 4*eval(eval("('len({('+'i%s,'*d+'0)'+'for i%s in range(n)'*d+'if '+'i%s**2+'*d+'0==n})')%"+`tuple(range(d)*3)`),locals())
```

It generated and evaluates code like this:

```
len({(i0,i1,0)for i0 in range(n)for i1 in range(n)if i0**2+i1**2+0==n})
```

So for some big **d** it will run very long and consume a lot of memory, having complexity of O(n^d)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
SeriesCoefficient[EllipticTheta[3,0,x]^#,{x,0,#2}]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 23 bytes

```
{+/y=+/{x*x}y-!x#1+2*y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWlu/0lZbv7pCq6K2UlexQtlQ20irspaLK01PXcNQwcDaUMHI2giMTUytjRUMzTX//wcA) It's a simple brute forcer.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 16 bytes

```
lfqQsm*ddT^}_QQE
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lfqQsm%2AddT%5E%7D_QQE&input=4%0A3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A1%0A2%0A2%0A45%0A2%0A17%0A3&debug=0&input_size=2)

It's horribly inefficient