# Very Simple Grid Marks

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, grid

Write a program or function that takes in three positive integers, W, H, and N. Print or return a W×H grid of `.`'s where every Nth `.` in normal English reading order is replaced with an `X`.

For example, given W = 7, H = 3, N = 3, the grid is 7 characters wide and 3 high, and every third character reading from the top left is an `X`:

```
..X..X.
.X..X..
X..X..X
```

Similarly, if the input is W = 10, H = 4, N = 5, the output would be:

```
....X....X
....X....X
....X....X
....X....X
```

#### Notes

- "Normal English reading order" means going left to right on each line, from the top line to the bottom.
- When N is 1 then all the `.`'s will become `X`'s.
- You may use any two distinct [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters in place of `.` and `X`.

  - If you use space ( ) then trailing spaces are not required when the result would be visually the same. (Empty lines are still required.)
  - You may not using something else in place of the newlines that shape the grid.
- The exact input format and order of W, H, and N is not super important. Things like `[H,W,N]` or `N\nW,H` are alright.
- A trailing newline in the output is fine.
- The shortest code in bytes wins!

## Examples

```
W = 5, H = 3, N = 1
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX

W = 5, H = 3, N = 2
.X.X.
X.X.X
.X.X.

W = 5, H = 3, N = 3
..X..
X..X.
.X..X

W = 5, H = 3, N = 4
...X.
..X..
.X...

W = 5, H = 3, N = 5
....X
....X
....X

W = 5, H = 3, N = 6
.....
X....
.X...

W = 5, H = 3, N = 7
.....
.X...
...X.

W = 5, H = 3, N = 15
.....
.....
....X

W = 5, H = 3, N = 16 (or more)
.....
.....
.....

W = 1, H = 1, N = 1
X

W = 1, H = 1, N = 2 (or more)
.

W = 8, H = 6, N = 2
.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X

W = 8, H = 6, N = 3
..X..X..
X..X..X.
.X..X..X
..X..X..
X..X..X.
.X..X..X

W = 8, H = 6, N = 4
...X...X
...X...X
...X...X
...X...X
...X...X
...X...X

W = 8, H = 6, N = 7
......X.
.....X..
....X...
...X....
..X.....
.X......

W = 8, H = 6, N = 16
........
.......X
........
.......X
........
.......X

W = 37, H = 1, N = 4
...X...X...X...X...X...X...X...X...X.

W = 1, H = 10, N = 8
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
X
.
.
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the restriction "*You may not using something else in place of the newlines that shape the grid*" includes "*You may not return an array `["..X..X.", ".X..X..", "X..X..X"]` as the grid*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Correct

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## J, <s>9</s> 5 bytes

```
$":&1
```

Uses spaces and `1`'s and expects input in the form `H W f N`

Explanation:

```
$":&1
   &1 bonds the fixed right argument 1 to ":
 ":   formats the right argument number (1) to take up left argument (N) number of cells
      padding with spaces, resulting  in "  1"
$     reshape to H-by-W with repeating the string if necessary
```

Usage:

```
   3 7 ($":&1) 3
  1  1 
 1  1  
1  1  1
```

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Comment: Does it also truncate the array if W*H is less than N?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes.

Comment: If the argument is `($":&1)`, wouldn't that count as 7 bytes?

Comment: No, the `()` aren't part of the function; you could write `f =. $":&1` and then `3 7 f 3`.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, 60 bytes

```
w,h,n=input()
s='%%%dd'%n%0*w*h
exec"print s[:w];s=s[w:];"*h
```

This prints space and `0` in place of `.` and `X`. Input is taken as a tuple in the form of `w,h,n`.

Comment: That's a clever string format.

Answer (score 7):

### J, 12 bytes

```
$'X'_1}#&'.'
```

This is a dyadic function that takes the array `H W` as its left argument and `N` as its right argument. Usage:

```
  f =: $'X'_1}#&'.'
  3 5 f 3
..X..
X..X.
.X..X
```

#### Explanation

```
$'X'_1}#&'.'
         '.'  The character '.'
       #&     repeated N times
    _1}       with the last character
 'X'          replaced by 'X'
$             reshaped into an HxW array
```

Comment: _Right tool for the job_?

Comment: Is the use of `X.` really shortest?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I believe so. I tried to use the numbers 0 and 1 instead, but then I had to surround the one next to `_1` with parentheses, and format away the spaces between columns, and it ended up being longer.

Answer (score 5):

## BBC Basic, 67 ASCII characters, tokenised filesize 43 bytes

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/download.html

```
INPUTw,h,n:WIDTHw:PRINTLEFT$(STRING$(w*h,STRING$(n-1,".")+"X"),w*h)
```

BBC basic has a handy command for limiting the field width. We use `STRING$` to make `w*h` copies of the string of `n-1` periods followed by an X. Then we use LEFT$ to truncate this to `w*h` characters.

Answer (score 4):

### [Minkolang 0.14](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>34</s> <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 22 bytes

```
n2-D1n$zn[z[1Rd6ZO]lO]
```

[Check one case here](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n2-D1n%24zn%5Bz%5B1Rd6ZO%5DlO%5D&input=3%205%203) and [check all test cases here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%28ndN2-D1ndN%24zndNlO%5Bz%5B1Rd6ZO%5DlO%5DlOlOIX%24I%29%2E&input=1%205%203%0A2%205%203%0A3%205%203%0A4%205%203%0A5%205%203%0A6%205%203%0A7%205%203%0A15%205%203%0A16%205%203%0A1%201%201%0A2%201%201%0A2%208%206%0A3%208%206%0A4%208%206%0A7%208%206%0A16%208%206) Expects input like `N W H`.

#### Explanation

```
n                 Take number from input (N)
 2-               Subtract 2
   D              Duplicate the top of stack (which is 0 because it's empty) N-2 times
    1             Push a 1 onto the stack
n                 Take number from input (W)
 $z               Store W in the register (z)
n                 Take number from input (H)
 [                Open a for loop that repeats H times
  z[              Open a for loop that repeats W times
    1R            Rotate 1 step to the right
      d           Duplicate top of stack
       6Z         Convert number to string
         O        Output as character
          ]       Close for loop
           lO     Output a newline
             ]    Close for loop
```

As Minkolang's codebox is toroidal, this will wrap around to the beginning. As every `n` will now take in `-1`, this eventually crashes with an error and no further output, which is allowed.

Comment: So it's easy for you to compare. (Note that it's not quite the exact same code.)

Comment: Ahead of you! :P :)

Answer (score 4):

### APL, 13 bytes

```
{⍪,/⍕¨⍺⍴⍵=⍳⍵}
```

This takes `H W` as the left argument and `N` as the right argument.

Explanation:

```
{⍪,/⍕¨⍺⍴⍵=⍳⍵}     Dyadic function (args are ⍺ on left, ⍵ on right):
        ⍵=⍳⍵      ⍵ = (1 2 3...⍵); this is ⍵-1 0s followed by a 1
      ⍺⍴          Shape by the left argument; e.g. 5 3 gives a 5x3 array
    ⍕¨            Stringify each entry
  ,/              Join the strings in each row 
 ⍪                Make column vector of strings
```

Try it online: [first test cases](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u236A%2C/%u2355%A8%u237A%u2374%u2375%3D%u2373%u2375%7D/%A8%20%28%28%u2282%u22823%205%29%2C%A8%28%u23737%29%2C15%2C16%29%2C%28%28%u2282%u22826%208%29%2C%A82%203%204%207%29&run), [last test case](http://tryapl.org/?a=1%2037%7B%u236A%2C/%u2355%A8%u237A%u2374%u2375%3D%u2373%u2375%7D4&run). Note that although this shows boxed output, my copy of Dyalog doesn't.

Comment: Are those actually just boxes, or is the SE app not displaying the characters properly?

Comment: @Carcigenicate They're not boxes. The characters should display fine on the online link, because it has a different font.

Comment: Ahh, right. I missed that. Do you have a special keyboard or are you a masochist?

Comment: @Carcigenicate On tryapl (and Dyalog student edition) you can type APL characters using backticks. `a turns into ⍺, for example.

Answer (score 4):

### CJam (16 bytes)

```
{1$*,:)@f%:!/N*}
```

Takes input on the stack in the order `N W H`, returns string using characters `0` and `1`. [Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=3%207%203%0A%0A%7B1%24*%2C%3A)%40f%25%3A!%2FN*%7D%0A%0A~)

#### Dissection

```
{        e# Anonymous function. Stack: N W H
  1$*,   e# Stack: N W [0 1 ... W*H-1]
  :)     e# Stack: N W [1 2 ... W*H]
  @f%    e# Stack: W [1%N 2%N ... W*H%N]
  :!     e# Map Boolean not, taking 0 to 1 and anything else to 0
  /      e# Split into W-sized chunks (i.e. the lines of the grid)
  N*     e# Join the lines with newlines
}
```

Comment: ;-; you beat me ;-; but good job! :D

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 20 Bytes

```
q~:Z;_@*,:){Z%!}%/N*
```

Takes input as H W N.

Comment: whoops, invalid

Comment: fixed :D :D :D :D

Comment: Still much longer than some of the solutions in other languages, but I got it to 18 bytes with CJam: `q~_@*,@(S*'X+f=/N*`, with input in order N H W.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Take another one off by replacing `'X` with `0`, and that'll be 17

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>33</s> <s>32</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
SpW-1 +Q p-~U*V/W f'.pU)·
```

Takes input in format `W H N`. Uses   and `"` in place of `.` and `X`, respectively. [Try it online!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
SpW-1 +Q p-~U*V/W f'.pU)·qR
          // Implicit: U = width, V = height, W = interval
SpW-1 +Q  // Create a string of W - 1 spaces, plus a quotation mark.
p-~U*V/W  // Repeat this string ceil(U*V/W) times.
f'.pU)    // Split the resulting string into groups of U characters.
qR        // Join with newlines.
          // Implicit: output last expression
```

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 Bytes

Thanks to @Sp3000 for pointing out that I don't need a duplicate and saving me 2 bytes!

Takes input as `N W H`. [Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=MX1cMFhyVlxbVlxbe0ROXWFPXQ&input=&args=Mw+Nw+NA&debug=on)

```
1}\0XrV\[V\[{DN]aO]
1                         Push 1 to the stack.
 }                        Push the backmost to the front and subtract 2.
  \0X                     Duplicate the 0 temp variable times.
     r                    Reverse the stack.
      V                   Save as final global variable.
       \[         ]       Repeat top item times.
         V\[   ]          Repeat global variable times.
            {DO           Duplicate, output, then shift over an item.
                aO        Output a newline.
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, <s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 14 bytes

Takes arguments as `(H W;N)`:

```
{".X"x#y=1+!y}
```

In action:

```
  f:{".X"x#y=1+!y};

  f.'((3 5;1);(3 5;2);(3 7;3);(4 10;5);(3 5;16))
(("XXXXX"
  "XXXXX"
  "XXXXX")
 (".X.X."
  "X.X.X"
  ".X.X.")
 ("..X..X."
  ".X..X.."
  "X..X..X")
 ("....X....X"
  "....X....X"
  "....X....X"
  "....X....X")
 ("....."
  "....."
  "....."))
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>61 55</s> 54 bytes

```
function c=g(d,n);b=ones(d);b(n:n:end)=0;c=[b'+45,''];
```

Wow, I thought MATLAB would be competitive in this one, but how wrong I was!

The function creates an array of 1's of the correct dimensions, and then sets every n'th element to be 0 (MATLAB implicitly handles wrapping around the indices into 2D). We then add on 45 ('-') to this number and converted to a char array to be returned.

The questions allows any distinct two ASCII characters to be used for the grid, I am using '-' in place of 'x' to save some bytes. The input format is also not fixed, so it should be supplied as `[w h],n` - i.e. an array of width and height, and then n as a second parameter.

---

This also works with **Octave** and can be tried online [here](http://octave-online.net/?s=QHPazBNGkfyhbhbdFrYAnJeGZmDvKMKYapOgHyikJRbmUTQP). The function is already set up in the linked workspace, so you can simply call for example:

```
g([4,5],3)
```

Which outputs:

```
..-.
.-..
-..-
..-.
.-..
```

Comment: Save one byte: `c=[b'+45,''];`

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks :). For some reason when I'd tried that I didn't think it saved any bytes, I must have miscounted!

Answer (score 2):

### Processing, 93 bytes (Java, 104 bytes)

```
void f(int a,int b,int c){for(int i=0;i<a*b;i++)print((i%c>c-2?"X":".")+(i%a>a-2?"\n":""));}}
```

The reason I used Processing instead of Java is that you don't need to acces the pointer by tiping `System.out` because a local variable is directly accessible. I earned 11 bytes with this. The function doesn't return the result but prints it.

Comment: You can save another by moving the increment (like `i++%a...`), and it looks like you left a spare `}` at the end you don't need, also.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
{y#|x$"X"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyNkV1rgzAUhu/zK4LrhYUaa/0aht3valeDBUqhYtVKP+zUDaXbfvs8OanVTrZJyHvCefKeN5gE5+buo55oQvsk5Dk4T5bNVxEklNGar/Md19dJmO15zRteTFfALHWb29Sfcl2jVMDSuIYFVFgIbboC1OUOtebIyga0+P8O6GC1w1wwEPDBgIEitLhA7V2BKQTayTNCdgf1o17CK8i5QqqpYJmqe9UVuqbuFCGvD6lxP5z8WwibXI1vIWKSbVWdysA0o3wTp/k+YWUVRru4jrbhMY1ZlB/M17e4rLL8WJqea3n35ntcNEaZHU772EiLbGMcwmJXEvJCH6g/o4+t2DP6BEIYE7AICiMoAmFrjrSDtNvSsg3An6V0cAfjLCL/22AfwRaQRkAWAZayHsFUeNJ7wBjmEIaAhGW6MUw9brCPYJ5syaG/ufkKQ0AG+Aa9lbne)

Takes input as two arguments; `N` as the first/left arg, and `(H;W)` as the second/right arg. Uses `" "` and `"X"` as the output characters.

- `|x$"X"` right pad "X" to the desired length (fills with spaces), and reverse it (to put the "X" at the end)
- `y#` reshape the above to the desired dimensions; the above gets repeated over and over until it is long enough

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

Hope to golf it more. Takes input as `N\n[W, H]`.

```
jc.[k+*dtvzN*FQhQ
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jc.%5Bk%2B%2adtvzN%2aFQhQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A7%2C3%0A5%0A10%2C4%0A1%0A7%2C3&debug=0&input_size=2).

Answer (score 1):

## R, 66 bytes

```r
function(w,h,n){x=rep(".",a<-w*h);x[1:a%%n<1]="X";matrix(x,h,w,T)}
```

This is a function that accepts three integers and returns a matrix of character values. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Ungolfed:

```r
f <- function(w, h, n) {
    # Get the area of the square
    a <- w*h

    # Construct a vector of dots
    x <- rep(".", a)

    # Replace every nth entry with X
    x[1:a %% n == 0] <- "X"

    # Return a matrix constructed by row
    matrix(x, nrow = h, ncol = w, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>65</s> 60 bytes

```js
(w,h,n)=>eval('for(i=r=``;i++<w*h;i%w?0:r+=`\n`)r+=i%n?0:1')
```

### Explanation

```js
(w,h,n)=>eval('    // use eval to remove need for return keyword
  for(
    i=             // i = current grid index
      r=``;        // r = result
    i++<w*h;       // iterate for each index of the grid
    i%w?0:r+=`\n`  // if we are at the end of a line, print a newline character
                   // note: we need to escape the newline character inside the template
  )                //       string because this is already inside a string for the eval
    r+=i%n?0:1     // add a 0 for . or 1 for X to the result
                   // implicit: return r
')
```

### Test

```html
W = <input type="number" id="W" value="7" /><br />
H = <input type="number" id="H" value="3" /><br />
N = <input type="number" id="N" value="3" /><br />
<button onclick="result.innerHTML=(

(w,h,n)=>eval('for(i=r=``;i++<w*h;i%w?0:r+=`\n`)r+=i%n?0:1')

)(+W.value,+H.value,+N.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 85 bytes

```
""<>(#<>"
"&/@ReplacePart["."~Table~{t=# #2},List/@Range[#3,t,#3]->"X"]~Partition~#)&
```

As with many other solutions, this creates a single row, then partitions it.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```
(w,h,n)=>(f=i=>i++<w*h?+!(i%n)+(i%w?"":`
`)+f(i):"")(0)
```

Uses the [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) `f` to loop to save a return statement.

Output for w=5, h=3, n=7:

```
00000
01000
00010
```

Answer (score 1):

**C#, 185 bytes**

```
using System;class x{void a(int w,int h,int n){int c=1;for(int i=0;i<h;i++){for(int j=1;j<=w;j++){if(c%n==0){Console.Write("x");}else{Console.Write(".");}c++;}Console.WriteLine();}}}
```

For a more readable Reading:

```
using System;
class x
{
  void a(int w, int h, int n)
  {
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= w; j++)
        {
            if (c % n == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("x");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(".");
            }
            c++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
     }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
new x().a(7, 3, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `jR`, 8 bytes

```
×ƛ?Ḋ]¹Ẇ“
```

input as `W,H,N`
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqUiIsIiIsIsOXxps/4biKXcK54bqG4oCcIiwiIiwiM1xuN1xuMyIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)

```
×ƛ?Ḋ]¹Ẇ“­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
×ƛ  ]     # ‎⁡Map over the range H x W
  ?Ḋ      # ‎⁢Divisible by N?
     ¹Ẇ“  # ‎⁣Split into chunks of length W and join on nothing
# ‎⁤j flag joins on newlines
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>67</s> 56 bytes

```
->w,h,n{(1..h).map{(1..w).map{o,$.=$.%n<1?1:0,$.+=1;o}}}
```

Printing an array since it is accepted.

**67 bytes**

```
->w,h,n{i=1;puts (1..h).map{(1..w).map{o,i=i%n<1?1:0,i+=1;o}.join}}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
-> w, h, n {
  (1..h).map {
    (1..w).map {
      o, $. = $.%n < 1 ? 1 : 0, $.+ = 1
      o
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
->w,h,n{(1..h).map{(1..w).map{o,$.=$.%n<1?1:0,$.+=1;o}}}[8,6,7]
=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 50 bytes

```julia
f(w,h,n)=reshape([i%n<1?"X":"." for i=1:w*h],w,h)'
```

This creates a function `f` that accepts three integers and returns a 2-dimensional array of strings.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(w::Integer, h::Integer, n::Integer)
    # Construct an array of strings in reading order
    a = [i % n == 0 ? "X" : "." for i = 1:w*h]

    # Reshape this columnwise into a w×h array
    r = reshape(a, w, h)

    # Return the transpose
    return transpose(r)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, 44 bytes

Note: Very different approach than the one used by Tom Carpenter.

```
@(x,y)char(reshape(~mod(1:prod(x),y),x)'+46)
```

Defines an anonymous function that accepts inputs as `[W,H],N`. I approached this problem using not-the-modulo-of-*N* for an array 1:W*H and then simply reshaping the solution to a two-dimensional array, which is then converted to a character array.

Example output for `[5,3],7`:

```
.....
./...
.../.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 94 bytes

```
(lambda(a b c)(dotimes(i(* a b))(format t"~:[.~;X~]~@[~%~]"(=(mod(1+ i)c)0)(=(mod(1+ i)a)0))))
```

#### Explanation

```
~:[.~;X~] <-- takes argument - if argument is true write ., if false write X
~@[~%~] <-- takes argument - if argument is true write newline, if not treat argument as if it was not used
```

`(=(mod(1+ i)c)0)(=(mod(1+ i)a)0)` looks pretty silly (because it's so similiar but I don't know if it can be solved, saving bytes

I use `(1+ i)` instead of `i` because `dotimes` starts from `i=0` and I want to start from `1`. It is also helpful because I can use `(* a b)` instead of `(1+(* a b))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as `[W,H],N` and uses spaces instead of `.`s & `"`s instead of `X`s.

```
×îQùV)òUÎ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=1%2b5R%2bVYp8lXO&footer=rrhxLiByUSdY&input=WzcgM10gMw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 17 bytes

```
↯⇌⊟⊙⊙(⇌⊂@X↯:@.-1)
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAg4oav4oeM4oqf4oqZ4oqZKOKHjOKKgkBY4oavOkAuLTEpCgpGIDcgMyAzCkYgMTAgNCA1CkYgNSA1IDEKRiA1IDUgMgo=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 44 bytes

```perl
print$_%$F[1]&&1,$/x!($_%"@F")for 1.."@F"*<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCVeVcUt2jBWTc1QR0W/QlEDKKDk4KakmZZfpGCopwdia9nY/f9vaKBgymXyL7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dRAA)

Input format is:

```perl
W N
H
```

Output uses `1` for the spacer and `0` for the character.

Answer (score -1):

## Java, <s>185</s> 183 bytes

Thanks Thomas Kwa, for saving me 2 bytes!

```
interface B{static void main(String[] a){int w = Byte.parseByte(a[0]);for(int i=0;i++<w*Byte.parseByte(a[1]);)System.out.print((i%Byte.parseByte(a[2])>0?".":"X")+(i%w<1?"\n":""));}}
```

Ungolfed (ish):

```
interface A {
  static void main(String[] a) {
    int w = Byte.parseByte(a[0]);
    for(
      int i = 0;
      i++ < w*Byte.parseByte(a[1]);
    )
      System.out.print((
        i%Byte.parseByte(a[2]) > 0 ? "." : "X"
        )+(
        i%w < 1 ? "\n" : ""
      ));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$ java B 5 3 7
.....
.X...
...X.
```

Maybe java will win one day :P

Comment: I think you can use `>0` instead of `!=0`, and `<1` instead of `==0`.

Comment: You can remove useless whitespace after `String[]` and around `=` to get -3 bytes down