# Write a program to elasticize strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Nice verb there, in the title.

Write a program that given an input string, will "elasticize" this string and output the result. Elasticizing a string is done as follows:

The first character is shown once. 
The second character is shown twice.
The third character is shown thrice,
and so on.

As you can see, the amount of duplications of a certain character is related to the character's index as opposed to its previous occurrences in the string.

You can expect to receive only printable ASCII characters. Based off the following [link](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html), these characters have decimal values 32-126.

Examples:

`Why: Whhyyy`

`SKype: SKKyyyppppeeeee`

`LobbY: LoobbbbbbbYYYYY` (Note how there are 7 b's since the first b is shown 3 times and the second b is shown 4 times, making a total of 7 b's).

`A and B: A  aaannnnddddd      BBBBBBB`

Shortest bytes wins :)

Comment: That seems to disagree with "no support for whitespace is needed, other than the space character". Should the output be the same as the input then? (Two one letter words?) Also note we have a nice place called the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) where you can put challenges for people to give you feedback before posting them.

Comment: FryAmTheEggman your assumption is valid. @TimmyD I realize where I was unclear, you may end up with strings separated my multiple spaces, as seen in the example FryAmTheEggman posted.

Comment: I'm assuming that the shortest code wins? ;)

Comment: @Adnan Yep, though I'm not sure if I should mark the answer with the shorted program as accepted, as certain languages are made for golfing purposes unlike others.

Comment: And here I was ready to be clever and start making strings more expensive as more of them were allocated...

Comment: Related: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61885/monday-mini-golf-6-meeesesessess-upp-teeexexextext), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77043/stretch-the-word)

Comment: Need it be a full program, or simply a function?

Comment: @Zymus Based on the answers, I would say function.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

Code:

```
ĖP€
```

Explanation:

```
Ė     # Enumerate.
 P€   # Product of each.
      # Implicit joining of everything.
```

Uses the **Jelly encoding**. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xJZQ4oKs&input=&args=TG9iYlk).

Comment: Nice abuse of the fact that Python's `*` does string multiplication. That's not really intended, but it works.

Comment: @Dennis: which `*`? There's no such thing in the whole answer.

Comment: @Thomas: Jelly is written in Python, and the Jelly `P` command calculates product behind the scenes using the Python `*` operator.  This post is abusing the leaky abstraction of the underlying code actually being in Python, so doing a `P` (product) command on a string works as expected.

Answer (score 17):

## J, 4 bytes

```
#~#\
```

### Usage

```
   f =: #~#\
   f 'Why'
Whhyyy
   f 'SKype'
SKKyyyppppeeeee
   f 'LobbY'
LoobbbbbbbYYYYY
   f 'A and B'
A  aaannnnddddd      BBBBBBB
```

### Explanation

```
#~#\  Input: s
  #\  Computes the length of each prefix of s
      This forms the range [1, 2, ..., len(s)]
#~    For each value in the range, copy the character at the
      corresponding index that many times
      Return the created string
```

Answer (score 13):

### Brainfuck, 15 bytes

```
,[>+[->+<<.>],]
```

Pretty straightforward implementation, shifting the memory space by 1 for each input char. Requires an interpreter that gives 0 on EOF, and 32-bit/arbitrary precision cells for inputs longer than 255 chars.

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-K1stPis8PC4-XSxd&input=QSBhbmQgQg) (Note: TIO uses 8-bit cells)

Comment: Also, I think that this doesn't work for strings longer than 255 characters.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That would depend on whether the interpreter in question has arbitrary precision integers or not (but indeed, for most implementations, it would cap at 255)

Comment: The convention is to use 8-bits. Which is 1 character. But some may indeed implement with 32-bit numbers. Since you specify you need that EOF be 0 (which is a compiler/interpreter-specific behaviour), it should be noted that for strings longer than 255 characters, you need a compiler/interpreter with 32-bit cells. I just though that it should be added to the answer, since it is also a compiler/interpreter-specific behaviour.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Sure, noted.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```
concat.zipWith replicate[1..]
```

Usage example: `concat.zipWith replicate[1..] $ "SKype"` -> `"SKKyyyppppeeeee"`.

`replicate n c` makes n copies of c and `concat` makes a single list out of all the sublists.

Comment: `id=<<` is a nice touch. :)

Comment: I just wanted to try it, but assigning `f = id=<<zipWith replicate[1..]` (in a file) did result in an ugly error, can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to assign this (unnamed, right?) function to a name, such that we can use it as  a function? I mean if it is a function, then `(id=<<zipWith replicate[1..] ) "SKype"` should still work? Otherwise I would consider it as a *snippet*. The *full program* you provided does have "SKype" hardcoded.

Comment: I'd say if you cannot use it like any other function, it is not a function. E.g. `:t` does not regard `id=<<zipWith replicate[1..]` as a function (it just throws an error) however `(id=<<).zipWith replicate[1..]` is considered as a function. I'd say the first one is just a snipped, that just works if you hardcode the input, but the second one that you just postet is a function (and `:t` agrees), would you agree on that?

Comment: Ok, great! If you disagree with my "definition", I think we should start a meta post for clearing this up. In the mean time I'm trying to find some other haskellians for their opinion on this, as this is just *my* view.

Comment: On the other hand, can `:t` consider something as anything but a function? I think everything is a *function* as long as there is no errror, but then again, I'm still a newbie=)

Comment: @flawr: there are also `values` (e.g. `:t "test"`) and [kinds](https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind).

Comment: @flawr: I agree, my first version is a snippet. Thanks for bringing it up for discussion. Btw: `:t` checks the type (function or value) `:k` checks the kind.

Comment: I didn't know about *kinds*! Couldn't you still consider values as constant functions?

Comment: @flawr: yes, most of the time (especially outside the Haskell terminology) you can see values as constant functions. Back to `:t` I'd consider it necessary but not sufficient for some Haskell code to pass a `:t` test to be a function. If `:t` throws an error it's definitely not a function. Not everything `:t`accepts is a function even in a broader sense and in particular not in our (PPCG) sense.

Answer (score 9):

## Java, <strike>158</strike> 121 bytes

Saved a whopping 37 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){int b=0,B;for(char c:A[0].toCharArray())for(B=b+++2;--B>0;)System.out.print(c);}}
```

As a bonus, this program can handle *all* Unicode characters in the existence, including [the control characters located at the very end of Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

Comment: Huh, this is very short for a Java code.

Comment: You can shorten it by 1 byte by replacing `for(int C=c+1;C>0;C--)` with `for(int C=c+2;--C>0;)`

Comment: Or even shorter (**121 bytes**): `interface a{static void main(String[]A){int x=0,i;for(char c:A[0].toCharArray())for(i=x+++2;--i>0;)System.out.print(c);}}`

Comment: Well, just make it a lambda or a method

Comment: Wow, using an `interface` for the default `public` methods. That's smart.

Comment: Apologies for no clarification, but your answer would still be valid as a function (therefore no interface is needed, as well as the main method).

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can golf it by 1 more byte: `interface a{static void main(String[]A){int b=0,B;for(char c:A[0].toCharArray())for(B=b++;B-->=0;)System.out.print(c);}}`. (Also, @MarDev said you are now allowed to use functions, so with a Java 8 lambda you can use `s->{int b=0,B;for(char c:s)for(B=b++;B-->=0;)System.out.print(c);}`, with a char-array as parameter.)

Answer (score 8):

### Perl, 16 bytes

```
s/./$&x$+[0]/ge
```

+1 byte for the `-p` flag.

```
s/./        /    find every character
             g   globally
              e  and replace with the eval'd result of
    $&           the matched string
      x          repeated
       $+[0]     by the index of the character after the match
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python, 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+s[-1]*len(s)
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZrxEbz).

Answer (score 7):

### CJam, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*Thanks to jimmy23013 for saving 1 byte.*

```
Sl+eee~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Sl%2Beee~&input=LobbY)

#### Explanation

Using the `LobbY` example:

```
                                      Stack:
S    e# Push space.                   [" "]
l    e# Read input.                   [" " "LobbY"]
+    e# Append.                       [" LobbY"]
ee   e# Enumerate.                    [[[0 ' ] [1 'L] [2 'o] [3 'b] [4 'b] [5 'Y]]]
e~   e# Run-length decode.            ["LoobbbbbbbYYYYY"]
```

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB, 45 bytes

```
g=@(m)sort(m(m>0));@(s)s(g(hankel(1:nnz(s))))
```

Explanation: The key is `hankel`, which produces a Hankel matrix of a given vector. From this matrix, we can extract a vector of indices, which defines which character of the string is at which position in the output. E.g. `hankel(1:4)` produces following matrix:

```
 1  2  3  4
 2  3  4  0
 3  4  0  0
 4  0  0  0
```

From this matrix we can extrac the vector `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4`. This vector allows us to output the first character of the string *once*, the second one *twice* e.t.c.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6, 39 bytes

```js
x=>x.replace(/./g,(y,i)=>y+y.repeat(i))
```

**Same length, but more fun:**

```js
x=>x.replace(i=/./g,y=>y.repeat(i=-~i))
```

**Snippet demo:**

```js
f= x=>x.replace(/./g,(y,i)=>y+y.repeat(i))
run.onclick=_=>output.textContent=f(input.value)
```

```html
<input id="input" value="SKype">
<button id="run">Go</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Small error, the program does not support spaces, which is required as a submission (check the OP).

Comment: @MarDev I changed the snippet to use `<pre>` instead of `<div>`, that should help.

Comment: @Neil Ah, so the result was correctly computed, but the output was rendered incorrectly by the HTML. Forgot that <div> does that.

Comment: ..."and ***output*** the result"

Comment: @spender returning is a valid form of output for functions

Comment: `x=>x.replace(/./g,(y,i)=>y.repeat(i+1))` - 39 bytes, same length

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```apl
⍳∘≢⌿⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/R72bH3XMeNS56FHP/kddi/5rcj3qmwqUSVNQz0jNyclX/w8A)

`⍳∘≢` enumeration of the argument... (indices of its length)
`⌿` replicates the elements of...
`⊢` the unmodified argument

Comment: link to interpreter?

Comment: @cat See edit (in header).

Comment: @cat What was your edit?

Comment: Identical to yours down to the character, because I googled it myself and my edit took 10 minutes to submit

Comment: Also, in which codepage is this 6 bytes?

Comment: Wow, that's twice on the same answer I idly answered my own question.

Comment: Wait, each of the lines in the explanation is a separate UCS-2 character? That's interesting.

Answer (score 4):

## APL (8)

```
{⍵/⍨⍳⍴⍵}
```

I.e.:

```
      {⍵/⍨⍳⍴⍵} ¨  'Why' 'SKype' 'LobbY'
┌──────┬───────────────┬───────────────┐
│Whhyyy│SKKyyyppppeeeee│LoobbbbbbbYYYYY│
└──────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Explanation:

- `⍴⍵`: length of given vector
- `⍳`: numbers 1..N
- `⍵/⍨`: replicate each element in `⍵` N times.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript ES6, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
s=>[,...s].map((e,i)=>e.repeat(i)).join``
```

Example runs:

```
f=s=>[,...s].map((e,i)=>e.repeat(i)).join``

f("Why")   => "Whhyyy"
f("SKype") => "SKKyyyppppeeeee"
f("LobbY") => "LoobbbbbbbYYYYY"
```

Comment: Same length: `s=>[...s].reduce((a,b,i)=>a+b.repeat(i+1))`

Comment: -1 byte: `s=>[,...s].map((e,i)=>e.repeat(i)).join\`\``

Comment: @nderscore Aha, thats clever, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
:ImC,0:Ie,Cw\
```

This prints the result to `STDOUT`.

#### Explanation

This is a good example of exploiting backtracking to loop.

```
:ImC            C is the Ith character of the Input
    ,
     0:Ie       Unify an implicit variable with an integer between 0 and I
         ,
          Cw    Write C to STDOUT
            \   False, trigger backtracking. It will go back to 0:Ie and unify the implicit
                variable with another integer, until all integers were used. After that, it
                will backtrack to :ImC and unify I and C with the next character.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>83</s> 50 bytes

-23 Thanks to Giuseppe, though he used essentially an entire new method altogether

```r
function(s)intToUtf8(rep(utf8ToInt(s),1:nchar(s)))
```

My original post:

```r
function(s){r="";for(i in 1:nchar(s))r=paste0(r,strrep(el(strsplit(s,""))[i],i));r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxCoAwDAXQq5RMCXTQVelJxEGkxYC05adO4tlrtwcPvacnn01LZpMXgWhNBaxOs5uXfF4HRghCPazFieGtAbFyvHnI6q2NzROJbLp7FVnx9f4D)

I feel like there's definitely a better way to do this, but with my new knowledge of a few functions in R, this is my approach.

Comment: Not a golfing tip, but your code link output was messed up. [Here](https://tio.run/##JcmxCsIwEAbg3acoN91BBl0teQM3Byni0JaEHpYk/BcHEZ89Btw@@NCib/GV1qo5sckHnmiMGayDpuF0Tus2o4fAl9lqODKcVSAUDjt3Wdm1sjkikbs@nIqM@LbIdNveJIeO63Mq4c9LXpaJpP0A)

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm new to TIO, so I didn't quite understand the header/footer portions. Thank You!

Comment: [Using `scan` saves 1 byte!](https://tio.run/##FcwxCsAgDEDRq4hTAg7tWvEGvUApHaxYGhCVxPundvvL@6wqQVKs4KxFz8Fa/zQGMlTNutX0RgZB5NCjjLwAOxnMuUMuMEt6oQHyYzzpcoRzonu770M/)

Comment: Very nice! However, using `rep` and the argument `collapse=""` to `paste` is shorter, and `utf8ToInt` is shorter still! [TIO](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jWDMzryQkP7QkzUKjKLVAoxTICMn3zCsByugYWuUlZyQWAZmamv/TNJTCMyqVNLmAjODsyIJUCNMnPykpUknzPwA)

Comment: Using `\(x)` instead of `function(x)` will save a few bytes

Comment: ... and `charToRaw` seems to fit for the purpose as well, so: `\(x)rawToChar(rep(charToRaw(x),1:nchar(x)))`

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 36 bytes

```
-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{"$_"*++$i})
```

Takes input `$args[0]`, explicitly casts it as a `char` array, sends that into a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration we take the current letter/character `"$_"` and use the `*` overloaded operator to concatenate the string pre-incremented `$i` times. The result of each loop iteration is encapsulated in parens to form an array and then `-join`ed together to form a string. That string is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\elasticize-a-word.ps1 Why
Whhyyy

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\elasticize-a-word.ps1 SKype
SKKyyyppppeeeee

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\elasticize-a-word.ps1 LobbY
LoobbbbbbbYYYYY

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\elasticize-a-word.ps1 'a b'
a  bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 23 bytes

```
@(x)repelem(x,1:nnz(x))
```

Creates an anonymous function `ans` that can be called using `ans('stringtoelacticize')`

Comment: What version are you using? Cannot find `repelem` in my (relatively old) version =(

Comment: @flawr [`repelem`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) was introduced in R2015a

Answer (score 3):

### [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))/[Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 14 bytes

```
{,/(1+!#x)#'x}
```

Usage:

```
k){,/(1+!#x)#'x}"A and B"
"A  aaannnnddddd      BBBBBBB"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>22 20</s>  19 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/(.)/{$0 x$/.to}/}
{S:g[(.)]=$0 x$/.to}
{[~] .comb Zx 1..*}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{          # implicit parameter $_
  [~]      # string concatenate the following list
    .comb  # the NFG characters from $_
    Z[x]   # zip combined using the string repetition operator
    1 .. * # 1 to infinity
}
```

Comment: What are the first two lines for?

Comment: @MarkReed Those are the first two versions I came up with

Comment: Oh! the 22- and 20-char solutions listed in the title. I'm dumb. :)

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 75 bytes

```
Function e(s):For a=1 To Len(s):e=e &String(a,Mid(s,a,1)):Next:End Function
```

Call as e.g. a user function in a spreadsheet.

=e(A1)

```
┌─────────┬───────────────┐
│   SKype │SKKyyyppppeeeee│
└─────────┴───────────────┘
```

It truncates if you feed it its own output a few times :-).

Comment: Welcome to the site! `=)`

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 22 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
.
$&$.`$*·
+`(.)·
$1$1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LgokJiQuYCQqwrcKK2AoLinCtwokMSQx&input=TG9iYlk&debug=on)

Basically, we insert the right amount of `·` as placeholders between the characters (since these extended ASCII characters can't appear in the input), then fill them up with the adjacent character in the second stage.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 32 bytes

```
!s=join(split(s[k=1:end],"").^k)
```

Unlike Dennis's solution, this is not recursive. `split` with argument `""` separates the string into an array of strings of length 1. The `[k=1:end]` is a trick to create a range from 1 to the number of characters in the string, and this range is used to concatenate n copies of the n-th character. `join` then recombines the array of strings into a single string, in order.

Usage example: `!"SKype"`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 68 bytes

```
<?php foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$i=>$a)echo str_repeat($a,$i+1);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: You can get it down to *47 bytes*: `for(;$a=$argv[1][$i++];)echo str_repeat($a,$i);`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ƶJ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//2Dav//998pOSKgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/2PbvP7r/A/PqOQK9q4sSOXyyU9KiuRyVEjMS1FwAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ƶ   # Multiply each character in the (implicit) input-string by its 1-based index
 J  # Join the list of substrings together to a single string
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 2 bytes

```
Þż
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiw57FvCIsIiIsIldoeSJd), or see a [3 byte flagless version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnsW84oiRIiwiIiwiV2h5Il0=)

Comment: [3](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnsW84oiRIiwiIiwiYWJjIl0=), 2 with the `s` flag

Comment: Ah, thought so. I saw that and wondered if that was it but I wasn't sure, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
⊢/˜1+↕∘≠
```

Anonymous tacit function. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqiL8ucMSvihpXiiJjiiaAKCkbCqCAiV2h5IuKAvyJTS3lwZSLigL8iTG9iYlki4oC/IkEgYW5kIEIi)

#### Explanation

```
⊢/˜1+↕∘≠
       ≠  Length of argument
     ↕∘   Range
   1+     Add 1 to each, making it an inclusive range from 1 to the length
 /˜       Replicate that many times the elements of
⊢         The original input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 33 bytes

```
1:i:0(?^$:?v~~1+00.
.!02o:$;!-1<|
```

[Try the animated version](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMTppOjAoP14kOj92fn4xKzAwLlxuLiEwMm86JDshLTE8fCIsImlucHV0IjoiYWJjIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

[image]

Basically if the counter is 0 skip to the second `:`, otherwise the first `:`. Properly adjust the counters.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 5 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @FryAmTheEggman.*

```
s*VSl
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2aVSl&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Why%22%0A%22SKype%22%0A%22LobbY%22&debug=0).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman ah, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 7 bytes

```
' +ñ♂πΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=JyArw7HimYLPgM6j&input=IldoeSI)

Explanation:

```
' +ñ♂πΣ
' +      prepend a space
   ñ     enumerate ("abc" -> [[0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'c']])
    ♂π   map: for each character, repeat it n times
      Σ  concatenate
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>48</s> 47 bytes

*Thanks to [mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego) for saving a byte with the `-~i` trick.*

```
lambda s:''.join(c*-~i for i,c in enumerate(s))
```

This is mostly self-explanatory. One thing for those not versed in Python: The `*` operator is overloaded to act like Perl's `x` operator, repeating its string argument the number of times specified by its numeric argument. E.g. `'foo' * 3 == 'foofoofoo'`

Comment: `c*-~i` is shorter than `c*(i+1)`.

Comment: know your language... there is an offset argument to `enumerate` :) - still 47 bytes though: `lambda s:''.join(c*i for i,c in enumerate(s,1))`

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 81 Bytes

```
void f(string s){for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)Console.Write(new String(s[i],i+1));}
```

Comment: you can save 1 byte by changing to a foreach loop, e.g. `foreach(var a in s)Console.Write(new C(a,1*i++));`

Comment: but if its a foreach we don't have the i variable so you'd need to declare it.

Comment: It seems you're missing a `using System` or a `System.` in front of the `Console`.

Comment: @ScifiDeath That's true - but the end result is still one byte shorter. Sorry for omitting it and causing confusion `int i=1;`

Comment: Also one byte shorter using Linq: `void f(string s){s.Select((c,i)=>{Console.Write(new string(c,i+1));return c;});}`. The need for a (unused) return value is ugly though. Edit: just found similar snippets in other answers further back.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
tn:Y"
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dG46WSI&input=J2NvZGVnb2xmJw)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implictly grab input as a string
tn  % Duplicate and compute the length (N)
:   % Create an array from [1...N]
Y"  % Perform run-length decoding to elacticize the string
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,i=1:s and s[0]*i+f(s[1:],i+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 34 bytes

```julia
!s=s>""?!s[1:(e=end)-1]*s[e:e]^e:s
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXM9cz4iIj8hc1sxOihlPWVuZCktMV0qc1tlOmVdXmU6cwoKZm9yIHMgaW4gKCJXaHkiLCAiU0t5cGUiLCAiTG9iYlkiLCAiQSBhbmQgQiIpCiAgICBwcmludGxuKCFzKQplbmQ&input=)

Comment: Your solution was good. But I managed to beat it.

Comment: I saw. I had `c%n="$c"^n;~s=join([s[r=1:end]...].%r)`, but that's actually longer. `split` was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

## TSQL, 97 bytes

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max)='Lobby'
DECLARE @ int=LEN(@x)WHILE @>0SELECT
@x=STUFF(@x,@,1,REPLICATE(SUBSTRING(@x,@,1),@)),@-=1PRINT @x
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max)='Lobby'

DECLARE @ int=LEN(@x)
WHILE @>0
  SELECT 
    @x=STUFF(@x,@,1,REPLICATE(SUBSTRING(@x,@,1),@)),
    @-=1

PRINT @x
```

[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/502802/write-a-program-to-elasticize-strings)

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
""<>Table@@@(#^Range@Length@#&@Characters[#])&
```

Unnamed function. Takes the characters of the input string and raises them to the power of their position in the string (i.e. `"abc"` becomes `{"a"^1, "b"^2, "c"^3}`). Yes, MMA don't give a shit 'bout types :-)

The `FullForm` of the above list elements is `Power["a", 1]`, etc.
`Table@@@` acts on the list, replacing the head of each element (in this case `Power`) with `Table`.
Results in `{Table["a"], Table["b", 2], Table["c", 3]}` (because `"a"^1 -> "a"`).
This evaluates to `{"a", {"b", "b"}, {"c", "c", "c"}}` Finally the infix concatenation operator `<>` concatenates this with the empty string.

I exploited the fact that `Power` is `Listable`, i.e. it automatically threads over corresponding elements of lists, but not orderless (because `"a" + 1` would evaluate to `Plus[1, "a"]`).

Answer (score 2):

## LINQPad w/ C#, 82 bytes

```
void m(string s){Console.Write(s.SelectMany((x,i)=>new string(x,++i)).ToArray());}
```

Single output operation.

Comment: @MartinEnder `using System;` & `using System.Linq;` are not necessary in LINQPad.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 84 bytes

```
main(c,v,i,j)char**v;{for(i=0;i<strlen(v[1]);++i)for(j=0;j<=i;++j)putchar(v[1][i]);}
```

This should compile on gcc with no flags. Input is taken through the first command-line argument. E.g.

```
$ ./elasticize Why
Whhyyy
$ ./elasticize SKype
SKKyyyppppeeeee
$ ./elasticize LobbY
LoobbbbbbbYYYYY
$ ./elasticize A and B
A  aaannnnddddd      BBBBBBB
```

Ungolfed:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
            putchar(v[1][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 86 bytes

```
(fn[s](apply str(mapcat #(repeat(+(nth % 1)1)(nth % 0))(map list s(range(count s))))))
```

Well, nearly beat C. Create a list of pairs (symbol, its position), then repeat each symbol given number of times and flatten the result list and concatenate the list into one string.

See it here: https://ideone.com/uQNar2

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
xJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1/h9f//fyVHhcS8FAUnJQA)

Comment: Why non-competing? it's completely okay.

Comment: @MatthewRoh `J` did not exist back then.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 38 bytes

```sh
for i (${(s::)@});repeat ++n printf $i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUrEoAgFAXQ7ipuMMC4Ay1q1WZwjH4eA@XBAAZlXDtSznmDzkrIlJX1MBB1EqFtZf/JzpOjPaJpGM4bjgq1yXRq290cKIK/qlJY9VNcpsdRebbHsZUH7HxhzD8)

-8 bytes thanks to roblogic

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFTQUOlWqPYykrToVbTuii1IDWxREElWls7L1ahoCgzryRNQSXzf2pyRr51aV5xaolCXi0XV5pCeEYlkAz2rixIBdI@@UlJkUDaUSExL0XB6T8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 47 bytes

```
f(s,[c=0])=>s.split("").map((i)=>i*++c).join();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BCsIwEETv/YplTxtbgvdSQa968yBSekgbgys2CUkpFPHbY@I7vRkYRquwpGQoNv3U7QfRHaKM/s0LIQo5K0/EueRdXU9CvhxbEm1aHWuYVQnwqSBjXKBVBWBgCz3enhs2gNfz5h9FLm4c70WOoKyGEw7iPyv4wHYhk39EW33TDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
;=i!=sP;W<iLsO+*Gs iT=i+1i"\"O""
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWkhPXNQO1c8aUxzTysqR3MgaVQ9aSsxaVwiXFxcIk9cIlwiIiwiSGVsbG8hIl0=)

expanded:

```
; = i ! = s PROMPT
; WHILE < i LENGTH s
    : OUTPUT
        +
            * (GET s i TRUE) (= i + 1 i)
        "\" # so no trailing newline
: OUTPUT "" # now output the trailing newline
```

-1 did `=i!` instead of `;=iF`

Comment: You forgot to put `=i+1i` in your expanded version.

Comment: Yo that `!` thing is actually super smart.

Comment: Why do you have to output a trailing newline? No one said you did.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 54 bytes

```c
i;c;main(j){for(;j=j-1?:read(0,&c,1)*++i;)putchar(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P9M62To3MTNPI0uzOi2/SMM6yzZL19Deqig1MUXDQEctWcdQU0tbO9Nas6C0JDkjsUgjWdO69v9/n/ykpEoA)

#### How it works

```c
i;            // declares a zero initialized int
main(j){      // j := argc (should be 1, program called with no arguments)
 for(;j=j-1?: // if (j > 1) j = j - 1, otherwise...
 read(0,&c,1) // try to read 1 byte, return number of bytes read (0 on EOF or 1)
 *++i;)       // increment i, j = read? * i (stopping on EOF)
  putchar(c); // write to stdout
}
```

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 51 bytes

- With help from [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) and [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt).

```c
i,j;f(*s){for(i=0;*s;s++)for(j=++i;j--;)printf(s);}
```

This function takes a wide-character string as input and works in the same way as the full program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P1MnyzpNQ6tYszotv0gj09bAWqvYulhbWxPEzbLV1s60ztLVtdYsKMrMK0nTKNa0rv2fm5iZpwHUoOGj5JOflFSpBBIEswA)

Comment: This is pretty interesting, but it's 54 bytes to declare a function and write to stdout: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSM5I7FIq1izOi2/SMNaq9i6WFtbE8TOstXWzrTO0tW11iwoLQGp0gAqs679n5uYmacBVK@h5JOflFSpBBIDswA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: you'd need to reset `i=0` if you want the ability to call the function more than once

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P1MnyzpNQ6tYszotv0gj09bAWqvYulhbWxPEzbLV1s60ztLVtdYsKC1JzkgsAqm0rv2fm5iZpwHUouGj5JOflFSpBBIEswA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
+pV
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=K3BW&input=IkxvYmJZIg)

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, 6 bytes

```
vN>Fy?
```

**Explained**

```
v       # for each char in string
 N>F    # index+1 number of times do
    y?  # print current char
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dk4-Rnk_&input=U0t5cGU)

Comment: This one looks like it has a question :D

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 62 bytes

It wasn't as easy or short as I thought it'd be. Note that the code contains no spaces. They are all tabs (which are rendered incorrectly here), and the last line is blank.

```
.*
$0¶ ¶
{+`^(.)(.*)¶    (.*¶.*)
$1$2    ¶$3$1
(   +)¶
¶   $1
}`^.

    |¶
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LioKJDDCtgnCtgp7K2BeKC4pKC4qKcK2CSguKsK2LiopCiQxJDIJwrYkMyQxCigJKynCtgrCtgkkMQp9YF4uCgoJfMK2Cg&input=QSBhbmQgQg)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 29 bytes

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/EIbKIY)

```
->s{i=0;s.gsub(/./){$&*i+=1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
Foh*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Foh%2a&input=LobbY)

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.7 - 47 Bytes**

```
''.join([s[i-1]*i for i in range(1, len(s)+1)])
```

where 's' is the given string
Output:

```
welcome: weelllccccooooommmmmmeeeeeee
00004:   000000000044444
Why:     Whhyyy
SKype:   SKKyyyppppeeeee
A and B: A  aaannnnddddd      BBBBBBB
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 125 bytes

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(SUBSTR(RPAD(' ',LEVEL+1,SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1)),2))WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 77 bytes

Not much room for golfing here. If only there were a string repeat operator.

```
i;main(j){char s[999];gets(s);for(;s[i];i++)for(j=0;j<=i;j++)putchar(s[i]);}
```

Try it online! http://ideone.com/UliJfD

Comment: You can do `i;main(j){...` and save a bye

Comment: @cat Good idea; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## brev, 42 bytes

```
(as-list flatten(over(make-list(+ i 1)x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 10 bytes

```
{+..*}wi\[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw9D4IwEIZ3fsW7@c2iiUmZcIW4OBCjDq0cthFbpDWmMf52LLD4JJe7e/PciVdbk32@qPtMWJKsLt1nEcfz71udT923qLtCeoZCSu99dMh8QwyHLAtbE6CeKDdCHBlyE/rAsQfTvXEEad5wkloCD7WFmFhYpa/Up6hUax0EVAiDqbGGUw@y4LocBEtXE8Y/YzMaSzz4XekbOJxxvIapxu@zOEqH8x1DCnDOdaDswcBu5Ac)

```
{
 +. # Increment
 .* # Repeat
}wi # Apply with 0-index
\[  # Concatenate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 53 bytes

```cs
a=>string.Concat(a.Select((c,i)=>new@String(c,i+1)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZA9b4MwEIZn@BVXq4OtUNSuJURtKnVJtgxRFGVw4EisIBuBaYsQv52ecVQl6rvch/28d7qsecoaNX62OoN5Y2ulTxH4uIACUhhluvB1/GF0Ji2X8QZLzCznWaREutD4/baZfrjG7EUIkYxfsgZzId7WLSahK5WuWttQiwDYH6Bn23PHImCbVVehS9bmeNy55B2kzmHJBk/iT0XzML9nz113xVeUVSR08kbkNGnn5C1BSqlJuRNMWnq5OYWpgSttQdGU54TC/LpxvEZ9sucEZjMlwj4MVAG84P5xrw4CHtK/FV0dBvQpoGs1psR4WyuLa6WRP7JCqhLzV@hv8cHx/Y3BwERCBtP5Clk2dL9gCIfQzTWXaYX/5sxcHDaMvw)

Answer (score 1):

### [Kustom](https://help.kustom.rocks/s1-general/knowledgebase/top/c2-functions), 67 bytes

This makes use of the fact that an undefined global variable works as empty string. The extra byte is for the name of the defined global variable.

```
$fl(1,tc(len,gv(n)),"i+1","tc(lpad,gv(x),i,tc(cut,gv(n),i-1,1))")$
```

Sort of ungolfed:

```
$fl(
  1,
  tc(len, gv(input)),
  "i + 1",
  "tc(
    lpad,
    gv(undefined),
    i,
    tc(
      cut,
      gv(input),
      i - 1,
      1
    )
  )"
)$
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 69 bytes

```
S*O:-append(H,[T],S),maplist([_,Y]>>(Y=T),S,R),H*Y,append(Y,R,O);O=S.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lco9CoQwEAbQq6TMhC8eQNHabsDYhBAk/rAEXB1U8PjZZl/95Dr382PvN5fiDNc2iWzHqnuEMcIRvkn2fD86TPCx67RvR4LDQOiNx397DGBquHVVqa0KCTOWqIxiKLny8WimqvwA)

I feel like this should be shorter...

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```
Fi,#aOa@iXi+1x
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGaSwjYU9hQGlYaSsxeCIsIiIsIiIsIi1wdyBcIldoeVwiIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 44 bytes

```arturo
$[s][i:0join map split s'c[i:i+1repeat c i]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?e3Oedx)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$9\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.41 bytes

```
DLR1+ZZ.P
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSl1LsgqWlJWm6FitdfIIMtaOi9AIg_AUwyic_KSkSwgEA)

##### Explanation

```python
DLR1+ZZ.P  # Implicit input
D          # Duplicate
 LR        # Push range(0, len(input))
   1+      # Add one to each
     ZZ    # Zip with the input
       .P  # Product of each pair
           # Implicit output, joined by J flag
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 6 bytes

```
i₁j₎w⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/NRU2PWo6a@8kddS///V3JUSMxLUXBSAgA)

Half-port of [Fatalize's v1 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83398/85334).

```
i₁        Choose a pair [element, 1-index] from the input.
  j₎      Replicate the element by its index.
    w     Print the result with no trailing newline.
     ⊥    Backtrack.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
dż×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZLU47uOTx9SXFScjFUZMHi8IxKCBMA)

##### Explanation

```python
dż×  # Implicit input           ->  "Why"
d    # Split into characters    ->  ["W","h","y"]
 ż   # Length range             ->  ["W","h","y"]  [1,2,3]
  ×  # Multiply together        ->  ["W","hh","yyy"]
     # Implicit output, joined  ->  "Whhyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 76 bytes

I'm sure this can be improved...

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<strlen($argv[1]);$i++)echo str_repeat($argv[1]{$i},$i+1);
```

Run from command line:

```
$ php [file] "Testing"
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Silicon](http://github.com/m654z/Silicon)(non-competing), 6 bytes

(This language is exactly the same age as this challenge, but I added some useful commands right after I saw it, so non-competing I think.)

```
biSÚÿj
```

Silicon uses CP037, which is a 255-bit codepage.

**Explanation:**

```
b        Push a space
i        Input
S        Split
Ú        Enumerate
ÿ        Replicate each list item n times
j        Join
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 58 bytes

`e=a=>(Array.from(a).map((e,i)=>(e).repeat(i+1))).join("");`

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 136 bytes

```
enum b{;public static void main(String[]a){int i=0,j=0;for(;i<a[0].length();i++){for(;j<i+1;j++)System.out.print(a[0].charAt(i));j=0;}}}
```

Takes input as program arguments.

Ungolfed with comments:

```
enum b {;
    public static void main(String[]a) {
        int i=0, j=0;                               // Init counters
        for (; i<a[0].length(); i++) {              // For each characters in string
            for (; j < i + 1; j++)                  // Loop from 0 to i
                System.out.print(a[0].charAt(i));   // Print character at i
            j=0;                                    // Reset j
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
xJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/C6////yGpxSUKxSVFmXnpAA)